# Calculate the Kronecker symbol

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, number-theory, primes

Relevant links [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSymbol.html), but here is the short version:

You have an input of two integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ between negative infinity and infinity (though if necessary, I can restrict the range, but the function must still accept negative inputs).

**Definition of the Kronecker symbol**

You must return the Kronecker symbol \$(a|b)\$ for inputs \$a\$ and \$b\$ where

$$(a|b) = (a|p_1)^{e_1} \cdot (a|p_2)^{e_2} \cdots (a|p_n)^{e_n}$$

where \$b = p_1^{e_1} \cdot p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_n^{e_n}\$, and \$p_i\$ and \$e_i\$ are the primes and exponents in the prime factorization of \$b\$.

- For an odd prime \$p\$, \$(a|p)=a^{\frac{p-1}2} \mod p\$ as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html).
- For \$b = 2\$,

$$
(n|2) = \begin{cases}
0    & \text{if } n \equiv   0   \mod 2 \\
1    & \text{if } n \equiv \pm 1 \mod 8 \\
-1   & \text{if } n \equiv \mp 3 \mod 8
\end{cases}
$$

- For \$b = -1\$,

$$
(n|-1) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } n  <  0 \\
1  & \text{if } n \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

- If \$a \ge b\$, \$(a|b) = (z|b)\$ where \$z = a\mod b\$. By this property, and as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol), \$a\$ is a quadratic residue of \$b\$ if \$z\$ is, even though \$a \ge b\$.
- \$(-1|b) = 1\$ if \$b \equiv 0,1,2 \mod 4\$ and \$-1\$ if \$b = 3 \mod 4\$.
- \$(0|b)\$ is \$0\$ except for \$(0|1)\$ which is \$1\$, because \$(a|1)\$ is always \$1\$ and for negative \$a\$, \$(-a|b) = (-1|b) \times (a|b)\$.

The output of the Kronecker symbol is always \$-1, 0 \text{ or } 1\$, where the output is \$0\$ if \$a\$ and \$b\$ have any common factors. If \$b\$ is an odd prime, \$(a|b) = 1\$ if \$a\$ is a [quadratic residue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65329/is-q-a-quadratic-residue-of-n) \$\mod b\$, and \$-1\$ if is it is not a quadratic residue.

**Rules**

- Your code must be a program or a function.
- The inputs must be in the order `a b`.
- The output must be either \$-1, 0 \text{ or } 1\$.
- This is code golf, so your code does not have to be efficient, just short.
- No built-ins that directly calculate the Kronecker or the related Jacobi and Legendre symbols. Other built-ins (for prime factorization, for example) are fair game.

**Examples**

```
>>> kronecker(1, 5)
1
>>> kronecker(3, 8)
-1
>>> kronecker(15, 22)
1
>>> kronecker(21, 7)
0
>>> kronecker(5, 31)
1
>>> kronecker(31, 5)
1
>>> kronecker(7, 19)
1
>>> kronecker(19, 7)
-1
>>> kronecker(323, 455625)
1
>>> kronecker(0, 12)
0
>>> kronecker(0, 1)
1
>>> kronecker(12, 0)
0
>>> kronecker(1, 0)
1
>>> kronecker(-1, 5)
1
>>> kronecker(1, -5)
1
>>> kronecker(-1, -5)
-1
>>> kronecker(6, 7)
-1
>>> kronecker(-1, -7)
1
>>> kronecker(-6, -7)
-1
```

This is a complicated function, so please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to disallow built-ins? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerSymbol.html

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was editing in examples when I saw your comment. I will disallow built-ins that directly calculate the Kronecker, Jacobi or Legendre symbols, but anything else (including prime factorization functions) should be fair game.

Comment: im not entirely sure why (31|5) gives 1. There shouldnt be a qudratic residue so why isnt it -1?

Comment: also 7/19 should be 1 and 19/7 should be -1 according to the wiki you linked

Comment: @Eumel 31 is a quadratic residue mod 5, because it is congruent to 1 mod 5. I have edited the question to explain this.

Comment: @Eumel Ah, you are correct. I'll edit the examples.

Comment: If solutions have to handle negative and zero inputs correctly, you should definitely add some test cases for that.

Comment: I think `kronecker(0, 12)` is 0.

Comment: I don't think you've actually defined the symbol for `a < 0`.

Comment: Half-way there. If you now define `(-1|b)` I think the spec will be complete.

Comment: Only very rarely does PPCG make me feel very, very stupid, as if I were browsing [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com), but this is one of those rare cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CJam (70 bytes)

```
{_g\zmf+f{:P2+"W>2*(
z1=
;1
7&4-z[0W0X0]=
P%P+P(2/#P%_1>P*-"N/<W=~}:*}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B_g%5Czmf%2Bf%7B%3AP2%2B%22W%3E2*(%0Az1%3D%0A%3B1%0A7%264-z%5B0W0X0%5D%3D%0AP%25P%2BP(2%2F%23P%25_1%3EP*-%22N%2F%3CW%3D~%7D%3A*%7D%0A%0A49%2C24f-_m*f*%5Bq~%5D%3D%5B%22Error%22%20%22Passed%22%5D%3D&input=VXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVWVXXXXWXWXXWWXXWWXWXWWWWVXXXXWXWXXWWXXWWXWXWWWWVXVWVWVWVXVWVWVVVWVXVXVXVWVXVWVWVWVXVVVXVXVWVXVXVXVVWXVWWVWWVVXVWXVXVVWWVXWVXWVXXVVWVWXVWVVXXVXXVWXVVWVWVXVXVVVXVXVWVWVVVWVWVXVXVVVXVXVWVWVVVWVWVXVXVWWXXWVXWWXXXXWXWXWWWWXXWVXWWXXXXWXWXWWWWXXWVXWWXXVXVVVWVWVVVXVWVVVXVXVVVWVXVVVWVWVVVXVWVVVXVXVVVWVWWWWXXWVWXWWWWXWWWWXWWWWVXXXXWXXXXWXXXXWXVXWWXXXXVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVVWXVVWVWWVXXVXVVWXVVWVWWVXXVXVVWXVVWVWWVXXVXVVWXVVWVVVWVXVWVWVXVWVVVWVWVWVXVXVXVVVXVWVXVXVWVXVVVXVWXXXXWXWWWXVXWWWXWWXWXXWVXWWXWXXWXXXWVWXXXWXWWWWXVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXVVVWVXWVXWXXXWWWXWVXWXXXWWWXWVXWXXXWWWXWVXWXXXWWWXWVXWVWVXVWVXVVVWVWVWVWVVVXVWVXVWVVVXVXVXVXVVVWVXVWVXVVXXVWXVWWVXWVXWVWXVWWVWWVXXVXXVWXVXWVXWVXXVWXVWWVVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXWWVXXWXWWVXXWXWWVXXWXWWVXXWXWWVXXWXWWVXXWXWWVXXWVXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXWWWVXXXWVXXWXVWXWXVWWXWVXWXXVWXWXVWXWWVXWWWVXXXWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVXVWVVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVXWVVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXXXWWXWWWXXWXXWWWXXWWXWWXXXWXXWWXXXWWXWWXXXWXXWWWVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVXVXVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVVXWVWWVWXVXXVXXVWWVWXVWXVXWVXWVWWVXXVXXVXWVWWVWXVVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXWWXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXVXWWVWXXWXWVWXWWXXVXWXXXXVXXXXWXVXXWWXWVWXWXXWVWWXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVXVWVWVXVVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVXXVVWVWVWVWVVVXVWVXVWVVVXVXVXVXVVVWVXVWVXVVVWVWVWVWVXWVWXXWWXWWWWVWXWXXXXWWXVXWWXXXXWXWVWWWWXWWXXWVWXVXVVVWVWVVVXVXVVVWVWVVVXVXVVVWVWVVVXVXVVVWVWVVVXVWXXWWWWXXWXVXWXXWWWWXXWXVXWXXWWWWXXWXVXWXXWWWWXXWVWVVVWVWVWVXVXVXVVVXVWVXVXVWVXVVVXVXVXVWVWVWVVVWVVWXVVWVXXVXWVXVVXXVVXVXXVXXVXVVXXVVXVWXVXXVWVVXWVVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVXVWWWXWXXVXXWXWWWXXWWWXWXXVXXWXWWWXXWWWXWXXVXXWXWWWVXVVVWVXVVVWVWVVVXVWVVVXVXVVVWVXVVVWVWVVVXVWVVVXVWWXWXVWXXXXWXWWXWWWXXXWXVXWXXXWWWXWWXWXXXXWVXWXWWVWVXVXVWVVVWVXVXVWVVVWVXVXVWVVVWVXVXVWVVVWVXVXVWVVWXVXWVXXVVWVWWVWVVXXVWXVXWVXXVVWVWWVWVVXXVWXVXWVVWVXVWVWVWVXVVVXVXVWVXVXVXVXVWVXVXVVVXVWVWVWVXVWVWVXWWXXWXXXXWXWXXXWWXWXXVXXWXWWXXXWXWXXXXWXXWWXVWVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXVXVVVXVWVVVWVWVVVWVXVVVXV) (test cases generated with Mathematica).

#### Dissection

```
{               e# Anonymous function. Stack: a b
  _g\zmf+       e# Factorise b, with special treatment for negatives
                e# CJam also gives special treatment to 0 and 1
                e# Stack: e.g. a [-1 2 2 5]; or a [-1 1]; or a [0 0]; or a [1 2 2 5]
  f{            e# For each "prime" factor P, find (a|P)
    :P2+        e# Extract code for P from an array formed by splitting a string
    "W>2*(      e#   a -> (a|-1)
z1=             e#   a -> (a|0)
;1              e#   a -> (a|1)
7&4-z[0W0X0]=   e#   a -> (a|2)
P%P+P(2/#P%_1>P*-" e# a -> (a|P) for odd prime P
    N/<W=~      e# Split string and select appropriate element
  }
  :*            e# Multiply the components together
}
```

I found several ways of evaluating `(a|2)` for the same character count, and have chosen to use the one with the clearest presentation.

`integer array <W=` is IMO a quite elegant way of doing fallbacks: if the integer is greater than the length of the array, we select the last element.

#### Other comments

It's disappointing that for odd prime `p` the direct Fermat-style `(a|p)` is so short, because there's a very golfy way of finding `(a|n)` for positive odd `n` which I wanted to use. The basis is Zolotarev's lemma:

> If `p` is an odd prime and `a` is an integer coprime to `p` then the Legendre symbol `(a|p)` is the sign of the permutation `x -> ax (mod p)`

This was strengthened by Frobenius to

> If `a` and `b` are coprime positive odd integers then the Jacobi symbol `(a|b)` is the sign of the permutation `x -> ax (mod b)`

and by Lerch to

> If `b` is a positive odd integer and `a` is an integer coprime to `b` then the Jacobi symbol `(a|b)` is the sign of the permutation `x -> ax (mod b)`

See Brunyate and Clark, [*Extending the Zolotarev-Frobenius approach to quadratic reciprocity*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Brunyate-Clark_final.pdf), The Ramanujan Journal 37.1 (2014): 25-50 for references.

And it can easily be strengthened one step further (although I haven't seen this in the literature) to

> If `b` is a positive odd integer and `a` is an integer then the Jacobi symbol `(a|b)` is the Levi-Civita symbol of the map `x -> ax (mod b)`.

Proof: if `a` is coprime to `b` then we use Zolotarev-Frobenius-Lerch; otherwise the map is not a permutation, and the Levi-Civita symbol is `0` as desired.

This gives the Jacobi symbol calculation

```
{_2m*{~>},@ff*\ff%::-:*g}
```

But the special treatment required for `(a|-1)` and `(a|2)` mean that I haven't found a way of calculating the Kronecker symbol which is shorter with this approach: it's shorter to factorise and treat the primes individually.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>747</s> <s>369</s> 335 bytes

As an example answer, only slightly golfed, and to give you an idea of what an answer will look like.

And yes, the prime factorization and run-length-encoding bits are cribbed from Pyth with apologies to [isaacg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/115644/isaacg).

```python
from itertools import*
def k(d,r):
 if d<0:a=-d;m=1
 else:a=d;m=0
 if r==1:return 1
 p=1;w=r;n=2;f=[]
 while n*n<=w:
  while w%n<1:w//=n;f+=n,
  n+=1
 if w>1:f+=w,
 z=[[k,len(list(g))]for k,g in groupby(f)]
 for i,j in z:
  if i==2:p*=pow(-1,(a*a-1)//8)
  x=pow(a,(i-1)//2,i)
  if x>1:x-=i
  p*=x**j
 if m:p*=pow(-1,(r-1)//2)
 return p
```

Comment: Apology accepted - I'm glad someone reads Pyth source code.

Answer (score 2):

## LabVIEW, 44 Bytes [LabVIEW Primitives](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

<s>Since its symetrical i swapped the inputs if a was bigger than b.</s>

Represents the real formula now

counting like always according to 
[image]

[image]

for true case

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `(a|b) != (b|a)` in all cases. In most cases, yes, but not in all of them. Though it would work if you reduced `a mod b` instead of swapping them.

Comment: since i have the explantion now i can edit it, give me a min

Comment: Is there any way I can test this? I don't really understand how LabView works.

Comment: that is a good question, i can think of 2 ways. First i can build an .exe and send it to you, second you can get a labview test version and i can send you the vi or you can rebuild it from the pic.

Comment: This is not 44 bytes. If you define a scoring system that is not based on the size of the file, you should call it something other than bytes.

Comment: For the moment, I will take your word for it. Send me the .exe anyway, but you have my upvote.

Comment: I thought there was a messanging system here but there isnt, how do i actually send it to you?

Comment: @Eumel Seeing as you put up a gif for some of your other LabVIEW solutions, can you put one up here? And change the heading from bytes to LabVIEW primitives?

Comment: will do when im at home

Comment: The gif appears to be for a different version to the image above. And if I'm correctly interpreting the symbols, this seems to be incapable of giving any output other than `-1` or `1`, which means that it must be giving incorrect outputs for some inputs.

Comment: And from looking at a [reference](http://www.princeton.edu/~mae224/labmanual/labviewreference.pdf), it seems to have some case structures for which the image only shows one case, so you haven't posted the full code.

Comment: The other case is just a 0 nothing more ill put it up though

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>169</s> <s>175</s> 165 bytes

```
(1|-1)~k~0=_~k~1=1
_~k~0=0
a_~k~-1=If[a<0,-1,1]
a_~k~2=DirichletCharacter[8,2,a]
a_~k~p_/;PrimeQ@p=Mod[a^((p-1)/2),p,-1]
a_~k~b_:=1##&@@(a~k~#^#2&@@@FactorInteger@b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 195 bytes

```julia
k(a,b)=b==0?a∈[1,-1]?1:0:b==1?1:b==2?iseven(a)?0:a%8∈[1,-1]?1:-1:b==-1?a<1?-1:1:isprime(b)&&b>2?a%b==0?0:a∈[i^2%b for i=0:b-1]?1:-1:k(a,sign(b))*prod(i->k(a,i)^factor(b)[i],keys(factor(b)))
```

This is a recursive function `k` that accepts two integers and returns an integer.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function k(a::Integer, b::Integer)
    if b == 0
        return a ∈ [1, -1] ? 1 : 0
    elseif b == 1
        return 1
    elseif b == 2
        return iseven(a) ? 0 : a % 8 ∈ [1, -1] ? 1 : -1
    elseif b == -1
        return a < 1 ? -1 : 1
    elseif isprime(b) && b > 2
        return a % b == 0 ? 0 : a ∈ [i^2 % b for i = 1:b-1] ? 1 : -1
    else
        p = factor(b)
        return k(a, sign(b)) * prod(i -> k(a, i)^p[i], keys(p))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 286 bytes

```
a#0|abs a==1=1|1<2=0
a#1=1
a#2|even a=0|mod a 8`elem`[1,7]=1|1<2=(-1)
a#b|b<0=a`div`abs a*a#(-b)|all((/=0).mod b)[2..b-1]=if elem n[0,1] then n else(-1)|1<2=product$map(a#)$f b where n=a^(div(b-1)2)`mod`b
f 1=[]
f n|n<0=(-1):f(-n)|1<2=let p=head$filter((==0).mod n)[2..n]in p:f(div n p)
```

Probably not completely optimized, but a valiant effort. The Kronecker symbol is defined as the infix function a#b, i.e.

```
*Main>323#455265 
1
```