# One OEIS after another

Tags: math, code-challenge, sequence, answer-chaining

> As of 13/03/2018 16:45 UTC, the winner is [answer #345](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156848/66833), by [Khuldraeseth na'Barya](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/khuldraeseth-nabarya). This means the contest is officially over, but feel free to continue posting answers, just so long as they follow the rules.
>
> As well, just a quick shout out to the top three answerers in terms of numbers of answers:
>
> **1.** [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob) - 41 answers
>
> **2.** [KSmarts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69481/ksmarts) - 30 answers
>
> **3.** [Hyper Neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) - 26 answers

---

This is an answer chaining question that uses sequences from OEIS, and the length of the previous submission.

This answer chaining question will work in the following way:

- I will post the first answer. All other solutions must stem from that.
- The next user (let's call them userA) will find the OEIS sequence in which its index number (see below) is the same as the length of my code.
- Using the sequence, they must then code, in an **unused language**, a program that takes an integer as input, n, and outputs the nth number in that sequence.
- Next, they post their solution after mine, and a new user (userB) must repeat the same thing.

The `n`th term of a sequence is the term n times after the first, working with the first value being the first value given on its OEIS page. In this question, we will use **0-indexing** for these sequences. For example, with [A000242](https://oeis.org/A000242) and `n = 3`, the correct result would be *25*.

### However!

This is not a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code doesn't matter. But the length of your code does still have an impact. To prevent the duplication of sequences, **your bytecount must be unique**. This means that no other program submitted here can be the same length in *bytes* as yours.

If there isn't a sequence for then length of the last post, then the sequence for your post is the lowest unused sequence. This means that the sequences used also have to be unique, and that the sequence cannot be the same as your bytecount.

After an answer has been posted and no new answers have been posted for more than a week, the answer *before* the last posted (the one who didn't break the chain) will win.

### Input and Output

Generic input and output rules apply. Input must be an integer or a string representation of an integer and output must be the correct value in the sequence.

### Formatting

As with most [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) questions, please format your answer like this

```
# N. language, length, [sequence](link)

`code`

[next sequence](link)

*anything else*
```

### Rules

- You must wait for at least 1 hour before posting an answer, after having posted.
- You may not post twice (or more) in a row.
- The index number of a sequence is the number after the `A` part, and with leading zeros removed (e.g. for `A000040` the index number is 40)
- You can assume that neither the input nor the required output will be outside your languages numerical range, but please don't abuse this by choosing a language that can only use the number 1, for example.
- If the length of your submission is greater than 65536 characters long, please provide a link to a way to access the code (pastebin for example).
- `n` will never be larger than 1000, or be out of bounds for the sequence, simply to prevent accuracy discrepancies from stopping a language from competing.
- Every 150 (valid) answers, the number of times a language may be used increases. So after 150 solutions have been posted, every language may be used twice (with all previous answers counting towards this). For instance, when 150 answers have been posted, Python 3 may be used twice, but due to the fact that it has already been used once, this means it can only be used once more until 300 answers have been posted.
- Please be helpful and post a link to the next sequence to be used. This isn't required, but is a recommendation.
- Different versions of languages, e.g. Python 2 and Python 3 are *different languages*. As a general rule, if the different versions are both available on Try It Online, they are different languages, but keep in mind that this is a *general rule* and not a rigid answer.
- It is not banned, but please try not to copy the code from the OEIS page, and actually try to solve it.
- Hardcoding is only allowed if the sequence is finite. Please note that the answer that prompted this ([#40](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/134996/66833)) is the exception to the rule. A few answers early in the chain hardcode, but these can be ignored, as there is no good in deleting the chain up to, say, #100.

### Answer chain snippet

```js
var QUESTION_ID=133754,OVERRIDE_USER=66833;function shareUrl(i){return"https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/"+i}function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getTemplate(s){return jQuery(jQuery("#answer-template").html().replace("{{PLACE}}",s.index+".").replace("{{NAME}}",s.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",s.language).replace("{{SEQUENCE}}",s.sequence).replace("{{SIZE}}",s.size).replace("{{LINK}}",s.link))}function search(l,q){m=jQuery("<tbody id='answers'></tbody>");e.forEach(function(s){if(!q||(l==0&&RegExp('^'+q,'i').exec(s.lang_name))||(l==1&&q===''+s.size)){m.append(jQuery(getTemplate(s)))}});jQuery("#answers").remove();jQuery(".answer-list").append(m)}function sortby(ix){t=document.querySelector('#answers');_els=t.querySelectorAll('tr');els=[];for(var i=0;i<_els.length;i++){els.push(_els[i]);}els.sortBy(function(a){a=a.cells[ix].innerText;return ix==0||ix==4?Number(a):a.toLowerCase()});for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++)t.appendChild(els[i]);}function checkSize(x){if(!x)return jQuery("#size-used").text("");var i=b.indexOf(+x);if(i<0)return jQuery("#size-used").text("Available!");var low=+x,high=+x;while(~b.indexOf(low))low--;while(~b.indexOf(high))high++;jQuery("#size-used").text(("Not available. The nearest are "+low+" and "+high).replace("are 0 and","is"))}function checkLang(x){}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.answer_id;answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return (e.owner.user_id==OVERRIDE_USER?"<span id='question-author'>"+e.owner.display_name+"</span>":e.owner.display_name)}function process(){b=[];c=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);if(a){e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[4],language:a[2],lang_name:a[3],index:+a[1],sequence:a[5],link:shareUrl(s.answer_id)});if(b.indexOf(+a[4])>=0&&c.indexOf(+a[4])<0){c.push(+a[4])};b.push(+a[4])}else{jQuery('#weird-answers').append('<a href="'+shareUrl(s.answer_id)+'">This answer</a> is not formatted correctly. <b>Do not trust the information provided by this snippet until this message disappears.</b><br />')}}),e.sortBy(function(e){return e.index});e.forEach(function(e){jQuery("#answers").append(getTemplate(e))});var q="A"+("000000"+e.slice(-1)[0].size).slice(-6);jQuery("#next").html("<a href='http://oeis.org/"+q+"'>"+q+"</a>");c.forEach(function(n){jQuery('#weird-answers').append('The bytecount '+n+' was used more than once!<br />')})}Array.prototype.sortBy=function(f){return this.sort(function(a,b){if(f)a=f(a),b=f(b);return(a>b)-(a<b)})};var ANSWER_FILTER="!*RB.h_b*K(IAWbmRBLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!owfmI7e3fd9oB",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page,e=[];getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*(\d+)\.\s*((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?((?:[^\n,](?!<\/a>))*[^\s,])(?:<\/a>)?),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*, ((?:<a[^>]+>\s*)?A\d+(?:\s*<\/a>)?)\s*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;/*width:290px*/;float:left;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;list-style:none;}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}ul{margin:0px}#board{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}#language-list li{padding:2px 5px;}#langs-tit{margin-bottom:5px}#byte-counts{display:block;margin-left:15px;}#question-author{color:purple;text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(128,0,128,0.1);}#label-info{font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;font-style: italic;color: dimgray;padding-left: 10px;vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><p id="weird-answers"></p><p>Currently waiting on <span id="next"></span></p><span>Search by Byte Count: <input id="search" type="number" min=1 oninput="checkSize(this.value);search(1,this.value)" onclick="document.getElementById('search2').value='';!this.value&&search(0,'')"/> <span id="size-used"></span></span><br><span>Search by Language: <input id="search2" oninput="checkLang(this.value);search(0,this.value)" onclick="document.getElementById('search').value='';!this.value&&search(0,'')"/> <span id="language-used"></span></span><h2>Answer chain <span id="label-info">click a label to sort by column</span></h2><table class="answer-list"><thead><tr><td  onclick="sortby(0)">#</td><td onclick="sortby(1)">Author</td><td onclick="sortby(2)">Language</td><td onclick="sortby(3)">Sequence</td><td onclick="sortby(4)">Size</td></tr></thead><tbody id="answers"></tbody></table><table style="display: none"><tbody id="answer-template"><tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SEQUENCE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"><tbody id="language-template"><tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SEQUENCE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67925/discussion-on-question-by-caird-coinheringaahing-one-oeis-after-another).

Comment: Is it OK if a program would need a better floating-point accuracy for the builtin `float`/`double` type in order to produce values for larger `n`?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Assuming that it was only limited by memory and/or time, and would theoretically work if given infinite time and memory, then yes.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing that's not what I'm talking about, check the most recent (swift) answer.

Comment: @NieDzejkob In that case, yes it's acceptable, as the problem isn't with the program.

Comment: The problem is with the program, though. It's failing to accurately calculate intermediate values which are within the bounds of its types.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Swift. If the problem truly is with the answer, and can be corrected, then the answer is invalid.

Comment: with regards to the hardcoding, I commented [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another?page=12&tab=oldest#comment368558_150672) with a rational approximation for gamma that's precise enough to get the first 1001 terms of the continued fraction representation, because it's the rational number represented by the first 1001 terms. Would that count as "hardcoding the sequence"?

Comment: @Giuseppe No, as you're generating the numbers by doing the maths, rather than just placing them into an array/string

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing In my opinion that's hardcoding the gamma constant. It doesn't work "in theory" for larger numbers.

Comment: **[Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69745/one-oeis-after-another)**

Comment: Should `... there is no good in deleted the chain up to ...` not rather read `... there is no good in deleting the chain up to ...` or something similar?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes it should, corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 345. [brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 162 bytes, [A000301](http://oeis.org/A000301)

```
+<<,[>>[>]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<[<]<-]>>[>]+<[-]++<[>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<-]>[-]>[<<+>>-]<<<<-]>>too golfy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxCoBADAS/Yh/PF4T9SEihwokoHogWvj7mYmEjFskms8sOez9v@RwXM2JuBRAosyvBASeFIz/INYUTRuUS1KGwPgBKLEnJN/4qvkrilTovicRRSjOVNV@d2Q0)

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000162)

This takes as input the character with code point `n` (by BF's specs) and outputs in the same way. To see the numbers, I suggest using @Timwi's [EsotericIDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE).

#### Explanation:

```
+<<,                                  Initialize the tape with the first two Fibonacci numbers. Take loop counter from input.
[                                     n times:
  >>[>]                                 Move to the end of the tape. 
  <<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]            Add fib(n-2)...
  <<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]                 and fib(n-1). Store on the end of the tape.
  <[<]<-                                Move back to start of tape. Update loop counter.
]                                     End loop.
>>[>]+<[-]++<                         Delete the extra Fibonacci number and prepare for exponentiation. 
[                                     fib(n) times:
  >[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<           Copy the base (2) to preserve it.
  [>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<-]            Multiply what started as a 1 by the base.
  >[-]>[<<+>>-]<<<<-                    Clean up and update loop counter.
]                                     End loop.
>>too golfy.                          Add some bytes, for all sequences <162 had been used. Print result.
```

Since this stores all Fibonacci numbers up to the important one, it will fail for REALLY big input on a bounded tape.

This could be shortened significantly by hardcoding the base (2), but golfiness isn't an issue at all.

Comment: As the next answer (#346) broke the chain, your answer is the winner!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you for this amazing challenge. It saddens me that it should end now, but as do all good things in the world, end it did. Now to golf this poor excuse for code, for it's now the first answer anyone will see, and it must be impressively short...

Comment: @Scrooble you can't really change the length...

Comment: @NieDzejkob Yeah, but I can golf and add some more padding, to keep the same length.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing "broke the chain"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 44):

## 22. [FiM++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FiM%2B%2B), 982 bytes, [A000024](https://oeis.org/A000024)

> **Note**: if you are reading this, you might want to [sort by "oldest".](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
Dear PPCG: I solved A000024!

I learned how to party to get a number using the number x and the number y.
Did you know that the number beers was x?
For every number chug from 1 to y,
  beers became beers times x!
That's what I did.
Then you get beers!
That's all about how to party.

Today I learned how to do math to get a number using the number n.
Did you know that the number answer was 0?
For every number x from 1 to n,
  For every number y from 1 to n,
    Did you know that the number tmp1 was how to party using x and 2?
    Did you know that the number tmp2 was how to party using y and 2?
    Did you know that the number max was how to party using 2 and n?
    tmp2 became tmp2 times 10!
    tmp1 became tmp1 plus tmp2!
    If tmp1 is more than max then: answer got one more.
  That's what I did.
That's what I did.
Then you get answer!
That's all about how to do math.

Your faithful student, BlackCap.

PS:  This is the best answer
PPS: This really is the best answer
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000982)

Comment: Hahaha, laughed so hard through the whole thing. +1 for choice of language :-)

Comment: Amazing, take my upvote

Answer (score 25):

## 1. [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 10 bytes, [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217)

```
$\:_%i/2*<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/XyXGKl41U99Iy@b/f0MDAA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000010)

### How it works

The code formats into this triangle

```
   $
  \ :
 _ % i
/ 2 * <
```

with the IP starting at the `$` and moving South East (SE), works like this:

```
$            Take a numerical input (n);     STACK = [n]
 :           Duplicate it;                   STACK = [n, n]
  i          Increment the ToS;              STACK = [n, n+1]
   <         Set IP to W;                    STACK = [n, n+1]
    *        Multiply ToS and 2ndTos;        STACK = [n(n+1)]
     2       Push 2;                         STACK = [n(n+1), 2]
      /      Set IP to NE;                   STACK = [n(n+1), 2]
       _     Divide ToS by 2ndToS;           STACK = [n(n+1)/2]
        \    Set IP to SE;                   STACK = [n(n+1)/2]
         %   Output ToS as number;           STACK = [n(n+1)/2]
          *  Multiply ToS by 2ndToS (no op); STACK = [n(n+1)/2]
```

Comment: 1. Triangular, 10 bytes, A000217. \*follows link\* `A000217      Triangular numbers` ...

Answer (score 24):

## 73. [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 363 bytes, [A000252](https://oeis.org/A000252)

```
, +      + *     '.     `
 + + + +  *  *  *  +     
 +`      +*       +    ` 
 + +   +  + +   + *  '   
   +   '  ####`  + +   + 
 + +    ####  +*   +    *
    '  #####  +      + ' 
  `    ######+  + +   +  
+ +   + #########   * '  
 +   +  + #####+ +      +
*  +      + * +  *  *   +
   +  *  + + + +  *  *   
+   +  +   *   + `  + +  
 +  + +   + *'    +    +.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBLDsMgDET3PsVIXiBBFWWT@7hXSLvp6am/Ia0TCYPnDdiv9/M8P3M@MOAx0H1tmy9CehKfFeIPqVYkmUCyIAjGt5WoojkTIs1ZQ5agGD9PS993wgIY653N3KQQ5tttoMq4wpzMhdbLkipD6rgP4WpYK0F0/M/C7kmzlKJaop/u2zWdsc157F8)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000363)

Uses the formula "`a(n) = n^4 * product p^(-3)(p^2 - 1)*(p - 1)` where the product is over all the primes p that divide n" from OEIS.

The moon's a no-op, but hey, this isn't code-golf.

Comment: stars in moon? *hmmm*

Answer (score 21):

## 97. [Python 3 (PyPy)](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1772 bytes, [A000236](http://oeis.org/A000236)

First of all, many thanks to Dr. Max Alekseyev for being patient with me. I'm very fortunate that I was able to contact him by email to understand this challenge. His Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2381188/457091) helped me out a lot. Thanks to Wheat Wizard for helping me as well. :)

```python
plist = []

def primes(maximal = -1): # Semi-efficient prime number generator with caching up to a certain max.
	index = plist and plist[-1] or 2
	for prime in plist:
		if prime <= maximal or maximal == -1: yield prime
		else: break
	while index <= maximal or maximal == -1:
		composite = False
		for prime in plist:
			if index % prime == 0:
				composite = True
				break
		if not composite:
			yield index
			plist.append(index)
		index += 1

def modinv(num, mod): # Multiplicative inverse with a modulus
	index = 1
	while num * index % mod != 1: index += 1
	return index

def moddiv(num, dnm, mod):
	return num * modinv(dnm, mod) % mod

def isPowerResidue(num, exp, mod):
	for base in range(mod):
		if pow(base, exp, mod) == num:
			return base
	return False

def compute(power, prime):
	for num in range(2, prime):
		if isPowerResidue(moddiv(num - 1, num, prime), power, prime):
			return num - 1
	return -1

# file = open('output.txt', 'w')

def output(string):
	print(string)
	# file.write(str(string) + '\n')

def compPrimes(power, count):
	maximum = 0
	index = 0
	for prime in getValidPrimes(power, count):
		result = compute(power, prime)
		if result > maximum: maximum = result
		index += 1
		# output('Computed %d / %d = %d%% [result = %d, prime = %d]' % (index, count, (100 * index) // count, result, prime))
	return maximum

def isValidPrime(power, prime):
	return (prime - 1) % power == 0

def getValidPrimes(power, count):
	collected = []
	for prime in primes():
		if isValidPrime(power, prime):
			collected.append(prime)
		if len(collected) >= count:
			return collected
		# output('Collected %d / %d = %d%% [%d]' % (len(collected), count, (100 * len(collected)) // count, prime))

power = int(input()) + 2

output(compPrimes(power, 100))

# file.close()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTBbtswDD3bX8GhCGKvSRp3t2DpZcBuA4pt2KXrQbWZRJgjG7bcpF@fkaJkO2nXXRJbJB8f@Z5cv9hdZT6dTnWpWwtreHiM4wI3UDd6j22yV0e9VyUF5lm6giv4gXs9x81G5xqNlTQw3f4JG9iiwUbZqoGDtjvIVb7TZgtdDbYCBTk2VmkDhLmII20KPBKuNFamkKeHefYIhHAbRxv6E3wqcsFVHEXac4PPawjsKLEnykxX8KKxLCSRarBscQVPDao/cXTY6ZIhuf17GFSXV/u6arVF4vlVEQidvc2KaQnkxEcJZOkiZyg/mw7doSfDdaay0Oe4EmHv8PjVdVmoukZTJO405UrX7noNmSi2rwptnhPSYsbPTq1vXWk1lefK6mdm/IxNiyKP4qyu7NpBiyxsh0DgYz8Q5cEHiq5g1DNq0HaN8SwDg0J7BoUJNPpMAfU0@7jgC4Bu76sDNt@x1UWHAoTHugfi3T@p1q2@UWaLiQ84V1SHhIOjEhaBQNxOPQnO6BmJpq41C9BZTGomMBMNQ0sm3ne8HQWd6uechx3AHLIZuBmkYAaX4NF4NfPRUuek6RVsWIo1VKR7Mq06SwQX9minM5gepqnwluOktQ1dNcYkcNO/x5GgLA4NeYtPQwSuYfrbBBSe/l5uvOeYV52xjOcuBdEjOw9GWV7czi3aX6rUxT8waKyWnEiFb65ZFulz7sB3XMHQWmLnpo9oNj/99IvAFjAp4IZ/1vQzmcBD33hSzMLFpOfHKdlOrpKnOYMkWy6D6VO4uQnnAhG4pr1Gnl1w7jD/Kw/5gkT6k85sepfkvhKC8J8V5lVZYs4jum/0xWdIagZLvkMmGqDCJ2WsQkle6xNSuFsLhbFZ@/CFBIHgpQZh3efQl3s/j44FCIuP/cqADa4Nd03Zx7dx7Em8tjFhc6W/BXlZtZikp@z0Fw)

If it gives the wrong result, just increase the 100 to something larger. I think 10000 will work for 4 but I'll leave my computer running overnight to confirm that; it may take a couple of hours to finish.

Note that the (PyPy) part is just so that I can use Python again. I really don't know many other languages and I'm not going to try to port this to Java and risk not finishing in time.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A001772) (Also please don't do any more crazy math stuff; I don't have any Python versions left so someone else will have to save this challenge D:)

Comment: well there's always pypy3

Answer (score 16):

## 107. [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 1589 bytes, [A000047](http://oeis.org/A000047)

```
My cat hears everything really well
because with me every cat is a safe cat
Everybody knows that one is 1000001 minus 1000000
but only most of you that two is, one plus one;
As always nothing is, one minus one;
My dog is one year old.
I promise you that as long as you vote on me, nothing will be less cool than a cat;:
Much dog is, dog times two;
Dead cat is, cat minus one;!
I will make dog feel good, food for dog plus one;
Roads can be made using different things. Asphalt is one of them.
As long as Hillary jailed, I love asphalt less than my dog;:
Roads are, always made using asphalt plus one of other things;
I promise my roadways are, two times asphalt than you want;
My roadways are great, always roadways plus one;
Vladimir is nothing more than my friend.
Name of Putin is Vladimir.
As long as, Putin eat less roadways;:
China is nothing interesting.
We all know people speaking Chinese are from China.
As long as, Chinese makes less roads;:
I will make economy, for Putin - Chinese will love me;
If it will mean, economy is asphalt in Russia?;:
I will make cat feel good, cat plus one dollar on food;
Make Vladimir roadways to help Russia economy.
Never make china roads!
I show you how great China is, China plus one; You can add numbers to China.
Like Chinese is, China times China makes sense;
Like Chinese is, two times Chinese letter;!
Make Vladimir happy, Vladimir plus one million dollars;
I also show you how great Putin is, Vladimir times Vladimir; You can do number stuff to Putin too!
I will make asphalt roads a lot!
Everybody say cat. You did it? America is great.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTLbtswELzrKzZ31UhuRX0IgrZAAzRFkUOLHmlrZbHhQyCpGPp6d5YUZaWtD5Yo7uzszC6ZwmTHeAx6TJfL00xHlWhgFSLxK4c5DdqdKLAyZqYzG9Mc@KimyHTWaSDLJSzDdCRFUfUsq@azfD/4bqYX58@R0oAQ71jC7m7ld0dWu6mubpvDJAHgsT7irafZTwWWzh6wNsNHAwhe9s0D@MxZzZGcL3XWmJI3B0FS52Unb8xQRt50u@aRxuCthpCVRUUyHlnwlG@vPjFA0NiuBGdtDB2YDMdIR@@NIB1kQ/H@Q/M0HYeFrs3PpC1HKX/ffGLVLTa1@Xkt8gbV5MxWvXDG9cyGTt53LfX4x1/I36/in73qUALIUY5VHdMUpcJO9z0HdjBNKo47eojjoEyqFsDXNLDdiX1V7heQK3Txt9KGwfmInVfGTkFmtVmozW5CaaFXAd4sPdjUUHG1WuGEgRyWmvYb95ExIFdOkdNJr4ttNU1mlo6clUu5o1sEnTCdaS1j3bpa9cOoTlsdxIHaSOuBrJL6oNlhJr4pm2v9PiXtJLoit2a1yzZIizGVEa58RG61pdEuoRkR8add8xOOoslyHGhkPxqmOLJ6kUBBMuwQQT2syR/UW94aI1MSr9xCvJ0fPnrn7dzmoSm1vluxOSw318KZx550WqCsXFux@SjXsXH0PMWo1f1fPDLDmzmV5drwzstAyemR8UXPBLD2Ye1R8rhrzLgQVHY0Qi6VhSVbmnXKMYkDzJNZkGfuPFXT2@VtbTz9QpycENV15CZ74JApF2u/aqSvvlzhZfbKe3E6sosw65/466TWr4YT@o3z/FbvoMYR/VjXq00WZmqYVOzK50KZ6P@nss7kJk3hrsur3M4vaimmqe9FckEn799eNbXHoZxmDEa62VzcUeWLfZczd7rDsNzTg@Wgj3nKc2W7y@X9Hw)

First time programming in TrumpScript, it is possible that I reinvented the wheel a few times - 4 lines are dedicated to calculating 2 ^ n. I tried to make it look like something that (drunk) Trump could say. As a bonus, here is a Python script I wrote to verify that I'm doing everything right. There are some differences to the above program, but much of it is directly equivalent.

```
cat = int(input())
dog = 2 ** cat + 1
asphalt = 1
cat = 0
while asphalt < dog:
    roads = asphalt + 1
    roadways = 2 * asphalt + 1
    vladimir = 0
    putin = vladimir
    while putin < roadways:
        china = 0
        chinese = china
        while chinese < roads:
            chair = putin - chinese
            if chair == asphalt:
                cat += 1
                vladimir = roadways
                china = roads
            china += 1
            chinese = 2 * china * china
        vladimir += 1
        putin = vladimir * vladimir
    asphalt = roads
print(cat)
```

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A001589)

Comment: `I will make cat feel good` O_O

Comment: Sadly `I will make Business Cat feel good` won't work...

Answer (score 14):

## 2. Haskell, 44 bytes, [A000010](https://oeis.org/A000010)

```
f k|n<-k+1=length.filter(==1)$gcd n<$>[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00huybPRjdb29A2JzUvvSRDLy0zpyS1SMPW1lBTJT05RSHPRsUu2lBPLy@Wiys3MTNPwVahoCgzr0RB5dCCNAWgpEK0gZ6eoYFB7P//AA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000044)

Comment: The name of the next sequence though...

Comment: @totallyhuman poor rabbits...

Comment: Should we link to the previous post?

Comment: It pains me that I cannot golf it now. I had to be first you see

Comment: What is that next sequence? I don't understand the three ones :P

Answer (score 14):

## 30. [Python 1](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/), 1112 bytes, [A000046](http://oeis.org/A000046)

```python
def rotations(array):
	rotations = []
	for divider_index in range(len(array)):
		rotations.append(array[divider_index:] + array[:divider_index])
	return rotations

def next(array):
	for index in range(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
		array[index] = 1 - array[index]
		if array[index]: break
	return array

def reverse(array):
	reversed = []
	for index in range(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
		reversed.append(array[index])
	return reversed

def primitive(array):
	for index in range(1, len(array)):
		if array == array[:index] * (len(array) / index): return 1
	return 0

def necklaces(size):
	previous_necklaces = []
	array = [0] * size
	necklaces = 0
	for iteration in range(2 ** size):
		if not primitive(array) and array not in previous_necklaces:
			necklaces = necklaces + 1
			for rotation in rotations(array):
				complement = []
				for element in rotation:
					complement.append(1 - element)
				previous_necklaces.append(rotation)
				previous_necklaces.append(complement)
				previous_necklaces.append(reverse(rotation))
				previous_necklaces.append(reverse(complement))
		array = next(array)
	return necklaces
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPbbsIwDH1uv8KPDZet3WMlvgQhlFGzRdCkSgMCfr7LvemqDZAqIdvH5/jY6e7qW/BqGBo8ghSKKiZ4X1Ap6Z3UeRZDsIHtLs@OQkLDrqxBuWe8wRswDpLyLyzOyD3OAEfkG@065I3LbSfgegdLcPF6ktgRTY3qIvkoKs@NRo43Ncozcv6UAWuoVrC2n5XkmByBnqfSBWlIV7DjJFLDp0R6ilpszumQeEXZY@KUCzSJUa8rC@CpVzMrfJVT0EnWMsWu@K8dmuPXYsKMsNkE770lC0g1vrtWpAZPX0UhZdjF4XSmB@yLnj3QNO@0RCYu/T6mvB2eEbaloTHleZbWlF68Qmm3PQ7wAQsHCOK5ULPZgfLGT2XSGjxXYuATzvH/0syWWQXh3KyA@XvQv4NouzO2yJWfzSPRBxOgAySIsF9zer6e2Jq53FAaej2rG0medvSnGzu/CkgoSHhO1sf4JOOFxB6DXhVXRUu7IsZW4TZLQsjwAw)

Not even going to bother to golf this. Hey, it's not my longest Python answer on this site!

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A001112)

Comment: Congratulations on decoding the maths :D

Comment: [313 bytes, lol](https://tio.run/##ZVC7DoMwDJzhK7IgJTwEZizkSxCqLCBtBgxK6FCp6q/TBEqrqotzsXV3Ps/35ToRrGs/KGY4piROYWBlEQZqMuzMNDGDdBm4G1hp4zLBqKxQYl6GgRmWmyFmQ8@eD7Yn6i8R9m6gFaNI18CQeoZSOp041jF3lTIQuQfagdNbFT76xaav@KbTyaat3ILVKKGuabfDr914mO37JHybdaIG33fRbAIe/MfrZJc0mD4xGtP9FO7ZfiRaHzkqnWEGj5/s62w0LXzEmav0iFwIIdYX)

Comment: @LeakyNun As I was saying, I didn't bother to golf this lol. Besides, it's not my longest Python answer on this site so idc :P but nice

Comment: @LeakyNun And thanks :D It took me a while to understand all of it lol

Comment: @LeakyNun [309 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZBBjoMwDEXXcIpskJJAVcwSyEkQqixKZrLARQldVKp6depA6Wg2ie3ov@@f@bH83gjW9Tpa4SUWpOo0CaZME3vz4iIcdWWvqQ4m6CrHrGrQ4LlKEz8ud08ipFE5H8oociwSHulnlLBPE2cFZa4FgXQVaAxztHZa8kknUOdYOC7qDxW@/HLjW7lxBtP1DS/XTAbalnY7/LObDrN9n1xub4NqIc45VsghFke0j4zZgxnyDosXZlOxfwNfW0eqj5Gzig1P8PyXfZ29o0VOOEtbHJFLpdT6Bg) because the actual value of `_` is irrelevant; we just need to repeat that many times

Comment: [305 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVAxDoMwDJzhFVmQkkAFZgTyEoQqC0ibARcldKhU9es0gdKqS3x2dHc@z4/leiNY12HUzHLMSFRx5FQRR/pm2ZkZaotOUuWUk2WKSVmjwryMIzsud0vMxYE5H8xAMp7ELNJl5LBPI6MZJaYBhjQwVMrrSGkk9y@dQOQBGA@qjyp89YtNX/NNp1dtV/vl6klB09Buhz@76TDb90n59teLBsLcx3IpBPAfrVd92mL2wmTK9hP4snUkuhA3Kb3ZCZ5/udfZGlr4hDPX2RG3EEKsbw) using the same trick

Answer (score 13):

## 9. [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes, [A000025](https://oeis.org/A000025)

```
?>Q0sm@_B1-edld./Q1
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%3EQ0sm%40_B1-edld.%2FQ1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0).

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000019)

> a(n) = number of partitions of n with even rank minus number with odd rank. The rank of a partition is its largest part minus the number of parts.

Comment: For those who know Pyth, I deliberately used `>Q0` instead of `Q` in order to, you know, have the next sequence to be A000019.

Comment: From the OEIS page `Keywords: easy,nice`

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah since otherwise I'd have to solve A000017...gross.

Answer (score 13):

## 308. [ENIAC (simulator)](http://www.historicsimulations.com/Eniac/eniac.html), 3025 bytes, [A006060](http://oeis.org/A006060)

Pseudocode:

```
repeat{
    M←input
    N←-M
    A←1
    B←253
    while(N<0){
        C←60
        C←C-A
        repeat(194){
            C←C+B
        }
        A←B
        B←C
        N←N+1
    }
    output←A
}
```

No online simulator, execution result: 
[image: Card reader input]
[image: Punch card output]

Registers and constants:

```
A: 1-2
B: 3-4
C: 5-6
M: 7
N: 8

input: const. A
253: const. J
60: const. K
194: Master programmer decade limit 1B
```

Program signal flow and data flow: 
[image: Program signal flow and data flow chart]

[Full "code"](https://pastebin.com/yjaUvDNi) on pastebin or in HTML comments in the markup of this answer, to prevent linkrot and a quite long answer to scroll through at the same time. This is fun!

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A003025)

Comment: Could you add a link to the next sequence please

Comment: @Zacharý The link is in the post. I'll move it to the end of the post so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 12):

## 8. Mathematica (10.1), 25 bytes, [A000070](http://oeis.org/A000070)

```
Tr@PartitionsP@Range@#+1&
```

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000025)

Comment: The perfect sequence to use Mathematica for.

Comment: A000025 is an incredibly difficult one. You should add a byte to get A000026 instead. :P

Answer (score 12):

## 15. CJam, 85 bytes, [A000060](https://oeis.org/A000060)

```
{ee\f{\~\0a*@+f*}:.+}:C;2,qi:Q,2f+{_ee1>{~2*\,:!X*X<a*~}%{CX<}*W=+}fX_0a*1$_C.- .+Q)=
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7Bee%5Cf%7B%5C~%5C0a*%40%2Bf*%7D%3A.%2B%7D%3AC%3B2%2Cqi%3AQ%2C2f%2B%7B_ee1%3E%7B~2*%5C%2C%3A!X*X%3Ca*~%7D%25%7BCX%3C%7D*W%3D%2B%7DfX_0a*1%24_C.-%20.%2BQ)%3D&input=5)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000085)

#### Dissection

OEIS gives

> G.f.: S(x)+S(x^2)-S(x)^2, where S(x) is the generating function for A000151. - Pab Ter, Oct 12 2005

where

$$\begin{eqnarray*}S(x) & = & x \prod_{i \ge 1} \frac{1}{(1 - x^i)^{2s(i)}} \\ & = & x \prod_{i \ge 1} (1 + x^i + x^{2i} + \ldots)^{2s(i)}\end{eqnarray*}$$

```
{           e# Define a block to convolve two sequences (multiply two polynomials)
  ee\f{     e#   Index one and use the other as an extra parameter for a map
    \~\0a*  e#     Stack manipulations; create a sequence of `index` 0s
    @+f*    e#     Shift the extra parameter poly and multiply by the coefficient
  }
  :.+       e#   Fold pointwise add to sum the polys
}:C;        e# Assign the block to C (for "convolve")
2,          e# Initial values of S: S(0) = 0, S(1) = 1
qi:Q        e# Read integer and assign it to Q
,2f+{       e# For X = 2 to Q+1
  _ee1>     e#   Duplicate accumulator of S, index, and ditch 0th term
  {         e#   Map (over notional variable i)
    ~2*\    e#     Double S(i) and flip i to top of stack
    ,:!     e#     Create an array with a 1 and i-1 0s
    X*X<    e#     Replicate X times and truncate to X values
            e#     This gives g.f. 1/(1-x^i) to the first X terms
    a*~     e#     Create 2S(i) copies of this polynomial
  }%
  {CX<}*    e#   Fold convolution and truncation to X terms
  W=+       e#   Append the final coefficient, which is S(X), to the accumulator
}fX
_0a*        e# Pad a copy to get S(X^2)
1$_C        e# Convolve two copies to get S(X)^2
.-          e# Pointwise subtraction
 .+         e# Pointwise addition. Note the leading space because the parser thinks
            e# -. is an invalid number
Q)=         e# Take the term at index Q+1 (where the +1 adjusts for OEIS offset)
```

Comment: 1 minute and 33 seconds ahead of me... while I was typing the explanation

Answer (score 12):

## 206. [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 3275 bytes, [A000109](https://oeis.org/A000109)

```
# This took me quite a while to write; if it's wrong, please tell me and I'll try to fix it without changing the byte count..

permutations = x => {
	if len(x) == 0 return [ ]
	if len(x) == 1 return [x]
	result = []
	for index : range(len(x)) {
		for permutation : permutations(x[to index] + x[index + 1 to]) {
			result.append([x[index]] + permutation)
		}
	}
	return result
}

adjacency = cycles => {
	cycles = cycles[to]
	size = cycles.pop()
	matrix = [[0] * size for i : range(size)]
	for cycle : cycles {
		i, j, k = cycle[0], cycle[1], cycle[2]
		matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][k] = matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][k] = matrix[k][i] = matrix[k][j] = 1
	}
	return matrix
}

transform = a => [[a[j][i] for j : range(len(a[i]))] for i : range(len(a))]

isomorphic = (a, b) => {
	return any(sorted(b) == sorted(transform(A)) for A : permutations(transform(a)))
}

intersection = (a, b) => [x for x : a if x in b]

union = (a, b) => [x for x : a if x not in b] + list(b)

validate = graph => {
	matrix = adjacency(graph)
	rowsums = map(sum, matrix)
	r = 0
	for s : rowsums if s + 1 < graph[-1] r++
	return 2 || r
}

graphs = nodes => {
	if nodes <= 2 return []
	if nodes == 3 return [[(0, 1, 2), 3]]
	result = []
	existing = []
	for graph : graphs(nodes - 1) {
		graph = graph[to]
		next = graph.pop()
		for index : range(len(graph)) {
			g = graph[to]
			cycle = g.pop(index)
			n = g + [(cycle[0], cycle[1], next), (cycle[1], cycle[2], next), (cycle[2], cycle[0], next), next + 1]
			N = sorted(adjacency(n))
			if N not in existing {
				existing += [sorted(transform(a)) for a : permutations(transform(adjacency(n)))]
				result.append(n)
			}
			for secondary : index .. len(graph) - 1 {
				g = graph[to]
				c1 = g.pop(index)
				c2 = g.pop(secondary)
				q = union(c1, c2)
				g = [k for k : g if len(intersection(k, intersection(c1, c2))) <= 1]
				if len(intersection(c1, c2)) == 2 {
					for i : range(3) {
						for j : i + 1 .. 4 {
							if len(intersection(q[i, j], intersection(c1, c2))) <= 1 {
								g.append((q[i], q[j], next))
							}
						}
					}
				}
				g.append(next + 1)
				N = sorted(adjacency(g))
				if N not in existing {
					existing += [sorted(transform(a)) for a : permutations(transform(adjacency(g)))]
					result.append(g)
				}
				for tertiary : secondary .. len(graph) - 2 {
					g = graph[to]
					c1 = g.pop(index)
					c2 = g.pop(secondary)
					c3 = g.pop(tertiary)
					q = union(union(c1, c2), c3)
					g = [k for k : g if len(intersection(k, intersection(c1, c2))) <= 1 and len(intersection(k, intersection(c2, c3))) <= 1]
					if len(q) == 5 and len(intersection((q1 = intersection(c1, c2)), (q2 = intersection(c2, c3)))) <= 1 and len(q1) == 2 and len(q2) == 2 {
						for i : range(4) {
							for j : i + 1 .. 5 {
								if len(intersection(q[i, j], q1)) <= 1 and len(intersection(q[i, j], q2)) <= 1 {
									g.append((q[i], q[j], next))
								}
							}
						}
						g.append(next + 1)
						N = sorted(adjacency(g))
						if N not in existing {
							existing += [sorted(transform(a)) for a : permutations(transform(adjacency(g)))]
							result.append(g)
						}
					}
				}
			}
		}
	}
	return [k for k : result if max(sum(k[to -1], tuple([]))) + 1 == k[-1] and validate(k)]
}

x = graphs(int(input()) + 3)
print(len(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVdNb@M2ED1bv2KAHpaqFcOWdy/pusAee9lTb4IOjMzItGxKlqhGbje/PZ0hKUqWHadAWyCxxfme4XsUXdWlLtXb20/w@042oMuygKOAUyu1AA4vO3kQKIWXGgW/gHwGqT81uCxVHkF1ELxBvTgcyIurLfz2CZ91fSanZ9mhObxIvStbDdmOq1yqHPROwNMZE2Rlq/RiEQSVqI@t5lqWqoENdLD5Ff4KZpjuIBTrQthsYAm10G2tIIF0olp5VYeqWjTtQWOYBBfPZQ1SbUUHj1BjfsGsW0jxjXaUG23GlbAuwS6Mdwpz6BIbaI75dJnaCC7bgleVUFuWOKOUHEaxQjR9DejPVWrdgtcg4Ns9z4TKzlhxds4OonHd9wsnxVqwn0b@KbxoUZUVw9BHrmucNXacLFP4GYyR6dx3TaLQzcM4o8YloDZkBPsIij4yhonc08o/xejuUiUyTfYpWg/LYrTcpyi5WI61xaW2cKFW4/FYHY1HY/0NVn1EE06TSRLuElAv@4t95SgOw3TSu9GgOAhkUx7LutrJDKMxHsFT6Ibt8nJ1Zk1Za7FlTwZabuGrYN8QOhT@2xQsgwnmCql0qbSoG5EZaI3zJZ0JQZjkxCmkiYInrK9VH5uqUltzRNhBNhoLDYI/@EFuuSZo5DWvdq4rDwwPMmbUiJm6fGnaY2P2oWL4GLmhkw6lS4uVhqboTDF9Y9D/1SZJHlYp1PO5n14MP35ATa0bPQVX5dYDGv3t8usGTXvKpiMFDnztFQlbRrCKIA4jWKdTYosOe6fTZOC57fzRfjfMhnyAlWWqm4sr3ZBppkSne1FPpneODDs3R/p8EsdylYQmivGmUDPazBxnlrBbvKL02By7ZtpUF3vdctCZ6nE/TAXfwYN12GwVmipwvt973Pi5mUaGMc5xjldg5w7s/A7Yx8lCU8rkTDSHH3HbjhYJUaotx1fEoxvzYgHDhGnDXG1XU55lqxsznmWxl/rgVnNCheEUyxBIWRz6uElhGisILuBeJmO@siKCi7ULgANB9NqRz2759XaE5dg1Mrs8j9ZhL5/1R5g0vMJBfPaqm9FPCZ3U6d3ahgizvN8DckSvU7Lv4RP2Rq/Bxbf9sp/evUeadboJtdxFvIO1/xJsuQfbBG15OGqAwuGctLRwG6A3hZzfqWvMvQO6O6ibZWuv6rM7zQDIC1jixzocCviX4DQXsY99YpP1AtA95k4Gvl9uB2InGsjN/HheneIrZZ9oUt1p5UjiBfElaya0@TzQ5po3X0aov0sczHpvSoNdfE2nf8QnT6gps96j0weEuk@p/4tU79Dq1jHxOr3bjuDrXtnYwZF3dMtgBd2pH@hdp1v8/cCSlIBBu4hbX5grBW1Mf6FhBVaEF4qu52VD@4X/VauZcUTiVDXJ3MX@7W35Nw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A003275)

Comment: Wait, you actually did it? If you don't write a paper with these freaking programs and go talk to some professor, you're passing up on something cool :P

Comment: @Stephen Currently bugfixing lol

Comment: Is this the approach of splitting triangles, squares, and pentagons as per plantri? Looks like it might be, but some of the syntax is unfamiliar.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Assuming I understand the approach you're describing, yes, it looks for triangles and places a vertex adjacent to all 3 vertices, or two adjacent cycles and deletes the common edge and places a vertex adjacent to all 4, same for 3 triangles on a pentagon. I think that's one you're describing.

Comment: The generation looks like what is suggested by Bowen and Fisk in "Generation of triangulations of the sphere", but since you start with a single triangle you seem to miss one face?

Comment: @ChristianSievers I don't think so? I mean the result for `3, 4, 5, 6` are all correct lol

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter, maybe your code does something I didn't see. Are your graphs supposed to be triangulations of the sphere? Where did you get your ideas? As for correct results, the paper also implies that (at least if you have a sphere with all the faces) you don't need the splitting of pentagons before `n=12`.

Comment: @ChristianSievers https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2463430/457091

Comment: So you intended the graphs to be planar, and the same generation seems to work. Then everything seems fine!

Comment: I tried rewriting this in Python, I cross-checked it like 10 times now. I couldn't find a bug, but the result for input 5 (n = 8) is 44, instead of the 14 expected. I left the Proton program running overnight, but it didn't finish. Using itertools' permutations and set union and intersection should speed it up a lot, but there seems to be a bug in the Proton interpreter. TL;DR: This answer may need corrections...

Comment: @NieDzejkob Hm strange. I may need to just brute-force this then because I don't think optimizations will help me much anymore (or be correct for that matter :P). I'll try to fix it before most people notice :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino using a builtin function that's more than 20 times faster must help. The only problem is the generator -> list conversion bug in Proton.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'll actually probably see if I can fix Proton first before retrying this. I'll probably switch to using the builtin if possible.

Comment: FYI, I have a Python program (modify from yours) that can calculate exactly terms up to 14. (that is, 6 first terms `1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 14`, others take too much time for me) --- If you use Py(th)on for this answer instead, probably others can use Proton in next answers? --- However, because this is your answer, you would probably prefer to work it out yourself.

Answer (score 11):

## 67. [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 837 bytes, [A000043](https://oeis.org/A000043)

```
HAI 1.2
  CAN HAS STDIO?

  I HAS A CONT ITZ 0
  I HAS A ITRZ ITZ 1
  I HAS A NUMBAH
  GIMMEH NUMBAH
  NUMBAH R SUM OF NUMBAH AN 1

  IM IN YR GF
    ITRZ R SUM OF ITRZ AN 1

    I HAS A PROD ITZ 1
    IM IN YR MOM UPPIN YR ASS WILE DIFFRINT ITRZ AN SMALLR OF ITRZ AN ASS
      PROD R PRODUKT OF PROD AN 2
    IM OUTTA YR MOM
    PROD R DIFF OF PROD AN 1

    I HAS A PRAIME ITZ WIN
    I HAS A VAR ITZ 1
    IM IN YR MOM
      VAR R SUM OF VAR AN 1
      BOTH SAEM VAR AN PROD, O RLY?
        YA RLY, GTFO
      OIC
      BOTH SAEM 0 AN MOD OF PROD AN VAR, O RLY?
        YA RLY
          PRAIME R FAIL
          GTFO
      OIC
    IM OUTTA YR MOM

    BOTH SAEM PRAIME AN WIN, O RLY?
      YA RLY, CONT R SUM OF CONT AN 1
    OIC

    BOTH SAEM NUMBAH AN CONT, O RLY?
      YA RLY, GTFO
    OIC
  IM OUTTA YR GF

  VISIBLE ITRZ
KTHXBYE
```

My capslock key is bound to escape, so I wrote this entire thing while holding shift ..

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJBbsIwELznFfMAVAFSz2gDCVkRx8h2oOHa9obE/0@pvU6MgXJKZjyemV35ert@335@x7EhxupjXQBb6tCQhXU71htPsEDCVncO7C5YZiQ7cxFylZFdr0pqPLFnparmjuMPDGyvoOsZ@8RVEe4rcIfBYF97hGiexIJm6T3saPQuNcg8lFboj8cIyFqcua2w47o2LINEN6uobU3u77XihGht5NMfXNAI4zXrOUv3ztEUV2R3Qk5@4aU0saqk9pm7h6MTmTfjTK2CIC0lALGPZ6V2DSxVaj4I@QtomHbYTBpgoIAX2LtaT6Tm7YvFMhgo3z@bw9u@sUsQ83QGNXGb8f/kPa@weKwwOflgv6an4HkKeZdpIYLSRkLMk@X9zQXpG8/UNPbMW8rbPLHlsq3kzRQH13yVQzWOn38)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000837)

Comment: +1 for using `PRAIME`

Comment: You're a programmer, you could have written this and then run it through a Python script that `upper`'d it -.-

Comment: @StepHen Or simply `gggUG` in vim where I wrote it, but I am not that clever

Answer (score 10):

## 10. Magma, 65 bytes, [A000019](https://oeis.org/A000019)

```
f:=function(n);return NumberOfPrimitiveGroups(n+1);end function;
```

Try it [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

lol builtin

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000065)

Comment: @ETHproductions :) no problem, thank the OEIS page though cuz it has the exact builtin there lol

Comment: ;_; I solved A000064 and you changed it. Downvoted.

Comment: My gosh, so many partition sequences

Comment: I accidentally solved [A007317](http://oeis.org/A007317) while trying to do this in Python ([TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8ZIIb9IwVC7uDRXI00jTzdTUytNI1MzDSiYqZCZp1CUmJeeqmGok6epyYUhaGigaVVQlJlXogDS8///fxMA)) :P

Comment: Re-upvoted! \o/

Comment: @LeakyNun \o/ thanks! anyway, you'll be able to answer this way so yay! \o/

Answer (score 10):

## 281. Java 5, 11628 bytes, [A000947](https://oeis.org/A947)

```java
// package oeis_challenge;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {

//  static void assert(boolean cond) {
//      if (!cond)
//          throw new Error("Assertion failed!");
//  }

    /* Use the formula a(n) = A000063(n + 2) - A000936(n).
    It's unfair that I use the formula of "number of free polyenoid with n
    nodes and symmetry point group C_{2v}" (formula listed in A000063)
    without understanding why it's true...
    */

    static int catalan(int x) {
        int ans = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
            ans = ans * (2*x+1-i) / i;
        return ans / -~x;
    }

    static int A63(int n) {
        int ans = catalan(n/2 - 1);
        if (n%4 == 0) ans -= catalan(n/4 - 1);
        if (n%6 == 0) ans -= catalan(n/6 - 1);
        return ans;
    }

    static class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
        final int x, y;
        Point(int _x, int _y) {
            x = _x; y = _y;
        }

        /// @return true if this is a point, false otherwise (this is a vector)
        public boolean isPoint() {
            return (x + y) % 3 != 0;
        }

        /// Translate this point by a vector.
        public Point add(Point p) {
            assert(this.isPoint() && ! p.isPoint());
            return new Point(x + p.x, y + p.y);
        }

        /// Reflect this point along x-axis.
        public Point reflectX() {
            return new Point(x - y, -y);
        }

        /// Rotate this point 60 degrees counter-clockwise.
        public Point rot60() {
            return new Point(x - y, x);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Point)) return false;
            Point p = (Point) o;
            return x == p.x && y == p.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 21521 * (3491 + x) + y;
        }

        public String toString() {
            // return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
            return String.format("setxy %d %d", x * 50 - y * 25, y * 40);
        }

        public int compareTo(Point p) {
            int a = Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(p.x);
            if (a != 0) return a;
            return Integer.valueOf(y).compareTo(p.y);
        }

        /// Helper class.
        static interface Predicate {
            abstract boolean test(Point p);
        }

        static abstract class UnaryFunction {
            abstract Point apply(Point p);
        }

    }

    static class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
        final Point a, b; // guarantee a < b
        Edge(Point x, Point y) {
            assert x != y;
            if (x.compareTo(y) > 0) { // y < x
                a = y; b = x;
            } else {
                a = x; b = y;
            }
        }

        public int compareTo(Edge e) {
            int x = a.compareTo(e.a);
            if (x != 0) return x;
            return b.compareTo(e.b);
        }
    }

    /// A graph consists of multiple {@code Point}s.
    static class Graph {
        private HashMap<Point, Point> points;

        public Graph() {
            points = new HashMap<Point, Point>();
        }

        public Graph(Graph g) {
            points = new HashMap<Point, Point>(g.points);
        }

        public void add(Point p, Point root) {
            assert(p.isPoint());
            assert(root.isPoint());
            assert(p == root || points.containsKey(root));
            points.put(p, root);
        }

        public Graph map(Point.UnaryFunction fn) {
            Graph result = new Graph();
            for (Map.Entry<Point, Point> pq : points.entrySet()) {
                Point p = pq.getKey(), q = pq.getValue();
                assert(p.isPoint()) : p;
                assert(q.isPoint()) : q;
                p = fn.apply(p); assert(p.isPoint()) : p;
                q = fn.apply(q); assert(q.isPoint()) : q;
                result.points.put(p, q);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public Graph reflectX() {
            return this.map(new Point.UnaryFunction() {
                public Point apply(Point p) {
                    return p.reflectX();
                }
            });
        }

        public Graph rot60() {
            return this.map(new Point.UnaryFunction() {
                public Point apply(Point p) {
                    return p.rot60();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null) return false;
            if (o.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
            Graph g = (Graph) o;
            return points.equals(g.points);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return points.hashCode();
        }

        Graph[] expand(Point.Predicate fn) {
            List<Graph> result = new ArrayList<Graph>();

            for (Point p : points.keySet()) {
                int[] deltaX = new int[] { -1, 0, 1, 1,  0, -1};
                int[] deltaY = new int[] {  0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1};
                for (int i = 6; i --> 0;) {
                    Point p1 = new Point(p.x + deltaX[i], p.y + deltaY[i]);
                    if (points.containsKey(p1) || !fn.test(p1)
                        || !p1.isPoint()) continue;

                    Graph g = new Graph(this);
                    g.add(p1, p);
                    result.add(g);
                }
            }

            return result.toArray(new Graph[0]);
        }

        public static Graph[] expand(Graph[] graphs, Point.Predicate fn) {
            Set<Graph> result = new HashSet<Graph>();

            for (Graph g0 : graphs) {
                Graph[] g = g0.expand(fn);
                for (Graph g1 : g) {
                    if (result.contains(g1)) continue;
                    result.add(g1);
                }
            }

            return result.toArray(new Graph[0]);
        }

        private Edge[] edges() {
            List<Edge> result = new ArrayList<Edge>();
            for (Map.Entry<Point, Point> pq : points.entrySet()) {
                Point p = pq.getKey(), q = pq.getValue();
                if (p.equals(q)) continue;
                result.add(new Edge(p, q));
            }
            return result.toArray(new Edge[0]);
        }

        /**
         * Check if two graphs are isomorphic... under translation.
         * @return {@code true} if {@code this} is isomorphic
         * under translation, {@code false} otherwise.
         */
        public boolean isomorphic(Graph g) {
            if (points.size() != g.points.size()) return false;
            Edge[] a = this.edges();
            Edge[] b = g.edges();
            Arrays.sort(a);
            Arrays.sort(b);

            // for (Edge e : b)
                // System.err.println(e.a + " - " + e.b);
            // System.err.println("------- >><< ");

            assert (a.length > 0);
            assert (a.length == b.length);
            int a_bx = a[0].a.x - b[0].a.x, a_by = a[0].a.y - b[0].a.y;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
                if (a_bx != a[i].a.x - b[i].a.x || 
                    a_by != a[i].a.y - b[i].a.y) return false;
                if (a_bx != a[i].b.x - b[i].b.x || 
                    a_by != a[i].b.y - b[i].b.y) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // C_{2v}.
        public boolean correctSymmetry() {

            Graph[] graphs = new Graph[6];
            graphs[0] = this.reflectX();
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) graphs[i] = graphs[i-1].rot60();
            assert(graphs[5].rot60().isomorphic(graphs[0]));
            int count = 0;
            for (Graph g : graphs) {
                if (this.isomorphic(g)) ++count;
                // if (count >= 2) {
                    // return false;
                // }
            }
            // if (count > 1) System.err.format("too much: %d%n", count);
            assert(count > 0);
            return count == 1; // which is, basically, true
        }

        public void reflectSelfType2() {
            Graph g = this.map(new Point.UnaryFunction() {
                public Point apply(Point p) {
                    return new Point(p.y - p.x, p.y);
                }
            });

            Point p = new Point(1, 1);
            assert (p.equals(points.get(p)));

            points.putAll(g.points);

            assert (p.equals(points.get(p)));
            Point q = new Point(0, 1);
            assert (q.equals(points.get(q)));
            points.put(p, q);
        }

        public void reflectSelfX() {
            Graph g = this.reflectX();
            points.putAll(g.points); // duplicates doesn't matter
        }

    }

    static int A936(int n) {
        // if (true) return (new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 12, 10, 29, 27, 88, 76, 247, 217, 722, 638, 2134, 1901, 6413})[n];

        // some unreachable codes here for testing.
        int ans = 0;

        if (n % 2 == 0) { // reflection type 2. (through line 2x == y)
            Graph[] graphs = new Graph[1];
            graphs[0] = new Graph();

            Point p = new Point(1, 1);
            graphs[0].add(p, p);

            for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i --> 0;)
                graphs = Graph.expand(graphs, new Point.Predicate() {
                    public boolean test(Point p) {
                        return 2*p.x > p.y;
                    }
                });

            int count = 0;
            for (Graph g : graphs) {
                g.reflectSelfType2();
                if (g.correctSymmetry()) {
                    ++count;

                    // for (Edge e : g.edges())
                        // System.err.println(e.a + " - " + e.b);
                    // System.err.println("------*");

                    }
                // else System.err.println("Failed");
            }

            assert (count%2 == 0);

            // System.err.println("A936(" + n + ") count = " + count + " -> " + (count/2));

            ans += count / 2;

        }

        // Reflection type 1. (reflectX)

        Graph[] graphs = new Graph[1];
        graphs[0] = new Graph();

        Point p = new Point(1, 0);
        graphs[0].add(p, p);

        if (n % 2 == 0) graphs[0].add(new Point(2, 0), p);

        for (int i = (n-1) / 2; i --> 0;)
            graphs = Graph.expand(graphs, new Point.Predicate() {
                public boolean test(Point p) {
                    return p.y > 0;
                }
            });

        int count = 0;
        for (Graph g : graphs) {
            g.reflectSelfX();
            if (g.correctSymmetry()) {
                ++count;
                // for (Edge e : g.edges())

                    // System.err.printf(

                // "pu %s pd %s\n"
                // // "%s - %s%n"

                // , e.a, e.b);
                // System.err.println("-------/");

            }
            // else System.err.println("Failed");
        }

        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            assert(count % 2 == 0);
            count /= 2;
        }
        ans += count;

        // System.err.println("A936(" + n + ") = " + ans);

        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Probably
        if (! "1.5.0_22".equals(System.getProperty("java.version"))) {
            System.err.println("Warning: Java version is not 1.5.0_22");
        }

        // A936(6);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            System.out.println(i + " | " + (A63(i+9) - A936(i+7)));
        //A936(i+2);
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVp7b9s4Ev/fn2LiQ3alxJYtJ3XbTRO0KLqPu1u02O7e7aJXFLRN22plSZbkxLqs76v3ZkjqTSppryjOSGtZmhdnhr8ZknrPrtkwjHjwfvHh8cePo5Pe63DDIWKLhResIA0h5my@BtedTh7BLEt54vT@Uvn0Tka93miEHPMPbMUh5F7ybr5mvs@DFb/o9bxNFMYpvEdFzi71fOfkonbPZ8GK7vXmPksS@Jl5AdwKkZCkLPXmcB16C8BnPE6tWRj6nAUwD4OFjXRERh9vCdaRuFncok@6jsMbCPgNvIjjMLb6z4QYLwxgyTyfL4769oXgOPR6xDA6gd8SjnwclmG82fkMmBXYcAnPxviZnlkBnMLEhqG48fhsik8dwfpT@m0CuwDlxsjPUvgJdg1R4RL6wW4z4zFdLmOOng79jAc0whsvXUMgRAXhgifAggUk2WbD0zhDOi9IYRWHuwiev7udXB/6YOVyfS9J@QLQc8pKW4ghieEuRaMWPEZnBiKmN@sMPLI1jXfccaTxFEX6Vi4nXXOWMgyORdd78nXuVLrBggR94l4UN9EUEKSeuI9fTy5hfwGnp57dg8pHctL/J2BNTvan7tCzYQReKSvm6S4OBM0Ihv/ZyyeHloXPMBz0HeitywcQjCYYLtcuFVC2BMfncHkJY1tQD6vk51ryqYl82iAvzdcZLtP8lQgnzgOfb3iQJvA83EQsZjOfPxHPripDWnoB88XA9gPISkWCUHjgHT4Q31nVFfTZoyPeYRwy@q7wKqNEzmP@P1VGU07QeNO1lwD@MZl4A5wuPiZziNkc33h4ZZUU13yehnEZ5Wg383Gg@VT1Emln0zKl0drjhEKzj@EMjtDBRhN/jdGjPku5NE5OiFlWGOA0DZA@RiSz5FXUtEBhColzSiu/@QaOICpvVCJbMZswRRKQ/ZFDkREXmW0cwS986aOpVfuZH@KU3A/ZHm3QDyCWXL@bHFi1ZAjZAIZdJoRpw4PTMSz4CqEoQVDdBSmPh3M/nH@gKJssCtPp@N7m7PXWPH15zePYW3BT3vDtDnPOejl7Tz4Lm@oE4lshpj0h25wjoAq1tp1bIlK2HjyVCDgXZE7YEGqju6e5jkGlZMjkdfZpoyA9a5asnyOUm1w1cR9MXILBs/PHLiYPouwp6PUoqa/TWJZledESjBFWsiWBQxWCpVbfOl4M4Hhh9wcCQ/Q53eBJeLrPkAn/iA0NfTCmkOLF5MFAfJ@P7S5zRRkRwMZ/DU2zUEwDjMhPmHsrHjvXzN/xl0trbzslL8aiYTPFnwnEKALOtKNqys3qcjsmy4/cj7BUC8Qup0JZgHi8ZHMOr2K@8OY0rRrwMkvSmGHu5hmNzVNaeEGrVckuOGWx@C1gcfb9LpiLxsWgRKFdFPmZWYeuFL1YYNumr0T0qF2IlKYBzC4o4VY7pEZncIziE5gVxMSsLMGUkxeZHoIxuTCQWTvA@0qokPeKgn1LSjNUta@RC2lAUmAG1HrUnh6AU/261bLsJUtD/@HeiS08yHV5TdWXVcbAHaZJ4309jffaNJ7VxMxqsa0YSXn7DPtEFq2pSU6wM0yo2cQ@MfUwxnD7dI6QJONxUGldy4cfBG85lij2rim5f0Q0@5lFsj1RAb2SRQQbnaaHhJQWPklqdApVCa1AqxNQpFRp4eozhK8cSdSpRK43yrZhUJS9MDW0EOZ2QREQ7100ERUaIoQ//1SDwZgHKa6Ikr/xTMhosiqyaIfsA2nhnf6DDYvk2Jw6siyD5vAkfcwTzB7lWBXYuhmi@0d3Oy8CXKw0U2QL3@WGcnr@mpMPNJOxLM/R1lnxlEZtD2Bb3PgHYXhTuSEOpNRIuK0TbtuEZMUycCSgIpTeX8W2yrktOe/WKR3t1IO6tU24VEEHyXl36O9qJkUvTPlRtHH1HLF0Yav327UKpKGuaIuc0p62N@oDPdwjsTsb068@NGnMZ47rS7THIQFKsPP9rpZYENLcek7oj07AWlT@6uJUMEzNtLg0NdP51JcGd0Pw/9RPK0UlmVaFsPXNW@D7iAUK5J2yh2uD4N@xhj4RXFd1KHwWxyyrPCWFbVjMQa3AwA/cjIBIgKYtuJ@y35UWeesWhu4AxgNwxR9dDd3DRZeAPxoCSm7BbBBQ28iZ0kbOcIh914Up39XwXKVMAhwtnU7VMN54bwe0fspv/IE3NLMiz0VN4Ytcm0riEYKqaKHxt5adPkQXuVWkJUlesOON2LSzuKxuBBUGE1cOdQYRei8yUCgQJ7LV3bO/Z0ZzJw1FhlmFYW/GbztRUPVxjQzPf4qmMFFluTPjMT21CU9NVflMn@7Kn2PMd6lQlziFSSh4NXaUoWiIIR@VUJeEmhKRkkc5Lk8ea@XWEuCucLlfLV6qp6aVAwUKvxJLiztyCWaAHfHw/64XE7M4h/ttZwAqzheb9LRkFC3P/XuemteFP01OH52clGJO4Pmazz@Ivc6bUKUq4PIKvCTchHG09uaO48i9c0jV3iO2CU5VRr5tqhZVtHt6IJH5b8SRA4h90lxmlbsle5Azimp7KLdbq0pH5o3WXIlphVTB18T7N1fF3qnd6qr4Kl1pzSy6KZW3WiJaUa/0FCJeqC/Epph1PJs1AQbXtiK75YIbM3nWLgRI8zpLUr5xsJFwcKIFqR/QwhvrTx@G@O8U6utnM1d/KD9wdfXkCfSb5qjNC4s5dNiVrsX@xEU3CXZkM3Xd3AmgDvPdTGwZYA47zKEN1Jm6HNCzrHyWlc8yzfzPC/hYnMRArl6ex@j6DtpNI@VHpMErtatLLKta9BRGlTxZyZN1JZJW5axUObuvylmpctatUo/cNGMN@3/qmM0xTbd5GMfYer9WJ3QCvnvaIiexpdJgvJm@rRsnSTCc@cwyrYs0x2zUpImoKiEeCcmvh@5b/UJErUkV3YOCyqmgSGGVrUlVcVgAtQObZrnubAEo/OrkpVSI6HN6KiRf6CY28Ui9V5d0CKtvBMpNcEPmIcGho7zUFQE2nxVoyDfH0zCEzW6@/g6OF8dBfyD9oXdyLmms33ZXnhTxRN036Ik1gvkAZizBDs33s4HI07u2rFTOvOb@8tcs4hNLv5uzynPsq62Fq@sCmq7itKy@825eGxvOb0qZtKQxoG7RhagKh12LFdl2U2q53/LM96sL1E8U2rZ0W7N0bLZ0qxG6tbt3@7Z372JWUuL3u9LBBDkm71CuLnaRLxYRCSxCngTfpoCzI@Vx98GDOLyndydap/dq7lG6F2BuFYvY27FYuxbr2MkAzsWfi1cu3p48xn8PB/Do0QAeTvH6HH9MXPzv4QRJpmeP6OcZcTweo4DpuXt2sN8Eby9qyJ/QOzC7QLz6QgchMBcvZGAzJt7lEAc5dFKmeelgXJEk3huAY5ioNwduJTQJN9N@a4qzFCYO4WAc7lZr8L0Ab4jDx8y@by1xO2pJbcP2c2ZSIUwue@Wq11yRAhiBeNmism/QmuPFGIRl@eIvX52WiFSsUC0TvjQqcu18zcBSPX49oW2Kq/rZrhmMtID0JSrhymkjt75dWjmtpsM0zqKMmkpkvZEuOnXzzsrnNdb3arBPWq21OQQoSBzl6aR9L97p6tudnV8OucI/x2puthcaOvkCs2ic9BJY3y4iT7fktXDFlbghFYwmrXJDQHF6qRhwvlQe1xvQXxpQ4Tq0wyFR2m5vaN6BDXfjggETqm1LNx40Aa9OXQqdkNAGbw1HrGDo2sI3Bhz5MhjyGfhRbO9n1NB9UgNjwIp74UQNI1ol@hOwoau9NkLCfWf00urp5PajHRwnEC3w/38FfR0JUSHJECmwm9ZKGSC6sIEBYrrX76MWvrQ6/k/AlEM14esF3tz9F0R12xUIXBIKtG2rIkW9Q7kPOklcQhnVwRteTqxvIIveccO8wJKvBNGeT7xKaitcNOJVHM6wPcpq8/8I@q7zwBm/m0z6eVOrrMWmFlkidEpm9cXLv9c8ThDe@nYrV3UD/CeLA7TmO/gr8oLipe21IEyhUGp6n0d2nFMj5qitkslY89KqsibcpYU1nsD6PyXUizdRTx@L14JFX3v6sNa8j0bq9sTO3X74@PG/)

---

Side note:

1. Tested locally with Java 5. (such that the warning is not printed - see TIO debug tab)
2. Don't. Ever. Use. Java. 1. It's more verbose than Java in general.
3. <s>This may break the chain.</s>
4. The gap (7 days and 48 minutes) is no more than the gap created by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144823), which is 7 days and 1 hours 25 minutes later than [the previous one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144327).
5. <s>New record on large bytecount!</s> Because I (mistakenly?) use spaces instead of tabs, the bytecount is larger than necessary. On my machine it's [9550](https://oeis.org/A9550) bytes. (at the time of writing this revision)
6. [Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A011628).
7. The code, in its current form, only prints the first 20 terms of the sequence. However it's easy to change so that it will prints first 1000 items (by change the `20` in `for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)` to `1000`)

Yay! This can compute more terms than listed on the OEIS page! (for the first time, for a challenge I need to use Java) <sub>unless OEIS has more terms somewhere...</sub>

---

## Quick explanation

#### Explanation of the sequence description.

The sequence ask for the number of free nonplanar polyenoid with symmetry group C<sub>2v</sub>, where:

- polyenoid: (mathematical model of polyene hydrocarbons) trees (or in degenerate case, single vertex) with can be embedded in hexagonal lattice.

For example, consider the trees

```java
      O                O           O      O       (3)
      |                 \         /        \
      |                  \       /          \
O --- O --- O             O --- O            O --- O
      |                                             \
      |                    (2)                       \
 (1)  O                                               O
```

The first one cannot be embedded in the hexagonal lattice, while the second one can. That particular embedding is considered different from the third tree.

- nonplanar polyenoid: embedding of trees such that there exists two overlapping vertices.

`(2)` and `(3)` tree above are planar. This one, however, is nonplanar:

```java
   O---O O
  /       \
 /         \
O           O
 \         /
  \       /
   O --- O
```

(there are 7 vertices and 6 edges)

- free polyenoid: Variants of one polyenoid, which can be obtained by rotation and reflection, is counted as one.

[image]

- C<sub>2v</sub> group: The polyenoid are only counted if they have 2 perpendicular planes of reflection, and no more.

For example, the only polyenoid with 2 vertices

```java
O --- O
```

has 3 planes of reflection: The horizontal one `-`, the vertical one `|`, and the one parallel to the computer screen `■`. That's too much.

On the other hand, this one

```java
O --- O
       \
        \
         O
```

has 2 planes of reflection: `/` and `■`.

---

#### Explanation of the method

And now, the approach on how to actually count the number.

First, I take the formula `a(n) = A000063(n + 2) - A000936(n)` (listed on  the OEIS page) for granted. I didn't read the explanation in the paper.

[TODO fix this part]

Of course, counting planar is easier than counting nonplanar. That's what the paper does, too.

> Geometrically planar polyenoids (without overlapping vertices) are enumerated by computer
>   programming. Thus the numbers of geometrically nonplanar polyenoids become accessible.

So... the program counts the number of planar polyenoid, and subtract it from the total.

Because the tree is planar anyway, it obviously has the `■` plane of reflection. So the condition boils down to "count number of tree with an axis of reflection in its 2D representation".

The naive way would be generate all trees with `n` nodes, and check for correct symmetry. However, because we only want to find the number of trees with an axis of reflection, we can just generate all possible half-tree on one half, mirror them through the axis, and then check for correct symmetry. Moreover, because the polyenoids generated are (planar) trees, it must touch the axis of reflection exactly once.

The function `public static Graph[] expand(Graph[] graphs, Point.Predicate fn)` takes an array of graphs, each have `n` nodes, and output an array of graph, each has `n+1` nodes, not equal to each other (under translation) - such that the added node must satisfy the predicate `fn`.

Consider 2 possible axes of reflection: One that goes through an vertex and coincide with edges (`x = 0`), and one that is the perpendicular bisector of an edge (`2x = y`). We can take only one of them because the generated graphs are isomorphic, anyway.
[image]

So, for the first axis `x = 0`, we start from the base graph consists of a single node `(1, 0)` (in case `n` is odd) or two nodes with an edge between `(1, 0) - (2, 0)` (in case `n` is even), and then expand nodes such that `y > 0`. That's done by the "Reflection type 1" section of the program, and then for each generated graph, reflect (mirror) itself through the X axis `x = 0` (`g.reflectSelfX()`), and then check if it has the correct symmetry.

However, note that if `n` is divisible by 2, by this way we counted each graph twice, because we also generate its mirror image by the axis `2x = y + 3`.
[image]

(note the 2 orange ones)

Similar for the axis `2x = y`, if (and only if) `n` is even, we start from the point `(1, 1)`, generate graphs such that `2*x > y`, and reflect each of them over the `2x = y` axis (`g.reflectSelfType2()`), connect `(1, 0)` with `(1, 1)`, and check if they have correct symmetry. Remember to divide by 2, too.

Comment: Given that I was asleep when this (and the other one) were posted, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and not accept an answer yet.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing You were online 3 minutes before the deadline...

Comment: Uh oh, the next sequence can be hard-coded... (although it's infinite) if I read it correctly. The calculation itself is ---pretty--- very easy, so don't do it.

Answer (score 9):

## 24. [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes, [A000023](https://oeis.org/A000023)

Expansion of [e.g.f.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_.28EGF.29) exp(−2*x)/(1−x).

```julia
!x=foldl((a,b)->a*b+(-2)^b,1,1:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f9fscI2LT8nJUdDI1EnSVPXLlErSVtD10gzLknHUMfQqkLzf0FRZl6JhqKhgeZ/EwA)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000033)

Answer (score 9):

## 91. [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 1733 bytes, [A000066](https://oeis.org/A000066)

```python
import itertools

girth = int(input()) + 3

v = 4

r = range

def p(v):
	a = [0 for i in r(v)]
	k = int((v * 2) ** .5)
	a[k - 1] = a[k - 2] = a[k - 3] = 1
	j = len(a) - 1
	for i in r(1, 3):
		a[j] = 1
		j -= i
	yield [x for x in a]
	while not all(a):
		for index in r(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
			a[index] ^= 1
			if a[index]: break
		yield [x for x in a]

def wrap_(p, v):
	m = [[0 for j in r(v)] for i in r(v)]
	k = 0
	for i in r(0, v - 1):
		for j in r(i + 1, v):
			m[i][j] = m[j][i] = p[k]
			k += 1
	return m

def completes_cycle(edgelist):
	if not edgelist or not edgelist[1:]: return False
	start = edgelist[0]
	edge = edgelist[0]
	e = [x for x in edgelist]
	edgelist = edgelist[1:]
	while edgelist:
		_edges = [_edge for _edge in edgelist if _edge[0] in edge or _edge[1] in edge]
		if _edges:
			edgelist.remove(_edges[0])
			if _edges[0][1] in edge: _edges[0] = (_edges[0][1], _edges[0][0])
			edge = _edges[0]
		else:
			return False
	flat = sum(e, ())
	for i in flat:
		if flat.count(i) != 2: return False
	return edge[1] in start

def powerset(a):
	return sum([list(itertools.combinations(a, t)) for t in r(len(a))], [])

while True:
	ps = (v * (v - 1)) // 2
	skip = False
	for Q in p(ps):
		m = wrap_(Q, v)
		output = [row + [0] for row in m]
		output.append([0 for i in r(len(m[0]))])
		for i in r(len(m)):
			output[i][-1] = sum(m[i])
			output[-1][i] = sum(row[i] for row in m)
		if all(map(lambda x: x == 3, map(sum, m))):
			edges = []
			for i in r(v):
				for j in r(i, v):
					if m[i][j]: edges.append((i, j))
			for edgegroup in powerset(edges):
				if completes_cycle(list(edgegroup)):
					if len(edgegroup) == girth:
						print(v)
						exit(0)
					else:
						skip = True
						break
		if skip: break
	v += 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVVLbyIxDD5PfoX3lrQD5dG9IHHde6W9jdgqhUAD84gy4fXrWdvJDENbJERiO5/tzw/cNXw29Wzkru56u9nKNT6ADcaHpilbIXbWh09Ygq2DtLU7BqkUPMNciBNKX4Xw@ON1vTNCbMwWnDyphcg0SosJbBsPFt@CR/FKZIeEJE/wBDMFT08w/q3QvDjACKYrVMfj7H6c03Eqsj3@lKaWWpGpyAbY0xzm5BVx9skazUfoS2RXa8oNFBeO5UL2GgM5f9rSQN0E0GWJkPSYAeuNuUTQu68cRvxlK/TBRiv4Fx1ldgudbAEf3ugDSn90ywydvXbv0uXARFVEVGJq3zP1I3GTh5wnCEDB9aGn1xarM03gWVYVdhU5qfAHL3hyxWFFugM8cwbehKOvoYrhrZvKlSaY9n19XZdGms3OlLYNhIeZEmWdCNDr8F5MF8hAgvujy9aIrA0aG2p5t5mgb7p8kxERA7o6ZTJnf8sHV10VOxkl/E6XlqD4xHDxNIAEzIOF6LiTQ2dYTHsZsdSZtkxnhzD2pmpORkYVwqjUCL1gALO4SzEwOTTJBw8SSOKml6PMIJPs/pHabamJkvZYSZMDzuWgP0i3iOHTcbxujjTACn4tYfa1Ruk2yJ6rlga6ORvfmhCHJJmSz4KIkP2qQBfVh611sE3dSp1DwEVB8YThOClMucBERSzdX3@kzBxVjHeCjD2t4OUFZtg9B@tQ1SWMaG@E5qRrub9peuI8vVHLo6Q5BlxS1AC@OeMoEOn0jm74slr1NmPtnKk38nFNUZgV1UJxOb5qVByriECzNeKlRXzQqKmBEjVx3kiJ7ukyjETF8tD@qbSTpa4@NhouC2z/5RLmOZAU3@JBJbd9c/P8PuwI1j/sgX4HsJu0CBZc5bbLnaz2SnVopNv55uiY5K7w/CJB2e8Lgtugf6kGPomxu4Ky4n@TZJA5T38FXDX6mIsNcpJufcvjJzUB9UqSdEsWfZCy37on3mi32/Q/)

I hope using Python 2 PyPy counts as another major version. If someone could get me a Python 0 interpreter, I could use that too, but I hope this is valid.

This starts at 1 vertex and works up, creating the adjacency matrix representation of every possible undirected graph with that many vertices. If it is trivalent, then it will look through the powerset of the edges, which will be sorted by length. If the first cycle it finds is too short, then it will move on. If the first cycle it finds matches the input (offset by 3) then it will output the correct vertex count and terminate.

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A001733) <-- have an easy one as a break from all this math nonsense :D

**EDIT**: I added some optimizations to make it a bit faster (still can't compute the third term within TIO's 60 second limit though) without changing the bytecount.

Comment: ... and I was seriously thinking the chain would end with answer 90

Comment: @ppperry :) I like doing hard challenges because most people can't even make a solution so I don't have to worry about getting outgolfed :) (e.g. the carbon chain namer problem)

Comment: Unless someone takes your solution and converts it into a terser language

Comment: @ppperry that too o_O :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Congrats on solving that! I was worried I had broken the chain, and was considering padding the byte count to point to a different sequence. Good job!

Comment: @ScottMilner Glad you didn't :) I would have rolled it back since we really don't like people doing that :P

Comment: Come on, this deserves way more upvotes than it has.

Answer (score 9):

## 156. C# (Mono), 2466 bytes, [A000083](https://oeis.org/A000083)

Note: the score is 2439 bytes for the code and 27 for the compiler flag  `-reference:System.Numerics`.

```cs
using Num = System.Numerics.BigInteger;
namespace PPCG
{
    class A000083
    {
        static void Main(string[] a)
        {
            int N = int.Parse(a[0]) + 1;

            var phi = new int[N + 1];
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                phi[i] = 1;
            for (int p = 2; p <= N; p++)
            {
                if (phi[p] > 1) continue;
                for (int i = p; i <= N; i += p)
                    phi[i] *= p - 1;
                int pa = p * p;
                while (pa <= N)
                {
                    for (int i = pa; i <= N; i += pa)
                        phi[i] *= p;
                    pa *= p;
                }
            }

            var aik = new Num[N + 1, N + 1];
            var a035350 = new Num[N + 1];
            var a035349 = new Num[N + 1];
            aik[0, 0] = aik[1, 1] = a035350[0] = a035350[1] = a035349[0] = a035349[1] = 1;
            for (int n = 2; n <= N; n++)
            {
                // A000237 = EULER(A035350)
                Num nbn = 0;
                for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)
                    for (int d = 1; d <= k; d++)
                        if (k % d == 0) nbn += d * a035350[d] * aik[1, n - k];
                aik[1, n] = nbn / (n - 1);

                // Powers of A000237 are used a lot
                for (int k = 2; k <= N; k++)
                    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                        aik[k, n] += aik[k - 1, i] * aik[1, n - i];

                // A035350 = BIK(A000237)
                Num bn = 0;
                for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                {
                    bn += aik[k, n];
                    if (k % 2 == 1)
                        for (int i = n & 1; i <= n; i += 2)
                            bn += aik[1, i] * aik[k / 2, (n - i) / 2];
                    else if (n % 2 == 0)
                        bn += aik[k / 2, n / 2];
                }
                a035350[n] = bn / 2;

                // A035349 = DIK(A000237)
                Num dn = 0;
                for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                {
                    // DIK_k is Polyà enumeration with the cyclic group D_k
                    // The cycle index for D_k has two parts: C_k and what Bower calls CPAL_k
                    // C_k
                    Num cikk = 0;
                    for (int d = 1; d <= k; d++)
                        if (k % d == 0 && n % d == 0)
                            cikk += phi[d] * aik[k / d, n / d];
                    dn += cikk / k;

                    // CPAL_k
                    if (k % 2 == 1)
                        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 2)
                            dn += aik[1, n - i] * aik[k / 2, i / 2];
                    else
                    {
                        Num cpalk = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 2)
                            cpalk += aik[2, n - i] * aik[k / 2 - 1, i / 2];
                        if (n % 2 == 0)
                            cpalk += aik[k / 2, n / 2];
                        dn += cpalk / 2;
                    }
                }
                a035349[n] = dn / 2;
            }

            // A000083 = A000237 + A035350 - A000237 * A035349
            var a000083 = new Num[N + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
            {
                a000083[i] = aik[1, i] + a035349[i];
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) a000083[i] -= aik[1, j] * a035350[i - j];
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine(a000083[N - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##nVZtb9s2EP4s/4r7ssCO40RWWnStmwKJGxRFM8PYOuyDIRSsRNuMFEoQ5bpBkf@y/7L/Ne@OLxKtaVg3fzBF8njP3XMPT0rU5KGQxeGwU0JuYLF7gCv45VHV/OEcJ7wSiTq/EZv3suYbXs0Gkj1wVbKEw3I5fzf4NgiSnCkF1yH@frwcBLgSqJrVIoEvhUjhJybkUNUVul/FwEa4TSaBkDUsEAzH8yWrFB@yVRiPYAzT2YAMvrAKyq1AE8n3ZLZa0GY8o811UcGQXND@dIbD6ytY4DgeE0IQ4MmViPXmkX2JS9EMB2NfWnsdUiDWMKSDZQxvYDqCpJC1kDuuXRxjlh4mjHFuYB3uKa7AxILrXEtGp@AUT@q1/VbkHOGY9mJOmyg6QKyLxCyUjzWz6MybPQ30n@OSicxyiYU1XJ6BR6m2CS@fXz4Pu3Ydg2cv@w0QYRWeQUi00zP6n@pn43UV@pN259lLbwcn056ySVM2aYmQR2W7uNDyiy5foNXtr3e3Pw@vDYphilQtP5OLsFPJzKgng9cgcXDiaQ1SY5ASboZjY6G1ksEPZIF@RxoAq5NihV2KaUwTQ4RENWSGpsAtUZ507AKGtD0dGeFTPstizysFxbrJjFUcdoqnwCAv6r@nEek0NDs9eQidvBGS9K6JCSbTwYxN1TIK5QxEJ3gRt9FdNzK5ef9haCNsuf4Xqq@OuLaaN@w1wVg9O5IjInnqQj7KSsJJ0wCkvSKRs/Tc@illSHl0ZlgXI5o4QJ4rDoQqHWrofHkRmuPSO/hkCmsLryurCxt1SNNX520faen/IA29oq9PGQiFiskf//gduKSuje23kLAX9RbqLYfkMcmxH2@qYlfC209Zc/qj3cScZcq/AgHjPmyZgnpfYK@pavUK5rjEZAr7LavhhqQJCctzBfPl9Z3nbu6eKaFEZFmb0n@/UnByArK9YK6i2i21QWx@qV/Q1FQkdaVMdb20@QUCDdoovaC/Q2DhP4or9cVl7sixwERXWubJVs@wVLLcp@l7sc05Cx/1wdtr7IcQ9Cv72FmPuhsytZ1WddCq3tM@dm@t/VQ2VuYFZFs0fiHgrmtp46aRTJq1U3dP2jeOO9bzxukly/sM@GZD0y7M90DbC8bNG0fEnXt3b9zdkzuBI7oDz8ukcXMfe/1eYB73sZe1/ZCaF1IVOT//rRI1vxMSP3WsrwUVKR7REWTxafB0OByi8M9knbONOkwqvuYVlwl/1fkk@ws). This is a full program which takes input from the command line.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A002466)

#### Dissection

I follow Bowen's comment in OEIS that the generating function `A000083(x) = A000237(x) + A035349(x) - A000237(x) * A035350(x)` where the component generating functions are related by transforms as

- `A000237(x) = x EULER(A035350(x))`
- `A035350(x) = BIK(A000237(x))`
- `A035349(x) = DIK(A000237(x))`

I use the definitions of `BIK` and `DIK` from https://oeis.org/transforms2.html but the formulae seem to have a number of typos. I corrected `LPAL` without much difficulty, and independently derived a formula for `DIK` based on applying Pólya enumeration to the [cycle index of the dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Dihedral_group_Dn). Between #121 and #156 I'm learning a lot about Pólya enumeration. I have submitted some [errata](https://oeis.org/wiki/Talk:More_Transformations_of_Integer_Sequences), which may prove useful to other people if these transforms come up again in the chain.

Answer (score 8):

## 3. JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes, [A000044](//oeis.org/A000044)

```
f=n=>n<0?0:n<3?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2)-f(n-13)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdLCoAgEADQq8zSQQyrXWmdxUrDkJmw8Pr2WT3e4Yq71hzPWy1u8UkRb77WYMlOZPSsBzL93A5BkGpRfnSo/vVYA2cQxWWIYEGPLwa6TykRVqaLk28S7yKIiFgf)

[Next sequence](//oeis.org/A000038) (should be an easy one :P)

Comment: "(should be an easy one :P)" it *was*

Answer (score 8):

## 11. Pari/GP, 64 bytes, [A000065](https://oeis.org/A000065)

```
{a(n) = if( n<0, 0, polcoeff ( 1 / eta(x + x*O(x^n) ), n) - 1)};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/vzpRI09TwVYhM01DIc/GQEcBiAryc5LzU9OAIoYK@gqpJYkaFQraChVa/hoVcXmamjoKQB26Coaatdb//ydqGGsCAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000064)

Comment: Is that valid input?

Comment: Didya *have* to get 64 bytes? :P

Comment: @totallyhuman yes: `;_; I solved A000064 and you changed it. Downvoted.`

Comment: @totallyhuman compromises lol. see chat

Comment: [Dang](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoAwDATvviLHBCui4EXwMYKtBkoaaoX6@loF57bLMHqnI8hYymYdBBTDy0BzA5Wbrd/qQ99yIUIGFoir7BbZSN@P7e/@hr5GzXTZZJq/AmA21GqjkSWht4Kez4QBWfRKSJVuoFKmBw)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder 127 wouldn't be interesting...

Answer (score 8):

## 13. VB.NET (.NET 4.5), 1246 bytes, [A000131](https://oeis.org/A000131)

```
Public Class A000131
    Public Shared Function Catalan(n As Long) As Long
        Dim ans As Decimal = 1
        For k As Integer = 2 To n
            ans *= (n + k) / k
        Next
        Return ans
    End Function
    Shared Function Answer(n As Long) As Long

        n += 7

        Dim a As Long = Catalan(n - 2)

        Dim b As Long = Catalan(n / 2 - 1)
        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
            b = Catalan(n / 2 - 1)
        Else
            b = 0
        End If

        Dim c As Long = Catalan(n \ 2 - 1) ' integer division (floor)

        Dim d As Long
        If n Mod 3 = 0 Then
            d = Catalan(n / 3 - 1)
        Else
            d = 0
        End If

        Dim e As Long = Catalan(n / 4 - 1)
        If n Mod 4 = 0 Then
            e = Catalan(n / 4 - 1)
        Else
            e = 0
        End If

        Dim f As Long = Catalan(n / 6 - 1)
        If n Mod 6 = 0 Then
            f = Catalan(n / 6 - 1)
        Else
            f = 0
        End If

        Return (
                    a -
                    (n / 2) * b -
                    n * c -
                    (n / 3) * d +
                    n * e +
                    n * f
                ) /
                (2 * n)
    End Function
End Class
```

[A001246](https://oeis.org/A001246)

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNT8JAED3Lr5h40K6k0oLRxIQDAUlI1Bgh8eJl205hwzKbdFv13@NuKSWlH@yl3Xlvdt6bdudH6IxLN@BahC5h6u4Uqf3@IwukCGEqudYw8TzPH/k9MKsAlhueYATzjMJUKIIpT7nk5BBMNLwqWrPjS55l10zsgJO28RmGYscljMEv4blKYGvBBaW4xsSAQ1gpoJJhlz3gbgymTh@2DAawLeF3/EvLzSemWUKWnode6KQ1D5zrn5D@xaRJfnmkKTmGp17Vz5Fm1J5a4MKQVXlBI29gHLrgs5K6iE2VNxWZ@Bg8WG2w6j7oTn@RGmt87wSbJiziqrCwUdh3cTLcgii@RiR@hLadcmKpVHLmL6p97dLKqNlKdGZldMFKdNEKtvT4oaXHD83CsDu9JgwvCotbhD22CHtsFhZ3p9eExZ3CigviVFLKWwZuY/zw0zG4M39WM4MMFnZlj2x2BP3WbOzA4hpiRkAt5gwNlVj94ttNPtH2ps2ZRDg8/N7VMgvgjQtyWGUeieo88uw8GnqVglNFWkm8/0pEiq@C0BFwA9fPcG0exeC8L6aLYKw@rawoUz4Xd9Cz/wc)

Answer (score 8):

## 26. TI-BASIC, 274 [bytes](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens), [A000183](http://oeis.org/A000183)

```
.5(1+√(5→θ
"int(.5+θ^X/√(5→Y₁
"2+Y₁(X-1)+Y₁(X+1→Y₂
{0,0,0,1,2,20→L₁
Prompt A
Lbl A
If A≤dim(L₁
Then
Disp L₁(A
Else
1+dim(L₁
(~1)^Ans(4Ans+Y₂(Ans))+(Ans/(Ans-1))((Ans+1))-(2Ans/(Ans-2))((Ans-3)L₁(Ans-2)+(~1)^AnsY₂(Ans-2))+(Ans/(Ans-3))((Ans-5)L₁(Ans-3)+2(~1)^(Ans-1)Y₂(Ans-3))+(Ans/(Ans-4))(L₁(Ans-4)+(~1)^(Ans-1)Y₂(Ans-4→L₁(Ans
Goto A
End
```

Evaluates the recursive formula found on the OEIS link.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000274)

Comment: Agh I knew when the site went down that it would be a mad rush when it came back up. Barely beat me.

Comment: I didn't realize the site went down...

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/888553194313449472

Answer (score 8):

## 39. [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 1 byte, [A000004](https://oeis.org/A000004)

```
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9///38A)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000001)

Answer (score 8):

## 121. [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 525 bytes, [A000022](https://oeis.org/A000022)

```
n:(a+1)//2
t:[[0]RL(3*a+3)PE1]
Fh,n{
  m:([0]RL(3*a+3))
  Fi,(a+1){
    Fj,(a+1){
      Fk,(a+1)m@(i+j+k)+:(t@h@i)*(t@h@j)*(t@h@k)
      m@(i+2*j)+:3*(t@h@i)*(t@h@j)
    }
    m@(3*i)+:2*(t@h@i)
  }
  t:(tAE(m//6PE1))
}
k:t@n
o:0
Fh,aFi,aFj,aI(h+i+j<a)o+:(k@h)*(k@i)*(k@j)*k@(a-1-h-i-j)
Fh,((a+1)//2){
  Fi,aI(2*h+i<a){o+:6*(k@h)*(k@i)*(k@(a-1-2*h-i))}
  I(a%2=1)o+:3*(k@h)*(k@((a-1-2*h)//2))
}
Fh,((a+2)//3)o+:8*(k@h)*(k@(a-1-3*h))
I(a%4=1)o+:6*k@(a//4)
o//:24
Ia(o+:t@n@a)
Fh,nFj,(a+1)o-:(t@(h+1)@j-t@h@j)*(t@(h+1)@(a-j))
o
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##XZExa8MwEIV3/YoshZMcoVhyTREtqEMChg6la8igzbKwncFbyG93n2SbhEzi7r579@50Ddd5Hiz5ouRKaTbZ8/lw@fshI3xh@O@xvLBTux9ubLfrLT3XOFKnsM@tqYyoe44QxyXuHYWiKyIvLE2udYGL/HbrG/nakEEtOoBGvKAZubMVMyIA0hvEltIE/e8j9UrVcA6Hdxbt5AY22kNaw8Ovh0vfUFvA0qfnIzxF12JMzMNichUdeVnKVgaJwWik7UB5t6TSkBbQgMINErV4Ecn9IGTgPDlryL/przKNMw@WNixLJ7vrLI2ESfDHE5xYA5azpFYtanU2q1TF2aiU1RVrPCGPrZ3P3oftW0aZzo/NS@46@fiAJQP5DtLjPM/v/w)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000525)

Fun fact: when the challenge was first posted, I drew up a list of small nasty sequence numbers that I wanted to aim for with CJam, and A000022 was at the top of the list.

This implements the generating function described in E. M. Rains and N. J. A. Sloane, [**On Cayley's Enumeration of Alkanes (or 4-Valent Trees)**](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/cayley.html),
Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 2 (1999), taking the sum for `Ck` to as many terms as a necessary for the `n`th coefficient to be fixed and then telescoping three quarters of the sum. In particular, telescoping the first half means that the cycle index of `S4` only has to be applied to one of the `Th` rather than to all of them.

The code breaks down as

```
; Calculate the relevant T_h
t:[[0]RL(3*a+3)PE1]
Fh,n{
  m:([0]RL(3*a+3))
  Fi,(a+1){
    Fj,(a+1){
      Fk,(a+1)m@(i+j+k)+:(t@h@i)*(t@h@j)*(t@h@k)
      m@(i+2*j)+:3*(t@h@i)*(t@h@j)
    }
    m@(3*i)+:2*(t@h@i)
  }
  t:(tAE(m//6PE1))
}

; Calculate the cycle index of S_4 applied to the last one
k:t@n
o:0
Fh,aFi,aFj,aI(h+i+j<a)o+:(k@h)*(k@i)*(k@j)*k@(a-1-h-i-j)
Fh,((a+1)//2){
  Fi,aI(2*h+i<a){o+:6*(k@h)*(k@i)*(k@(a-1-2*h-i))}
  I(a%2=1)o+:3*(k@h)*(k@((a-1-2*h)//2))
}
Fh,((a+2)//3)o+:8*(k@h)*(k@(a-1-3*h))
I(a%4=1)o+:6*k@(a//4)
o//:24

; Handle the remaining convolution,
; pulling out the special case which involves T_{-2}
Ia(o+:t@n@a)
Fh,nFj,(a+1)o-:(t@(h+1)@j-t@h@j)*(t@(h+1)@(a-j))
```

Note that this is my first ever Pip program, so is probably not very idiomatic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64887/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-taylor-one-oeis-after-another).

Answer (score 8):

## 250. [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org), 711 bytes, [A000171](https://oeis.org/A000171)

```
from collections import Counter
from math import gcd, factorial

def sparts(n, m=4):
  if n%2==1:
    return [ [1] + p for p in sparts(n-1) ]
  elif n==0:
    return [ [] ]
  elif n<m:
    return []
  else:
    return [ [m] + p for p in sparts(n-m,m) ] + sparts(n,m+4)

def ccSize(l) =
  centSize = [ val**mult * factorial(mult)
               for val, mult in Counter(l).items() ] |> reduce$(*)
  factorial(sum(l)) // centSize

def edgeorbits(l) =
  samecyc = sum(l) // 2
  diffcyc = sum ([ gcd(l[i],l[j])
                   for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(i) ])
  samecyc + diffcyc

def a(n) =
  sum ([ ccSize(l)*2**edgeorbits(l)
         for l in sparts(n)         ]) // factorial(n)

def f(n) = a(n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHLboMwEEX3fMUsUskG2jyUVVWy6Sd0iVi4xk4d@YGMqdSq/07HQICkKguE587MPVxzx53tQt9L7wxwp7XgQTnbgjKN8wFeXWeD8MmgGxY@rsKZ1zlIxoPziukkqYWEtmE@tMTmYIojfU4AlAT7cCiKfTwAeBE6b6GEcl9BBg1I5/Gt7Dz6uKdQYa/QcbQodveD1Up@MbfqqLTifsb8Z2Zyg3YozuQmO9LxZzh/U9@CaAoFruPChniGAhd@Mp2mptMB0iUCEgt0cF490RPbMZHYjt5ToLj3SQVhWhIBfk5IW3dcbEgaVyxL285gK4XtdkYY8UR9Fs6/K6SeEFtmBP/iSDgOxZkD1msl5VwHUsarI7pUVa7LS/WH@EqtIq1n9owZCDtAxPJlKStEpyvj7Go1EjJiJ7DRdg40PaTpDX5yY6zXV0RnqRp@aEnGTvckB5volu1pP5IddzRmalizIRI/0xM0XtnQ/wI)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000711)

This can easily compute more values than the 31 that OEIS has.

Once again we have a symmetric group acting on nodes, inducing an
action on the set of possible edges and on graphs. It acts on the set
of self-complementary graphs, but I don't see how to count how many of
these are fixed by a given permutation to apply the lemma that is
often named after Burnside. So instead I use the formula in the
comment of the OEIS entry that says that the number of
self-complementary graphs with `n` nodes is equal to the difference of
the number of graphs with `n` nodes with an even number of edges and
with an odd number of edges. The symmetric group acts on these sets of
graphs as well. Instead of computing both numbers independently, we
will consider the cases of an even number and an odd number of edges
in parallel, which will turn out to be simpler and allow
optimizations.
We'll see that "evaluate the graph polynomial at `-1`" will lead to the
same result.

As usual, we take the sum over the group elements in Burnside's lemma
conjugacy class wise, and represent the conjugacy classes by
partitions of `n`. For each conjugacy class, we want to know the
difference between the numbers of graphs with an even and odd number
of edges that is fixed by a permutation from that class.

Assume we are given a concrete permutation `g`. The group generated by
`g` acts on the set of possible edges and partitions them into orbits.
A graph is fixed by `g` if for each orbit, it contains either all or
none of its edges. Let's look at the orbits. Each edge in one orbit
has its endpoints in the same two (possibly same) cycles of `g`.

Let's first assume the endpoints are from the same cycle of length
`k>=2`. If `k` is odd, then there are `(k-1)/2` orbits of length `k`.
If `k` is even, then there are `k/2-1` orbits of length `k` and one of
length `k/2` (for example, if `g` contains the cycle `(123456)`, then
the there is an edge orbit of size 3 containing `{1,4}`). Note that we
get all orbits of even size exactly when `k` is a multiple of four.

Next consider the case that the endpoints are from different cycles
of lengths `k` and `l`. Then the orbit has size `lcm(k,l)`, and there
are `gcd(k,l)` such orbits.

In order to combine all the possibilities, consider the product, for
each edge orbit, of `1+x^r`, where `r` is the size of the
corresponding orbit. The coefficient of `x^s` of the product gives the
number of graphs that are fixed by `g` and have `s` edges. We want the
sum of the coefficients at even exponents minus the sum of them at odd
coefficients, which we get by evaluating the polynomial at `x=-1`.

If we kept the polynomials and added them together, we'd get the graph
polynomial. Instead, we don't even create these polynomials, but do
the substitution immediately. For an edge orbit of even size, we get a
factor of `2`, for an odd size we get `0`. (There is also a direct
combinatorial argument that if there is an edge orbit of odd size then
there are as many fixed graphs with an even number of edges as there
are with an odd number of edges. And the factor `2` corresponds to the
choice of including the edges of one orbit to the fixed graph or
not).

So, by the considerations about edges with points from only one cycle,
we get a difference of `0` whenever `g` contains a cycle of odd length
greater than one, or a cycle of even length not divisible by four. We
also get a difference of `0` whenever `g` contains at least two fixed
points (cycles of length one).

This means we only need to sum over conjugacy classes with at most one
fixed point and all other cycle lengths multiples of four. `sparts`
computes the corresponding partitions of `n`. There are none unless
`n` is of the form `4k` or `4k+1`, so in the other cases there are no
self-complementary graphs, which can also easily seen by noting that
in these cases the total number of possible edges is odd. But this
observations alone doesn't lead to the optimization of only
considering special partitions, of which there are only as much as
there are partitions of `k`.

`ccSize` computes the size of a conjugacy class with given cycle
lengths. `edgeorbits` computes the number of edge orbits of the action
of the group generated by a permutation with the given cycle lengths,
assuming they are of the special form. In the general case, `samecyc`,
the number of edge orbits with edges that have both nodes from the
same cycle, could not be calculated like this. (When I wrote the code,
I didn't notice that it only depends on `n` in the relevant cases.)

`a` puts everything together, and `f` fixes the different indexing.

Comment: This looks like Python with a touch of JavaScript added :P

Comment: @ChristianSievers I'm stupid. Anyway, don't forget that some PPCGers have OEIS accounts and could add more values to A000171 :)

Comment: @Stephen I consider doing that

Comment: Can you explain what algorithm are you using and/or what does the abbreviated function names (`sparts`, `ccSize`) means?

Comment: @user202729 I finally added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks! / Can you explain what's the difference between "cycle" and "orbit"? "cycle" applies to vertices while "orbit" applies to edges? Also, what is "the graph polynomial"?

Comment: @user202729 Here "cycle" refers to the basic elements of cycle notation for permutations, e.g. the permutation `g=(12)(3456)` has cycles `(12)` and `(3456)`. The orbits depend on an action of a group on a set, two elements belong to the same orbit if there is a group element which transforms one to the other. E.g. the action of the group generated by `g` on edges has as orbits `{{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{4,6}}` and `{{1,4},{2,5},{1,6},{2,3}}` and three more. I mostly discuss egde orbits; node orbits indeed correspond to cycles. "graph polynomial" as in @KSmart's comment to you under the last answer.

Answer (score 8):

## 318. [Funciton](https://github.com/Timwi/Funciton), 1688 bytes, [A000652](https://oeis.org/A000652)

```
╔═══╗  ┌─────────╖  ┌─┐ ┌───╖  ╔═══╗
║   ╟──┤ str→int ╟──┤ └─┤ ↑ ╟──╢ 2 ║
╚═══╝  ╘═════════╝  │   ╘═╤═╝  ╚═══╝
  ┌─────────────────┘     │
┌─┴┐                      │
│┌─┴─╖                ┌───┴───┐
││ ♭ ║              ┌─┴─╖   ┌─┴─╖  
│╘═╤═╝┌───╖    ╔═══╗│ ♭ ║   │ ! ║  
│  └──┤ ↑ ╟────╢ 2 ║╘═╤═╝   ╘═╤═╝
│     ╘═╤═╝    ╚═╤═╝  │       │
│    ┌──┴─┐      │    └───┐   │
│  ┌─┴─╖  │┌───╖ │  ┌───╖ │   │
│  │ ! ║  └┤ ↑ ╟─┴──┤ ↑ ╟─┘   │
│  ╘═╤═╝   ╘═╤═╝    ╘═╤═╝     │
│    │ ┌───╖ │   ┌───╖│       │
│    └─┤ × ╟─┘ ┌─┤ × ╟┘       │
│      ╘═╤═╝   │ ╘═╤═╝ ┌───╖  │
│  ╔═══╗ └─────┘   └───┤ + ╟──┘
│  ║ 2 ╟┐              ╘═╤═╝
│  ╚═╤═╝│        ┌───╖   │
│    │  └──┐   ┌─┤ ÷ ╟───┘
│    └──┐┌─┴─╖ │ ╘═╤═╝┌─────────╖
│ ┌───╖ ││ ↑ ╟─┘   └──┤ int→str ╟─
└─┤ × ╟─┘╘═╤═╝        ╘═════════╝
  ╘═╤═╝    │
    └──────┘
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A001688)

Calculates the formula from the OEIS page. I'm sure there's a more compact way to do this, without multiple `2` constants, but this took me long enough.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZS9TsQwDMf3PIWZ2RBvhIR0S5Gg7KcONzGkKOUCEjrp1JWtEg/Am@RFSj4uxI4dlSpSU9d23d/f8f1zd7frH7p1dZNxk87rCODMizP75preioumzvEVTafcNEKwnrLbDE/9ozu87rqemp0xeXcY0avpDDf@cfSpPlDqz5DVIgNfwcUMUBznEklSqc2/bi4L4fKfUTnDEriIV/IakGNiVnvhSha01yl6APf@BQmsEFfSMkuMpyyYgExC@sHwdJX2KsLNsgnKUf2YCLUsKZ8kVxFspsIiqhW65dKg2SXdDKaJYxkqpFNGQxyJEef5wxO/RpEsMilLMmxhahCiHIZmocTaoJgP4s8R1ZhDi9nyWLH@UE1l5XOj/D@dR1S0PQKG7TNc48azOdcYe@/EjqTYelWTFTi83Jo2LkejAA/ruzoRVvF21HX/Ccw257JqyB7NrN3QqfWj2A9kP5YvLkruAKnp4B9TWMkt7AHyQ1korevtLw)

Answer (score 7):

## 6. [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 71 bytes, [A000072](https://oeis.org/A000072)

```r
function(n)length(unique((t<-outer(r<-(0:2^n)^2,r*4,"+"))[t<=2^n&t>0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoQgEADQX1k6LDOlYNEprB@JgghthZhsGg/79eb18Tj7j9XZJ9olXASEp6NDfpAo3MkBiNVXEsfAVoMZupVw7RTXvaqaCnEWOxb7ymQWxBw5kMCzxXj@y26N8kVf)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000071)

Comment: For the love of God, I didn't check the next sequence before I posted this answer.

Comment: Isn't an easy next sequence a strategic advantage?

Comment: @BlackCap They can't answer twice in a row or less than 1 hour after they last answered.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `the answer before the last posted (the one who didn't break the chain) will win`

Comment: @BlackCap at this point that isn't going to happen

Comment: @StepHen You never know, you could get digits of Chaitin's constant or something of that nature

Answer (score 7):

## 14. [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes, [A001246](https://oeis.org/A001246)

```python
f=lambda x:x<1or x*f(x-1)
c=lambda n:(f(2*n)/f(n)/f(n+1))**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NckxDoAgDADA3VcwtlVjIHEh@hhEqyZSCHHA1@NgXG659NxHFFMrz5cLy@pUsWXSMatCDKXX2Ph/xAKDIcGB4aPViESmpnzKrYJL4DuVnewb6BGxvg)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000060)

Comment: Wow you ninja'd by 2 seconds

Answer (score 7):

## 34. [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 168 bytes, [A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073)

```
tribonacci(0,0).
tribonacci(1,0).
tribonacci(2,1).
tribonacci(A,B):-
	C is A-1,
	D is A-2,
	E is A-3,
	tribonacci(C,F),
	tribonacci(D,G),
	tribonacci(E,H),
	B is F+G+H.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/v6QoMyk/LzE5OVPDQMdAU48LScAQXcBIxxBVwFHHSdNKl4vTWSGzWMFR11CHi9MFwjQCMl0hTGMgE0mPs46bJqqIi447moirjgdIxAlkgJu2u7aHHopLjQx0IjT1AA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000168)

Answer (score 7):

## 49. [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), 74 bytes, [A000003](https://oeis.org/A000003)

```
lambda n: len(BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-4*n, primitive_only=True))
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVyDsKgDAMANBd8A4ZW6mg4iS4OLgL7hJtlEIbS_yAt1enB2-FFjyG2SJwA55YdY5RnqGfhOy1kP2MQgfxiae76VB5nbGBKC64P6ad_dOOcpHWaZImAaNaDQjyRqo0VaH1CwoqIbA=&lang=sage)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000074)

Comment: And I just spent an hour trying to work this sequence out using JavaScript... oh well, I'll just have to move on to the next one...

Answer (score 7):

## 76. [Pygmy](http://peterolson.github.io/Pygmy/Docs/), 4147 bytes, [A000036](https://oeis.org/A000036)

```
globaln: 0                                                                                           

Pi:: 3.141592653589793                                                                               

floor:: (number) {                                                                                   
    floatPart: number % 1                                                                            
    number >= 0 =>                                                                                   
    number - floatPart                                                                               
    number - floatPart - 1                                                                           
}                                                                                                    

fsqrt:: (number) {                                                                                   
    floor| number ^ 0.5                                                                              
}                                                                                                    

summation:: (f i imax) {                                                                             
    i > imax => 0                                                                                    
    (f| i) + summation| f, i + 1, imax                                                               
}                                                                                                    

absoluteValue:: (number) {                                                                           
    number < 0 => -number                                                                            
    number                                                                                           
}                                                                                                    

A:: (number) {                                                                                       
    globaln~: number                                                                                 
    1 + 4 * (fsqrt| number)                                                                          
       + 4 * (fsqrt| number / 2) ^ 2                                                                 
       + 8 * summation| (j){ fsqrt| globaln - j * j }, (fsqrt| number / 2) + 1, (fsqrt| number)      
}                                                                                                    

V:: (number) {                                                                  
    Pi * number                                                                      
}                                                                                    

P:: (number) {                                             
    (A| number) - (V| number)                               
}                                                           

recordMax: 0                                           
findRecord:: (searchIndex record recordCount) {                                    
    x: absoluteValue| P| searchIndex                                               
    (x > record && recordCount = recordMax - 1) => searchIndex                     
    x > record => findRecord| searchIndex + 1, x, recordCount + 1                  
    findRecord| searchIndex + 1, record, recordCount                               
}                                                                                  

A000099:: (number) {                                                                 
    recordMax~: number                                                              
    findRecord| 1, 0, 0                                                              
}                                                                               

A000035:: (number) {                                                                       
    floor| (P| (A000099| number)) + 0.5                                         
}
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A004147)

You can run the code [on this page](http://peterolson.github.io/Pygmy/Tester.html). For example, you can get the 10th number in the sequence by copying the code above and adding:

```
alert| A000035| 10
```

Comment: ... the next sequence is uncomputable...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I know :P I did this on purpose

Comment: Evil... >.< But anyway, I'll just hardcode the 4 elements in the sequence. Easy enough xD OP approves of it apparently ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7):

## 184. CJam, 142 bytes, [A000061](https://oeis.org/A000061)

```
{_,@f*\f%1\{)1$f-@+:*\}h;g}:J;
{)_mF{~2/#}%:*:M_*/:B_4%1={_2/,f{)_2$J@@4*-*}}{_,{1&},f{1$1$J@@-*}}?1b0.5e|M3#*Mmf{2>},_&{_2#_@B\J-@*\/}/0.5+i}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B1%201%202%204%204%206%208%208%2012%2014%2014%2016%2020%2020%2024%2032%2024%2030%2038%2032%2040%2046%2040%2048%2060%2050%2054%2064%2060%2068%2080%2064%2072%2092%2076%2096%20100%2082%20104%20112%2096%20108%20126%20112%20120%20148%20112%20128%20168%20130%20156%20160%20140%20162%20184%20160%20168%20198%20170%20192%20220%20168%20192%5D%0A_%2C%2C%0A%0A%7B_%2C%40f*%5Cf%251%5C%7B)1%24f-%40%2B%3A*%5C%7Dh%3Bg%7D%3AJ%3B%0A%7B)_mF%7B~2%2F%23%7D%25%3A*%3AM_*%2F%3AB_4%251%3D%7B_2%2F%2Cf%7B)_2%24J%40%404*-*%7D%7D%7B_%2C%7B1%26%7D%2Cf%7B1%241%24J%40%40-*%7D%7D%3F1b0.5e%7CM3%23*Mmf%7B2%3E%7D%2C_%26%7B_2%23_%40B%5CJ-%40*%5C%2F%7D%2F0.5%2Bi%7D%0A%0A%25_p%3D). This is an anonymous block (function) with an auxiliary named block (function) to calculate the Jacobi symbol.

Note: the formulae given in OEIS as it currently stands (revision 39) are badly transcribed from the Shanks paper. They miss an exponent and one special case and give a different special case incorrectly. I shall propose amendments.

Also note that for the Jacobi symbol I'm using the Zolotarev-style approach I mentioned in [an earlier answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67125/194) of calculating the Levi-Civita symbol of a linear map. The implementation of J above is not the same as the one I previously proposed: it's the same length, but I think it's less wasteful.

The [next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000142) is a nice easy one, so maybe someone can bring the lowest uncovered sequence, A000017, into play. That should make the hard-coders happy.

Comment: minor nit: you can always make the next sequence the lowest uncovered one by adding 300,000 bytes of padding.

Answer (score 7):

## 191. Haskell, 1824 bytes, [A000725](https://oeis.org/A000725)

```
import Data.List (sort, group, permutations)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

type V = [Bool]

parts :: Int -> [[Int]]
parts n = partsm n n
  where partsm 0 _ = [[]]
        partsm n m = [ v:p | v <- [1 .. min n m], p <- partsm (n-v) v ]

fact :: Int -> Integer
fact n = product [1 .. fromIntegral n]

centralizerSize :: [Int] -> Integer
centralizerSize cyclens =
  product [ l^m * fact m | ll <- group (sort cyclens),
                           let l = fromIntegral $ head ll,
                           let m = length ll             ]

ccSize :: [Int] -> Integer
ccSize cyclens = fact (sum cyclens) `div` centralizerSize cyclens

repr :: [Int] -> [Int]
repr cyclens = reprh cyclens 0
  where reprh []     _ = []
        reprh (l:ls) m = [m+1 .. m+l-1] ++ [m] ++ reprh ls (m+l)

act_it :: [Int] -> V -> V
act_it p v = [ v!!i | i <- p ]

act_ot :: V -> [Int] -> V -> V
act_ot neg p = zipWith (/=) neg . act_it p

orbit :: ( V -> V ) -> V -> [V]
orbit act x = x : takeWhile (x /=) (iterate act (act x))

orbitLengths :: S.Set V -> ( V -> V ) -> [Int]
orbitLengths o act = sort $ orblens o act
  where orblens o act
          | S.null o  = []
          | otherwise = let orb = orbit act (S.findMin o)
                        in length orb :
                           orblens (S.difference o (S.fromList orb)) act

oeis725 :: Int -> Integer
oeis725 n =
  let v = replicateM n [False,True]
      o = S.fromList v
      m = M.fromListWith (+)
          [ (pcls, centralizerSize pcls * ccSize cls) |
            cls <- parts n,
            let pcls = orbitLengths o (act_it $ repr cls) ]
  in sum [ M.findWithDefault 0 (orbitLengths o (act_ot neg p)) m |
           p <- permutations [0..n-1], neg <- v ]
     `div` ( (fact n)^2 * 2^n )

f n = oeis725 (n+1)
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001824)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVVLb9swDL77V7BAD/KSeG2xYUCw7LAVAwY0pwzpwXBbzZETobLkyXL6QP97RlG2E3fN5oMj86WP5Edmw@t7odRuJ8vKWAeX3PHkStYOWI3fY1hb01RjqIQtG8edNLqOo9b4m9HOGpXMjeYrYFZUSubciXlv8bvhShZSrELghXDAa1gcUc95lSyclTlZzaPIPVUCljCD9KsxKouiiltXw3QKP7SDyRdIUzxkWSvXaEmnEo86AnjYCCs60Rnc@kgpmkP79Mal18B2WsELbOHzBNJzSBIopfbKDPP3wtac6ck2RjPEU3DEuoeDP2ItbBATGmtWDZ5DuMKakkwsV6DRPRdYQCzBs7ALfPlIlNBhrNc2@VOuhK5hhln04UHdlPAO6N4Sc1DK46XehUZ2bvG4T/6NR2F/FMIeAD2FjcD2KvVfV19FvGTtNh7A4eNzzY@nmA8zC3mwuil72HC3kts7OFKMKELu2UFsOgTxPq7/3PTfZz1DgjzNCCuxZM@RoGNqqhAF8aQcBXKM1OQ8g9EIJfQTLFUNDFVxFGESt9INUC3p1WkqJBHx7uREYtMkcczXyusNeS77XF65o1qLNZrP4FlW1xJrzt7PYhIm0F0QRcb@ChhY6w1xHyldZq3e1/sRQz3CFBy/F9cbqQSwR/AhmXTC4liTFSPTOG4jX1G7aSQXNN4UeHhXaMXA3FCsGRA1TwF11BES9115Le2eF7xKN8gwA8NWeZVx6Psga0FcdD4InvZZskVSSL2a42Sb@CihUdsS2ftP/0X8DiUGXsmiQOA6R@x0EY4R7VK0iWPKIjJC1p8uPr6xNDqNptH22LeBsu1SRUX6natajH/aRnRZG7Q5uGnbij1R57040GN0mG8KrMpVPf5rpLwUV0k3k571L4P8vb5bhqCHS8GjpgBtyff9Zi0lTyHMpI/rc8BK@zlPPVrsi0d6KQreKIcLm70VpGN@7MdxAC0s6YN/KkjPkkTjlI7JBbVbaAsX9gkDFnZ1fHOBSV/caEBmF7S7u34wPTqPo13JZdjoUvssCviw@wM)

#### The math behind it

Let `V` be the set of the `2^n` boolean vectors of length `n`
(which is also a group under component-wise xor),
and `P` be the group with the `(2^n)!` permutations of `V`.
Let `S` be the symmetric group on `n` points of size `n!`.
`S` acts on `V` by permuting the components, thus embedding `S` in `P`.
Let `IT` (for input transformations) be this subgroup of `P`.
For the output transformations `OT < P`, we combine the action of `S`
and the xor-ing action of `V` on itself. (Abstractly, it is a semidirect
product of `V` and `S`. It's order is `n!*2^n`)

Now let the direct product `OT*IT` act on `P` by
`p(ot,it)=ot^-1*p*it` (`ot` is inverted for formal reasons
that are not important here). We want to know how many orbits this action
has. To use Burnside's lemma, we need to know how many elements of `P`
are fixed under the action of a particular `(ot,it)`, that is, how many
satisfy `ot^-1*p*it=p`, which is equivalent to `p*it*p^-1=ot`.
So there are only solutions if `it` and `ot` are conjugate in `P`, which
means they need to have the same cycle lengths. Then, the number of
solutions is the size of the centralizer of `it` (or `ot`) in `P`,
which can be computed from the cycle lengths.

Instead of running over all elements of `OT*IT` and summing the
corresponding number of fixed elements, we can run only over `OT`
and sum the product of the number of conjugate elements in `IT` and
the centralizer size. These products can be precomputed for each
conjugacy class of `IT` represented by the cycle lengths.

In GAP I would only run over the conjugacy classes of `OT`, but here
I'm too lazy. This program is already good enough to compute more
values than OEIS has.

Answer (score 7):

## 229. [FMSLogo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), 1147 bytes, [A000361](http://oeis.org/A000361)

Number of byte: 1132 (code) + 15 (flags) = 1147. Avoid confusing the code snippet.

Need parameter `-h 8200 -w 8200` to enlarge the canvas size.

```
to size ; Constant. Must be power of 2
    op 4096
end

to draw :halfedge :maincol :altcol
    if :halfedge < 4 [stop] ; all fractals need base case
    draw :halfedge / 2 :maincol :altcol
    fd :halfedge rt 60
    fd :halfedge rt 60
    draw :halfedge / 2 :altcol :maincol
    rt 60
    drawtria :halfedge :maincol
    rt 60
    draw :halfedge / 2 :altcol :maincol
    fd :halfedge rt 120 bk :halfedge
end

to drawtria :edge :col
    if :edge <> 4 [stop]
    setpc :col
    pd
    repeat 3 [fd :edge rt 120]
    pu
    rt 30 fd :edge/2
    setfc :col
    fill
    bk :edge/2 lt 30
end

to main :index
    make "index :index + 1 ; Must be 0-based
    pu home ht
    bk size rt 90 bk size lt 60
    if not namep "drawn [
        draw size "purple "gray
        make "drawn "
    ]
    fd 8 * :index
    rt 150
    fd 4 * (sqrt 3) / 2 * (4 / 3) ; Go to the centroid of the next triangle
    localmake "result 0
    while [ycor > -size - 10] [
        if pixel = [128 0 128] [make "result :result * 2 + 1] ; purple
        if pixel = [128 128 128] [make "result :result * 2] ; gray
        fd 8 * (sqrt 3) / 2
    ]
    op :result
end
```

Testing:

```
print main 10
```

Unfortunately, no implementation of the [Logo programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)) I can find include the function `pixel` (used to retrieve pixels on the screen), and FMSLogo appear to be limited to Windows. However [JSLogo](http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/) can draw the fractal.

However, this code is likely to take forever to run on FMSLogo. For testing purposes:

- Change the `4096` in `size` procedure to `128`.
- Don't pass that parameter, it is unnecessary in case of `size = 128`.
- For JSLogo, type `to setfc :col end`
- Remove the line `if :edge <> 4 [stop]` so that all triangles are drawn, and not just size-4 ones.

Explanation:

1. What is that sequence: See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw4Ar.png) for details. Basically the sequence is binary representation of the columns of congruent triangles. Also the pattern is defined like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkZAV.png) (drawn lines indicates symmetry axes of the triangles).
2. Why is Logo useful here: Because Logo has *built-in* turtle graphics. So draw the fractal at smaller size and rotated is not problem for Logo. After drawing, you just need to read the pixels.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A001147)

Answer (score 7):

## 232. [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), <s>326</s> <s>330</s> 332 bytes, [A000938](https://oeis.org/A000938)

```
function gcd (a, b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    };
    return a;
}

function A000938 (n) {
    n = n + 2;
    ans = 0;
    for (m = 2; m <= n; ++m) {
        for (k = 2; k <= n; ++k) {
            ans = ans + (((n - k) + 1) * ((n - m) + 1) * gcd(k - 1, m - 1));
        }
    }
    ans = (2 * ans) - (
        (n*n) *
        ((n*n)-1) / 6
    );
    return ans;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBtS8MwGPzc/IpTEJJl1a6CKN0Ef0pb2y10fSp9QUT22@slHZ2Ql7vnnlxyqSdpfua5nqQcXSc4lp/Q@RaFwa@Kvk/uXEEXuDsgCZWoxAE5HlBkJDlJAAVBSXDh7Ktx6gV5pi5KrcYfSZK8Pb9CS/ARHhBYpDyQy0CWENVdD92SpBla7NmSwdp2uTmIzSI2q9gs4tXErxZaa0EMShY7gw0W3q6cKekUY7flNdyM8SEuyo/FSKdsIzSUNTUtGz5841GAMX2e8KIi8y@xDD7z7GrospOhO1eP5@5o8NU7Gf0P3YqZCnFcCA6HPdLEx3HXbs2axT3idy729nvUjZr/AA)

Polyglot with Javascript. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDbTsMwFHtevsIgISXNCl2REKgbEp@Sdt0Ia0@ntoMHtG8vTjptSLnYxydOnC/37Yaq98cxlW5bT9PuJNXoO8G@2kK7JUqDX7X4@fRNDV3iboMsVhYVNnB4QFmQOJIISoKK4MzZ1@OpF7hCnZW6Gn9kWfb2/Aot0Ud4QGCR84CTgSwj2nU9dEuSF2ixZksBa9v55igeZvFwFQ@zeDEJq4XWWpCCksXKIMHM2ytnSjqlWC15DTdjQoizCmM20jnbCA1lTU1LwocnAUWY0ucJL2ph/iWWIWSe/A666mTomvqx6fYGx97LGH7oVixUjONjcHiskWchjr90a9Ys7pG@c7G336Nu1PQH)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000332).

---

Use the formula on the OEIS page for `O(n^2 log n)` complexity, instead of the naive `O(n^6)`.

Quick explanation:

- This code use the formula `a[n_] := 2*Sum[(n - k + 1)*(n - m + 1)*GCD[k - 1, m - 1], {m, 2, n}, {k, 2, n}] - n^2*((n^2 - 1)/6)` described in the Mathematica code section.
- Formula proof:

  - The formula is equivalent to [this](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwEEWfzVdchEJmVaoulF3SLPRToq3dkDourlIW8dttEmn7ktyZMzN3ppvZPbatm7md7MD4bN@lyRtavq/260N60Wrz1CijG9XoVq3KrEL8lb@VZXk@niCZsIiEkWnUSiSG79AoveqGEbJHSKPHK1ghy/pYvTO3M/fL3M7iCD9NMgr43GFXfVRhS5eHoEBF3iVZRbL6vw40doJjy0FyUVF4ayI84wUkwgHB2cYVYb1zVQdrS7iNlicJmyNFcUGa/5/oKW3bDw).
  - Let the size of the bounding box of three points be `m * k`. Consider 2 cases:

    - `k != 0` and `m != 0`: There are 2 ways to choose the orientation of the three points (`\` or `/`), `gcd(k-1, m-1)-1` ways to choose the point lies between the other 2 points, and `(n - k) × (n - m)` ways to choose the position of the bounding box.
    - `k == 0` or `m == 0`: There are 2 ways to choose the orientation (`|` or `-`), `n` ways to choose the row/column the points lies on, and `Binomial[n, 3]
      == (n*(n-1)*(n-2)) / 6` ways to choose the points on that row/column.

---

Some polyglot notes:

- Funky doesn't really have keyword `return`. However, as [ATaco explained](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40673940#40673940), 
  [Funky] thinks `return` is a variable. So it's parsing that expression, which conveniently does nothing, then parses the next expression. And this is used as an output.
- Javascript use `^` as bitwise xor, unlike Funky which use `^` as exponentiation. So `n*n` have to be used instead of `n^2` to ensure Javascript compatibility.
- In Funky, all operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, etc.) have equal precedence and right-associative, so expressions need to be parenthesized properly.

Comment: +1 was not expecting a polyglot.

Comment: There's no Pentagony, but Hexagony fits well.

Comment: This bytecount was used already... [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144168/55934)

Comment: So, to fix the bytecount problem, could you please pad this answer to 330 bytes? I'll handle the rest.

Comment: \[Answer padded to 332 bytes because of bytecount conflicting issues, see [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41576837#41576837)]

Answer (score 7):

## 265. [brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 636 Bytes, [A000102](https://oeis.org/A000102)

```
[-]>[-]+[[-]>[-],[+[-----------[>[-]++++++[<------>-]<--<<[->>++++++++++<<]>>[-<<+>>]<+>]]]<]<

<<<<<+<++<+++++>>>>>>>

[
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]

<<<<<<<
[>>>>>>>++ >+< <<<<<<<-]
>[>>>>>>+ >>+<< <<<<<<-]
>[>>>>> >>>+<<< <<<<<-]
>[>>>>-- >>>>+<<<< <<<<-]
>[>>>--- >>>>>+<<<<< <<<-]
>[>>-- >>>>>>+<<<<<< <<-]
>[>-<-]

>>>>>>>>-]

<<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]>>>>>>

[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]
  ++++++++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[->>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[.[-]<]<
```

Input is a normal decimal number.

Note that the result is calculated modulo the cell size, so for TIO 256, but it works for other cell sizes as well.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZLLigNBCEX3fkXtjbMfEH9EXCSBgRDIIpDv71wt@zGQfaTr0feI2H29PM@3x9/rel8WlzAs9r6cnF328IIVrlMyCdxUXcx4C9Uw5KqyWWCLCA0l0gxWzgdhM4icNLMnbjW@plEr5C0xD2MdLUuQNYEOsJIdDCu9waaLDGsy0UqkyUTFGq2gSaJJJE/qBk2qa7jzaW1/GVWqTkne34wcnPATRQ8OwlD4nf5ZDkGaWG/VRQ0HjbFm@/STLcemyh4umR7/BuSQDvCTbYYuy@8b)

---

Explanation:

Relies on the recursive definition `a(n) = 2*a(n-1) + a(n-2) - 2*a(n-4) - 3*a(n-5) - 2*a(n-6) - a(n-7)`

```
[-]>[-]+[[-]>[-],[+[-----------[>[-]++++++[<------>-]<--<<[->>++++++++++<<]>>[-<<+>>]<+>]]]<]<
```

takes input (decimal value in ASCII) and write actual decimal number in a cell. Taken from the [esolang site listing BF algorithms](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms).

```
<<<<<+<++<+++++>>>>>>>
```

initialize first seven values (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5)

Then comes the main block. Basically the seven cells to the left of the input represent `a(n) a(n-1) a(n-2) a(n-3) a(n-4) a(n-5) a(n-6)` and the input represents how many 'window shifting' operations have to be performed still, where a window shifting operation consists of `a(n-6)=a(n-5)`, `a(n-5)=a(n-4)` etc. and the calculation of the new `a(n)`(so `a(n+1)` in terms of our old labels) as described above. The former `(a-6)` is dropped.

```
<[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]
```

Move a value seven cells left, do this for all sequence terms. Then we move to the former `a(n)` with value `x` and execute

```
[>>>>>>>++ >+< <<<<<<<-]
```

which increases the new value of `a(n)` by 2*x and the value of `a(n-1)` by x. Repeat the same for the other sequence values with the corresponding factor for `a(n)`.

Finally, move back to the input, decrease it by 1. If input is zero, we're done with the main block. If not, execute another window shift operation.

```
<<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]>>>>>>
```

Zero all the sequence numbers not required for the final output. (This is not necessary, but I like to do it anyway to make sure it does not interfere with the output function.

```
[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]
  ++++++++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[->>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[.[-]<]<
```

Lastly, output the number left to the input which started as `a(0)`, so it is `a(n)`after n window shifts. The algorithm for this is again taken from the esolangs site linked above.

---

This window shifting algorithm is generally quite efficient, but this implementation can be optimized a lot.

For some input n, we do n window shifts, but after that our lowest stored value is `a(n)`, which means we already calculated `a(n+6)`. This is obviously inefficient but saves the special handling required for inputs <7, so it saves some characters and mainly nerves of the programmer.

Second, it is not necessary to copy the whole sequence. It'd be sufficient to copy one value, but this way it's more convenient to write and understand.

[Here](https://tio.run/##bVFBCgIxDLznFXuP8S6EfCTkoIIgggfB99dMorWCw3Y3mUmbZvb0OF7vl@f5NoZLWC72d7BzdvnCSyy4NmUSGam6mPGEaljWqrJZ5CsiNJRIAVbGk7AGkbeCY1BN1II3KZ1JkDYjzWzGOklpcuWKmcQUeHIgOWMk75bVBkrO9WfNC@e02KhFoRnXVnzTGvPVjPQmrYMVBj8xYWU1S/lM2/ap9raGDX@gjl0ClMeP10t5CntcM3SMwws) is a solution implementing the second optimization. Only the old `a(n)` is moved. The other values move one spot to the right and their corresponding multiple is added/subtracted in one loop. This actually saves more time then I expected for larger values with unbounded cell size.

---

[Next sequence: A000636](https://oeis.org/A000636)

Comment: Could you please add a link to the next sequence in order to help the next answerer?

Comment: Personally I find the recurrence relation somewhat magical.

Comment: I think I know how to calculate the next sequence, but I don't know how to enumerate unrooted trees without duplicates, so I'll leave this here: for brevity, let's define a branch as a non-leaf element of a tree. The value of the sequence for the index n is the sum of "scores" of all unrooted ternary trees with n branches. The score of a tree is defined as c² – c + d, where c is the number of branches with **at least one** leaf, and  d is the number of branches with **at least two** leaves

Comment: Clarification: the trees are unordered and unlabelled

Comment: Honestly I didn't look at the next sequence at all. But there's a g.f. in terms of A000642 which in turn has a g.f. in terms of A000598 which can be defined by positive integer solutions for a polynomial. I haven'z checked that, but if it's true, it should be fairly easy to implement in most languages. And I just noticed A000642 has a Mathematica implementation and A000598 has a Maple solution. So it should be definetely possible.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Deduplicate by tree isomorphism. Unacceptably slow. Tree centroid / center can be somehow useful here, but I don't know. / Actually two X atoms are "special" in comparison with the remaining 2n H atoms, which explains the scoring.

Comment: Also I guess that is often called "rooted subtree"? I'm not sure.

Comment: @user202729 I know where the scoring comes from because I came up with it. I'll look into the g.f. some more...

Answer (score 7):

## 271. Java 6, 10008 bytes, [A000103](https://oeis.org/A000103)

#### This program was written entirely by user202729. I am posting this with the creator's [explicit permission / request](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41602883#41602883).

```java
/*
Edit: Why must I map from Edge to index, 
and then get edge from index, 
while I can map Edge to Edge? Fixed.
--------
Edit 2: Remove some dependency on ArrayList.get.
--------
Edit 3: Remove a factor of n! because I didn't think
about this efficient graph isomorphism checking.
---------
Ok... the solution turns out to be too short now to
get to 10008 bytes. Therefore I'm going to add some
random things here.

#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
#############################################
*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
	
	static class Edge {
		Edge next, prev, twin;
		final int node;
		Edge(int node) {
			this.node = node;
		}
		Edge pairNext(Edge e) {
			this.next = e; e.prev = this;
			return this;
		}
		Edge pairTwin(Edge e) {
			this.twin = e; e.twin = this;
			return this;
		}
	}
	
	static class Graph {
		List<Edge> edges;
		int nVertices;
		
		/** 
		 * Initialize to a tetrahedral graph.
		 */
		Graph () {
			nVertices = 3;
			
			edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
			
			edges.add(new Edge(0));
			edges.add(new Edge(1));
			edges.add(new Edge(2));
			edges.get(0).pairNext(edges.get(1));
			edges.get(1).pairNext(edges.get(2));
			edges.get(2).pairNext(edges.get(0));
			
			edges.add(new Edge(1));
			edges.add(new Edge(2));
			edges.add(new Edge(0));
			edges.get(3).pairTwin(edges.get(0)).pairNext(edges.get(5));
			edges.get(4).pairTwin(edges.get(1)).pairNext(edges.get(3));
			edges.get(5).pairTwin(edges.get(2)).pairNext(edges.get(4));
			
			addVertex(new Edge[] {
				edges.get(0), edges.get(1), edges.get(2)
			});
		}
		
		/** 
		 * Copy the other graph.
		 * Expected time complexity O(n) where n is the number of edges
		 * in the graph.
		 * @param other The other graph.
		 */
		Graph (Graph other) {
			nVertices = other.nVertices;
			edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(other.edges.size()); // initial capacity
			Map<Edge, Edge> map = new IdentityHashMap<Edge, Edge>();
			for (Edge e : other.edges) {
				Edge f = new Edge(e.node);
				edges.add(f);
				map.put(e, f);
			}

			assert other.edges.size() == edges.size();

			for (Map.Entry<Edge, Edge> ef : map.entrySet()) {
				Edge e = ef.getKey(), f = ef.getValue();
				f.prev = map.get(e.prev);
				f.next = map.get(e.next);
				f.twin = map.get(e.twin);
			}
		}
		
		/**
		 * Find circuit from one edge.
		 * Note that if the circuit length is less than {@code n}, {@code null}
		 * is also returned.
		 * @param e The input edge.
		 * @return An edge array of length {@code n} consists of node indices, 
		 * or {@code null} if not found.
		 */
		Edge[] findCircuit (Edge e, int n) {
			
			assert edges.contains(e);
			
			Edge[] circuitEdges = new Edge[n];
			circuitEdges[0] = e;
			for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
				circuitEdges[i] = circuitEdges[i-1].next;
				
				assert circuitEdges[i].prev == circuitEdges[i-1];
			}
			return circuitEdges[n - 1].next == e ? circuitEdges : null;
		}
		
		/**
		 * Add an vertex to the plane bounded by {@code circuit}. <br>
		 * The vertex will be connected to all of the vertices inside the 
		 * circuit. <br>
		 * Time complexity: O({@code circuit.length}).
		 * @param circuit The specified plane. Should be listed in the order
		 * such that {@code circuit[i].next == circuit[(i+1) % nVertices]}
		 * for all valid {@code i}.
		 */
		void addVertex(Edge[] circuit) {
			int n = edges.size(), k = circuit.length;
			
			for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
				assert(circuit[i].next == circuit[(i+1)%k]);
				assert(circuit[(i+1)%k].prev == circuit[i]);
			}
			
			for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) edges.add(
					new Edge(nVertices)
					.pairNext(circuit[i])
			);
			for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) edges.add(
					new Edge(circuit[i].node)
					.pairTwin(edges.get(n + i))
					.pairNext(edges.get(n + (i == 0 ? k : i) - 1))
			);
			for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) 
				circuit[i].pairNext(edges.get(n + (i == k-1 ? i : i + k) + 1));
			
			++nVertices;
		}
		
		/**
		 * Remove an edge from the graph. <br>
		 * Time complexity O({@code edges.size()}).
		 * @param edge The edge to remove.
		 */
		void removeEdge(Edge edge) {

			assert edges.contains(edge);
			
			Edge twin = edge.twin;
			twin.prev.pairNext(edge.next);
			edge.prev.pairNext(twin.next);
			
			// it is possible to implement this in O(1) with LinkedList but I'm lazy...
			boolean success = edges.remove(edge);
			success = edges.remove(twin) && success; 
			assert success;
			
		}
		
		/**
		 * Calculate the minimum degree of any vertex.
		 * @return The minimum degree of any vertex.
		 */
		int minVertexDegree() {
			int[] degree = new int[nVertices];
			for (Edge e : edges) ++degree[e.node];
			
			int ans = degree[0];
			for (int d : degree)
				if (d < ans) ans = d;
			
			return ans;
		}
		
		/**
		 * Check isomorphism between two graphs (reflection does not count).
		 * @param g Other graph.
		 * @return whether the graphs are isomorphic under rotation.
		 */
		boolean isomorphicToWithoutReflection(Graph g) {
			check_edge_equivalence:
			for (Edge e : edges) {
				Map<Edge, Edge> map = new IdentityHashMap<Edge, Edge>();
				map.put(e, g.edges.get(0));
				
				/**
				 * List containing edges which are mapped, but their neighbors 
				 * ({@code next, prev, twin} are not mapped.
				 */
				List<Edge> pending = new ArrayList<Edge>(); 
				pending.add(e);
				
				while (!pending.isEmpty()) {
					Edge f = pending.remove(pending.size() - 1), map_f = map.get(f);
					for (Edge[] adj : new Edge[][]{
						{f.next, map_f.next},
						{f.prev, map_f.prev},
						{f.twin, map_f.twin}
					}) {
						Edge map_adj = map.get(adj[0]);
						if (map_adj == null) {
							map.put(adj[0], adj[1]);
							pending.add(adj[0]);
						} else {
							if (map_adj != adj[1]) 
								continue check_edge_equivalence;
						}
					}
				}
				
				assert map.size() == edges.size(); // the graph is connected
				return true;
			}
			return false;
		}
		
		/**
		 * Reflect this graph.
		 */
		void reflect() {
			for (Edge e : edges) {
				Edge f = e.prev; e.prev = e.next; e.next = f;
			}
		}

		/**
		 * Check isomorphism between two graphs.
		 * Algorithmic complexity: O(n<sup>2</sup>).
		 * @param g The graph to check isomorphism with {@code this}.
		 * @return {@code true} if the graphs are isomorphic,
		 * {@code false} otherwise.
		 */
		boolean isomorphicTo(Graph g) {
			boolean ans = false;
			for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
				ans = ans || isomorphicToWithoutReflection(g);
				reflect();
			}
			return ans;
		}
	}
	
	/**
	 * Given a graph with length {@code n}, generate all graphs with length 
	 * {@code n+1} using the approach in MishaLavrov's answer to 
	 * HyperNeutrino's question on Math.SE about A000109
	 * @param graph The input graph.
	 * @return A List of graphs.
	 */
	static List<Graph> generateGraph(Graph graph) {
		ArrayList<Graph> result = new ArrayList<Graph>();
		
		// case 1: add vertex to list of 3 edges
		for (int i = 0; i < graph.edges.size(); ++i) {
			Edge edge = graph.edges.get(i);
			
			if (!(edge.node < edge.next.node && edge.node < edge.prev.node))
				continue; // avoid redundancy, for each triangular face 
			// only consider the edge with minimum node index
			
			Graph newgraph = new Graph(graph);
			edge = newgraph.edges.get(i);

			Edge[] circuit = newgraph.findCircuit(edge, 3);
			assert circuit != null; // the graph is supposed to be triangular 
			// decomposition of a sphere.
			
			newgraph.addVertex(circuit);
			result.add(newgraph);
			
		}
		
		// case 2: add vertex to 2 adjacent triangular faces
		for (int i = 0; i < graph.edges.size(); ++i) {
			Edge edge = graph.edges.get(i);

			Edge twin = edge.twin;
			if (edge.node > twin.node) continue;
			
			assert graph.findCircuit(edge, 3) != null;
			assert graph.findCircuit(twin, 3) != null;
			

			Graph newgraph = new Graph(graph);
			edge = newgraph.edges.get(i);

			Edge next = edge.next;
			newgraph.removeEdge(edge);
			Edge[] circuit = newgraph.findCircuit(next, 4);
			assert(circuit != null);
			newgraph.addVertex(circuit);

			result.add(newgraph);
		}
		
		// case 3: add vertex to 3 adjacent triangular faces
		for (int i = 0; i < graph.edges.size(); ++i) {

			Edge edge = graph.edges.get(i);
			if (edge.twin.next.twin == edge.prev.twin.prev) continue;
			
			Graph newgraph = new Graph(graph);

			edge = newgraph.edges.get(i);
			Edge next = edge.next, prev = edge.prev;
			assert newgraph.findCircuit(edge, 3) != null;
			
			newgraph.removeEdge(edge); newgraph.removeEdge(prev); 
			Edge[] circuit = newgraph.findCircuit(next, 5);
			assert(circuit != null);
			newgraph.addVertex(circuit);

			result.add(newgraph);
			
		}
		
		return result;
	}
	
	/**
	 * Evolve the graphs with number of node {@code n} to get graphs with 
	 * number of node {@code n+1}.
	 * @param graphs The list of graphs with {@code n} nodes.
	 * @return A list of graphs with {@code n+1} nodes.
	 */
	static List<Graph> evolve(List<Graph> graphs) {
		List<Graph> result = new ArrayList<Graph>();
		
		for (Graph graph : graphs) {
			outer: for (Graph g0 : generateGraph(graph)) {
				
				assert(g0.nVertices == graph.nVertices + 1);
				
				for (Graph g1 : result) {
					if (g0.isomorphicTo(g1))
						continue outer;
				}
				result.add(new Graph(g0));
			}
		}
		
		return result;
	}
	
	public static void main(String[] args) {
		Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
		int n = in.nextInt();
		
		List<Graph> graphs = new ArrayList<Graph>();
		graphs.add(new Graph());
		
		for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) graphs = evolve(graphs);
		
		int ans = 0;
		for (Graph g : graphs) {
			if (g.minVertexDegree() >= 4) ++ans;
		}
		
		System.out.println(ans);
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vpbb9vGEn6WfsUEB22kWKYlOwFOLdtNkLptcJIGqI32ITACilxJG1NLlRfJaqrfnjMze@GSouXkpH07QSKJu7MzuzPfXHaYD@EqPEyXQn2Ib7/79OnoSfcylsUp/D7fwKLMC3gFi3AJ0yxdwGU8E1CkIFUs7gbQDVUMxVwomIkCBE0ymZ1ez2UicH0UKuZhl9P39/CjvBNx0D00f1gsHJ/Cr2KRrgTk6UJALHBjsVDRBlIFL7Is3LyWeRGgvObKE7cyhGkYFWkG6RTUI5iIKCxz2kcsY/W4wB1LddsNJ2nJv3MQ06mMpFAFzLJwOQeJstNsiVMLiOYiupVqVok77L69DYKADo6bTMpC4taKMlM5MMcUJeJnCvk8zQpQ6RqfuqQhnBoNh8N/w2RTiDyA67nIxDTNcG@PFzBLUQzRhHHMp@9mqF9UJ@13lgMRB93uv77kz/@pv5r6yVG3KxdLMuUHdJUA7Z0EDonj3bl7ht@Ey5bRVwjuQhabn8N83k5xhd6jRDbudpflJJERREmY5/AmlAo@djvdTl6EhRtmF8PhDv9Q4q4YwDITqwEUa6nGODGVKkzQRQmZsRgb0p4d6PPqDvlFQM9w7ui2lu0ylNkvyLrHT/UlOIxLxBhEQHLxN43T8k4myEvcc43dNe6uhR1t2rIzv/ew2@6o4yf2Z@JHVjkjARccqHgJn/k3kSG9HsC/R0@eAH7BE3ilZCHDRP7JMSuEQhRZOBdxhurjOBEw3RF@ajE9s3PHEnd7wlulfyyVtCnWVSDTO@r161QBRoAe0bFlhn093TI1un/quDaF0Qf5BM5w1ehoh27USrfL77iVzu72a3e8RwUk5kQLZ9jUhLft6dnO8qety0fty092lj9rXX7cvvyppxE8FYFD3LmzvbvRoKkZagD@pvyn4z4Rb/vWgWqIfZkuN5yWUvzIfJDC5d1SRIXAdC0xrUbpYpmIO4w78Lan@rCm3AIKEx8vV@ViIjh9smDNQSqe85k@X4ZZuDDSrtvkes6hv5iixU94PKg5416P0fRaLzm6aA@VDEdHuEt2Wiw5lmGE5yM@GFd51QC0/1Mpork2oq9PZXwSszOYuASn4Ek1Z9ARbGr4MVgFx0293APz1Iyg9GBZIkAGYIa2XYZGnuPhYfdgcH4O/vO46zaGew4uVZFtaucTU9wqiRE0dYWo6dd2SzFdTAlO/xGbHsJr6gZ@C5NSmKN3pjaCEy8Cnw7pbtbE@mqWBtysCdfVLA3YA/vg1Vj6EYtGiGQWlVjLcRWZKsHnNmD7JS0wEM/DAuSUkWiJE6FmBRVt@CsnAGO1@fF5RLlLbQfuZ5kkW4PkHMIkT0EnEKpBfTQLRrJUaCNf/HOTbl4oXeiGBEhyESPeSUTnUjkCNefyk8bwZITpgfFSNJy/JzqOSvHMaaniymtMbMBsHb80BzU4HOjkbUzqQUeDBMUXWBvkPVGFHcPMaOzS8yueUTdM6U@/G95w3nVQI5kSh0Zj/DoDNYaDA2lhVVspaWV95HB0w@DQ2OAPs@fGSoO4lvUOODbv1ygUHIKRwe4C39cPe8q6Hrfg7gUW2wiYFUdlSvQErWUSIvgmZBEMmZONNZjhuQ3gbJJdaAaEFrN6LZOEin80gTLRFgsHHEs1Ylc23qF5ZCx4TDMxjGt864H6FCN1fReBRt62X8evdQvaV45BX04lboRPFMDVPC2TmPaYIERx3ET1NItFptnkZTTXflYXR9ax@rVDPXkw6sM3VRF1Y1yMIEMHX2H9FFtGclvBe5XieJUN6wA1sGKYQz34DeC2QpfRgIN5DahDDdTbGlA16noPHemb2xsTxxoL7GwTp8ipCm0P7qVKCiyj41KH02NfT1TlhCeHpvrj/1mGf3bKU56kRj2j4ABkf2crdYKeJDUM0eFu0ctQMDpi/zP36McOdv59Im4PRyhEkhAcu@3jx8irrA4OasVD081ta0B5bYqqnLnf7Sqv81HY9DnmSQ4nTIcjY3ENuOtBNoKO5PhBwNwTwomiFsXB3ogoM9krXYd@MCTrKvQSMj/WKXhRRUH/qIAqKD8u0zyXk0Q3e0gXC@qOcLMExb/FohSDHWa911LdipjqMphgvqQ2RhL@uQkCOnpnkqaJQJVjSIkoNVtX1orwTncPAVcM8O23lsEYPFXZMbP3psFfhklUJmGho@wC68JFuYBYzDIhKB6HamPCdiPBX38W@ZG5PiKlDmE/MGmvCl0YzsxynWlpqIqTLcWlKSsPDvSyd7qOvHHGIXGhIiUZguFN3cNiZKKntM9iYdGL0d1wUd@udNzMaXG4zV1eUter1gebiGItBGaLdaqdJodeJqYJ5jnqf8UppjUqYyJMmkXDPWbwdudCYtWNVw@ec86IxRneRZzoCCgJZ5CldK9PVaV@i66K9Dr9HUGZlsWvbmPm2jEzduFu3nvS9HvxRykxPQkVidN7jaGzxtdcIPx6fxbs3pN1NaQVz4phZzIRgBqC@ha0xuPNWTPIbyniAfsbKk1muBE5m0/SLAfLw8asZv9nyxzITJpLYBYc8bfXIqGuKwm/r12hJRkqzjLCP45u/PYeWQKZXy6Wxaa6h1TXJktiXN4@mqsPJZMBbfb91LtL2KtUZTN0tjD@QGWeu1a/uzGiOh/1VcXw4d/bQTWn1aPn6Lc/R0qzc6xAPbV159AHIQKSX20Rn9A/7T7ZFR3RORejFQsHEb1oQEd5N6oW1/TcYLwFkeSiYuULenRuOYGd7hCwpCoFtHuCY9v1vrY7VTtt@J7LKV3CnS9TKnHFMDOwTbusFDsV/RRvZaI9ebM76/zT6C6YzMoENvrucWWHO50NvTalzpZj840DU@@u@qWx0QS5F8kszTAkLaghWSvl1VleLi@Oz47oaydcXjsFYv6NduRx6jUuTjrZNmKqnUIlb@1tuTW2DvQ6Q8/63@oOxFrmYn@obURWS6LzjDNla/13XK/JeQV9/vXXA8F8ZnDv7L2DoSqfcTOYjYYn/Emu0D6hUSrrr3lvx/AslMioYqCbi9GXT9r1dKUORlsoc35jg9rFaJqlIUZorI7eyHwevg5XWbp6nNOG1pTeUr38581SYPlVFplUKU7/UYqcEyj@fRMW8@DqEvSbqRfD4XA0/K7rA4N3X7UnrCv47QmdP7BicUBkE5quOAdxNtyFOy4/WmvSpzZMFfQNfSbyMil2UoKe1abocgkZhRiRRqf8Hqu6VydmXyeuqdgGDX2kekSpsOLKZlzgU1LElVUZS0HwkamAyVhn4KphPYAl5c4sF8d8I9LVk42UHNFCE2ZiLEZCFW0GfMMVZHG0ZKhmWGpm9NqRL/SkhFQlG90Kik11w/tmPNny0naHxJ3dubYCKlibWutaG0ibxhXzeq5NCbsNH5/WayixhgZwopnWGzKUPLhlshPPMWDh7UD3NuhFZ3V8c/JYUKhLc6lxjbUz5Ev98tKc0m2magDYm795s0NIs68AvIN7ucHA7LgJs2PKeWgHuq7ULfPPQG7/xYyQWCHtAvSdi1@zOXw1unj3m8nZZC@1Llka1N2/G1xgX/RZxxrXDOtddatb3ueBUpdqT31Q9hqg7I8fRNE@GDUgdNKE0MnfCaHPDFsOKO5Wbhro5150ctf8FvR8hnEftu59xtV3CPD24mNwb2ypw3AvRqBtSr9xgC/Fz7N/ED9eGDJZV1OOG0XH5SpNVsKvvjj6V2/XOChULw4QevS/RHxa5nPPAqxAgp3qIOfyIKnVALV6EeUQl7xZNuxbQrVOtai9mhB82F6twGBW/er1@xcVEuxnXlWClbzPsIM1kshOwScbEk2tqtFGs5Wm39GdDQPv/aP1y2qIuovejdYXM0Ix@gzuDkfuixxr9fFsZHun1a2LNz32blV1jFmHtc2B7QNIM/8jxJiDa5RFKFXvisrLGV2Ks5nRl/lvJMBJikSZgd7VJi/EIjDv5mzP3QShV6pwBtk17V4TmvqzfrJ@zbqNKGrfKTnmBlPG7GZl1QYbjhswaUKErRLstuguzjG/oKx688soAk2EEQ6lJKpHnTPW9bb76dOz/wI)

Note: TIO runs the program on Java 9, but I've tested running the program on Java 6u45 - Windows 32 bit locally, and it also works. Input 5 gives output 5 in about 21 seconds now, and input 6 gives output 12 in 7 minutes 14 seconds.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A010008)

Comment: This sequence would be a good candidate for [hardest sequence to golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188230/find-the-hardest-oeis-sequence-to-golf)

Answer (score 6):

## 5. [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes, [A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002)

```python
n=int(input())
l=[1,2,2]
for i in range(2,n):l+=[1+i%2]*l[i]
print(l[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTK8c22lDHSMcolistv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNIJ0/TKkcbKK2dqWoUq5UTnRnLVVAE0pwTnRer@f@/GQA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000072)

Comment: Gosh darn it, I was playing around with `f=lambda n,r=1:n*(n<3)or 3-f(n-f(r),r+1)` for around 40 bytes (works except `f(3)` is omitted), but my internet decided to bug out while I was playing around on TIO

Comment: I don't get what this sequence is about at all. Could someone explain it simply?

Comment: @geokavel See [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8369/generate-a-kolakoski-sequence)

Answer (score 6):

## 7. [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 70 bytes, [A000071](https://oeis.org/A000071)

```
({}[<>((()))<>]){({}[()])<>({}<>)<>(({})<>({}<>))<>}<>{}{}({}<>{}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6NtrGTkNDQ1NT08YuVrMaJKChGQvkAFk2diAayIBzgQwgVV1bXQvmQxX//28KAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000070)

### Explanation

```
({}[<>((()))<>]) #{ place a one on the off stack and subtract 1 from the input (to zero index)}
                {({}[()])                          } #{n times}
                         <>({}<>)<>(({})<>({}<>))<>  #{Add the top two numbers in place}
                                                    <>{}{}({}<>{}[()]) #{Clean up and subtract 1}
```

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't know.  Is that not allowed?

Comment: no its fine. I just thought that it could help the next answerer

Answer (score 6):

## 17. [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 18 bytes, [A000069](https://oeis.org/A000069)

```
[bits  sum odd]nth
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/Pzops6RYQaG4NFchPyUlNq8k47@DVRqXuUKaQkpmccF/AA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000018). Pretty simple. Computes the number of bits, calculates the sum, then checks for odd parity. Then takes the nth such number. Hehehe good luck.

In retrospect, I could have made it 16 bytes instead of 17 or 18:

```
[bits sum 2%]nth
```

But oh well

Comment: Next sequence is...?

Comment: How are we supposed to do an erroneous sequence?

Comment: C'mon, you left us with the broken one???

Comment: Fixing...........

Comment: Please change this one's byte cont, because the next one is [broken](http://oeis.org/A000017)

Comment: Technically you could hard code it but ok

Comment: Oh, the next one is hell

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder it isn't really hell compared to A60 :D

Comment: @LeakyNun and you didn't even get credit for it because you were writing your explanation :P

Comment: Next one may be perfect for Brachylog, though I don't know it so I couldn't say for sure...

Comment: At least I left you guys with A19 @StepHen

Comment: @LeakyNun and I woulda gone to http://oeis.org/A000006

Comment: @MDXF I don't quite get it? What does it mean by "erroneous sequence"?

Comment: @ThomasPeng https://oeis.org/A000017 is "erroneous" in that it has no producing formula, but is rather a finite set of values which incorrectly represent a separate sequence, https://oeis.org/A032522 . That means any answer must hard code the sequence.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien What's the point of these sequences? I mean, I can just take a part of any sequence out to make a new one namely AXXXXXX. (Nothing to do with the challenge, just a confusion, and it's possible that I have been misunderstanding your words.)

Comment: @ThomasPeng At the time of the challenge, specifically A000017 wasn't viewed as a "proper" sequence, I guess. it's hard to go back 5 years and try and remember why lol

Answer (score 6):

## 25. [eta](http://eta-lang.org/#), 183 bytes, [A000033](http://oeis.org/A000033)

```
f x = sum $ map f [2..n]
  where f k = g k `div` h k
        g k = (-1)^k * n * v (2*n-k-1) * v (n-k)
        h k = v (2*n-2*k) * v (k-2)
        v n = product [1..n]
        n = x+1
```

[Try it online](http://eta-lang.org/#)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000183)

Comment: To quote the OP: `You must wait for at least 1 hour before posting an answer, after having posted.` This makes your answer invalid; you can ask OP in chat but I believe this invalidates your answer.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino My FiM++ answer was posted `22:28`, this was posted `23:29`

Comment: My bad. It must've rounded down to "1 hour" which is why I thought your FiM++ answer was younger than it was. Sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Comment: Reading through all answers here, and wondering how many essentially-haskell answers are coming still :p

Comment: @tomsmeding I still have idris and elm left

Answer (score 6):

## 31. [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/humanities/research/research-projects/past-projects/joy-programming-language), 172 bytes, [A001112](http://oeis.org/A001112)

```
DEFINE acf == [20 <] [[0 1 1 3 4 11 136 283 419 1121 1540 38081 39621 117323 156944 431211 5331476 11094163 16425639 43945441] of] [10 - dup 10 -] [[39202 *] dip -] binrec.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY69CsJAEIR7n2JqwXD7c5scmM4INr5ASKGJgaQwQbDw6c89tpn9ZmBm3X45X7rr7d7hMc5oW/QccB7Q9wHkJ1CQCzFw4w8lf9lB1ABpQuORZAVQLSzOLalCxUOEKEJam5shKZnbphxNkgeSRlUasM3eRgEnTN8dRZR2SRwYxwHTshfyXN6f11hlX1eGVof8Bw)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000172)

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @LeakyNun a(0)=0, a(1)=1, ..., a(19)=43945441. For n>19, a(n)=39202*a(n-10)+a(n-20). It is based on the MAGMA code on OEIS.

Answer (score 6):

## 50. [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 26 bytes, [A000074](http://oeis.org/A000074)

```
1o2pU 2 èÈo f_¬v1Ãd_nX ¬v1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3zDfqCBUwUjh8IrDHfkKafGH1pQZHm5Oic@LUAAxgQoMAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000026) (I was quite tempted to ungolf it by 1 byte to get [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027), but this one should be fine)

#### Explanation

```
1o2pU 2 èÈ  o f_  ¬ v1Ã d_  nX ¬ v1
1o2pU 2 èX{Xo fZ{Zq v1} dZ{ZnX q v1}}   Ungolfed
                                        Implicit: U = input integer
  2pU                                   Yield 2 ** U.
1o    2                                 Create the range [1, 3, 5, ..., 2**U - 1].
        èX{                         }   Find the number of items X where this is true:
           Xo                             [0, 1, ..., X - 1]
              fZ{     }                   filtered to only items Z where
                 Zq v1                      sqrt(Z) is divisible by 1 (Z is square)
                                          (this gives a list of the squares less than X)
                        dZ{        }      contains an item Z where
                           ZnX              X - Z
                               q v1         is also square.
                                          In other words, assert that an integer solution
                                          to X = a**2 + b**2 exists.
                                        This gives the number of odd integers less than 2**U
                                        that can be represented as the sum of two squares.
                                        Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 6):

### 69. [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), 333 bytes, [A000761](https://oeis.org/A000761)

```
dirs:=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]];
dirs:=Concatenation(dirs,-dirs);

count:=function(pos,seen,n)
  local newseen;
  if (pos in seen) or AbsInt(pos[1]-2)>n then
    return 0;
  fi;
  if n=0 then
    return 1;
  fi;
  newseen:=Concatenation(seen,[pos]);
  return Sum(dirs,d->count(pos+d,newseen,n-1));
end;

f:=n->count([0,0,0],[],n+2);
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000333)

Comment: The partitions don't stop, do they?

Comment: [Solution to the next one](https://tio.run/##TY4xb4MwEIV3/4onxGCEckqkThGwtGMydeiQRpUlTIxibGobhaH/ndqQITed3r1331PC36XWy9IPo3UBHyIIOvU@sKfwbk1wVtPZGtEy1sHA4w8a1Q5B3OWX6rUE/56xa8A9SvjfGJsLVDVMgcuB6MqwTo1BjBgnJ2O@LME1mqbGlk0nPh8LEBIkhy@fnxgLUdjCSoqWbs5OI/lYj5KWlrzjpjwU@2UQffJ21p1/wEOVN5c90du1iB83UGtjnXEKn8GdEifT0tyCOiJLnbyyj1hslRL7xUqYzMO61sfQyk3W@dWRZcs/ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'd just let `g x n|x<0=0 | otherwise =1+sum(takeWhile(>0)([g(x-sqrt k)k|k<-[n..]]))` and call `g(n+1)1 - 1`. BTW, I wonder how to do it without relying on floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 6):

## 80. [Mathics](http://www.mathics.org), 140 Bytes, [A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013)

```
EulerPhi[x_] := Sum[If[CoprimeQ[i,x], 1, 0], {i, 1, x}]
OEIS[x_] := Sum[If[IntegerQ[x/d], (EulerPhi[2d]*2^(x/d))/(2x), 0], {d,1,x}]
OEIS[#]&
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv7/37U0J7UoICMzuiI@VsHKViG4NDfaMy3aOb@gKDM3NTA6U6ciVkfBUEfBAEhVZ4KZFbWxXP6unsFoejzzSlLTU4sCoyv0U4CKNeBGG6XEahnFaQCFNTX1NYwqNKGmpegY6sDNUo5V@x9QlJlX4gDiOhga/AcA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000140)

Comment: Wellp, I'll be waiting for 81 https://oeis.org/A000140 hah.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn It's actually not that hard. If you understand Jelly, it's just [`!ḶÆ!S€ĠL€Ṁ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/x4Y5th9sUgx81rTmywAdIPtzZ8P//fzMA)

Comment: @ETHproductions was looking to do an 05AB1E entry :P.

Answer (score 6):

## 81. [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 290 bytes, [A000140](http://oeis.org/A000140)

```
fact n {
  b = 2
  x = 0
  while [ n > 0 ] do
    x += n % b
    n = floor(n / b)
    b += 1
  done
  return x
}

A000140 n {
  x = 1; q = n; while [ q > 0 ] do x *= q; q -= 1; done
  t = 0
  while [ x > 0 ] do
    x -= 1
    t += 1 if [ fact(x) = floor(n * (n-1) / 4) ]
  done
  return t
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDdisIwEIXv8xTnRki6lE3FG9EK@xziRWtbDLgTGyJbWPrscdLW@nd1kpnDnG/G2aoIoSmOHoR/AZTIsWTtWDXr38mca@y5u4PGAZXlYmx/5VxboBy@xO7mbK2ThG@UaiiW0ZPxs7JUs7jaXx2hE70QP1rrbKWn0BiWbdCy0GaObOdINiQ52uhIB@c00b9Bdu@Q6QgQnZEFpmFX3FZ26gk5gaQ0U4y@Ujh8EHvRh9/C0ERrME69pxpssX6kXpwhLzFtKI3CeA7zco4@hBs)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000290)

Each item in A000140 is the largest number of permutations of a length-**n** array all having the same inversion count. This may sound daunting, but it's really not. Here's the table of possible inversions for **n = 3**:

```
    [inv. table]  [permutation]  inversion count
0:     [ 0 0 ]      [ 0 1 2 ]    0
1:     [ 1 0 ]      [ 1 0 2 ]    1
2:     [ 0 1 ]      [ 0 2 1 ]    1
3:     [ 1 1 ]      [ 2 0 1 ]    2
4:     [ 0 2 ]      [ 1 2 0 ]    2
5:     [ 1 2 ]      [ 2 1 0 ]    3
```

1 permutation has zero inversions, 2 permutations have one inversion each, 2 others have two inversions each, and 1 has three. The maximal number of permutations with **x** inversions is **2**, shared by **x = 1** and **x = 2**, so the output is **2**.

Now don't get concerned; we don't have to calculate all permutations of a length-**n** array. You may have noticed that each inversion table (in the second-to-left column) sums to the number of inversions of that permutation. Also, it turns out calculating the sum of the inversion table for a permutation index **k** is remarkably simple: just convert **k** to the [factorial base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) and sum the digits. Examples:

```
 k: [fact. digits]  sum
 0: [          0 ]  0
 1: [          1 ]  1
 2: [        1 0 ]  1
 3: [        1 1 ]  2
 4: [        2 0 ]  2
 5: [        2 1 ]  3
 6: [      1 0 0 ]  1
 7: [      1 0 1 ]  2
 8: [      1 1 0 ]  2
...
22: [      3 2 0 ]  5
23: [      3 2 1 ]  6
24: [    1 0 0 0 ]  1
25: [    1 0 0 1 ]  2
...
```

This sequence itself is [A034968](http://oeis.org/A034968). So to calculate the **n**-th term in A000140, all you have to do is find the **x** that appears the most often in the first **n!** terms of the factorial digit sum sequence, then return how many times **x** appears. And you don't even have to find **x** manually: the OEIS page mentions that it's always **floor(n(n-1)/4)**.

After I made all of these realizations, implementing it was a piece of cake. The hardest part was learning how Röda itself works, but that was a fun challenge in itself. Thanks [@fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq) for the nice language :-)

Comment: NB for an efficient implementation, the first comment on A000140 points you at A008302, which has a nice recurrence.

Answer (score 6):

## 116. Kotlin, 1156 bytes, [A000273](https://oeis.org/A000273)

```kotlin
import java.math.BigInteger;

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    var a = accum(n, n, Array(n, { x -> 0 }), Array(n, { x -> 0 }), 0, BigInteger.ONE, n);
    println(a.first / a.second);
}

fun accum(n: Int, m: Int, part: Array<Int>, freq: Array<Int>, off: Int, c: BigInteger, omega: Int): Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger> {
    if (n == 0) return Pair(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(omega), c);
    if (m == 0) return Pair(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);

    var sum = accum(n, m - 1, part, freq, off, c, omega);
    part[off] = m;
    freq[off] = 0;
    var c1 = c;
    var omega2 = omega;

    var delta = -1;
    var j = 0;
    while (j < off) delta += 2 * freq[j] * gcd(part[j++], m);

    var im = m;
    while (im <= n) {
        freq[off]++;
        c1 = c1 * BigInteger.valueOf(im.toLong());
        omega2 = omega2 + 2 * (im - m) + delta;
        val term = accum(n - im, m - 1, part, freq, off + 1, c1, omega2);
        sum = Pair(sum.first * term.second + sum.second * term.first, sum.second * term.second);
        im += m;
    }

    return sum;
}

fun gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##fVPJbtswEL37K@ZSQIpkVfKhB29AA@RQIKiL9tbAB1qmZCoi5VJUkiLwt6tDarQ4SGoYNmd/b5bHypRCta2Q50obKNgTiyQzp@hW5N@U4TnXq9ksaxRIJpTHdF4v4avW7O/6l9FC5VsfXmeAnydWgoINUFSEcsN3mQt5iPf@irw0MPRiadpIT4WAX5fOvl/hBeZbiOHif6SNQxiRRbvvd5iBUp8RjikRY5QJXRv4DCyqeVqpIzpcOhJUdmlRhiDp/8y06VmhYhtCpvmfa02VZeSdLicQ0CB5zpzJX8IPJvR6ah3fW@qTyMDDPm0g9kFz02jlorxrWlF9Epm555nxXAGknhJPm0D@P8Hvu5@7t43C6GECdSOnM5Awh6RrQ0fd0cWKxK5vMNof0LDHWNmprHOviscJpwnK6Si7LAvUuccEyJGXxq7DPBmdizHX80mUHLwC1haQT@7BBhZw09Uu9vjK06PnwBVBsEc6U6pCjmgpHarWG1wbGsgVjyBYDcqORYIFJp3s11rIyFT3lco93x9DrokuIHBIbcU5wkLRMRj97dEYrifTQEchPxoJJkBlmtBcFpPK3UjdIuCTTuDGJacrwGBrIYFMzi98xzBcTl8AOQRDJy9dg2n9MHq4MDsLRpdy6M8CfxGcXdwDLS4DXtbceR9ClD7BwW/b9ss/)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001156) is a nice easy partition sequence.

#### Notes

This implementation follows J. Qian, *Enumeration of unlabeled directed hypergraphs*, Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, 20(1) (2013), and in particular exploits corollary 6. Although it may not look it, it's much simpler than the Maple implementation listed in OEIS.

Answer (score 6):

## 123. [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 278 bytes, [A002057](https://oeis.org/A002057)

```
 ️➡
  p 1.0
  k⏩2➕1
   ✖p➕➗k 1
  
  p
 
 ️➡
  ➗✖️➕1✖2➕3
 



 ️➕110 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/wJ3R/mz2r6ML@3nUsByJv2YX7rxvc7@h/NW4gQB0r0ritQMNQzALOnNGU/6l9p9GjeVEOgjqlQNWBFj@ZMKwCKP5o3Hai7ASI7qyFbwRBiSCeE6vswv7@9gAsqArV1AzZb@4AmAc2EO2oqyEhDoIgRiAHkG4NoqElgAkj2N8K8MwPohCkL4YaD3Nu7C2LDlO0QqRnrgfQSEDY0UDA0ABvy/7@hAQA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000278) (have an easy one)

This is Emojicode 0.5, which is currently the newest version, but I'm mentioning it because of the major changes that are planned for 0.6.

## Explaination:

**Note**: a lot of emoji choice doesn't make much sense in Emojicode 0.5. It's 0.x, after all. 0.6 will fix this, so if you want to learn this (because who wouldn't want to), I recommend waiting a moment.

Emojicode is an object-oriented programming language featuring generics, protocols, optionals and closures, but this program uses no closures and all generics and protocols can be considered implicit, while the only optional appears in the I/O part.

The program operates on only a few types:  is the integer type,  is the floating-point type,  is the string type and ⏩ is the range type (yes, a range is a type in Emojicode).

There are currently no operators in Emojicode, so addition, comparsions and other operations that are normally operators are implemented as functions, effectively making the expressions use [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation). Operators are also planned in 0.6.

```
 ...
```

Extend the  type. This is a feature that is not commonly found in programming languages. Instead of creating a new class with  as the superclass,  modifies  directly. Grapes and watermelons declare code blocks in Emojicode.

```
️➡ ...
```

️ is a method that returns . ️ calculates [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108) using the `Product_{k=2..n} (1 + n/k)`. The OEIS states that the formula is only valid for `n > 1`, but this method will only be called with `n >= 1` and the value is ignored in the `n = 1` case because of a multiplication by 0, so no special case is present.

```
p 1.0
```

Create a variable named `p` and set it to `1.0`. This automatically makes the type . This is necessary because fractions are present in the product.

```
k⏩2➕1 ...
```

iterates over anything that implements the ⚪️ protocol, while ⏩ is a range literal that happens to implement . A range has a start value, a stop value and a step value, which is assumed to be 1 if `start < stop`, or -1 otherwise. One can also specify the step value by using the ⏭ to create the range literal. The start value is inclusive, while the stop value is exclusive, so this is equivalent to `for k in range(2, ➕1)`. ➕ is a method of the  type that adds numbers together and  refers to the object the method was called on, so ➕1 means `n + 1`. This corresponds to the range of `Product_{k=2..n}` from the formula, since the stop value is not included in the range.

```
✖p ...
```

This is an assignment by call, which means "call ✖ on p with the arguments (`...`) and set p to the return value". ✖ is a method of  that multiplies numbers together. This can sound familiar, because it's similar to the operators like `+=`, `*=` or `>>=` in some popular emoji-free (and therefore inferior) languages.

```
➕➗k 1
```

, in addition to being a type, is a method of the  type, that returns a  of the same value as  - by convention, methods that share the name with a type are used to convert to that type. Therefore this expression represents `(n / k) + 1`, which is then multiplied by, and stored in `p`.

```
p
```

is used to return values from methods, while  is a method of the  type that returns the nearest . Whether one uses an equivalent of `round`, `floor` or `ceil` shouldn't matter since the formula always results in integers, but using  makes the code more immune to floating-point inaccuracies.

```
️➡ ...
```

This creates a method named ️ that returns . This method implements [A002057](https://oeis.org/A002057).

```
➗✖️➕1✖2➕3
```

This is a return statement with the formula "encoded" in prefix notation. If you decipher it, you'll see ️ being called on `n + 1`, the result multiplied by `2 * n` and divided by `n + 3`, resulting in the formula `2*n*A000108(n+1)/(n+3)` from the OEIS.

```
 ...
```

marks the equivalent of a `main` function.

```
️➕110 10
```

Let's break it down.

marks the beginning and end of a  literal.  is used for constructing objects, so this creates a  with the constructor  called with a single argument of an empty string.  is used to read a line of input from the user, and the argument is used as a prompt.

```
10
```

is a method of the  type, and as you might guess, it converts the string into an integer. It takes one argument, the number base to use.

```
10
```

returns an optional, . Optionals can contain a value of the base type or nothingness, ⚡. When the string doesn't contain a number, ⚡ is returned. To use the value of an optional, one has to unwrap it using , which raises a runtime error if the value is ⚡. Normally it is bad practice to unwrap an optional without checking, but this is codegolf.SE, we don't care. If you want to see an example with error checking, see my answer at [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141278/55934).

```
➕110
```

The formula used for A002057 appears to have an off-by-one error, so 1 is added to the input to make the offset correct.

```
️➕110
```

️ is called on the corrected input, calculating the sequence.

```
️➕110 10
```

You guessed it.  is a method of the  type that converts it to a , taking the base as an argument.

```
️➕110 10
```

Finally,  is used to print the result.

Comment: Wow, what's that? So colourful!

Comment: This is Emojicode, the only serious programming language that's bursting with emoji! Stay tuned for the explaination.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I just thought I'd notify you that now you can learn this beautiful, superior language on my example.

Answer (score 6):

## 178. [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org), 933 bytes, [A000214](https://oeis.org/A000214)

Luckily GAP wasn't taken for [No. 167](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143412/56725) (A000638)!

```
AG := function( n )
  local b, sw, sh, xr, tr, gens;
  b := BasisVectors(Basis(FullRowSpace(GF(2),n+1)));
  gens := [];
  if n>1 then
    sw := ShallowCopy(b);
    sw{[2,3]} := sw{[3,2]};
    sh := ShallowCopy(b);
    sh{[2..n+1]} := sh{Concatenation([n+1],[2..n])};
    xr := ShallowCopy(b);
    xr[2] := xr[2]+xr[3];
    gens := [ sw, sh, xr ];
  fi;
  tr := ShallowCopy(b);
  tr[2] := tr[1]+tr[2];
  Add(gens, tr);
  return Group(List(gens,TransposedMat));
end;

Fix := function( g )
  local o, h, s, i, k;
  o := One(g);
  s := 2^(Size(g)-1);
  i := 1;
  h := g;
  while not IsOne(h) do
    k := NullspaceMat( h-o );
    if ForAny( k, v -> IsOne(v[1]) ) then
      s := s + 2^(Size(k)-1);
    fi;
    i := i+1;
    h := h*g;
  od;
  return 2^(s/i);
end;

f := function( n )
  local grp;
  grp := AG(n+1); # zero based
  return Sum( ConjugacyClasses(grp),
              cc -> Size(cc)*Fix(Representative(cc)) ) / Order(grp);
end;
```

This is using somewhat advanced group theory (Burnside's lemma, twice), but no deep knowledge of the affine group. Still it is good enough to compute the 9th and 10th value (and more), which are:

```
3743090921588631997590183810292071781042846067942809230428008257901850006463197026597863697259931801933484260185559925420090026
479084991876032922658580043148767307553909132799686744495116429395794360341231625183693228836152593000430870733973647565874325953529940377811130038575926765372370447759627109606902989971984053705702177123141099357638755205930373003087364483930095902877678789627725054625735636
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000933)

#### How does it work?

There are `2^(2^n)` Boolean functions of `n` variables.
The affine group `AG(n,2)` acts on these functions by transforming
the input. An affine transformation can permute the input,
xor one input to another, and negate an input.
(xor is addition in the field with two elements, negation is
addition of one.)

If a Boolean functions can be transformed in this way into an other,
we consider them equivalent. The equivalence classes are called orbits.
We want to know how many orbits there are.

[Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)
tells us that the number of orbits of an action of a group `G` on a set `X`
equals the sum of the number of elements of `X` that are fixed by `g`
(the sum is over each element `g` of `G`) divided by the order (size) of the
group `G`.

Since the affine group is big for moderate sizes of `n`, we want to avoid
summing over all its elements. Conjugated elements fix the same number of
elements of `X`, so we can sum instead over conjugacy classes and multiply
with the size of the conjugacy class. There are not that much conjugacy
classes, and GAP can compute them in reasonable time. (I wasn't sure about
this when I started programming.)
This is what the main function `f` does, using helper functions `AG`
to create the affine group and `Fix` to determine the number of
boolean functions that are fixed by an affine transformation.

An affine transformation can be given by an invertible matrix `A` and an
translation vector `b`, it maps `x` to `Ax+b`. This can be brought into
the realm of linear algebra by embedding it into `n+1` dimensional space.
The affine transformation is represented by `[[1, 0], [b, A]]` (GAP wouldn't
accept this). To see where the `n` dimensional `x` is mapped to, add a first
component of `1`, multiply with the matrix, and drop the first component of
the result (which will be `1`). You can think of adding an extra input that
is always `1` and can not be changed by the transformation, but can be added
(xor-ed) to other inputs. The `AG` function creates the affine group as
matrix group using this representation.

We create the affine group using four generators, the first three are only
meaningful for `n>1`. The first swaps the first two inputs, the second
cyclically shifts the inputs. (For `n=2` they are the same, but that is
no problem.) Together they generate all permutations of inputs. The third
xors the second input to the first. By conjugation with a permutation, this
gives all needed xor operations. Together, these three matrices generate the
general (or special, that's the same in this case) linear group `GL(n,2)`.
The last generator negates the first input. Again, conjugation with a
permutation gives the other negations, so all matrices together generate the
affine group `AG(n,2)`. You may have noted that my thinking, explaining and
constructing has been in terms of right multiplying a column vector to a
matrix. GAP however uses row vectors and left multiplication. Since I will
use GAP's linear algebra functionality later, I compensate by transposing
the generating matrices before construction the group.

Now to the function `Fix`. We are given an affine transformation `g` and
want to calculate the number of Boolean functions that it fixes. A function
is fixed by `g` if it gives the same result to some input and to this input
transformed by `g` (or `g^2` etc). If an input can not be transformed into an
other by a power of `g`, then the function may give different results for them.
So the result is 2 to the number of classes of inputs that may get different
results. We can get this number by another application of Burnside's lemma!
This time the group is the cyclic group generated by `g`, and it is acting on
the set of inputs of size `2^n`. We really sum over all elements of the group
now. The identity fixes all inputs, so we start the sum `s` with this number.
Now assume we have a power `h` of `g` and want to know how many inputs it fixes.
That means we want to know how many `n+1` dimensional vectors with first
component `1` are fixed by the matrix `h`, or how many are mapped to zero by
`h-1`. So we use `NullspaceMat` to compute a basis of the kernel of `h-1`.
If that contains no element with a `1` at the first component, then there are
no solutions, otherwise there are half as many as the kernel size.
In the end `i` contains the number of elements of the cyclic group, by which
we divide the sum `s` as Burnside's lemma tells us.

The [last time](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867814/338756) I wrote
similar code I used it to compute some numbers which I could use to find
the series on OEIS and then find a better way to compute them there...

I guess that the algorithm could be improved a lot without very complicated
math. For example, I think it should be useful that the affine group is a
semidirect product, but we give it to GAP as if it were any random matrix group.

Now I hope this was useful or interesting for someone. I never know how much
detail I should give in an explanation here.

Answer (score 6):

## 226. [Java 7](http://openjdk.java.net/), 4903 bytes, [A000080](https://oeis.org/A000080/)

Originally programmed by HyperNeutrino.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract interface BooleanCombiner {
	abstract boolean combine(boolean left, boolean right);
}

class Main {
	static void print(boolean[][] matrix) {
		for (boolean[] row : matrix) {
			for (boolean e : row) {
				System.out.print(e ? 1 : 0);
				System.out.print(' ');
			}
			System.out.println();
		}
	}

	static boolean[] combine(boolean[] left, boolean[] right, BooleanCombiner f) {
		assert left.length == right.length;
		boolean[] result = new boolean[left.length];
		for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) result[i] = f.combine(left[i], right[i]);
		return result;
	}

	static boolean none(boolean[] row) {
		for (boolean element : row) if (element) return false;
		return true;
	}

	static boolean all(boolean[] row) {
		for (boolean element : row) if (!element) return false;
		return true;
	}

	static int weight(boolean[] row) {
		int weight = 0;
		for (boolean element : row) if (element) weight++;
		return weight;
	}

	static boolean[] DFS(boolean[][] matrix, int node, boolean[] visited) {
		assert visited.length == matrix.length;
		if (visited[node]) return visited;
		visited[node] = true;
		for (int neighbor = 0; neighbor < visited.length; ++neighbor) {
			if (matrix[node][neighbor]) DFS(matrix, neighbor, visited);
		}
		return visited;
	}

	static boolean isConnected(boolean[][] matrix) {
		return all(DFS(matrix, 0, new boolean[matrix.length]));
	}

	static int[][] triples(int length) {
		int[][] triples = new int[length * ~-length * ~-~-length / 6][];
		int index = 0;
		for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
			for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
				for (int k = j + 1; k < length; k++) {
					triples[index++] = new int[] { i, j, k };
				}
			}
		} return triples;
	}

	static boolean isomorphic(boolean[][] a, boolean[][] b) {
		int[] permutation = new int[a.length];
		for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length; ++i) permutation[i] = i;
		while (true) {
			// check here
			boolean maybe_valid = true;
			for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length && maybe_valid; ++i) {
				for (int j = 0; j < permutation.length; ++j) {
					if (a[i][j] != b[permutation[i]][permutation[j]]) {
						maybe_valid = false;
						break;
					}
				}
			}
			if (maybe_valid) {
				return true; // actually valid!
			}
			
			// advance the permutation here. Implement C++'s std::next_permutation
			int j = permutation.length - 1;
			while (j != 0) {
				if (permutation[j - 1] > permutation[j]) --j;
				else break;
			}
			if (j == 0) break; // reached last permutation
			// reverse [j, permutation.length) segment
			for (int k = j, l = permutation.length - 1; k < l; ++k, --l) {
				int tmp = permutation[k]; permutation[k] = permutation[l]; permutation[l] = tmp;
			}
			// find smallest element in [j, permutation.length) that is still larger than permutation[j-1]
			int k = j; // sorry, meaningless variable name;
			while (permutation[k] < permutation[j-1]) ++k;
			int tmp = permutation[j-1]; permutation[j-1] = permutation[k]; permutation[k] = tmp;
		};
		return false;
	}

	static boolean[][] construct (int size, boolean[] mask, int[][] triples_table) {
		assert triples_table.length == mask.length;
		boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[size][size];
		for (int index = 0; index < mask.length; ++index) {
			if (mask[index]) {
				int[] triple = triples_table[index];
				int i = triple[0], j = triple[1], k = triple[2];
				matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][k] = matrix[k][i] = matrix[j][k] = matrix[k][j] = true;
			}
		}
		return matrix;
	}

	
	static List<boolean[][]> calculate (int size) {
		List<boolean[][]> matrices = new ArrayList<>();
		int[][] triples_table = triples(size);
		boolean[] mask = new boolean[triples_table.length];
		while (true) {
			boolean[][] matrix = construct(size, mask, triples_table);
			process_matrix:
			if (isConnected(matrix)) {
				// check if matrix is isomorphic to any existing matrix
				for (boolean[][] existing_matrix : matrices) {
					if (isomorphic(matrix, existing_matrix)) break process_matrix;
				}
				// check if the matrix is minimal
				for (int delete_triple = 0; delete_triple < mask.length; ++delete_triple) {
					if (! mask[delete_triple]) continue;
					mask[delete_triple] = false; // temporarily set to false
					if (isConnected(construct(size, mask, triples_table))) {
						// it is not minimal
						mask[delete_triple] = true; // remember to restore it ... 
						break process_matrix;
					}
					mask[delete_triple] = true; // ... in any condition
				}
				/* it is both minimal and not counted now, */ matrices.add(matrix);
			}
			
			int i = mask.length - 1;
			while (i >= 0 && mask[i]) mask[i--] = false;
			if (i == -1) return matrices; // considered all <mask> possible.
			mask[i] = true;
		}
	}
	
	public static void main(String[] args) {
		System.out.println(calculate(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + 3).size());
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVhLbxs3ED5bv2J8SaRoJdsN0IPXdtGmKBCgPeUoLAxKS0lc7UPgUn40UP66O8PXkqsVkjQHZ8kZDme@eVIFe2KzZs/rIt@9vYlq30gFBW7OD0qU89@lZK9tOjoh/C1aNbCt@Q1txJatkmylQNSKyzVbcfijaUrO6k9NtRQ1l/B1dOG5loYGK0Mcu3XJ1yrxVCk2WzVJR8fRaFWytoV/mKhJTquYEit4akQOe4lXOgGLbJFBxZQULxNivFg3EjoiyOYZbiOGiAM4UpHHki6@vLaKV/PmoObmGg6/wQ3yXKNWgwzv4b0hHUcD5LIeayoS0SZnRqdeDw7ciQAhAwiS5ATbtdEYMeLoIjo0L3m9UVu4vzdn7JpuD6Tx9lAquIeaP/tLgtNZ6iBE5UEg43WK/93Zg04miOl0YvcWIkO29dyZQtJwLzFa4JcGQHJ1kLU9kg6hAXUTAeG9Evur5BVH1azXxBrGdov00XesWdny4E4lD3z4RlaW/@fCy5@/kdB85gTI0IUdVQP@MzabY9NpcLvZSs9E3J9/fRnInURrWDc5D2PvSbRC8TwKNbsXRJuREIQbKWjZFiQy80DZXWKKGNBsi1kXfDWZscSVjkG/uutpkMJ06og2i@l@o5SRvnB0VITMdya77cQbalP14kTdgeAR7aemrvkKGc4WIyuH4iy8@DqJ8i8CMJtMTkJHy0WefclbjY1h9cET0m1u06510Qf4Ngs@/eIKfsVzqY0/Uef8JQq/XgWIUr8rpMRVIJeAKdyk@NlxFp6zY90ha2FYdwHrrmO9sIYstEbTaRZYlMFXEAkUCR4@moJ8dLX3CD779PlzXmuqRu63YhU5jQVhj8tlAC3suawOJKWpA1XY9ypmcCwIVTEJCaZ2ChLxvBUlhzGlgUXi6gpWW77awZZLThvOhoq9LvnjEyuxGXaJ84NKwLt3oQCrU89LhZFQnDWj8N6iZGNox6LI4PIelovYvCxaF1nmD17EZvgaSv@WkrOdXRxjN9vs9kedvLD0AkKHQ8cB8@4VNNelP26RZfkTq3FmUVseOZiwnsPnam9r7qfp9H0Lrcpvb2v@oh4DXq2MBWsA5xnGOLFYxxaEzrXTloyIgCH2DB4gRmsCs1lhcOAID3S4eCgKKsEo15DIcvzAuMkBBygFPX01@YlLlLXALDpVewIt35Dlo5OsTaA8b6nJZgqNXYJKl95QPK2qfXxwscvS3rrHUPYYSt0iqn1nO1qyxgoBbYVe5mip65I4MJ4zTW0Z0smdoiwRH7nBSQo36xj22U3mfKsN16i2jZSvCVSYgKLe4I0tRpYUbInOrVnFQ1/3TLs7ET8hnNLRWXyIJz3Z@REQLUbHYB5wmTU0DugRtMYZ/YAzunZ1K/6NZoCKtbuk34QeFdkdzQURJZoO2t3QKOo7ZW8Ypfsz8zeurL4/2c@7SDSVMdqORoB2Z5pIFkSjN0KXzkBny5r6sBWeY3GN42zRLW@yREeGXf5iD9mZw9RCNxfht6nyHXUXLHcxtTihFuFwZBpd51rDZn3rvUsvtLsA6AdYsXJ1KJninY8NJKesWuTKzxH@yXf3YF4yg5HQYTnWsuNHBzmi5@WhaMmG2@BgxPigHZt4NVEaR6cGbC8bNKZ9NCdvXWyEw5sd2FyM@LaLfPY@LBnd3ACqAVa/An9BVLAUWKaugYYKOyZ7v3uKokpRAw2mEjcj9k5ObIWH2KBgBooUp7bWKV@JWmCZjHt8jgVT8UefDJhY8dZJgkXkSP9LzbqIGDDp0EtowsG19QEe3/ipxOLLed9ILKrYtVuuCGhNDHHq3PYjITDppg2UL3TxrxsVAXJOLz9JSOwr1ZI6RUPvV9VITqLm8zmE48qgZ6xrvncFycK@RWGFZuXCtWvn2Q9W92WDRdUqj9y5NmbVHGoEBL@fE/hw5SNsznIf3Gk0/7jqFvi3P64IeMCQMMMilVH0pvmYzbJoWtNuoUI/u/HPPKeBto38JHIcq3J6B8EdicE5p2lbQbk/cuiIsNDp30tQ1/1hWWLKhT//VEzU4y94Qb2hwV1ubCoN/PTiy974MyKEzX6@Zzj64GJM57CsYyOGj5M5RdDYPryOb29vH/8D)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A004903)

Comment: Nice! @HyperNeutrino Did you find out what was the problem with the lean fish graph?

Comment: @J.Salle user202729 pointed it out to me; my `isValid` function didn't work because one of the cycles didn't have any vertices with order `2` because rather than disconnecting a single node, it split the graph. Credit goes to them, not me :)

Comment: `abstract interface` makes me sad... and now it's immortalized here since you aren't allowed to change it...

Comment: Very nice. Next sequence looks easy enough even I might give it a try hahahah

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix `Originally programmed by HyperNeutrino`.

Comment: I'm confused about how, for the next sequence, `0` is a sum of _any_ NONZERO 10th powers, unless I'm totally misreading it...

Comment: @Giuseppe Sum of 0 numbers in the set `{1,2^10,3^10,...}` is 0. The sequence said "at most 8 numbers".

Comment: Is the next sequence infinite?

Comment: @Stephen Yes. (well you need to read the sequence details if you want to implement it anyway, so why asking?)

Answer (score 6):

## 233. [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 141 bytes, [A000332](https://oeis.org/A000332)

```
    ? } = & \
   . . @ } ( .
  ( . . . _ . .
 . } . . 2 & . .
. . * . 4 . { . .
 . . ' \ ' \ * . 
  . . ( . : . "
   . . { ! . .
    . . * . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/18BCOwVahVsFdQUarmAHH0FdQUzIKdawQbI1VOwAmII1OICU3YKigoOYJYSl62CtoImWLcWkNRU0OeCq4ZCsBmofHQugvf/v6EBAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000141)

**Note:** due to problems with remembering to check whether a bytecount was used before (to be clear: in this case, not by me), this answer has changed 2 times in total, with each of the 3 programs having a full explanation. Check the revision history if you want.

### Explanation

<s>There's practically no control flow here.</s> The code has one, constant execution path. It starts at the top left corner going right, gets reflected by multiple mirrors, wraps around a few times and passes through unrelated instructions after printing the result to end at the `@` (I'm sorry) in the second row. For reference, here's a picture of the execution path, with a color change every time it hits a mirror. I also changed the color during a long stretch of instructions on the bottom left to make the wraparound clear.

[image: control flow diagram]

The code operates on 3 memory edges: let's call the one we start on A, the one to the left of it - L, and the one to the right of A - R. `binomial(n, 4)` can be evaluated with the formula `n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/24`, which is imminent if you think about it, and a similar one could be created for every constant value of the bottom argument. Let's consider the linear path the code takes:

```
?}=&(}=*{('*}("*{&24':!*=@
?                          Input integer. A = n
 }=&                       Move to the R edge and copy the value of n. R = n
    (                      Decrement. R = n - 1
     }=                    Move to the L edge.
       *                   L = A * R = n(n-1)
        {(                 Move to the R edge and decrement. R = n - 2
          '                Equivalent to ={=, move to the A edge.
           *               A = L * R = n(n-1)(n-2)
            }(             Move to the R edge and decrement. R = n - 3
              "            Equivalent to =}=, move to the L edge.
               *           L = A * R = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)
                {&         Move to the R edge and set it to 0 using an edge that
                           hasn't been used before
                  24       Set the value of the R edge to 24. A digit in Hexagony
                           multiplies the edge value by 10 and adds its value to
                           it, which allows chaining them to create multi-digit
                           numbers, but requires the value of the edge to be 0
                    '      Equivalent to ={=, move to the A edge
                     :     A = L / R = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/24 = a(n)
                      !    Print the result
                       *=  Instructions that happen to be in the execution path
                           and not disrupt it
                         @ End the program
```

Answer (score 6):

## 241. [Trefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 230 bytes, [A000256](https://oeis.org/A000256)

```
       v   >51>R1-:v>RRO:8*'+-*'9+*O3*9-2Pv
>4      (&:|  \    >|v   ;>v;      <:R: -4<
^"FRTH"<@.1<  +  @.$<>R1-:|>\1-RO*\^
 ^ useful     1     v\0\$$< A000256
 library      \     >:1-:v >\:v
O:8*'3-*'Q+/4/^     ^    _$^ *_$/7*\-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7dCsIwDIXv@xRBikpHXavzZ7UEvRHvpsXL0qEwRRCRqQVh7z63NpBw4OQk36eurt/nreL5ir9@QbYtxPJd41yikVx5NKZQKzZKOBvlCStmLOfTgyeYxeXxUDUAtpfY9Mk1@nW0tDIKeKaJG@zMaT/Qm4nUAAnAZkJ1ON@gldwUzDoCDr7vDuoRsjKSWGEp1bAVQkznCwKP@6U@1794PzwFVD0moFWeBNJZR3pM0ix1wQ@zpA5YSdMls7xtZS7IHw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000230)

To understand this monstrosity, you first need a quick primer on Funge:

- All variants of Funge are primarily stack based.
- The stack can only contain numbers.
- Befunge is a 2D language. While Trefunge is 3D, this code would work fine without the third dimension.
- `<^>v` are used to redirect execution exactly like you would expect.
- `+-*/` do addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.
- Digits push the corresponding number on the stack
- The instruction pointer starts in the upper left corner pointing right.
- Space is a no-op
- `"` toggles stringmode. In stringmode, the ASCII code of each character is pushed on the stack

```
       v
>4      (
^"FRTH"<
```

You can see that immediately the execution is redirected on the string `"FRTH"`. Because the execution goes right to left, 70 (`F`) is on the top of the stack. Then the number `4` is pushed and `(` loads the fingerprint.

Fingerprints are similar to libraries from other languages, except they are not created in Funge,  which would make them more of a language extension. Fingerprints change the semantics of the commands `A` through `Z`, which normally all act like `r` (reflect). You can load fingerprints using `(`, which more or less pops the number of characters the fingerprint code takes and then pops the characters themselves.

The `FRTH` fingerprint stands for FORTH, because it includes some useful stack manipulation primitives that originated from FORTH. This program uses the following of them:

- `R` - rotate. `(... a b c) -> (... b c a)`
- `O` - over. `(... a b) -> (... a b a)`. Equivalent to `1P`.
- `P` - push. Takes a number n and copies the element buried n elements deep to the top. For example, `2P` would change the stack like this:
  `(... a b c) -> (... a b c a)`

```
   >51>R1-
(&:|  \
@.1<  +
```

After loading the fingerprint, `&` inputs a number and pushes it on the stack. 
`:` is used to duplicate it because `|` consumes one copy. `|` is the vertical conditional. If the number it consumed is zero, it's equivalent to `v`. Otherwise, it acts like `^`.

It is used here because the input of zero needs to be a special case - the loop counter would immediately go negative making the loop infinite and OEIS claims that the formula only works for `n > 4`. If zero is passed, `1` is pushed, `.` is used to output it and `@` ends the program.

You can also see here the beginning of the main loop of the program. The loop begins with `R1-` and ends with `+\`. The stack at the beginning of each iteration looks like this: `i n a(n-1)`. `i-1` is the number of repetitions the program will do, since it is decremented and compared at the beginning of the loop. `n` is the index in the sequence of the value we will be computing, while `a(n-1)` is the previous value. We implement this formula from the OEIS:

```
a(n) = (1/4)*(7*binomial(3*n-9, n-4)-(8*n^2-43*n+57)*a(n-1)) / (8*n^2-51*n+81)
```

Let's tackle the main loop itself:

```
R1-:v>RRO:
    >|
  @.$<
```

`R` brings `i` to the top. Funge doesn't have a decrement instruction, so we subtract `1` explicitly with `-`. We duplicate the new `i` with `:` for testing with `|`. If we're finished, we will hit the `<` and execute the following linear code:

```
$.@    The stack is now: n a(n-1) i
$      Discard i
 .     Output a(n-1)
  @    Exit.
```

In most cases, however, `|` will act like `^`, which will make the interpreter execute this long stretch of linear code (ignoring the line wrap):

```
RRO:8*'+-*'9+*O3*9-2P4- The stack is now: n a(n-1) i
RR                      Bury i where it belongs. Stack: i n a(n-1)
  O:                    Copy n to the top and duplicate. Stack: i n a(n-1) n n
    8*                  Multiply by 8. Stack: i n a(n-1) n 8n
      '+                Use the ASCII value of + to push 43 on the stack
        -               Subtract 43. Stack: i n a(n-1) n 8n-43
         *              Multiply. Stack: i n a(n-1) 8n^2-43n
          '9+           Add 57. Stack: i n a(n-1) 8n^2-43n+57
             *          Multiply. Stack: i n (8n^2 - 43n + 57)*a(n-1)
              O         Copy n to the top. Stack: i n (...)*a(n-1) n
               3*9-     Compute 3n-9. Stack: i n (...)*a(n-1) 3n-9
                   2P4- Copy n to the top, compute n-4.
                        Stack: i n (...)*a(n-1) 3n-9 n-4. Notice how the top two
                        elements are the arguments for the binomial.
```

We will now compute the binomial(n, k) using the following algorithm which I've come up with myself a few sequences before, but it's probably not anything innovative, since it is obvious when you look at the formula. You can also see it in my Boo answer above.

- Multiply k numbers starting with n, going down
- Divide by the factorial of k

Let's only consider the very top of the stack when considering the algorithm.

```
v   ;>v;      <:R:
>R1-:|>\1-RO*\^
  \$$<
```

This is the part before computing the factorial. After `:R:`, the `;` is a bridge, which skips the `>v` part.

```
   v   ;>v;      <
:R:>R1-:|>\1-RO*\^ Stack: n k
:                  Duplicate. Stack: n k k
 R                 Rotate. Stack: k k n
  :                Duplicate. Stack: k k n n. The bottommost k is used later.
                   The other k is the loop counter. The topmost n is the number
                   we're multiplying by, while the other n is the partial product.
   >               The loop starts here. Let's rename the variables and ignore
                   the bottom k. Stack: k product n
    R1-            Decrement k. Stack: product n k-1
       :|>         Exit the loop if k-1 is zero. Uses the >v part that is skipped
                   using a bridge
          \1-      Bring n to the top and decrement. Stack: product k-1 n-1
             R     Rotate. Stack: k-1 n-1 product
              O    Over. Stack: k-1 n-1 product n-1
               *   Multiply - extend the partial product.
                   Stack: k-1 n-1 (product)(n-1)
                \  Swap, restoring the stack to the order from the start of the
                   loop. Stack: k-1 (product)(n-1) n-1
                 ^ Jump to the beginning.
```

When the loop ends, we execute this:

```
$$\                Stack: k p n-k 0
$$                 Discard the top two elements, we only need the product
  \                Bring k to the top for computing the factorial. Stack: p k
```

Let's consider the factorial code:

```
v\0
>:1-:v >\:v
^    _$^ *_$
```

It consists of two loops. Let's consider the factorial of 4.

```
0\>:1-:v_$ Stack: 4
0\         Push the marker used in the second loop, swap. Stack: 0 4
  >        The loop starts here
   :1-     Duplicate and decrement. Stack: 0 4 3
      :v_  Duplicate for the comparsion, loop if not 0.
  >        Consider the loop again, with stack: 0 4 3 2 1
   :1-     Duplicate and decrement. Stack: 0 4 3 2 1 0
      :v_  Duplicate for the comparsion and exit the loop.
         $ Discard the top 0. Stack: 0 4 3 2 1
```

The second loop multiplies the numbers together, while 0 is marking the end.

```
>\:v_*  Stack: 0 4 3 2 1
>       The loop starts here
 \      Swap. Stack: 0 4 3 1 2
  :v_   If the top element is 0, end the loop
     *  Multiply. Stack: 0 4 3 2
>       Consider the loop again, with stack: 0 4 6
 \      Swap. Stack: 0 6 4
  :v_   (doesn't end the loop)
     *  Multiply. Stack: 0 24
>       Finally, let's see how the loop terminates.
 \      Swap. Stack: 24 0
  :v_   Ends the loop. Stack: 24 0
```

Let's finish the main loop, since it now consists of only linear code. It is useful to see the formula while following the code:

```
a(n) = (1/4)*(7*binomial(3*n-9, n-4)-(8*n^2-43*n+57)*a(n-1)) / (8*n^2-51*n+81)
```

Let's mark the numerator `x` and the denominator `y`, to simplify the description.

```
a(n) = (1/4)*x/y
```

Keep it mind that when the instruction pointer hits the edge of the Fungespace, it wraps around.

```
$/7*\-O:8*'3-*'Q+/4/\1+\ Stack: i-1 n (...)*a(n-1) p k! 0
$                        Discard the 0 marker from the factorial loop.
 /                       Divide to compute the binomial.
                         Stack: i-1 n (...)*a(n-1) binomial(3n-9 n-4)
  7*                     Multiply by 7. Stack: i-1 n (...)*a(n-1) 7*binomial
    \-                   Swap and subtract. Stack: i-1 n 7*binomial-(...)*a(n-1)
      O:                 Over, duplicate. Stack: i-1 n x n n
        8*               Multiply by 8. Stack: i-1 n x n 8n
          '3-            Subtract 51. Stack: i-1 n x n 8n-51
             *           Multiply. Stack: i-1 n x 8n^2-51n
              'Q+        Add 81. Stack i-1 n x 8n^2-51n+81
                 /       Divide. Stack: i-1 n x/y
                  4/     Divide by 4. Stack: i-1 n a(n)
                    \1+\ Increment n. Stack: i-1 n+1 a(n), or as the next
                         iteration would call it: i n a(n-1)
```

Comment: "nominator"? Should it be "numerator"?

Comment: @user202729 You are right. That's what you get when you don't learn math in English... :P

Comment: Also can you add an explanation what is the sequence?

Comment: @user202729 I totally would if my current understanding of this sequence aligned with the values given by the OEIS.

Answer (score 6):

## 253. [MIT/GNU Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), 1516 bytes, [A000251](https://oeis.org/A000251)

```
(define (add f g)
  (stream-map + f g) )

(define (sub f g)
  (stream-map - f g) )

(define (scale c f)
  (stream-map (lambda (v) (* c v)) f) )

(define (adddiag sf)
  (let ((f0 (stream-first sf)))
    (cons-stream (stream-first f0)
                 (add (stream-rest f0) (adddiag (stream-rest sf))) ) ) )

(define (mult f g)
  (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (v) (scale v g)) f)) )

(define (prependzeros n f)
  (if (= 0 n) f (cons-stream 0 (prependzeros (-1+ n) f))) )

(define (intersperse f n)
  (cons-stream (stream-first f)
               (prependzeros n (intersperse (stream-rest f) n)) ) )

(define (iterate fun init)
  (cons-stream init (iterate fun (fun init))) )

(define (from n)
  (iterate 1+ n) )

(define (scanl fun init s)
  (cons-stream init (scanl fun (fun init (stream-first s)) (stream-rest s))) )

(define (expx f)
  (cons-stream 1
               (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (s g) (scale (/ 1 s) g))
                                    (scanl * 1 (from 2))
                                    (iterate (lambda (g) (mult f g)) f) )) ) )

(define (eu f)
  (expx (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (n) (scale (/ 1 n)
                                                (intersperse f (-1+ n)) ))
                             (from 1) ))) )


(define ones
  (cons-stream 1 ones) )

(define s
  (iterate eu ones) )

(define r
  (stream-map sub (stream-rest s) s) )

(define t6
  (sub (stream-ref r 1)
       (cons-stream 0 (mult (stream-first r) (stream-ref s 1))) ) )

(define (f n)
  (stream-ref t6 (+ 6 n)) )
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001516)

Use like this:

```
$ scheme -load t6.scm
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
[...]
1 ]=> (f 49)

;Value: 1110994054004
```

This answer is based on generating functions given in J. Riordan's paper
*The Enumeration of Trees by Hight and Diameter* mentioned
at the OEIS entry of the sequence. Equation numbers will refer to this paper.

First, let `s_h(x)` be the counting generation function of rooted trees with
height at most `h` by number of nodes, i.e. the coefficient of `x^n` will
give the number of such trees with `n` nodes. All our generating functions
will count by number of nodes in this way.

We can get one such function from the previous by eq. (1):

> s_{h+1}(x)=x*exp(s_h(x)+s_h(x^2)/2+s_h(x^3)/3+...)

This is a shifted
[Euler transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html),
which makes sense: the transformation takes a series `a_0=0, a_1, a_2...`
where the `a_i` tell in how many ways you can get a thing of
size/weight/whatever `i` and gives a series `b_0=1, b_1, b_2...` where
`b_j` tells in how many ways you can get a multiset of such things with total
size/weight/... of `j`.
A rooted tree of height at most `h+1` corresponds to a bunch (multiset) of
rooted trees of hight at most `h`, with all their roots connected to a new root,
which explains the shifting (multiplication with `x`).

My function `eu` (I'm reusing a big part of my solution
[No. 122](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141287/56725))
to compute the Euler transformation takes a sequence starting
with `a_1` and returns a sequence starting with `b_0`. If we keep
our sequences starting with the coefficient of `x`, we just need to iterate
the `eu` function and the shifting is automatic.
The code defines `s` as infinite
stream of `s_h` (the highest we need is `s_3`, but it is still simpler like
this), where we could start with `s_0(x)=x`, or even `s_{-1}(x)=0`, but we
start with `s_1(x)=x/(1-x)=x+x^2+x^3+...`. BTW, `s_2` is almost the generating
function for the partition numbers, just shifted.

Next, let `r_h(x)` be the generating function for rooted trees with height
exactly `h`. Obviously, we have `r_h(x)=s_h(x)-s_{h-1}(x)`.
The code defines `r` to be the stream of these `r_h`, starting with `r_2`.

Finally, let `t_d(x)` be the generating function for trees of diameter `d`.
For even `d`, thos can be expressed by eq. (6a) as

> t_{2d}(x) = r_d(x) - r_{d-1}(x)*s_{d_1}(x)

The paper derives this formula algebraically from some other, but it can
also be seen directly by comparing coefficients. For fixed `d` and `n` it claims that
there are as many rooted trees of height `d` and with `n` nodes, as there
are elements in the disjoint union of (1) trees of diameter `2d` and with
`n` nodes, and (2) pairs of rooted trees of height `d-1` and of rooted trees
of height at most `d-1`, where the pair has a total number of `n` nodes.
This can be shown by a bijection: given a rooted tree of height `d`, remove
the root and look at the multiset of subtrees you get. At least one of
them has height `d-1`. If there are more than that, then the original
tree was of diameter `2d`. So forget the root and map it to this
tree. Otherwise, form a pair with the one subtree of size `d-1`, and
a tree of size at most `d-1` that is created by rejoining the other
subtrees with a new root.
(Details are left as an exercise to the reader...)

The code directly defines `t_6` according to this formula.
Since we kept the generating functions starting with `x` while
the multiplication function expects series starting with the constant
term, the result must be interpreted as starting with the coefficient
of `x^2`. To compensate, we put a `0` in front of it.

And if you ever need to enumerate trees with odd diameter, their
generating function is given by eq. (5) as

> t_{2d+1}(x) = (r_d^2(x)+r_d(x^2))/2

Comment: Cutting it a little close, don't you think?

Comment: Since just using some formula isn't very well recieved, I wanted to give time for other solutions. (But now I mostly understand what I do...) And I had to look for a free language, and initially didn't want to use scheme again.

Comment: There are reasonable hints towards eq. 5 in OEIS, but nothing towards eq. 6a. Did you find an electronic copy of the paper or did you have to go to a library? Either way, well done.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I went to a library.

Answer (score 6):

## 259. [Hy](http://hylang.org), 1333 bytes, [A000329](https://oeis.org/A000329)

```
(setv precision 80)

(import decimal)

(setv ctx (.getcontext decimal))
(setv ctx.prec precision)
(setv Decimal decimal.Decimal)

(defn approx-pi [series-terms]
  (sum
    (list-comp
      (/ (- (/ 4 (Decimal (+ 1 (* 8 n))))
            (/ 2 (Decimal (+ 4 (* 8 n))))
            (/ 1 (Decimal (+ 5 (* 8 n))))
            (/ 1 (Decimal (+ 6 (* 8 n)))))
         (** 16 n))
      (n (range series-terms)))))

(setv pi (approx-pi precision))

(defn cos [x series-terms]
  (cond
    [(>= x (* 2 pi))
     (cos (- x (* 2 pi)) series-terms)]
    [(neg? x)
     (cos (- x) series-terms)]
    [(>= x (/ (* 3 pi) 2))
     (cos (- (* 2 pi) x) series-terms)]
    [(>= x pi)
     (- (cos (- x pi) series-terms))]
    [(>= x (/ pi 2))
     (- (cos (- pi x) series-terms))]
    [True
     (sum
       (list-comp
         (*
           (if (even? n) 1 -1)
           (reduce *
             (list-comp
               (/ x (inc i))
               (i (range (* 2 n))))
             1))
         (n (range series-terms))))]))

(defn tan [x series-terms]
  (/
    (cos (- x (/ pi 2)) series-terms)
    (cos x series-terms)))

(setv bvalues {0 (Decimal 1)})

(defn b [n]
  (try
    (get bvalues n)
    (except [KeyError]
      (do
        (assoc bvalues n (tan (b (dec n)) precision))
        (get bvalues n)))))

(defn A000329 [n]
  (int (round (b n))))
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001333)

The difficulty with this sequence is that it's an [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function), which means that small floating-point errors are magnified as `n` increases. So we need very accurate numbers. Enter Python's `decimal` module, which supports arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic!

Because the `decimal` module doesn't seem to have trig functions, I reimplemented `pi` and `cos`. To calculate pi, I used the series approximation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14179), which converged pretty fast. For cosine, I used the [MacLaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions). Then I implemented `tan` as sine over cosine, with `sin(x) = cos(x - pi/2)`.

Finally, I used the definition of A000329 from OEIS: "Nearest integer to b(n), where b(n) = tan(b(n-1)), b(0) = 1." I memoized the definition of `b`--not really necessary, but speeds up the generation of tables of values. Some experimentation showed that a decimal precision of 80 was sufficient to correctly compute n = 1000.

Now, of course, Python itself has already been used in this challenge, so the next task was to find a Python-based language that hadn't been used yet. I found Hy, which is basically Python with Lisp syntax. One translation, new Ubuntu VM, and language installation later, and voilà!

Answer (score 6):

## 336. [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 159 bytes, [A000620](https://oeis.org/A000620)

```
b:[1]
c:[1]
Fi1,a+1{
 d:0
 e:2*(i%3%2)*c@(i/3)
 Fj,i{
  Fk,i-j{
   Ij=k{ d+:b@j * b@(i-j-k-1) }
   e+:c@j * c@k * c@(i-j-k-1)
  }
 }
 bAE:d
 cAE:e//3
}
c@v-b@v
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##PYq7CsMgGIX3/yn@JRBvWCN0EAJ2qNBnKB3qZVCXTFlCnt0ah8LhnAPft@WtNW/e6gNhtMuKf5k6AKO5ASaz0DlPeloIDXbOUhNAV3juArrKsyjXw1dZ64GRGW8LUvRdFUVUoQieF0/MhEGCraP/vNNu9PjH00TA0CdJqeGEYHfh7d5aU/cf)

[Next sequence](//oeis.org/A000159)

---

Basically this uses A000620 = A000625 - A000621 and the generating function relations for A000625 and A000621. I'm no chemist, but by the power of species theory I think I can reverse engineer the logic behind the g.f. relations, at least for one interpretation of the sequences. We're interested in monosubstituted alkanes, which correspond to graphs which are trees where every node has valence 4 (carbon atom) or 1 (either hydrogen atom or the substituted part, X).

In other words, modulo the trivial cases, we have a marked carbon atom which is attached to X:

```
   X
   |
a--C--b
   |
   d
```

The 3D geometry is relevant to the symmetries. The carbon atom is at the centre of a tetrahedron, and the other four elements are at the four vertices. Rotating around the axis `CX` doesn't change the molecule, so we'll need to avoid double-counting.

Note that if we consider the diagram from the perspective of e.g. `a`, the rest of the diagram (`CXbd`) can be considered as an `X`, and that's the heart of the recurrence logic.

If we ignore all restrictions and symmetry then by elementary species theory we have a generating function with recurrence \$F(x) = 1 + xF(x)^3\$. The \$1\$ corresponds to the special case that there's one molecule with 0 carbon atoms (`X`); the \$xF(x)^3\$ says that a molecule with \$n\$ carbon items can be identified with a molecule with one (\$x^1\$) identified carbon atom and then the remaining \$n-1\$ carbons are supplied by three smaller instances of the same type of object (`a`, `b`, `d`).

A000621 counts the non-stereoisomeric molecules. That means that they're symmetric: `a = b`, and all of `a`, `b`, `d` are non-stereoisomeric<sup>1</sup>.  That gives generating function \$G(x) = 1 + xG(x)G(x^2)\$. The \$x\$ corresponds to the identified carbon atom `C`; the \$G(x)\$ corresponds to `d`; and the \$G(x^2)\$ corresponds to `a` and `b` being equal. (It uses \$x^2\$ to count each carbon atom in `a` twice).

A000625 counts all molecules under the rotational symmetry about the axis `CX`. If `a`, `b`, `d` are all different then there are three rotational positions, so we need to divide by 3; if two of them are the same then there are still three rotational positions; if all three are the same then there is only one rotational position, so we don't want to divide by three. We have g.f. \$H(x) = 1 + \frac13 xH(x)^3 + \frac23 xH(x^3)\$ where the final term is to bring the weight of the case where `a=b=d` back up from \$\frac13\$ to \$1\$.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually the choice that `a = b` is arbitrary, but works out nicely. We could alternatively consider the cases `a = d` and `b = d` as well, but then we have to divide by 3 to account for the symmetry.

Answer (score 6):

## 344. [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 301 bytes, [A000382](http://oeis.org/A000382)

```
p = a => {
	if len(a) == 1 return [a]
	values = []
	for i : 0 .. len(a)
		for j : p(a[to i] + a[i + 1 to])
			values.append([a[i]] + j)
	return values
}

a = n => {
	total = 0
	n += 4
	for j : p(0 .. n)
		if all((j[i] - i) % n < 4 for i : 0 .. n)
			total++
	return total
}

print(a(int(input())) / 4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NisMwDITP8VPMpWATmv6QU6n3RUwOgqbgYGTjOr0s@@xZOQ2lvQhG@jwzTjmWyMuSYEGwP/hVjb8jjKzJwFqckMcyZ4ajQTVPCvP4ENaJuMcMjwuO6LrthWrW7STbpMmVCD@gBTkv84QSh4psNh2lNPJNOzkPFZvkuKW9CPWnlLQCb81KLBREH1XDaC169RG31uDqLx@gELSexBd7eIOdWFzR46vyyr482/advOoanLLnoknX6TnNRRtjcEBvluX8Dw)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000301)

This code takes a long time on `n = 2` and I don't want to try testing it on larger cases :P In theory, it works for all cases; the code is an exact implementation of the sequence description, so no fancy math stuff that could break.

Inefficient Coding 101 with hyper-neutrino \o/

(this is intentionally posted from my bot account. someone downvoted one of my posts and now I only have 19 reputation, which isn't enough to chat. and also I'm not going to go upvote it with my main account because that's
evil, so I'm making a new post to earn some reputation, hopefully)

Comment: does it count as chaining myself if I use a different account LOL (obviously yes)

Comment: The next sequence should be rather easy; `ÆḞ2*` should work in Jelly.

Comment: Haha, beep boop go brrr

Comment: Hi yes hello beep boop. This is good mesage

Answer (score 5):

## 4. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes, [A000038](https://oeis.org/A000038)

```
ṆḤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzraHO5b8///fAAA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000002)

Comment: Noo, Kolakoski....

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder well that's why it's called a "challenge"

Comment: `I deleted this because I don't want to use Jelly just yet;` so much for that

Comment: And I even had `f(x){return!x*2;}` in ANSI C...

Answer (score 5):

## 12. [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 131 bytes, [A000064](https://oeis.org/A000064)

```java
int f(int n){int[]a=new int[n+1],c={1,2,5,10,1};a[0]=1;for(int i=0,j,k;i<5;i++)for(j=c[i],k=0;j<=n;j++,k++)a[j]+=a[k];return a[n];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/PisMgEMbPyVN4jOiGWOjJ@gh76lE8uGla1HQS1LSUkGfPjoGFZWC@@cM3/Mbbl/2a5gH8Lezz8jO6nvSjTYl8Wwfr7iCTe1My0BVFG6tgeJNSAhOG92oV/MTPXHRcbNLqzigh71M8TE513PMg3eUsHWO0zL3qtTM8qE76iwLpGeMBd1Z7w5TVwcg45CUCsRqM3P6wUrYZ5TW5G3kiXHPN0cEDieIj0bWuCvGxIYoUxtI3VNbVPxokOXUHChqq6yfl4dlOS25nvJVHaIq/xY9pMW41xv4L)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000131)

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY/BjoMgEIbP@hQcJbBGm/REOewD7KlHwmFqbQMqGsBuGuOz25nNhmT@4Sf/zIeHF3zNSx/8fTjctMwxM49evWY31t8xwjupcllvo@tYN0JK7Adc2A4XMntUVAPfSMBYHfpfhr0JorWyQ2Nr5UmeZdtIMI3V7S6dbqSXg3rMsVLuclacOq8744SwctCN8hcdFAfj0RAazICqYp/XGHBLsGo//oFShozymt2dTYhVXXN04WksxGfiW1kQ698L04zg6F5xVRa0lKgRBylOWISgQHF9p9xP9bzmesFZeQwV5Wv8K6fgXuI5Pg "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## 19. [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/), 45 bytes, [A000037](https://oeis.org/A000042)

```
f n=[x|x<-[1..],notElem x [y*y|y<-[1..x]]]!!n
```

[Try it online](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap/smap.cgi?new/curry)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000045)

Comment: ninja'd by 37 seconds >.<

Comment: but you were ninja'd by 23 seconds rip

Answer (score 5):

## 20. [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 15 bytes, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045)

```
$0=0,1:z+y)))))
```

`$0` means 0-indexed, `=0,1` means it starts with `0,1`, `:` means if given `n` it returns the `n`th item in the sequence, `z+y` means each item is the previous two added together. `)))))` are no-ops due mostly to interpreter bugs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XA1kDH0KpKu1ITBP7/NwUA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000015)

Answer (score 5):

## 27. C++, 584 bytes, [A000274](http://oeis.org/A000274)

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
int f(int i) {
    map<int, int> m;
    function<int(int)> a = [&](int j){
        if (!m.count(j)) {
            switch (j) {
            case -1:
            case 0:
                m[j] = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                m[j] = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                m[j] = 3;
                break;
            default:
                m[j] = (1+j)*a(j-1)+(3+j)*a(j-2)+(3-j)*a(j-3)+(2-j)*a(j-4);
            }
        }
        return m[j];
    };
    return a(i - 1);
}
```

Recursive solution with caching.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000584) (shouldn't be a tricky one)

Comment: Since now different compilers are considered different languages, I think you should specify which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 5):

## 28. [Positron](https://github.com/alexander-liao/positron), 9 bytes, [A000584](http://oeis.org/A000584)

```
->{$1**5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvziwpys/7X1CUmVfikJtY4KDxX9euWsVQS8u09r9OUWJeeqqDoYHmfwA)

Finally got Positron in here ^_^

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000009)

Comment: Gosh darn it, I thought I had a chance to use Cubix, where the linear code is just `I:***O@`

Comment: @ETHproductions :) Finally I managed to not get ninja'd... for once... lol

Answer (score 5):

### 29. JavaScript (SpiderMonkey), 46 bytes, [A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009)

```
f = function(n,q=1)n?n<q?0:f(n-q,q)+f(n,q+2):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchRCoMwDADQq@QzoQrqp67zLMUZyIZpG6vg6ev8evC@4Qz7YpJKuyf5rLZF/a1Xrez50KVIVNQm@5501rfPM6O2ucnk@Hk30NiNfeVoeAYDAQ/d9OcFw6NzBMlECzIKUb0B) The OEIS page is rather daunting, but after reading it for a while I realized that this boils down to the partitions problem, but using only odd integers. Change the `q+2` to `q+1` and you have a function that calculates the number of partitions of a number.

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000046). I tried hard to leave it off on an easy one, I really did...

Comment: Please put a "29." in your header. I think you're confusing the Stack Snippet.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ah sorry. This is my first time since #3, so I've already forgotten how to answer :P

Comment: @SilvioMayolo he made the stack snippet :P

Answer (score 5):

## 32. [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 216 bytes, [A000172](http://oeis.org/A000172)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define cube(x) (x)*(x)*(x)

int main(int a) {
	int n;
	scanf("%d",&n);
	int nCr = 1;
	int sum = 0;
	for(int r=0;r<=n;r++) {
		sum += cube(nCr);
		nCr *= n-r;
		nCr /= r+1;
	}
	printf("%d",sum);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3NDoIwEITP7VNsIBqg/sC51ItPgm3RJrKYBRITw7PXFuthkpnszjf6eNfa@9yhfi7GQjvNxo2nx4Xz3NjeoQW93GzxLiGoSuLc4QxD57CIpivhw1l0KDmbdId9ke1MdthjKdPhSqCgSWlahpDqkPqRNgSpWlKrUJIQG43FH6F@66EdQSxSKgV4pH86KyARsStnLwqktBzaobF639Rf)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000216)

Answer (score 5):

## 35. [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 67 bytes, [A000168](https://oeis.org/A000168)

```
?sw[1[li*li1-dsi0<o]soli0<o]se3lw^2*lw2*silex*lwsilexlw2+silex*/p0P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@@uDzaMDonUysn01A3pTjTwCY/tjg/B0KnGueUxxlp5ZQbaRVn5qRWAFlgGiigDRHQLzAI@P/fAAA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000067)

Comment: [65 is already used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133796/48934)

Comment: @LeakyNun Fixed

Answer (score 5):

## 36. [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 124 bytes, [A000067](https://oeis.org/A000067)

```
squares =: *:@i.@>:@<.@%:
filter =: ] #~ [ >: ]
f =: [: <: (2^]) +/@:>: [: ~.@,/ (2^<:@]) (] +/ 2 * filter) [: squares (2^])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3dCoJAEAXg@32KAxGoxWpmf8O2zHuIQcRKRhBp3frq26413X2cMz8374fn@9y7AUdCRtxptsRG85xU291fro9Fg9mIGjZItTGoCYaQlKcmxSJnslM0al7mMTXEoUia0KFEhu@lNM7Iu2nXu8v1gRaF@mElKAVrQSXYCLaCnWAvOPwPFv4D)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000124)

Comment: Please make the next sequence in 6 bytes lol

Answer (score 5):

## 37. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes, [A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124)

The courtesy of [Leaky Nun](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38940341#38940341).

```
D>*2÷>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxU7L6PB2u///DQ0A)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000006)

Answer (score 5):

## 38. [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes, [A000006](https://oeis.org/A000006)

```
P√LA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z/gUccsH8f//w0NAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000004)

Answer (score 5):

## 41. PHP, 503 bytes, [A003416](https://oeis.org/A003416)

```php
function f ($n) {
  $i=12495; $cnt=0; $used =[];

  while (true) {
    $i++;
    $ns = [];
    $v = $i;
    $sm = $i;

    while (!in_array($v, $ns)) {
      $ns[] = $v;
      $s = 0;

      for ($k=1; $k<=$v/2; $k++)
        if ($v % $k == 0) $s += $k;

      $v = $s;
      if ($s == 1) break;
      $sm = min($sm, $v);
    }

    if ($v < 2) continue;
    if (in_array($sm, $used)) continue;
    if ($cnt == $n) return $sm;
    $cnt++;

    for ($i=0; $i < count($ns); $i++) $used[] = $ns[$i];
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFRasMwDP33KTTwICaFNGX7GGnWG@wCpYwuc4hI6wTbSRmjZ88k221/BgZblt570tPYjcuy3Y3dKEQ7mcbjYKCFTBoFvwJAYl1uXt5eK5CN8fWa7snpb6hhf6gEFVw6PGnIvJ10RDAmz6v4Mi5VhmimQGIK3DlFIUw0T2g@j9YefzI5rxiubqSBbH9gzFzdfph9nRgA2sFS431dUpP9tpZzseFXnqtUAIA82gzP9A01YRVz5MTZ31lil@6mERCOi0sFX1Yf@4c6T3BGQ/kzNTurmLlGpiS1hY2CZjAezaSre@YxZ8Cyp@q/OnadxXkfVvvJGtZNFlKOnRaP4TFsCEm1GSbjM3awCgtRUSQ6SE5KDFu5iqtYRouk0mZrqi0K@Bi8XoHv0AEddxouYve@/AE)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000503)

Answer (score 5):

## 42. [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 28 bytes, [A000503](https://oeis.org/A000503)

```
n->(tan(n)|0)-(tan(n)<0?1:0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITUlJLPqfk1qikKZgq/A/T9dOoyQxTyNPs8ZAUxfKtDGwN7Qy0PxfUJSZV6KgYVBjZ2mpqZebWKCRpvkfAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000028)

Answer (score 5):

## 43. [Swift 4](https://swift.org), 651 bytes, [A000028](https://oeis.org/A000028)

```swift
func bit_sum_parity(n: Int) -> Int {
    var res = 0;
    var test = n;
    while test > 0 {
        res ^= test%2;
        test /= 2;
    }
    return res;
}

func A000028(n: Int) -> Int {
    var res = 1;
    var iter = n;
    while iter > 0 {
        var clone = res;
        var p = 2;
        var parity = 0;
        while clone > 1 {
            var count = 0;
            while clone % p == 0 {
                clone /= p;
                count += 1;
            }
            parity ^= bit_sum_parity(n: count);
            p += 1;
        }
        if parity == 1 {
            iter -= 1;
        }
        res += 1;
    }
    return res-1;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://iswift.org/playground?I1FQjV)

[Next Sequence - A000651](http://oeis.org/A000651)

Answer (score 5):

## 44. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 94 bytes, [A000651](http://oeis.org/A000651)

```
f(n):=sum((2*k)!/k!/(k+1)!,k,1,n)+sum((2*binomial(n+k-1,k)-binomial(n+k,k))*f(n-1-k),k,0,n-2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEER/JYEedk0Wsx4t/ZiISMOaTdEK9utjCj30OPOYNzmeKcdaF1AcH/uRAYZO0PZiexDHaL149orux6akJae4gjoh9oL037SMXXMRk2BbBq804L0uZTM6BvN@bofhYOZi5rS/1viB7zPe6gU)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000094)

Comment: ... and we're back to partition

Answer (score 5):

## 57. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/), 119 bytes, [A000138](https://oeis.org/A000138)

```
f\left(n\right)=n!\sum _{i=0}^{\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)}\frac{\left(-1\right)^i}{i!\cdot 4^I}
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/abvynrjaxx)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000119)

Comment: `\operatorname`?

Comment: Gosh darn it, ninja'd again... I had come up with `q=n=>n?n*q(n-4)+(-n/4%2||1):1;f=n=>n?f(n-1)*(n%4?n:q(n)/q(n-4)):1` in JS which uses a similar technique

Comment: @ETHproductions That seems to be a common theme with this challenge. I've had 3 other Desmos answers that just got beat out.

Comment: @BlackCap Desmos auto-formats while you type. When you copy-paste, you get a bunch of **TEX**-like code, but it won't necessarily work in **TEX**.

Comment: Pasting the equation directly in still works with `f(n)=n!\sum _{i=0}^{floor(n/4)}(-1)^i/i!/4^i`. Not that you should golf it now, but...

Comment: @ETHproductions That's true. Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

## 59. [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 59 bytes, [A000011](https://oeis.org/A000011)

```
;2↔^gP~g⟦k;Pz+ᵐḃᵐbᵐ{↔;?T{{;1↔-}ᵐ}ᵐ,T{{~cĊ↔c}ᶠb}ᵐ{∋∋}ᶠo}ᵐ∋ᶜ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39roUduUuPSAuvRH85dlWwdUaT/cOuHhjmYgmQTE1UBZa/uQ6mprQyBLtxYoBMI6QJG65CNdQLHk2ofbFiTVgtV2dAMRiJ8P4gPZD7fNObTz/3@L/1EA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000059)

Answer (score 5):

## 72. SML, 252 bytes, [A000401](https://oeis.org/A000401)

```
fun A000401 x =
    let fun helper x y z =
        if z mod 4 = 0 then helper x y (z div 4)
        else if z mod 16 = 14 then helper x (y + 1) (y + 1)
        else if x = 0 then y
        else helper (x - 1) (y + 1) (y + 1)
    in helper x 0 1
    end
```

[Online demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smlnj_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMc1EyTmFnZjd0MlE)

*(Note: those blocks which look like four spaces each are really tabs. I forgot about StackExchange forcing tabs into spaces, and now that I've posted the next sequence it's a bit late to change. If anyone is really fussed then they can be changed to use a single space for indentation).*

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000252)

#### Dissection

This uses the characterisation given in Dickson's *History of the Theory of Numbers*:

> These are the numbers not of the form 4^k*(16*n + 14)

I could have defined one helper function to test for numbers not in the sequence and another to find the `x`th number which passes the test, but I think it's more in the spirit of PPCG to use a single helper function with two accumulators. `x` is the number we still have to discard; `y` is the number currently under consideration; `z` is `y` divided by some power of `4`.

There is a small hack in calling it as `helper x 0 1`: if I called it as `helper x 0 0` then there would be an infinite loop because `0` is divisible by `4` yielding `0`.

Comment: Good to see that you've decided to participate again!

Comment: I was a little nervous about leaving it on this sequence, but I saw the 4^k*(16*n + 14) note in the OEIS comments and knew that would be quite doable.

Comment: @ETHproductions, it would have been easy to do it directly too. In CJam I would have used the definition because it's easier to do a three-way Cartesian product and set union than to do the loop to remove powers of 4.

Answer (score 5):

## 101. [Fortress](http://web.archive.org/web/20080119125304/http://fortress.sunsource.net:80/), 335 bytes, [A000020](https://oeis.org/A000020)

```
relativelyPrime(a,b)=array[\ZZ32\]((a MIN b)-1).fill(fn(n)=>1) EQ array[\ZZ32\]((a MIN b)-1).fill(fn(n)=>if ((a MOD (n+2))+(b MOD (n+2))) NE 0 then 1 else 0 end)
totient(n)= do
 S : ZZ32 = 0
 for i <- 1:n do
  S += if relativelyPrime(i,n) then 1 else 0 end
 end
 S
end
A000020(n) = do
 |\if n = 1 then 2 else totient(2^n-1)/n end/|
end
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000335)

[Direct download of Fortress](http://web.archive.org/web/20070715233437/http://fortress.sunsource.net/files/documents/81/140/fortress_168.zip)

If the language was equivalent to the specification at the time that FOrtress got axed, then this would probably be easy. But sadly, Fortress got the boot, and I'm stuck with this crap >_<.

Comment: Link to the language?

Comment: Dead. Very dead. There it is.

Answer (score 5):

## 115. [shortC](//git.io/shortC), 273 bytes, [A001560](https://oeis.org/A001560)

```
pa(m){Fm%2){T-1;}E{T1;}}
pt(m){Ii,p[200],s,j,k,t,kk;p[0]=1;for(i=1;i<=m;i++){j=1;k=1;s=0;Wj>0){kk=k*k;j=i-(3*kk+k)/2;t=pa(k);if(j>=0){s=s-t*p[j];}j=i-(3*kk-k)/2;Fj>=0){s=s-t*p[j];}k=k+1;}p[i]= s;}Ts}
AIi,c;scanf("%d",&c);Oi=0;i<131;i++){Fpt(i)%2==0)c--;Fc==1)break;}R"%d",i
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000273) and [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xasQwDIb3e4pykBInNk1yU9HpoEMDnQol0CFkSN2Gk0XuTJzN@NlT9QpdOkhC6NOvX@F8XVa7bX7MZxXbOWtU7EwN6Tl2ktPOrz@DF9K@b6pq0EE7zXrVzOD7asAapuuSk1Q64gxUlio66VgiYAXv7lSpyIxcMDgkkx8K5pLVQwMryllWQFPuTihYwGDWwvdugPTHmhvb/idEsxSPvqcB7wKkLqTdkzi1EOx4mfJ99rnX91bBK4kROtaH@tdfK0@RyhoURWsMtBaxVh/L18iQ3m5rtG2P3w)

It's surprisingly hard to calculate partitions in a language that doesn't have many math builtins. This could be more golfed, but it could also be a lot less golfed. :P

Comment: Formula: `~` very helpful, I'm glad I can approximate it

Comment: @StepHen hey it's not as bad as answer 96 :P

Comment: It's not that hard to calculate partitions: you just need some kind of loop and addition. The number of partitions of `n` is the sum over `1 <= k <= n` of the number of partitions of `n` into `k` parts, which has recurrence `p(n, k) = p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)`. Alternatively the number of partitions of `n` into parts of at most `k` has recurrence `q(n, k) = n == 0 ? 1 : sum(q(n - i*k, k-1), i = 0 to n/k)`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I wasn't very clear; I tried this in lots of languages that weren't built to deal with math before I resorted to shortC.

Comment: Hmm. Tackling the next sequence by formula rather than enumeration requires working with big rationals.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hmm maybe that's why this is the only answer to this question with 0 votes... I could easily modify the bytecount. Should I?

Comment: **NO**. That's a complete violation of the spirit of the game.

Answer (score 5):

## 149. dash, 1993 bytes, [A000173](https://oeis.org/A000173)

**Important:** this is a precaution in case the INTERCAL answer for #149 is disqualified, to avoid #148 ending the chain due to the week having expired. It is deliberately the same length in order to preserve following answers.

```
succ () {
    # The successor is the sum of strictly smaller unitary divisors, where a
    # unitary divisor is a product of some subset of the maximal prime power divisors.
    # In other words, if we factor n as
    #   \prod_i p_i^{a_i}
    # then the successor should be
    #   \prod_i (p_i^{a_i} + 1) - n
    local n=$1
    local m=1
    factor $n | sed "s% %\n%g" | tail -n +2 | uniq -c |
        # Workaround for buggy read on my computer
        sed "s%^ *%%;s% %\n%" |
        while read x
        do
            read y
            z=1
            for i in $( seq $x )
            do
                z=$(( z * y ))
            done
            m=$(( m * (z + 1) ))
            # echo here and take tail because scope problems mean that m loses its
            # value outside this pipeline
            echo $(( m - n ))
        done
}

inseq () {
    local n=$1
    # We detect rhos using the little-step big-step method. If at any point we hit a
    # value less than n, clearly n isn't the smallest element of a cycle
    local k=$( succ $n | tail -1 )
    # If we loop already, it's unitary-perfect
    if test $k -le $n ; then return 1 ; fi

    local m=$( succ $k | tail -1 )
    # Loop already => it's unitary-amicable
    if test $m -le $n ; then return 1 ; fi

    while true
    do
        # Advance k once
        k=$( succ $k | tail -1 )
        # Advance m twice
        m=$( succ $m | tail -1 )
        if test $m -eq $n ; then return 0 ; fi
        if test $m -lt $n -o $m -eq $k ; then return 1 ; fi
        m=$( succ $m | tail -1 )
        if test $m -eq $n ; then return 0 ; fi
        if test $m -lt $n -o $m -eq $k ; then return 1 ; fi
    done
}

idx=$1
# Naive approach: test all values from 2 to see whether they're in the sequence
# until we've found enough that are
j=2
while true
do
    if inseq $j
    then
        if test $idx -eq 0
        then
            echo $j
            return 0
        fi
        idx=$(( idx - 1 ))
    fi

    j=$(( j + 1 ))
done
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##zVVNb9s4EL37VzzENuK0dZHkuIUX6LFAsacF9lI0oKmRRZsiFZKKo7T97d4hKauyGnSvq4MgkjNvPvjeqBC@Op18KyVWN/g2Az9z/F0R4h55bx2UR0gbNWwJH5ySQXfwtdCaHFqjgnAdCvWk2Ny/w7EiRxA92OQ8wgk0zhatDAnQ1hF86yktY6haPCtGZyvFZ409cpgz/Pse9pOBZVuHo3UFB1UljoRSyMAxDITv7YAvMdiDQvOgvn4TD@pHf8Lepq/sXKqvbKsLbOkX59Xgjbe4u8EaJtloKzlRs1ncjZb1Jq/6bBYG3@GpwJVfYvnFLHdXvBGE0lgbvL3nBTfpEWuJ78kvB//HuoNwtjUFSkbZtrtdB0eigDWoO0hbN20gN7j0Ib7izXL5oQ91NYI8VkpTRngeNgs7fMYnnXYXWy99NecnJqOgDBYrDvmIxTNuLgwmkBljsVrhBW/Q4WZqbehio062NduuXnKzJx5zkKwsMsu4O0EcKLdzS1K0nm9U2oYiybaaao@aRLxpERhVW08eKvgJ5JPQLcG2wauC0SqmaaMa0mqSXQqdE2QOjFNLhfyYzZSJXRnkNGEI3yuhoEDMfldZj9Yrs0s81CoETWsfqMFW7fJHTaGyxXt8KsH5C9OxHpQJkeyVCoPKcvqaaRwLNTDvIDUJx0I1LDlzHTLVk2h9AHFjyCTFCciObUfJHjbxauNQSNTNTL3rb3keU@Ho2toGQkfCdCy/cO3PUl835EquL5mzLkMMuDhgzexjwA9ZeY5C6wzueF2q2YV6huiHV6J/HsXF5s/LyKJWUmz7YobQ9X@HztoIrs2uIwrP8bF4EkYSDiw8@ZMNh9/leelZIxzVyHVUYv2q6zj1KLFp6rc59dfMdYjmazv4Hl4v@/@WyyCf4jlqZY6/hHpigTcsYyGrPzIq0zdz3aN0tsY9guUpRPGnk34H/OqueTCofrbTY0vx1uKPKHBpR7pm1DKNVTK23VV5MghHs/3mfjYiQk8CLihLerFP65j/r9Vy2qnE2@Howu7n6NhP5m3u4bA57mTsBE@aBM2t6mfNmbL7dLiPIzIexf6dTqfbfwE)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001993)

Comment: I wonder how the snippet will react to that :P

Comment: No, I don't have A000083. I don't have a slightest idea about what is happening. Go ahead and choose some saner next sequence ;)

Comment: Uh, @PeterTaylor did you get a notification when I replied?

Comment: @PeterTaylor gogogo

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, I don't understand your request. On the basis of the discussion on meta, where no-one has provided any answer contrary to mine or downvoted it, it's the other 149 which should be deleted and this one remains necessary.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ah, I thought the discussion on meta was settled, for whatever reason. Removing comment

Answer (score 5):

## 231. [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 938 bytes, [A000086](https://oeis.org/A000086)

```
The Beautiful Story of Solving Quadratic Equations.
Theseus, the mathematician.
Dogberry, his calculator.
Page, to avoid mistakes caused by imperfect mental math.
Mistress Page, to make Page feel less lonely.

     Act XLII: Introducing modulus arithmetic.
    Scene I: Dogberry as a motivational speaker.
[Enter Dogberry and Page]
 Dogberry:
   Listen to your heart!
[Exeunt]

   Scene II: Complex math without complex numbers.
[Exeunt]
[Enter Theseus and Dogberry]
 Theseus:
   You are the remainder of the quotient between the sum of a cat and
   the product of Mistress Page and the sum of Mistress Page and a
   Microsoft and Page. Are you as big as nothing?
 Dogberry:
   If so, you are the sum of yourself and a cat.
[Exit Dogberry]
[Enter Mistress Page]
 Theseus:
   You are the sum of yourself and an angel. Are you as trustworthy as
   Page? If not, let us return to Scene II.
 Mistress Page:
   If so, open your heart.
[Exeunt]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJPb9swDMXv/hTcPTCwXYb1UnRbDwFaYEN22DD0oNi0LUyWXIlK6k@fParOv21YEMQORT7@yKc0ucPh28D0kU0W22VHGwlxptDRJrid9T19zaaNRmxD988Zz@BTXaEmcU4rEhSPBr@jpljj6@pz6Lcc47yiwSZqjGuyM1Ctqy@mZ5QEMrtgWxptEvOLNScnbmk7kx0njh03QiN7Ma5o19UjMiOnRCeFEYXlH3XMjpweuuDZzXVVkX7uIPL9Yb2@obWXGNrc6DQjXlxOZKKVYWQw1yV907BnQvKRngySkC52V4YGS5oYXTHHz3svHC9SfVtYnqpT7EZVH4DNXnHnkCMNbKK8QfULZy9PhXPpi8afwjg5fikT0x50IQs1S9DnEbKpPhcvDIsRBeHYGxhLuFD8CBnjcrEqwifrWxTCYQ08Z0yIVdOWZc8Ki2DKo54bGCOqrCoan8oaRc@uHCndLwr/PjQq8WibGFLo5LSwmu4ANitgoq3t9eGDDHDq9o9drjtKYfWauwyzdNPdJnbdayNlLmuycrGQZVtXYP9Z0z@VPb49uytmiTnJPkQZ9MKojCrfKi3mWOFeCsGdyJJjuQhHv3HrrmAuZwwTfDjfmLPph8Pb9@8@/AY)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000938)

It's suprisingly hard to introduce words that mean nothing in the statement, so I didn't. Yes, `Microsoft` has a meaning - in fact, it's a negative noun so it means `-1`.

Comment: Please note that the bytecount changed in the first 10 or so seconds.

Answer (score 5):

## 244. [UCBLogo](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html), 1524 bytes, [A000112](https://oeis.org/A000112)

```
to permutations :list
    if :list = [] [op [[]]]
    op map.se [
        map [[ls] fput ? :ls] permutations (remove ? :list)
    ] :list
end

to dfs :node
    repeat :N [
        if and
        (1 = item :node item repcount :matrix) 
        not(item repcount :visited) 
        [
            setitem repcount :visited "true
            dfs repcount
        ]
    ]
end

to tuples :items :n
    if :n = 1 [op map "list :items]
    op (crossmap "fput :items tuples :items :n-1)
end

to isomorphic :mat1 :mat2 ; they must both have size N*N
    foreach permutations iseq 1 :N [
        catch "failed [
            for [i 1 :N] [
                for [j 1 :N] [
                    if (
                            (item      :i    item       :j    :mat1)  
                            item (item :i ?) item (item :j ?) :mat2
                    ) [throw "failed]
                ]
            ]
            op "true
        ]
    ]
    op "false
end

to solve :N
    if :N = 0 [op 1]

    localmake "visited array :N
    localmake "matrices []
    local "valid

    foreach tuples (tuples [0 1] :N) :N [ [matrix]
        make "valid "true
        for [node 1 :N] [
            repeat :N [
                setitem repcount :visited "false
            ]
            dfs :node

            if (item :node :visited) [
                make "valid "false
                throw "for.catchtag ; FMSLogo-specific way to break for loop
                ; because Logo doesn't have Break command.
            ]
            repeat :N [
                if and (item repcount :visited) (0 = item :node item repcount :matrix) [
                    make "valid "false
                    throw "for.catchtag
                ]
            ]
        ]

        if :valid [
            catch "nextmatrix [
                foreach :matrices [
                    if isomorphic :matrix ? [throw "nextmatrix]
                ]
                make "matrices fput :matrix :matrices
            ]
        ]
    ]
    op count :matrices
end
```

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A001524)

There are 7 spaces in the last line.

You can try it online [here](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb). Just enter the program and append `print solve 3` (for example) in the end.

I choose UCBLogo for this sequence because I don't want to use FMSLogo, which I want to keep for a more geometry-related sequence.

So, in the end I gave up and just post my bruteforce solution.

This one takes a long time to calculate for just `n=4`. The MD5 I mentioned in the chat is for the version with some spaces at the end removed.

---

Explanation:

First, the program generates all possible `N×N` matrices `tuples (tuples [0 1] :N) :N`. Each matrix represent a directed graph with `N` vertices.

For each matrix (store in variable `matrix`, it checks whether it represents a poset (Two vertices `A` and `B` has the edge `A→B` connected if and only if `A<B`) by: for each node, it runs a `DFS` from that node, and verify that it can't reach that node (there is no cycle in the graph), and there is an edge from the node to every reachable nodes (because `<` is transitive).

After having checked that the matrix represents a valid poset, the program checks whether it is isomorphic to any existing poset, stored in the `matrices` variable. If it is not, the program `put` `:matrix` to the `f`irst of the variable `:matrices` (`make "matrices fput :matrix :matrices`).

Then in the end the program `o`ut`p`ut the number of elements of `:matrices` (`op count :matrices`).

Comment: I need to stop trying to write *efficient* code for these tougher sequences. Or at least, I need to start seriously attempting them before there's only a day left.

Comment: You could avoid the poset check by observing that each poset can be obtained from the subset relations among `n` subsets of `{1,...,n}`. But I'm not sure if creating all these (which can be optimized) and turning them into the.matrix representation of the graph is easier...

Comment: @ChristianSievers So there would be ${2^n} \choose n$ graphs which is still significantly less than $2^{n^2}$. May be faster. It is not necessary to turn it into matrix representation too, if there is a way to check isomorphism of those. (Is it possible to check isomorphism of posets in polynomial time? Not for general graph, I know.)

Comment: You can easily bring the number of relevant matrices down to $3^((n-1)(n-2)/2)$, and my approach with the mentioned optimizations to less than $2^same$. So that seems nice, but my main idea was just to try to simpify the algorithm. I don't know about the isomorphism check, but be careful: graph isomorphism is not known to be NP-complete (subgraph isomorphism is), but has unknown complexity in NP (I mixed that up once myself)

Comment: @ChristianSievers I don't really understand. First, how can I get complexity $3^{(n-1)(n-2) \over 2}$? I find it not obvious. (BTW your LaTeX need curly bracket in necessary places) Second, how is it important that graph isomorphism is NP-unknown? I can just use the fastest-available _known_ algorithm that I can implement.

Comment: Not total complexity, but number of matrices. My exponent was wrong, it should be $n(n-1)/2$. There are that many unordered pairs of different elements $i, j$ with $1<=i,j<n$, and they are either unrelated, or one is less than the other according to the poset. So for the matrix entries $M_{i,j}$ and $M_{j,i}$ there are only three possibilities altogether. Of course the status of graph isomorphism is not important here, one just should not think it is NP-complete when that's not known, as I did for a while.

Comment: @ChristianSievers Thanks, understood.

Comment: And then you can assume that the elements are numbered according to a topological sort, so there are only two possibilities for each pair and the matrix is triangular. Now it is not too difficult to only construct matrices that represent posets. It's slightly easier to explain when the matrix describes $<=$, not $<$: For $i=1$ to $n$, let $M_{i,i}=1$ and for $j=i-1$ downto $1$, if $M_{j,i}=0$ we may componentwise "and" the $j$-th column to the $i$-th column.

Answer (score 5):

## 254. [Enlist](https://github.com/alexander-liao/enlist), 98 bytes, [A001516](https://oeis.org/A001516)

```
W F †  0r   ‡ ;@ ±@ ¹ ! :/ §€¹  Ė  ‡ 2* :2 :@ §/€   † ↕ ḥ1 ↕ ×J ḥ1 § † ↕ ḥ1 ↕ ×J ḥ1 §   ;0   S  §€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f8/XMFN4VHDAgUFgyIFBSBroYK1g8KhjUC8U0FRwUpf4dDyR01rgByFI9Mg8kZaClZGClZAFcv1gVJgXQsUHrVNVXi4Y6khmHF4uheEc2g5fkkFBWsDIBGsALHm////BjqGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6ljqGBgA)

haha enlist can do a thing :D

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000098)

## Explanation

```
WF†0r‡;@±@¹!:/§€¹Ė‡2*:2:@§/€†↕ḥ1↕×Jḥ1§†↕ḥ1↕×Jḥ1§;0S§€  Main Link
W                                                      wrap; x => [x]
 F                                                     flatten (WF is just for test suite purposes lol)
                                                    €  For each (this just returns the first `n` elements if the input is an integer)
  †                                                §   Execute a monadic bracketed chain on each (let's call the argument `z`)
   0r                                                  Range from 0 to `z`, inclusive
               €                                       For each in the range
     ‡        §                                        Execute a dyadic bracketed chain on each (let's call the argument `n`)
      ;@                                               Append `n` to
        ±@¹                                            [z + n, z - n]
           !                                           Factorial (of each)
            :/                                         Reduce over division (this gives (z + n)! / (z - n)! / n! which is what we want as the coefficient)
                ¹                                      Identity as right argument to prevent dyad-monad chaining
                 Ė                                     Enumerate 1-indexed
                           €                           For each enumerated element (let's call the argument [x, y])
                  ‡      §/€                           Reduce over dyadic function (gives `x $ y`)
                   2*                                  2 ^ x
                     :2                                / 2 (floored)
                       :@                              y / (floored)
                                                     (this is y / 2 ^ (x - 1))
                            †        §                 Monadic bracketed expression (derivative step)
                             ↕                         Reverse
                              ḥ1                       All but last 1 element
                                ↕                      Reverse
                                 ×J                    Multiply each with its index
                                   ḥ1                  All but last 1 element
                                      †↕ḥ1↕×Jḥ1§       Derivative again
                                                ;0     Append 0 (to prevent empty-sum errors)
                                                  S    Sum
```

Comment: For the second time. Well, that means Enlist can't be used again till 300th answer.

Comment: *cough cough* bytecount *cough*

Comment: @user202729 oh well, enlist isn't that great for this challenge due to its current lack of functionality. By the time it gets functionality it will probably be in the 300s.

Comment: Shouldn't it return the n-th number instead of a list of all numbers up to n? Anyway, good job

Comment: @NieDzejkob eh, technically yes. fine, I'll fix it

Answer (score 5):

## 277.  [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 104 bytes, [A000188](https://oeis.org/A000188)

```
Ln¹%1‹Oquery: no rules about unnecessary text?
Nearest available byte count is 104 so this code is on it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxDQIxDEbhnin@hv6CKNA1LIBgBidYIlJki9hBpLu1rmUUFglc9/QV72AUC49xkc@6D99lvT0b1z5DFLUVNlDU5mginNiMaofz28@7K1Nlc9CLctkmiN0ZSZs4siFMR5jCH/9OeufNVJB9jHD6AQ)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000104)

It didn't seem like there was a rule against unnecessary text but if I misinterpreted I will delete.

**Explanation**

```
Ln¹%1‹Oq     Only part of the code that gets evaluated
L            [1...n] where n is the input
 n           square: [1,4,9,...n**2]
  ¹          push the input n
   %         mod: [1%n,4%n,...(n**2)%n]
    1        push 1
     ‹       less than 1: [1%n<1,4%n<1,...(n**2)%n<1]
      O      count the ones in the array
       q     terminate the program
uery: no...  not evaluated
```

Regarding the next sequence, I almost skipped it because it looks hard but then changed my mind. It seems like a high level language would be useful there. I've noticed there are no Maple answers so someone could try it in that. There is also [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon) which from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146916/75553) seems like it is essentially just Python so I don't know if we are counting it as a separate language. Fortran is also available for an answer but I don't know if many people use it and it is not so high level.

Comment: Unnecessary bytes are allowed (and sometimes forced), mostly because of byte restriction.

Comment: [tag:hard]? No, this one is easy.

Comment: @user202729 good, I was worried a little

Comment: For those working on the next one, you may want to look at Donald Knuth's [POLYNUM and POLYSLAVE](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html) programs.

Comment: BTW Pyon is a superset of Python, kind of like Coconut. Most Python code works in Pyon, and if there's code that doesn't, then it's a bug with Pyon.

Answer (score 5):

## 280. [Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_(computer_algebra_system)), 947 bytes, [A002852](https://oeis.org/A002852)

```
artanh:(Float) -> Float
artanh(x) == 
    y := x 
    k := 1
    for k in 1..precision() repeat
        z := x^(2*k+1) / (2 * k + 1)
        y := z + y
    return y

ln2:() -> Float
ln2() == artanh(0.5) + artanh(1.0 / 7)

gamma:(NonNegativeInteger) -> Float
gamma(e) ==
    precision(2 ^ e + 100)
    n := 2.0 ^ e
    eps := 1.0 / n
    A := - e * ln2()
    B := 1.0
    U := A 
    V := 1.0
    k := 1
    repeat
        B := B * n^2 / k^2
        A := (A * n^2 / k + B) / k
        if (A < eps) /\ (B < eps) then
            return U / V
        U := U + A
        V := V + B
        k := k + 1

fractions:(NonNegativeInteger, Integer) -> List(Integer)
fractions(e, n) ==
    y := gamma(e)
    l : List(Integer) := []
    for i in 0..n repeat
        f := floor(y)
        l := cons(f, l)
        y := y - f
        if y > 0 then 
            y := 1 / y
    reverse(l)

)set messages prompt none
)set messages type off
fractions(12, 1000)
)quit
```

[next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000947)

There doesn't seem to be a good way to read input in this system, but called like this (using the [fricas](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/) fork)

```
fricas -noht -eval ")read em.input )quiet"
```

where `em.input` contains the source code, will print a table of the first 1001 elements of the sequence.

Comment: I don't have Axiom installed on my machine, but is `e=12` enough to calculate 1000 terms? Because in that case you have `eps = 1 / (2 ^ 12)` (I guess `^` is exponentiation?) and the terminating condition is `(A < eps) /\ (B < eps)` (I guess ``/\`` is conjunction)...

Comment: Also, can you explain which series are you using to calculate gamma? It's not entirely obvious from the code.

Comment: That should be `eps = 10 ^ -n`. Odd that it works anyway.  Series used is from [Brent](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1980/brent-gamma.pdf).  There also is an [axiom docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/daly/axiom/).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Does the next series involve group theory

Comment: 1 day left for next sequence! Is this hard enough for Java? / Anyone else working on this?

Comment: @HusnainRaza (Probably) yes, but this one is pretty simple. Just "have symmetry group C_{2v}". In simple terms it can be explained as "having 2 perpendicular plane of reflection".

Comment: I give up this time. Anyone else? [Progress](https://goo.gl/Uku1AK).

Answer (score 5):

## 297. [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 1460 bytes, [A000161](http://oeis.org/A000161)

```
A000161 - Number of partitions of n into 2 squares.
Romeo, the first square.
Juliet, the second square.
Othello, the input.
Macbeth, the counter.
Hamlet, the narrator.
The Ghost, the temporary actor one.

          Act I: Main Program.
       Scene I: Retrieving Input.

[Enter Hamlet and Othello]
 Hamlet:
  Listen to your heart!
[Exeunt]
  
       Scene II: Initialization.

[Enter Romeo and Juliet]
 Juliet:
  You are nothing!
[Exit Juliet]
[Enter Macbeth]
 Romeo:
  You are as good as me!
[Exeunt]

       Scene III: Calculation.

[Exeunt]
[Enter Romeo and The Ghost]
 Romeo:
  You are as bad as the product of me and me!
[Exit The Ghost]
[Enter Juliet]
 Romeo:
  You are as lovely as the square root of the difference between Othello and The Ghost!
 Juliet:
  Is Othello as lovely as the sum of the product of me and me and the product of you and you?
 Romeo:
  If not, let us proceed to Scene V.
[Exeunt]

       Scene IV: Add One.

[Enter Romeo and Macbeth]
 Romeo:
  You are as good as the sum of yourself and a flower.
[Exeunt]

       Scene V: Decision.

[Exeunt]
[Enter Romeo and Hamlet]
 Hamlet:
  You are as good as the sum of yourself and a flower.
 Romeo:
  Am I not better than the square root of Othello?
 Hamlet:
  If so, let us proceed to Scene III.
[Exeunt]

       Scene VI: Ending.

[Enter Hamlet and Macbeth]
 Hamlet:
  You are as good as the quotient between the sum of you and a flower and a beautiful flower. Open your heart!
[Exeunt]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNb9swDL37V7D3znB22CGXItiK1cO6Dt1QYBh6UGw6FiCLrj7aZX8@o2zZcT6MDs1FkSjyPb5H2bZqt1tlWbb4sIB38M03azRAFbTCOOkkaRt2GqR2BO/BPnlh0KbJPTVIl@BqhEoa62IkTb54JdH1EYsF6XIM3fGZUjFL6ta7NLkVxRpd3Z8V5LVDkyY3olFDES2MEY749CfvPtdkY8Bh05IRZgui4DiQZowExt@qcJAv4VZIDd8NbYxo0iH8o0CNIXqPzkh8lnoDec8o@X0dSEDPAQQ3EIk/JvFwyWW@SutQA6uyJW@gRhbsgnP/IPfAN@EIirFyzYoKJf@KIOweqdOyA@rF4@z@T8D5RR5YPdDkambZQUg33owlooyc2RWbJgoLG6IyrA1OGB7zY4IfhSq82rOLN09ojkbM4K1FBxdMag2Vno3gIWqwS44kuIdJmQgx9n@uqqJnVNuhcD9UYIi64uGolFWFBnWBwGK8INsTnTtkfTHVN7f7SycYvhlqn@ujW46C28CXj3m9mrSRV8HASwgT5W1IKBDLMD29/A/prDEPS1iVPIPddJ9Y8X/GT5oJ02pRVV22gErRS3hxM@gM/gkLaV@biP5dHDyQN9HYd7FqIA@aBSsDlquFPmd8NO9qCs1qW5oXm2d9vmF@Bte65Jd29kuwl/vVRp88OYnajbN42P1B43GzRuGdrLwa9IC7lhPPfWB2u0WW/QM)

[Next sequence: A001460 - just some trivial factorial things](http://oeis.org/A001460)

Added some padding bytes so that the next one will not be calculating on the graphs (originally 1429 bytes).

Added more padding so that the sequence points to a 0-indexed array

Translated code (Python):

```
import math
R, O = 0, input()              # Act I Scene I & II
M = R                          # Act I Scene I & II
while R <= int(math.sqrt(O)):  # Act I Scene V
 G = R * R                     # Act I Scene III
 J = int(math.sqrt(O - G))     # Act I Scene III
 if O == R * R + J * J:        # Act I Scene III
  M = M + 1                    # Act I Scene IV
 R = R + 1                     # Act I Scene V
print (M + 1) // 2             # Act I Scene VI result = ceil(M / 2)
                               #                because all except n=2a² are counted twice
```

Answer (score 4):

## 16. [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 69 bytes, [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085)

```lua
function f(n)
 if n<2 then return 1 end
 return f(n-1)+~-n*f(n-2)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDoAgFEN3TtFRVBLUVQ9jFCKJKeYHVq@OMLi1eX29816KzzxSiITvqBWCB9cZ6XKEuJSFmOB4qr/VmZn08Br2Lc5aVVp8FHCz42JxRjwSmLp2qJtbPg)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000069)

Comment: Open problem: does Lua have memoization? This should have exponential complexity...

Comment: Hold on, you 4 people \o/

Answer (score 4):

## 18. [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes, [A000018](https://oeis.org/A000018)

```apl
{+/(1↓∪,∘.{(⍵×⍵)+16×⍺×⍺}⍨⍳1+2*⍵)≤2*⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x2BZLW2vobho7bJjzpW6TzqmKFXrfGod@vh6UBCU9vQDMTYBSZqH/WueNS72VDbSAsk96hzCZhR@/@/4yGwhAEA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000037)

Warning: this is terribly inefficent

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, forgot the number

Comment: Note: I changed the bytecount of this solution to make it slightly easier for the next solution. cc @ETHproductions

Comment: -1 for changing the next sequence for no good reason

Comment: Oh, that'll probably be solved before I'm back at a computer then

Answer (score 4):

## 21. [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 24 bytes, [A000015](https://oeis.org/A000015)

```
Ṫ*Ḣ
l2Rp²ÆR$µÇ€<³$ÐḟṂ
‘Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9t///huaoq4biiCmwyUnDCssOGUiTCtcOH4oKsPMKzJMOQ4bif4bmCCuKAmMOH////Mg)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000024)

Sorry for changing the next sequence; I had to fix my indexing.

### Explanation

```
Ṫ*Ḣ                !!!!!!! Helper Link
Ṫ                  Last element
 *                 To the power of
  Ḣ                First element
l2Rp²ÆR$µÇ€<³$ÐḟṂ  !!!!!!! Main Link
l2R                Range up to log_2(input); this is the largest power we need to handle because 2**k will be at least `input` this way
   p               Cartesian Product with
    ²ÆR$           All primes up to `input squared`
        µ          New Monadic Link
         Ç€        Call the last link on each element (all prime powers)
              Ðḟ   Filter to discard
           <³$                       elements smaller than the input
                Ṃ  Minimum Value
‘Ç                 !!!!!!! Called Link
‘                  Decrement
 Ç                 Call the Main Link
```

Answer (score 4):

## 23. Ruby, 23 bytes, [A000982](https://oeis.org/A000982)

```
a=->(n){(n*n/2.0).ceil}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9FW104jT7NaI08rT99Iz0BTLzk1M6f2/38A)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000023)

23rd entry uses 23 bytes!

Comment: Could you format this as asked in the question please?

Comment: fixed, sorry bout that

Answer (score 4):

## 33. [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 73 bytes, [A000216](https://oeis.org/A000216)

```matlab
function o=s(x)
if x<2
o=2;
else
o=sum((int2str(s(x-1))-'0').^2);
end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP08h37ZYo0KTKzNNocLGiCvf1siaKzWnOBXIKi7N1dDIzCsxKi4p0gAq0jXU1NRVN1DX1Isz0gSqyksB4f/FGiaa/wE)

Pretty basic recursive formula.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Answer (score 4):

## 45. [D](https://dlang.org/), 190 bytes, [A000094](https://oeis.org/A000094)

```
int A000094(int n) {
	if (n<4) {
		return 0;
	}
	int[] gf = new int[n+1];
	gf[0] = 1;
	for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
		for (int j=i; j<=n; j++) {
			gf[j] += gf[j-i];
		}
	}
	return gf[n]-n+1;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BCoMwDIbP@hRBGCjOUcHLqD3sOaSHQa1Etji6bh6Gz96lblrS5m9@@qUxAe@PyXl4enPijZMMSB4ugte5yaOmAj5pghZyaptVJ673L0cgZJosbJHvNAwWFFA/Q7xSWWs2B9sJzeWatZ0crDxUtQRsiY@y/PF2b1QoYWwVm@NmRsqooVQQRYURHNty/P/BddIV95TpEt4TGrhfkfL1@Y4mJSRQW4uYNvbs0Pf2Rnl2MNlxm5qKYp1sCV8)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000190)

Comment: Never thought I'd see a D answer, nice job making me use Fortress. Grr.

Answer (score 4):

## 46. [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 21 bytes, [A000190](https://oeis.org/A000190)

```
p
d^0
1|&*&*r
 E    i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P@/gCslzoDLsEZNS02riEvBVQEIMv//twAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000021)

Comment: Oh noes, it's "Number of positive integers <= 2^n of form x^2 + 12 y^2. "

Comment: This "Jellyfish" looks like a llama

Answer (score 4):

## 47. awk, 194 bytes, [A000021](https://oeis.org/A000021)

```
{
 n=0;
 for (i=1; i<=2**$1; i++) {
  stop = 0;
  for (x=0; x<=i && !stop; x++) {
   for (y=0; y<=i && !stop; y++) {
    if (x**2 + 12*y**2 == i){
     n++; stop=1;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 print n;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7PCsIwDMbvfYpPkOGSi@vBS5eH8TIIQjfmwBXZs3fpqoKQhC/JL3/ur0fOb4co1@AwjDMuKl2A9uKJzkUxtzACz2WcIChcBVebwdqLomlwKm1Lv3RFUkHSP5J@CHSwLUQejM5TKkoE2tYuInM4ztpHR2Vzn2BuNs0aF8TgtpxvOw)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000194)

Answer (score 4):

## 51. [Burlesque](http://mroman.ch/burlesque/), 8 bytes, [A000026](https://oeis.org/A000026)

```
fCf:FLpd
```

[Try it online!](http://cheap.int-e.eu/%7Eburlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=24fCf%3AFLpd)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000008)

Comment: I swear we've already done the "partitions of N into 1,2,5,10" sequence... perhaps an answer got deleted though

Comment: I thought so too @ETHproductions but I don't see it, probably a similar sequence

Answer (score 4):

## 52. [Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/), 484 bytes, [A000008](https://oeis.org/A000008)

```
Integer f(Integer n) {
	variable Integer coin1 = 0;
	variable Integer coin2 = 0;
	variable Integer coin5 = 0;
	variable Integer coinT = 0;
	variable Integer count = 0;
	while (coin1 <= n) {
		while (coin2 <= n / 2) {
			while (coin5 <= n / 5) {
				while (coinT <= n / 10) {
					if (n == coin1 + 2 * coin2 + 5 * coin5 + 10 * coinT) {
						count++;
					}
					coinT++;
				}
				coin5++;
				coinT = 0;
			}
			coin2++;
			coin5 = 0;
		}
		coin1++;
		coin2 = 0;
	}
	return count; 
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBboMwEEXXcIpZmrIo49ZNK8oBsucCJDGNpchULqSqIs5OkD1uPZWS3fz/DH6evf45DXZZtnbUH9pBL@JkC7jk2blzptudNMR6PxiL0EBV34DyHlT3YHsbTnYk@H00KxFB470hzbSWvoZHkAGlTEWmiKWwjRCrSDPTg7DQNPTuEiQ80DNLUDSrdcaKQvv7bea9y7IOcc6pXM/EMnT@H7FKN0EH/H3E0y166sUCTNe/IqfHydmwvRryefk6dk4f4DyYA7jJCm/66YwdRS@qoqj/ErIkWXpi6ZklxdILSxuWXll647f/k@E2yHWQ@yAXQm6EXAm5E3Ip9FbzcgU)

huehue I'm a Ceylon noob

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000484) (c'mon this is so easy)

Answer (score 4):

## 55. [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 41 bytes, [A000196](https://oeis.org/A000196)

```
:1>::*$@(?vv
  ^ +1@@:$ <
          \1-n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38rQzspKS8VBw76sjEtBIU5B29DBwUpFwQbIgYEYQ9086////@uWKZgCAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000041)

Comment: `f=function(n,q=1){return n?n>=q?f(n-q,q)+f(n,q+1):0:1}` solves A000041 in Node.JS, but it's an extremely trivial modification of [another answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/134953) so I don't know if I really want to post it... (also, A000054 is "Local stops on New York City A line subway", so...)

Answer (score 4):

## 58. [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 11 bytes, [A000119](https://oeis.org/A000119)

```
<DÅFÙïæOrQO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fxuVwq9vhmYfXH17mXxTo//@/JQA)

```
<DÅFÙïæOrQO  Program
<            Decrement for 0-indexing
 D           Duplicate top of stack (for later use)
  ÅF         List of fibonacci numbers up to the current number
    Ù        Remove duplicates
     ï       Convert each element to an integer (they become strings for whatever reason ;_;)
      æ      Powerset
       O     Sum of each subset in the powerset
        r    Reverse stack (I don't think this is necessary, but 10 bytes isn't allowed anyway)
         Q   Equality check; vectorizes
          O  Gives number of occurrences; done
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000011)

Comment: Have we not had A11 already?

Comment: @BlackCap We had A46, which is similar, but is slightly different (they're very similar; you may remember me raging last night about not being able to get the definitions lol)

Answer (score 4):

## 62. [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 57 bytes, [A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005)

```
readIO
n=i
lblb
r=n%i
r/r
r=1-r
s+r
i-1
if i b
printInt s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058rzzaTKycpJ4mryDZPNZOrSL8IyDLULeIq1i7iytQ15MpMU8hUSOIqKMrMK/HMK1EAav1vBgA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000057)

---

<sup>*LeakyNun asked me to post this, again.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## 68. [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 761 bytes, [A000837](https://oeis.org/A000837)

```pascal
function Mobius(n: integer): integer;
type
	iarray = array of integer;
var
	result: iarray;
	i, j, sum: integer;
begin
	setlength(result,n+1);
	result[1] := 1;
	for i := 2 to n do
	begin
		sum := 0;
		for j := 1 to i-1 do
			if (i mod j = 0) then
				sum := sum + result[j];
		result[i] := -sum;
	end;
	Mobius := result[n];
end;

function A000837(n: integer): integer;
type
	iarray = array of integer;
var
	partitions: iarray;
	i, j, sum: integer;
begin
	setlength(partitions,n+1);
	partitions[0] := 1;
	for i := 1 to n do
		for j := i to n do
			partitions[j] := partitions[j] + partitions[j-i];
	sum := 0;
	for i := 1 to n do
		if (n mod i = 0) then
			sum := sum + partitions[i] * Mobius(n div i);
	if (n = 0) then
		A000837 := 1
	else
		A000837 := sum;
end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLLboMwEDybr9gjNFBBc2iVKId@QL8gyoEEkywia2SbVPl66jWEh9JL1Qtmd2fGywxNbk55nZTNqevKlk4WFcGXOmJrQtoAkpVnqaPxbRvYeyMDgbnW@R120J@qnAC3XAdCS9PW1tH8fOsIMVQxmPY6kzrKM1IgjLS1pLO9hD0rplUWbR8a@@wAmx1krlEqDcjFG1gFBIUKxKAhnDJPUgfzuMqTGIdJ5pFCYAkhwlUVbuqgEdiLZO7I5mMFw73VgbWGAv0SiQO4pqTCPXuXuD1gyBH8KBid/EzT9GP9/i8rm1xbZDXzVzsn5sPSqbNPn23NJlsnD3HWnPMrz182Vos6QXZwFsyvF3Eo5EPBZSiLTGa6LoqX8ReFAm@A/Gm9zlxhMN9f6EKrjVw2fZgcWOd9pmcreWHy2/PC67Tf@FujlTWFY7hR5HVeux8)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000761)

### How it works

It generates the partitions using the trivial gf:

```pascal
prod(q=[1,infty], 1/(1-x^q))
```

and then uses the [Möbius Transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusTransform.html).

Comment: Anyone having the feeling that A000761(3) should be 464 instead of 468?

Answer (score 4):

## 74. [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 77 bytes, [A000363](https://oeis.org/A000363)

```
(define(a n)(/(-(expt 5 n)(*(sub1(* 2 n))(expt 3 n))(* 2 n)2(-(* 2 n n)))16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WikpKZl5qVqJCrkaWroa@hqpFYUlCiYgnhaGsWlSYYaWgpGQJ4mRMIYzIQIGQFVg1kgMU1DM03N/0BjzDX/AwA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000077)

Answer (score 4):

## 75. GolfScript, 36 bytes, [A000077](https://oeis.org/A000077)

```
~2\?):P.*,{.P/.*\P%.*6*+}%.&{P<},0-,
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84oxl7TKkBPS6daL0BfTysmQFVPy0xLu1ZVT606wKZWx0BX5/9/UwA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000036)

Comment: This is similar to the GolfScript answer I was working on when an earlier answer was changed for no good reason.

Answer (score 4):

## 82. [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 14 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290)

```
....I:*....u@O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/18PCDyttEBUqYP///9mAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000014)

Comment: Finally Cubix gets in here :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions I was in the midst of editing this one! thanks. As a note, this is actually a 6-byter but 6 was already taken.

Comment: Dang, too slow for me

Answer (score 4):

## 95. [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 478 bytes, [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 1 l 1 r 3 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

Adds `1` to the input, since this has to be `0`-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZFNDoIwEIX3nGJOQER37HDjTknkAhWGMrG2pC1BT1/Lb5AY2biYdPIm8730jWVPcu6kwCpIlbFwKUvKMW4hAuFLd28YpJTfmxoY1MwYlBw1cEWSd2tZhXBkNxQlmQr1KwwG3FqPzcT8zUuKgiwpCYkQ6GkRkIGWec3PmYWrZTqvSBRwbh6olVB89vw2i@XoO9R@6z9r/4H8qfb56DmjQ9/rP@UkR/YGb3GuCbW8oJzTdm73Bg)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000478)

Answer (score 4):

## 102. Perl 5, 158 bytes, [A000335](https://oeis.org/A000335)

```perl
@b[0]=1;
while($n++<=$ARGV[0]){
  for($d=1;$d<=$n;$d++){
    for($k=$d;$k<=$n;$k+=$d){@b[$n]+=$d*$d*($d+1)*($d+2)/6*@b[$n-$k]}
  }
  @b[$n]/=$n
}
print @b[-1]
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hKdog1tbQmqs8IzMnVUMlT1vbxlbFMcg9DCiuWc2loJCWX6ShkgJUopIClMkDUtraYAmoVLatSoq1SjZELlsbyNOsBpqqkhcLYmsBEVC7tqEmmDLS1DfTAsvqqmTH1gJNAWGIcn2gCVy1XAVFmXklICFdw9j///@bAgA). This is a full program which takes input as a command-line parameter.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000158)

Answer (score 4):

## 104. [Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala), 267 bytes, [A000713](http://oeis.org/A000713)

```
static int main(string[] args) {
	int n = int.parse(stdin.read_line());
	int[] a = new int[n+1];
	a[0] = 1;
	for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
		int iter = i==1?3:2;
		for(int j=0;j<iter;j++)
			for(int k=i;k<=n;k++) a[k] += a[k-i];
	}
	stdout.printf("%d\n", a[n]);
	return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BDoIwEEXXcIqGxASCEsCdpfEg2JiJFDOgoylFF4az44wLV2363sz/fcEN1nUKEPCikIK6A1I6BY90ba0Cf50y9YkjQaSMKMUT/OTY6ZAK76A735BcmmX6p8kUi@TeIreUV5YBtKXl14qv/cOnsg5NpbExpDHPM474ZWBwXmKMqY77Q8363x9MqYdGBD3wBJM/Gg3qUVaNDBS0o1W5kXOHEr7EEbd9zFyd/xX6NNl0J0q2bJCV2t6F2ZMqdbysa11@AQ)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000267).

### Explanation

Uses the g.f. `1/[(1-x)^3 (1-x^2)^2 (1-x^3)^2 (1-x^4)^2 ...]`.

Comment: `{a={s=[];b(it,it,s);return s.size()};b={n,m,p->if(!n){p<<0;return;};for(int i=Math.min(m,n);i>=1;i--){b(n-i, i, p);}};(0..it).sum{d->(0..d).sum{a(it)*a(d-it)}}}` - so much wasted effort on my part :(.

Comment: I implemented A000041 to implement A000712 to implement A000713 xD.

Answer (score 4):

## 114. [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 1560 bytes, [A000228](https://oeis.org/A000228)

```
Dirs = [0,1,-1].permutations.to_a

def addhp(a,b)
  (0..2).map{ |i| a[i]+b[i] }
end

def hexh(n,use,seen,possible)
  if n==0
    testhex(use) ? 1 : 0
  else
    if possible.empty?
      0
    else
      elem = possible[0]
      remain = possible[1..-1]
      newseen = [elem]+seen
      c = hexh(n,use,newseen,remain)
      newpossible = Dirs.map{ |d| addhp(elem,d) }
      newpossible = newpossible.select \
         { |p| ! ((seen.includes? p) || (remain.includes? p)) }
      c + hexh(n-1,use+[elem],newseen,remain+newpossible)
    end
  end
end

def hex(n)
  empty = [] of Array(Int32)
  hexh(n,empty,empty,[[0,0,0]])
end

def rot(hl)
  hl.map{ |h| h.rotate }
end

def neg(hl)
  hl.map{ |h| h.map{ |v| -v } }
end

def mirr(hl)
  hl.map{ |h| [0,2,1].map{ |i| h[i] } }
end

def normhex(hl)
  x = hl.map{ |h| h[0] }.min 
  hl = hl.map{ |h| addhp(h,[-x,0,x]) }
  x = hl.map{ |h| h[1] }.min
  hl.map{ |h| addhp(h,[0,-x,x]) }
end

def check(shl,chl)
  ( shl <=> chl.sort ) == 1
end

def testonesided(hl,ohl)
  return false if check(hl,ohl)
  nhl = normhex(rot(ohl))
  return false if check(hl,nhl)
  nhl = normhex(rot(nhl))
  return false if check(hl,nhl)
  nhl = normhex(neg(ohl))
  return false if check(hl,nhl)
  nhl = normhex(rot(nhl))
  return false if check(hl,nhl)
  nhl = normhex(rot(nhl))
  return false if check(hl,nhl)
  true
end

def testhex(hl)
  hl = normhex(hl)
  return false if hl[0] != hl.min
  hl.sort!
  mhl = normhex(mirr(hl))
  testonesided(hl,hl) && testonesided(hl,mhl)
end

n = ARGV.size==1 ? ARGV[0].to_i : 7
puts "f(#{n}) = #{hex(n)}"
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001560)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVRNi9swEL37V8zuwiITRcTpoVDqhoVC6bWHXlJTHFupTW3ZSPI2aZzfns5Yduxk00J7aAJG0sx78/WkRO@NjYvT6X2uDYSwXvCAz4NI1FKXjY1tXikjbPU19rxUbiFO06xmMd/4HgBbCLH0RRnXB2jzFuJ1Hs02@IGjJ1XqEJncZUzxxkhupFS8rozJN4UkgnwLKgwXuAKw0lj0ZejowwoCeANkkIWRnR19B6iQZW33q@4YwMHPfrSUJZYyeK8XUW/QsoxzNTUFQmCxvVnJH5QhdYEoohnteluCp5NKelfuGP2RYGBGd@po35u07RtHvDz1sT@3EJOdMOiaWPjSO@IPeeoW7oAxCi1ylRRNKs0Kah/aFpjL5eJ8DJTArM9/HlAFM1fiVSGzSQauKBqj@04HyrqSuylQtyKotvCkdbxnH5V9tSRj36zOp/@uUVz4jyJ/JNOVZVnRAYq@WVkLmcDz2MqpjpT8dtPTLZ9bmD/DcQooc61vIDCJJUeBn1WbdYK9CFXpkqp04B2NfhoSBQVHUaKSOuorsxt0xtfzHVa7i9wMXpIEPclVemf4giOBg58TSzKZfGcmK3jicmOAG3gbvkNTIUylLfgQhhCMGLpXlZImT2WKFfHKIbW0jVawjfHe0N1y1KNddYUNnaAxkeGPSPU7pPonJA38f8f8G6TVjbxs86iZC9LbDc8K0tGdk8UgA5rgHS7LC4JByV3Uq3HiMTw@vjguKWiXHL1nT58@fBYm/ynDMMC3lbYYnJ71HJ/Z117dWAP3W/ZwUEfUDzwc3CU/3nun0y8)

This is a full program that takes input from the command line and computes the value for `n=7` if no argument was given, because that has a nice value. I don't really know this language, it may show. And I don't know how to give command line arguments to TIO, you may just replace the assignment to `n` in the line before the last one instead.

Strangely, it compiles fine (on old debian jessie using crystal's external debian repository) with `crystal build hex.cr`, but the optimizing call `crystal build hex.cr --release` fails with what seems to be an internal error.

Comment: `partitions` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: It seems to always output `f(7) = 333` regardless of the input. (by the way, [Crystal](https://tio.run/#crystal) is on TIO)

Comment: Do you run it locally? I can use command line arguments just fine. But I have no idea how to give them with TIO. And I wonder how I did not see the language there.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I don't have it installed (and I'm on my work computer right now so I can't). I was trying to get it to work on TIO but I couldn't figure it out either, best I could tell it kept trying to open files named `6` or whatever I input.

Comment: @ChristianSievers see [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39492442#39492442) from Dennis

Comment: The compile problem is nothing special, I can't even build a hello world program with `--release`

Comment: @BusinessCat TIO's handling of crystal programs has been changed. Command line arguments work as expected now.

Answer (score 4):

## 124. [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC), 796 bytes, [A000278](https://oeis.org/A000278)

```
IT'S SHOWTIME

HEY CHRISTMAS TREE input
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE result
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE x
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE y
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE temp1
YOU SET US UP @I LIED

GET YOUR ASS TO MARS input
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY

STICK AROUND input

GET TO THE CHOPPER temp1
HERE IS MY INVITATION x
ENOUGH TALK

GET TO THE CHOPPER x
HERE IS MY INVITATION x
GET UP y
ENOUGH TALK

GET TO THE CHOPPER y
HERE IS MY INVITATION temp1
YOU'RE FIRED temp1
ENOUGH TALK

GET TO THE CHOPPER input
HERE IS MY INVITATION input
GET DOWN 1
ENOUGH TALK

CHILL

GET TO THE CHOPPER result
HERE IS MY INVITATION x
ENOUGH TALK

TALK TO THE HAND result
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##lZI/b8IwEMX3fIq3MXfrWJMc@ERsp7ZDlLEqDJUoRRQk@PTpmdA/QkHQxcO933v23fllu/5YLV67juMoIGjXRDaUZZpa5NpziEYFRE@Et/Vmv8taVyNQRB1QV3hilEzFEL5dfu5X/@AP96PHS9Q6VN6NSzJuiN8t3zcPV@KzqZRE8lBBcAejfDj3WjhwhHVNxmiUjUlWYZZwKIxrm2u4CZ5rCpGdDVC2wC@q1ZwQNRmph4Y8iWgMFawilW2WiSmfQXlXi62/8fQasYpLmnBVRf78ei1@cIBpwXbOUaUbZWhkXT3ViKqcDboPV50JlkEcb0Ycr0T8jHUk6oRTf33pVmDf63BoryVT4RqLi7Bcc1kOZp6/211jSue3X6ed/fmrp6WNiSwiecNWdlV03eMX)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000796)

Comment: [useful for the next person, perhaps?](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/nthdecimaldigit.pdf)

Comment: I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY: How does this work?

Comment: @NieDzejkob `GET YOUR ASS TO MARS` assigns a variable from a method call, `DO IT NOW` calls the method, and `I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY` reads an integer input.

Comment: @Giuseppe Of course, lots of math software have built-ins for arbitrary precision pi, too.

Comment: @KSmarts sure, but I'm having trouble picking one that hasn't been used yet, so I provided that link as at least one example of a "roll your own" algorithm

Comment: @Giuseppe Maple is unused

Answer (score 4):

## 168. [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 261 bytes, [A000101](https://oeis.org/A000101)

```python
import sympy

def A000101(n):
  i = 0
  p = 2
  max_difference = 0
  while i <= n:
    next_p = sympy.nextprime(p)
    if next_p-p > max_difference:
      max_difference = next_p - p
      i = i + 1
    p = next_p    
  return p

print A000101(int(raw_input()))
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000261)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwDIbve4ocW2TS7igq@CRjuJQVbBdqx9anr@ksCmIvf5N8@ZNQitPsu5YSpZytozlEeCZHqWlGNHBTSmmlhZenBsDCBRQrsXasbtj60RqDAf0da3Gd7AMZPV/AlyYAj1vsS89ufCwhBetQkNzr1lSkJbj@mL4d/oyqpi1QJcpyFg6g95i@CD9OBYxL8Ew3PNvHz2X8F2FYe@tpiUJKmbNWLw)

Others want to starve the challenge of the use of Python, so I'll help.

Comment: Might want to note that you use sympy somewhere. It's not in the standard library...

Answer (score 4):

## 171. [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 541 bytes, [A000204](https://oeis.org/A000204)

```
Putin hears all your life
Putin is safe because its Putin
Trump is, 1000001 minus 1000000; great
Our beautiful America is, 1000003 minus 1000000; the greatest
Of course everything is, Trump plus Trump;
Every million is for Trump;
If you want, Putin is Trump?;:
Say Putin!
Otherwise: if for you, Putin is Everything?;:
Say America!
Otherwise:
Money is Everything
As long as, our Money less than Putin;:
Russia is America
America is, Trump plus America;
Trump is Russia
Money is, Money plus Million;!
Say America with force!!
America is great.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZExbsMwDEV3nYLeg8JJt3goMmToEKRoewHFoGICim2IUgOf3qUk21DrSRb5/uenvAuPkVtHo5/nj@Cphw61Y9DWwjQEB5YMqlwhBtYG4YatDoxAniFV1HeUkfoO9nX89vCgPvDyVzdwd6i9uoreDbUgJlg4PdBRqwvs9T/mO8wostAGWplIjPEH3eQ76u8Jzu6jFTIdG3WODSJmLQ1pbjO4tfZuYjB46t7vYAuWim/NUX3pKd9W6ir27kmMRyCTJAQsmPM2xgoukUpUXYYep7/t6sRgB5ley/RxybnHIrNE1n22EM3PwExxQ6uyKpdW5F6um@0lIKOb@27xSN2XvJimKoeGJ/kupmyxqgqf/AAv83yofwE)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000541)

Pseudocode for explanation:

```
var Putin = int(input())
var Trump = 1
var America = 3
var Everything = Trump + Trump
var Million = Trump
if(Putin == Trump)
    print(Putin)
else if(Putin == Everything)
    print(America)
else
    var Money = Everything
    while(Money < Putin)
        var Russia = America
        America = Trump + America
        Trump = Russia
        Money = Money + Million
    print(America)
America is great.
```

Answer (score 4):

## 174. [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 54 bytes, [A000257](https://oeis.org/A000257)

```cpp
int f(int n){return n?~-~-~-~-(n<<3)*f(~-n)/-~-~n:01;}
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBDoIwEIXhvadoMCQzAgq6MLFFL@LGtIy20YFUWBF79Uo1L3mLf/HpYajuWsdoeRQE6Rln342TZ8GXUP0HrNQBNwShYtylxKe6kZ@4tqyfk@nUezS23z7Oq0S8bpYBZ@r9T3RtqKUrCtXUEge/JIKMIN8bFK3Ij@bKWelKAoe4mF8)
- Next sequence: [A000054](https://oeis.org/A000054) :P
- Alternative [C solution](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoMwFESvEgThfzWo7aKLxJu4EfWXBDuVYFfSXD0qMvAWjzejHpcB75SEwLu7GObtFxD1PYK1Ty6EogbXl4K5C9Waf/oMDuR5l28g38XG@LK0bWN4DQ6bUCaUPyZWncpfU4@s8pWcPZ/XAw) (as C (clang) and C (gcc) are not considered to be different languages, even if Python interpreters are, I switched to C++)

Comment: What the hell is this next sequence... Wonder if Mathematica has a built-in

Comment: Wasn't C already used before?

Comment: @NieDzejkob `Every 150 (valid) answers, the number of times a language may be used increases.` It was used once before my answer.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Answer 32 and 157.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Right... I am going to use another compiler.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Maybe you should edit in the C++ solution so that the only interpreter stupidity is with Python? (we said python is OK because of the long chain of answers that would have to be deleted)

Comment: @NieDzejkob The OP said `C (gcc)` and `C (clang)` are considered to be the same language, so I switched to C++.

Comment: Given that CPython and PyPy are considered different languages, [I have reverted that decision](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another#comment351752_133754) and am going to say that clang and gcc are different languages. Please don't change this answer however, this is just for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

## 185. [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes, [A000142](http://oeis.org/A000142)

```matlab
@(n)factorial(n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08zLTG5JL8oMzEHyLb@n6ZhqvkfAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000017)

Comment: Next sequence just asks for some funky language. Malbolge anyone?

Comment: Next sequence is uncomputable and erroneous. I'm editing your bytecount (no code changes) to give us an actual sequence to use :) Nothing personal; we've run into this problem before **edit** never mind

Comment: If [A000017](http://oeis.org/A000017) just an erroneous version of [A032522](http://oeis.org/A032522) does that mean it's not really even a sequence? Would hard-coding the 19 values on OEIS count as outputting it in its entirety, then?

Comment: I believe hardcoding is permissible in this case since it's not computable / a finite sequence.

Comment: Just hardcoding is lame. You could compute the real sequence and add a "correction" for the error. If we knew how the wrong result was obtained, we could even try to redo that...

Answer (score 4):

## 194. [ALGOL 68 (Genie)](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/algol.html), 589 bytes, [A000160](https://oeis.org/A000160)

```
BEGIN
  LONG LONG INT n   := read int + 4;
  LONG LONG INT r   := 0;
  LONG LONG REAL ma := ( n / 4.0 ) ** 1.5;
  LONG LONG REAL mb := ( n / 3.0 ) ** 1.5;
  LONG LONG REAL mc := ( n / 2.0 ) ** 1.5;
  LONG LONG REAL x  := 2.0 / 3;
  INT a             := 1;
  WHILE a <= ma DO
    INT b := a;
    WHILE b <= mb DO
      INT c := b;
      WHILE c <= mc DO
        INT d := c;
        WHILE a ** x + b ** x + c ** x + d ** x <= n DO
          r := r + 1;
          d := d + 1
        OD;
        c := c + 1
      OD;
      b := b + 1
    OD;
    a := a + 1
  OD;
  print ( whole ( r , 0 ))
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJBS8NAEIXv@RXv2FapiVYR1x5aEmogJCCC591NqUKaliDYfx9nZrvZiKI5bCbvfUze7qxudofm7n7X9@tsk5cRUFTlxi15@YIWwMMS3VbXeG8/cIGF@gF1Doq/O8/ZqsBeszOhPldYzGNMMZshmd/@hpqA3vyD2oBe/42eJBpD1JV9DqwxfshP2Hl9youMvMclx06riE3GJZhW8u0gI5DxkMMklFFnxYFWQBtAh9aMWjVo/te0jROdsfGF9UXtCmrWjnuBzp7HQ0SiRqr0r1kdxCoNgCS1IzuYslczWN6QMeqz7MRjxxdigs@3Q7Old4dL0CimUVamfZ/EXw)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000589)

Based on the comments of the sequence, counts the solutions to the inequality

> a<sup>(2/3)</sup>+b<sup>(2/3)</sup>+c<sup>(2/3)</sup>+d<sup>(2/3)</sup> ≤ n

for any four integers 1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d.

I also gave a fairly straightforward next sequence, to make up for last time.

Edit: This was originally written for Java 8, but I missed that there were already two Java 8 answers when I wrote this. Probably because one was labeled "Java (OpenJDK 8)" and the other was just "Java 8". Whatever the reason, this answer was invalid. I re-wrote it in a different language, with the same byte count, to fix this.

Comment: Note that this is valid because `You can assume that neither the input nor the required output will be outside your languages numerical range`

Comment: @Stephen You could get picky and say that it doesn't count because Java has the "long" type, but that's an easy fix. All of the test cases on the OEIS page fit in 32-bit integers anyway.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about that. It needs to work for n=0 to 1000 then or it is invalid (since you also have BigInteger)

Comment: @Stephen Fixed (Byte count unchanged).

Answer (score 4):

## 199. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 92 bytes, [A000466](https://oeis.org/A000466)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val n = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    println(4*n*n-1);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08jsSi92ErBsagosdImuKQoMy/dTrOaSwEIyhJzFPIUbBU880pS01OL9ID80lT/NLCOaINYTWuwqgKglpKcPA0TrTytPF1DoGjt////TQE)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000092)

Answer (score 4):

## 207. [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 389 bytes, [A003275](https://oeis.org/A003275)

```lua
coprime = eq(max((#table.unpack)(where(range(1,max(a,b)),eq(d%first(a,b,c,d,e),0)*eq(e%a,0),a,b))),1)
phi = len(where(range(1,n),coprime(a,first(n,b,c)),n))
A003275 = list()
local A003275_n = 0
return function(n)
	while(#A003275 < n)do
		A003275_n = A003275_n + 1
		if(phi(A003275_n) == phi(A003275_n+1))then
			A003275[#A003275+1] = phi(A003275_n)
		end
	end
	return A003275[#A003275]
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NTsMwEITP8VNYqirtEgvF/IgLOfAcqEKusyEW7iaYROXtzYYm/ORiWfPNzI5Lx0g5@35I4US61vQOJ/cJsBudkOuJB@ffEM4dJYLk@JXAmtnhzBHRiL3ZtyF9jLNgvGkMoanwSgDtnfzMtxGNRTV0QS5E4k0do1kGSMmljOcySTGieqqq25uH@zkaBKGKvXdRL/ILC6hUonFKrNuJ/Rh6BkZVnLsQCXZr/lEzNr0qir/J33@prbDQgsyEHxl1Xet/SmkRx45YzGvT83qjtAe9scuOgrhRl2eZuc0dlNCc890X)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000389)

Answer (score 4):

## 225. [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), 80 bytes, [A001232](http://oeis.org/A001232)

```
Sub s(n)
While k<n+1
i=i+1
If i*9=StrReverse(i) Then k=k+1
Wend
MsgBox i
End Sub
```

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000080)

Output is a popup message. A not-very-exciting sequence deserves a not-very-exciting solution, I think.

Comment: I hate the fact that can't see that a new answer showed up without scrolling to the top or reloading the page... At least I learned the basics of a new language.

Comment: [C for next seq](http://oeis.org/A000080/a000080.c.txt)

Comment: @NieDzejkob Same here. I (sort of) know Perl now.

Answer (score 4):

## 235. [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 3295 bytes, [A000512](https://oeis.org/A000512)

4 days passed without anyone answered.

```pascal
Type
	int = LongInt; // Can be changed to Integer

Var
	n, n_column, matrices_len, i, j, k: int;
	row_values, matrices: Array of array of int;
	row_id, column_sum: Array of int;
	valid: Boolean;

Function next_permutation (var A : Array of int): Boolean;
var x, y, z, temp: int;
begin
	if Length(A) <> n then writeln('Error!!');
	x := Length(A) - 1; // or High(A)
	z := x;
	while (x > 0) and (A[x-1] > A[x]) do Dec(x);
	y := x;
	while y < z do
	begin
		temp := A[z]; A[z] := A[y]; A[y] := temp;
		Inc(y); Dec(z);
	end;
	if (x = 0) then
		Exit(false);
	y := x; temp := A[x-1];
	while A[y] < temp do Inc(y);
	A[x-1] := A[y]; A[y] := temp;
	Exit(true);
end;

Function equivalent (mat1, mat2: int): Boolean;
{ Use highly sub-optimal solution, O(n!^2 x n^2).
  O( n! x n^2 x log(n) ) solution is possible by trying all row permutation
  and sort the columns, and check if the matrices are equal.
  Sort the rows and the columns alternatively does not work, though.
}
var
	xP, yP: Array of int;
	x, y: int;
	different: Boolean;
begin
	SetLength(xP, n);
	SetLength(yP, n);
	for x := 0 to n-1 do
	begin
		xP[x] := x;
		yP[x] := x;
	end;
	repeat
		repeat
			different := false;
			for x := 0 to n-1 do
			begin
				for y := 0 to n-1 do
				begin
					if row_values[matrices[mat1, x], y] <>
					row_values[matrices[mat2, xP[x]], yP[y]] then
					begin
						different := true;
						break;
					end;
				end;
				if different then break;
			end;
			if not different then Exit(true);
		until not next_permutation(xP);
	until not next_permutation(yP);
	Exit(false);
end;

Begin
	Read(n); Inc(n);
	If n < 3 then
	begin
		Writeln(0);
		Halt;
	end;
	SetLength(row_values, (n * (n - 1) * (n - 2)) div 6);
	n_column := 0;
	for i := 0 to n-1 do
		for j := i+1 to n-1 do
			for k := j+1 to n-1 do
			begin
				SetLength(row_values[n_column], n);
				row_values[n_column, i] := 1;
				row_values[n_column, j] := 1;
				row_values[n_column, k] := 1;
				Inc(n_column);
			end;
	// Dynamic array in FP is 0-based
	if n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) <> 6 * n_column then
	begin
		WriteLn('Error!');
		exit();
	end;

	matrices_len := 0;
	SetLength(matrices, 4);

	SetLength(row_id, n);
	SetLength(column_sum, n);
	while true do
	begin
		for i := 0 to n-1 do column_sum[i] := 0;

		for i := 0 to n-1 do
		begin
			for j := 0 to n-1 do
				Inc(column_sum[j], row_values[row_id[i], j]);
		end;

		valid := true;
		for i := 0 to n-1 do
		begin
			if column_sum[i] <> 3 then // column_sum[i] = sum of all values on column i
			begin
				valid := false;
				break;
			end;
		end;
		if valid then
		begin
			if matrices_len = length(matrices) then
				SetLength(matrices, 2 * length(matrices));
			matrices[matrices_len] := copy(row_id, 0, n);
			Inc(matrices_len);
		end;

		i := n - 1;
		while (i <> -1) and (row_id[i] = n_column - 1) do
			Dec(i);
		if i = -1 then
			Break;
		Inc(row_id[i]); Inc(i);
		while i < n do
		begin
			row_id[i] := row_id[i-1];
			Inc(i);
		end;
	end;

	row_id := nil; column_sum := nil;

	k := 0;
	for i := 0 to matrices_len-1 do
	begin
		valid := true;
		for j := 0 to i-1 do
		begin
			if matrices[j, 0] <> -1 then
			begin
				if equivalent(i, j) then
				begin
					valid := false;
					break;
				end;
			end;
		end;
		if valid then
			inc(k)
		else
			matrices[i, 0] := -1;
	end;
	Writeln(k);
End.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVdNb9s4ED1Lv2JyqrRrp7a36MFOAiTbFA0QYIN2Pw6GG9ASbTOWKS8lJ5IX/e3ZGX5IlOOkF0ckH2eG8x5nmC0rEpb1F9vk@fnPesvDQMgSzuE2l8sbWU7g/Xv4nUmYc0hWTC55CmUOuMKXXIXh30yFgeyBvE/ybLfBrw0rlUh4cZ9xHIkePPRgPQa0OgkDlT/dP7Jsx4sWOIZLpVgN@QKY@2jRIu2BMX1f7DYe1kDQmEjHcJXnGWdyEoafdzIpRS5B8qq833K12ZVMT0SPTMEldE3E3l5ar3pQ92Dfg5JvtjbqOV8KiXlZwC2Xy3IVXcZwdgESyhWX8KREyTMZvbtWKlcnJ@9iDKuC8bmH7sNQJzJX8EUsaSoM9gSpEPu0EhmHqIILGMTAZArR5bTqD2c4gR@zGNIcPvEkqshy3d1WwxnsERAGNsqAAifM5XQ/m@hfM6r1qNYjwqCJ4EYmUR1PtPU9WecyneiTYjjnFA4dEYHXlSijBcsK7sUArSsKt4lJezkzqylpRTsJA3uq16LRPkq1Ixc6jpZL/u9OINMclRmhbIZaPKPxIYH/wV8FhxVmOKuh2M37@bYUG5ZBgQIiQz34I5In30dQgfw@ik9DwAmQJ2aMv1m@jGQMcbMDRAHbvCjEHA82r6FUtZBLYFkGqE7w9IW2iLsiVyVlzYoWdU6zyYona8C80ooTPsqd09FYRoF8cxvRbqE3eVbQYcmVREePHM@W5rhb5iU85WqNWl3lu@XqNPxBEkbx3aGI715cFZK2u4epWCy4wnx62bMC@sZLK1yyI4m4dqp2UwuUshb5gMqB7A87GqzuULdOqEHtj4zCFN9yVuJa89GGREgtNdr7iqOgcWUQ9RGEByFFt6Vn6giYGi1VM8wMKvbCYF8BjhBIByHwHSp35u5G11P3HCTniV2YK87WdmCy4H9ghO1OXVhavAMhhkg/wPn3Jgh2shSZhh0WQOSTEG8Aag3o3HVzEa/M@b5yluL1mOgrrWVwgxHhVf/N5sLl4R9bEwc6pC8o3ob5Vkt@L4gk/EI/WChj9zWKsfKJR/hIRlx/0Txb/YmXpNP0A02LX4ddNdDKmlYeDlda8o7FNnWeZ1b5XYW0fU9oiQ/fQDz8FLH2ETrJdin2dIB95FMt2UYktl8KCZ/vqFAN@nNW8FQX8KMJpbb1EYdNNo/Qdtu0Mt3JAk5yaHpDGPj93bHRJs6t9uBDTOhuSqmZH1SUtrfbJdNDSM@dknKMcO9hMDXpH5DP18TREN2o5LBiUMo9mw/IuceTOQF6IipNbkxKzCvEv@8/iwAJ6saOxJhLRM@E7tI5trKNfh1h0zGhADYmy6DoSriJpK2gwYtCYv9gEAZuC5kfXYflc8i67MZt7TtG/QgldrjDKNgvqI19zVySb@tGI4PmrhEjPraTdp1hrXGate8oQbnsD@1LquEMD9GoXl8KQzm9fERssyEQhFS5s125vFEQjSFb/swm4xNdYhhdhlvHGKMbmFeSMSjao7gDGZg@lMgmngzcFGLWxyugn6ODZnxUnK38xTFxNjzh430wMxlt8tKqDZHt0yyit76nDK8pHlOl3w9dg3tbn/ifSRKtYwKglY6chA5zTPQ1ncY1oTUm@lqmp@Hz84f/AQ)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A003295)

I can easily delete a byte to get [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A003294) instead (which seems to be much easier to understand), but I didn't do that.

Comment: Mathematica code in case next sequence will be hard coded: https://tio.run/##NUu7CsMgFP2VO6ptSax0kk4Fp0J1FgURgw4mGP1/axO6nPfJrsWQXUve9a4kPEHJzcfocg47BzGCQpTUxTJD0CmYmQ5lzoJSgzGHekzRjVK4APoBIwLbO0F0EsP9Ezz4M86WPuaZg9zT2vRrC8uSfApre6fadL1CMab3Lw

Comment: @HusnainRaza Comment downvote. (Don't hardcode the sequence!)

Answer (score 4):

## 236. [Axiom](http://www.axiom-developer.org), 341 bytes, [A003295](https://oeis.org/A003295)

```
qpc(n,k) ==  -- inspired by 3rd PARI code for A010815
  qr := divide(n,k)
  if qr.remainder>0 then return 0
  sq := perfectSqrt(24*qr.quotient+1)
  sq case "failed" => 0
  jacobi(12,sq)

qp(k) == series(n+->qpc(n,k),'q=0)

q := series q

F := q*qp(3)*(qp(33)/(qp(1)*qp(11)))

s := q*(-11+(1+3*F)^2*(1/F+1+3*F))

f(n) == coefficients(s).(n+1)
```

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000341)

Put it in a file called `a003295.input` and, at the axiom prompt, type `)read a003295`. Now you can for example call `f 25`. The first time it will give a warning before still giving the correct result. Here it is computing the first values:

```
(9) -> [f n for n in 0..20]
   Cannot compile map: f 
   We will attempt to interpret the code.

   (9)
   [1, - 5, 17, 46, 116, 252, 533, 1034, 1961, 3540, 6253, 10654, 17897, 29284,
    47265, 74868, 117158, 180608, 275562, 415300, 620210]
                                              Type: List(Expression(Integer))
```

`qp(k)` computes the series of the q-Pochhammer symbol for `q^k`. The definition of `F` and `s` follows the Mathematica code.

Comment: could have used `coefficient(s,n)`

Comment: I wonder if I should upvote or downvote this answer.

Comment: @user202729 why would you downvote?

Comment: Can you add an explanation what is the sequence?

Comment: @user202729 I hardly understand the basics of what is said in the OEIS entry, so I'm not sure what I can explain. But I like that it is related to the fascinating phenomenon of monstrous moonshine.

Answer (score 4):

## 256. [Pygmy Forth](http://pygmy.utoh.org/pygmy64.html), 562 bytes, [A000454](https://oeis.org/A000454)

```forth
CODE PICK  dpush(_stack[~dpop()]) END-CODE
: COEFFICIENT-A(N-1) 2 * 5 - 2 * ;
: COEFFICIENT-A(N-2) DUP 6 - * 6 * 55 + ;
: COEFFICIENT-A(N-3) DUP DUP 7 - * 2 * 25 + SWAP 2 * 7 - * ;
: COEFFICIENT-A(N-4) 4 - DUP * DUP * ;
: ADVANCE DUP COEFFICIENT-A(N-1) 2 PICK * OVER COEFFICIENT-A(N-2) 4 PICK * - OVER COEFFICIENT-A(N-3) 5 PICK * + OVER COEFFICIENT-A(N-4) 6 PICK * - SWAP 1 + ;
CODE ADVANCE-LOOP  for i in range(dpop()): ADVANCE() END-CODE
CODE CLEAN-STACK  global _stack; _stack = [_stack[-1]] END-CODE
: A000454 0 0 0 1 5 5 PICK ADVANCE-LOOP DROP CLEAN-STACK ;
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000562)

Nice, round number of answers! Computes up to `16 A454` on 64-bit Forths, and you can [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##fZBRa8IwFIXf9yvOY1PpMGmqMBmjaAWZWFHnXobgZrWF2Q5bsfv17iam0TFYSpObc7/be263xaFKvd1WHefzG9ZOzvAI4TrCzeEhYC5JHmcUOx03XwkKfArQQmCSgtHF8F2mKzXGpcaEwXz9jdyTbCW1INmdbWhXza8N/6xaXBv@s2q/aaiXh9o2fEA/joZDDgdklzIcDAIuAsLU2WsQYRFByOBlig4hLu0EB2TAkr4lfUOqt6tp9Umh6PlrONW3i26LpS2WVCwpqYpdsyssHCzDST/SijEvMB31nykfL6NZY1c2oncj@zSYkVs3sqQxLK2tcTNRKAOJtn441ZrqNp4GsXUyjmOacUZb70xjjKNw4s0XIXE0S4Fsk6yRFidUBTZ0rfB@rCjK8h3KAmlySPCxzin4/MIpq1Lsk31x@EZWlsekpN@gjCyi@QK8a1qPLsbuf3XTPnqaPP8A) on gforth with some modifications. However, Pygmy Forth is arbitrary precision and it can compute n=1000 in a blink of an eye.

### Explanation

Forth is a stack-based language, like 05AB1E or Actually, but it was not designed that way to be esoteric. Forth was designed in 1970, and being stack based allowed the interpreter to fit in extremely small space - even now, an x86 interpreter could fit in the MBR and VBR (two 512 byte sectors) of a hard disk, with the code loaded from a FAT32 filesystem (first-hand experience). The most important consequences of the stack-oriented design are the postfix notation in which all calculations are described, and having to keep the words  ("functions") small so you don't get lost. Breaking up a word into smaller chunks is called *factoring*.

ADVANCE expects the last 4 numbers of the sequence on the stack, with <s>a cherry</s> the sequence index `n` on top, and calculates the next number in the sequence as well as increments n. The sequence can start as `0, 0, 0, 1`, and the next number will be assigned the index of 5, so you can calculate a specific element of the sequence like this:

```forth
0 0 0 1 5 ADVANCE ADVANCE ADVANCE ADVANCE ADVANCE
DROP ( the index )
. ( print )
```

Now we only need to loop `ADVANCE` a given number of times, and this is exactly what `A454` does. The `0 0 0 1 5` at the beginning initializes the stack, then `5 PICK` brings the argument this word was given to the top. Normally in Forth, one would do `limit start ?DO stuff LOOP`, which is a construct equivalent to Python's `for i in range(start, limit): stuff`. However, Pygmy Forth is missing a lot of words, so I have to make up for it with `CODE`, which is used to define words in Python. At the end of `A454`, `DROP` is used to remove the sequence index, leaving the result at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 4):

## 260. [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 504 bytes, [A001333](https://oeis.org/A001333)

```
<>       # switch to another stack
(())(()) # push two 1s. Assuming top = a n-1, second top = a n-2 apart from the input
<>({}<>) # transfer the input to this stack
{        # repeat input times
    ({}[()]<     # subtract 1, ignore 
      (
        ({}<>)   # move top a n-1 to another stack
        ({})     # + top a n-1
        <>{}<>   # add to a n-2 on the other stack
      )          # and push 2 * a n-1 + a n-2
    >)           # and push back again
}
{}{}     # remove redundant values on top
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFNboMwEIX3PsVI3UDTVCVritRzVF0MYMBKsJHHThaIs9Ox@QlSLHnjefPNe@PSotLn5obXec4LWM4b0EO5qgNnALVxnbRADqurSJI0DZclgycWPAxk9Ak/RL5XuuWOAb4BQZ@zDyBZGV0f3i6AA1oHjTU9MBaUHrwTeZGMU14EqrOoqeF5ezWYcJ2i1cEIu0krB4luU6lekggFZv0m6V@@RfElQysHbEi12lgJYiEkYmOt44O8N3cZHccMrxs4tKTrhNNTv5fzIiBjGes6YmJ@o2OyV2IK8EyGvLW43wu8r0ZOCyCqi4P4qC4ZB9jyj4pJjNM47YuKqaysva5RO7jjzUuKZtj5PGdf/w)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000504)

The actual code is only 52 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/38ZOQ0NTE4SBrOpaGzvNaiAVraEZa6MB4QNJoByYaadZWw2E//8bGgAA)

Use the recurrence relation

> a(n) = 2a(n-1) + a(n-2)

described on the OEIS page.

---

The mathematical information about that sequence is pretty simple and elementary, and not worth the effort I write the explanation, so I decide to not write explanation for this sequence.

Comment: Huh, using the explanation as the actual program. Original, +1

Comment: Note that 503 is already used. I switch to 504.

Answer (score 4):

## 261. [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 115 bytes, [A000504](https://oeis.org/A000504)

```
/
 i                            >'Qa*:\ o
  /.!.h*?2Ea*?a5+*+2+*?2*3+.!w=
                              >?*?2-.!K @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1@fSyFTAQ@wUw9M1LKKUcjnUlDQ11PUy9CyN3JN1LJPNNXW0jbSBvK0jLX1FMttuRTwAjt7oFJdPUVvBYf//w0NAA)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000115)

Uses the formula used by the Mathematica snippet on OEIS:

```
a[n_] := n (n+1) (10n^2+15n+2) (2n+3)!! / 810
```

In detail:

```
/      Switch to Ordinal mode.
i      Read all input as a string.
/      Switch back to Cardinal mode.
.!     Implicitly convert the input to an integer N and store a copy on the tape.
.h*    Multiply N by (N+1).
?2E    Retrieve a copy of N and square it.
a*     Multiply by 10.
?a5+*  Retrieve another copy of multiply it by 15.
+      Add the last two results.
2+     Add 2.
*      Multiply the initial value by this, giving N*(N+1)*(10N^2+15N+2)
?2*3+  Retrieve another copy of N and compute 2N+3, which will be our
       iterator for the double factorial.
.!     Store a copy of this on the tape.
w      Push the current IP address to the return address stack. This starts
       a loop.
  =      Sign junction. Pops the current value of the double factorial iterator.
         If it's positive, turn right (continuing the loop). If it's negative,
         turn left (exiting the loop).
  >      Redirect the IP eastward again.
  ?*     Multiply our result by the current value of the iterator.
  ?2-    Retrieve another copy of the iterator and subtract 2.
  .!     Store a copy on the tape to update the iterator.
K      Jump back to the w to get to the next iteration.

       Once we exit the loop, we continue here:
>      Redirect the IP eastward again.
'Qa*:  Divide the result by 810 (computed as 81*10).
\      Switch to Ordinal mode.
o      Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
@      Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

## 262. [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 91 bytes, [A000115](https://oeis.org/A000115)

```
$:7*1+4/1**1+55/1RFD'/2%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9fxcpcy1DbRN9QC0iZmuobBrm5qOsbqVpRDv7/NzQFAA)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A91)

Use the formula

> a(n) = round((n+4)^2/20).

listed on the OEIS page.

Originally I intended to format the code as a cube, something like

```
  $:7*1
 +    4
/1**1 +
5   5 /
1   RF
D'/2%
```

but it does not work out too well, because Cubically does not have comments and it is not allowed to put spaces between command and parameters, unfortunately.

More explanation later.

Comment: The Cubically interpreter now allows arbitrary whitespace in source code. Thanks for prompting me to redo the interpreter, I've been trying to get around to that for months :)

Answer (score 4):

## 284. [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 211 bytes, [A000384](https://oeis.org/A000384)

```
     ? } 2 \ . .
    . . . " . . .
   . @ ! * = < . .
  . . . > ( { / . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
  . . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . .
     . . . . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/18BBOwVahWMFGIU9BT0uEB8PTBUgtBcYAEHBUUFLQVbBRuoEESJnYKGQrWCPkRMDxNy6WEVxS6IVQybEBYRZIH//y0B)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000211)

What better language is there to compute hexagonal numbers?

#### Explanation

I decided to make this code use each character (except `.`, space and newline) only once, because I had too much time on my hands. Let's label the edge the MP starts on `A`, the one to the left of it `L` and the one to the right - `R`. The following linear code gets executed:

```
?}2"*({=*!@
?           A = input()
 }2         R = 2
   "*       L = A * R = 2 * n
     (      L = L - 1 = 2 * n - 1
      {=*   R = A * L = n(2n-1) = a(n)
         !  Print the result
          @ End execution
```

Answer (score 4):

## 309. Haskell, 699 bytes, [A003025](http://oeis.org/A003025)

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

-- (n, es) has n nodes; es is a list of (i,j) where 1 <= i < j <= n.
type Dag = (Int, [(Int, Int)])

both f (a,b) = (f a, f b)
powerset = filterM (const [True, False])

-- All dags with n nodes.
dags :: Int -> [Dag]
dags n = map ((,) n) $ powerset [(i,j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [i+1..n]]

-- Is there only one node with no exits?
ok :: Dag -> Bool
ok (n, es) = not $ any (\i -> not $ any ((==i) . fst) es) [1..n-1]

-- All ways to relabel the given dag.
rewrites :: Dag -> [Dag]
rewrites (n, es) = [(n, sort $ map (both ((p!!) . pred)) es) | p <- permutations [1..n]]

-- A003025
f :: Int -> Integer
f = genericLength . nub . concatMap rewrites . filter ok . dags
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJLb9swEITv/BUTwAcRlQm7j0tqpegDBQLEt94UHWh7JTOhSYGk6xrIf3eXkur6wseI2Pl2VnsdX8nay8Uceh8SvnuXgrdq7Z3eiUn8oZNWTyYmIeZzFK4ERYm9jnBwfkfxMwswERqWX8G3KEz5InHaUyAssapgsMJLPjgl0rknLtqhQvHoUol63HiRjRRi49MeXEOXG5nftNAl3zdS9P5EIVJitTU2UVij2HrHnvWvcKQSP7WNlGsw6FdrsdNdxMlwvQlViUG6v89umD@gZpBmFB2XPegeRVFKOIkZrn712NBb7mOOeqmUa8rcEF/Mu@HaDKaPEWno2jt75oUG2wnBg/6YFL8I/5oJcgRM8M17m5V/wXJGPrG5dmcUzyY/uRGKqjISCm1Mcng@wMyXzbXnkz4zhEcgqzdkMw8685tcTkOJQKdgEsUbgjGD64f/IHU@xvwPzMZkhtEURX93lxn6QDs5Uryhz2H0FA7HpJPhoUwxTWCLxYfF@0@ivYmeN@oosFahI0fBbJ/Ideyg4I4bXnm2W53W7HyFU9PkwYmpYb6XgzZ5dH0wXJf/ltXsYfD@2MjLXw)

Enumerates the n-node labeled acyclic digraphs with 1 out-point.

`print (f 5)` produces the correct output (16885) after 20 seconds when compiled with `-O3`.

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000699)

Answer (score 4):

## 311. [ALGOL 68 (Genie)](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/algol.html), 334 bytes, [A000148](http://oeis.org/A000148)

```
BEGIN
  LONG LONG INT n   := read int + 2;
  LONG LONG INT r   := 0;
  LONG LONG REAL ma := ( n / 2.0 ) ** 1.5;
  LONG LONG REAL x  := 2.0 / 3;
  INT a             := 1;
  WHILE a <= ma DO
    INT b := a;
    WHILE a ** x + b ** x <= n DO
      r := r + 1;
      b := b + 1
    OD;
    a := a + 1
  OD;
  print ( whole ( r , 0 ) )
END
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000334)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBLC4JAFIX3/oqzVAtfUUTmolBMEIUIWo8kFpiGBPnv7d4ZhaJmMY/znfsaUVdtvVpXw7CP4iTTgDTPYrUl2QkNgE2ArhQX3JonZvD8H1OnTM43OUa7FHfBRKc8NjzLgQHThGst/1h7mYRNNhbMObXA5yLuMjkfkjQitg24QJhrDNlesEX48j2ZqGBPfRfqQiHNFAHqnIcj6vqjIjMUrEghDxWQY4hRVuKj4w/R8bq2dUlnhzl4QEOLsnAYXOcN)

Comment: C (gcc) is allowed right now (2018-01-09), right?

Comment: @Blacksilver looks like it, it's only been used twice so far.

Answer (score 4):

## 312. [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 1811 bytes, [A000334](http://oeis.org/A000334)

```python
partition_result_set = []
location_result_set = []
big_max = 1

def p_value(coord, value):
 global big_max
 i = value
 for d in coord:
  i = i * big_max + d
 return i

def partition(number, max, row = []):
 global partition_result_set
 if number == 0:
  partition_result_set[len(row) - 1] += [row]
  return
 
 for i in range(max, 0, -1):
  if number >= i:
   partition(number - i, i, row + [i])

def init_partitions(number):
 global partition_result_set
 for i in range(number):
  partition_result_set += [[]]

 partition(number, number)

def enumerate_locations(number_of_blocks, dimension, have_locations = [], possible_locations = []):
 global g, result_set, y, big_max, partition_result_set, location_result_set
 
 if possible_locations == []: 
  possible_locations = [[0] * dimension]
  y = [0] * number_of_blocks
  temp = number_of_blocks
  while temp > 0:
   big_max *= 10
   temp //= 10
 
 for location in possible_locations:
  new_have_locations = have_locations + [location]
  new_possible_locations = [l for l in possible_locations if l != location]
  for i in range(dimension):
   m = [location[d] + (1 if i == d else 0) for d in range(dimension)]
   is_ok = True
   for j in range(dimension):
    n = [m[d] - (1 if j == d else 0) for d in range(dimension)]
    if [d for d in n if d < 0] == [] and n not in new_have_locations: is_ok = False
   if is_ok: new_possible_locations += [m]

  len1 = len(new_have_locations)
  for x in partition_result_set[len1 - 1]:
   location_result_set += [repr(sorted([p_value(new_have_locations[k], x[k]) for k in range(len1)]))]
  if number_of_blocks > 1:
   enumerate_locations(number_of_blocks - 1, dimension, new_have_locations, new_possible_locations)

def A000334(n):
 init_partitions(n + 1)
 enumerate_locations(n + 1, 4)
 print len(set(location_result_set))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNj5swEL3zK6Y32Dha6O6hipqVeukv6A0hRBYn8QZsZMgm@fXpzBhICo7aSgjJ8/XePI@nuXR7o78um0tzuV6bwnaqU0bnVrbHqstb2cEa0iyozHvhdWzULq@LMx6SICjlFpr8s6iOMnw3xpYC@BCtAthVZlNU0McHoDCFnQFsjYUSlAbOwVh2KngaomEBZQBWdkerQfU4A9dQH@uNtAIwUIA1JyZ2B@nrCvG34BJhvYaYQH1xaSV1iDUjWEKSwQJL4ynDaMcmAEdfEX1b6J0MmUYsYJlE3MqI84Y9kWVGHWsrQR@RX0Cqssj1qLTq8jG67cP/2tqE0C3LG89NpVkWBB5N@1xHR@JJ2qKT@TAOA6XcbPMNGg@tgFLVUrfoFLAvPu9i@V4ENKZt1aaaOu662qESIz0BFzHMgfA2IMAznXQxKL0PjNBWQGp4maRxhpM3dkF3fSE7m6ftorOTdYN@j@e0V5V0/jc3YuNAP@F7icnA3udnd3RXN7ChG5xTpDJanvKZthMDztFwyPoUf7@VA/WjkYYVfFnDfa3JfI1S8YhBzUX78LTERwNhQnUUSV@CrFoJcXR79dMqBAGqzc0BK/2ytCEc5sdDTNAEWhPaskf7@B80SkjLW5AmQwnfAS@d5wUKXaJVm47dM/1XI@GfBSIGriTbVo@0p3dX07MDXDIJptKumZeOesXPfEMPdlTC@4m18K1q3luysWFrbCfLMB229BwuPeAbPePfaXa4aUYwURaxYuNWuw08znjCBP5lTRDdP1bFnIh4oFu/jH7Ecfzy8hryBMwWJQ5dgsJ5qZBPwCu6G6t0x7KjSKFHuCi6Djjfoutv)

[Next sequence: A001811, Laguerre Polynomial. At least there is a closed-form formula](http://oeis.org/A001811)

Sorry for Python again, but when the question comes to enumeration **I think Python is the easiest way to deal the question with**.

Answer (score 4):

## 314. [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 4166 bytes,  [A000146](https://oeis.org/A000146)

I hope I didn’t accidentally add any bytes outside of the M code page in the code.

The actual source code is the markdown source of this post. To prevent infinite recursion, the source can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/ffc30c91-23d6-44a2-9093-7fe2acec7d8f/view-source).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZNb9s2GL77V7z1Sc4s@SNBumyJ0SJdggDzUCzZaVgHhqIswhSpUZQ/0A0odth5t3bActqGYcBQ7BKsZ3t/pPkj2UtKcpxESfoeZJsy36/neV4yubzcjXsD2OxtBbBLINYs2mvGxqTZJ53OiJs4Pw2oSjrPmJQ8G3JDYyZEJ2kOhrsdMmjDVm97G07nhmXt2w4U41mg9KjztNvt9ra2mwMov4HdjQ8M3mgcQaxSBkcQ8lBevPrFAKGUh0waIsQcSBgCkfMiCqjcZPgOVAQmZjAEqvBXSkYMuHRLdiFoNHYf@T5cvPoVhv6Q6HGophJSJeYjoQzwDIxSEBMdtjEwkyHkKeQZlyPcnyQYOwvA9zG7E3RJqMmJgEzlmhYBnAd8k1Suy3cuLXyXqswEcKIg1WyC3jC5iEtuGGhGc51xJdvOQeWTSDhlEKkcU/k6Zpp941VttPFGSkRBZggdsxmNiRwxhws659ZX1okiutmlOz2/vxlu@1tbpO/vdHc2/ccR6xPK6OPw46gz4WzqFxFbtkUVYEQa7lcZ@qsMm4MTPQduQEnBJXvkQPOmSAu4Y0drzWkdCyxdkAVfsJmBjH2XM0nZI0eGFWBnRdt34/4APpulgkhi0LMlSx/XAW3xFpY/PcP/vsHP58ufI/jvH7iy9@/@tbgDHHCdGcDUxwHsE0FzQRCA4zz59qWX@r3W9335A/Q6aRtsTQ14yCxeEyJyB3MfMTdKs7DinWYjnhmmg/Uc77KnQiDdETyls9Kbh5zJ@KkoY7hll2ZwlZkt@Zat6j2SVDPL3QAOGaoIY9T6XPcIVQtv2QEXWE0bxoyllgFz5DJPKk/BrXZdw8DZkZwwnbFglfyZ2@RvwPI1fYIP2Fi8XfxRW8sxowql4IVzEnLaKlE85CgmmCD9Qhi3UTUlqA9j52EjX0xgA7wx0FipDAtp4c/JiwQ6uPgR9hm8BPagvyFb7YcdEsDuJBBplRRjR6DP0I@UXcQH5lX0yL/Py@coH42jxe@VDd2458/P1RTpBfu51nakFFTcK0tbAeJ6W2/DXBieIpLe8nULB2o5L5NTXorMw047fWdTkqbIbe9J6wNaoUe5G5mAmwTHbehq7ECaXKdaDeLXEytzWqnMwr/udRIEN5hX37AvCUeEDc5f17Obm6w8a6yScBnfo0WnMa@YTKqsHEdka43QVpXv3/2@@Au6Ghbn@Fj@efHj37BELr9ZnNuvn/qL3@DguOL3kODQcJRu3CnrG5K4EnejWrcR77SvZEwEJu2FKscB0Lrqa9sh44aX7dD1ueUMK6i3QyaRrvYUs0dQQf7u9d4uzoPSisrXBorSwAiNq@6Ob8rsjrCjuqDglRPNm7Rq5FoAcJupaermGB6bKs8qh1VeTLgG14rfYVkzp2wr7SDHKwFyt5gjdyrGsaCwfSUp1iRtXcXpkVkN4P1DIBqFCNeV8LAKywMqWjv0ZhgOLyNNao8Cu4RnVchmMAOCWv0gl5ILgnckvHWIPLTpFbeekr4FlaaapDgE7N2lGdznFQXgPnBkY@klD/MkWDvfzi4vL/u9/wE) (with anti-infinite-recursion)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A004166)

### Explanation

```
® ÆD ‘ ÆPÐf İ           ḷ“   First link. Calculate Sum_{(p-1)|2n} 1/p, with
                             the value of 2n stored in the register.
® ÆD                         All divisors of 2n (possible values of (p-1).
     ‘                  ḷ“   Increment. Get all possible values of (p).
       ÆPÐf                  Filter, keep only prime values.
            İ                Inverse.       ”
-* ×c@ × *®¥            ḷ“   Second (dyadic) link. Given v and k, calculate
                             (-1)^v * (k choose v) * v^m / (k+1). (m = 2*n),
                             a term from the closed-form formula.
-                            Literal -1.
 *                           Power. Current value = (-1)^v.
   ×c@                       Multiply (×) by the combination (c) with swapped (@)
                             arguments applied on k and v.
       × *®¥                 Multiply by the value of dyad applied on v...
         *                     Raise to power...
          ®                    register value (currently have value m = 2n)   ”
‘ Ḥ© 0r µ0r ç€ ÷‘µ€ ;-£ FS ḷ“ Main link.
‘                          ḷ“ Increment.
  Ḥ©                          Unhalve (double) the value, and store to register.
     0r                       Generate range from 0.
        µ........µ€           For each value (k),
         0r                     generate range from 0 (values (v)),
            ç€                  apply previous range for each element,
               ÷‘          ḷ“   and divide by (k+1).
                    ;-£       Concatenate the resulting list with the value of
                                the first link. x£ is "call link index x as a
                                nilad, excluding the main link, and wrap around".
                       FS     Flatten, and sum.         ”
```

Comment: Another bignum sequence... this one is easy enough, please don't use Hy. (or another-Python-variant)

Comment: I think you should edit in an explanation of how the polyglot works ;)

Comment: This answer broke the snippet, but I will nudge the regex used to make it work.

Comment: Is M just an early version/precursor of Jelly?

Comment: @dylnan Infinite precision version.

Comment: @user202729 Interesting. Could you demonstrate how they're different? What would be a program that differs between the two?

Comment: @dylnan [Numerical](https://tio.run/##y/3/31jL2ODIBm1D5yMb/v8HAA) [inaccuracy](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Yy9jgyAZtQ@cjG/7/BwA). [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o0N5Dm/7/BwA) [also](https://tio.run/##y/3/3@jQ3kOb/v8HAA) works (adding ceiling will make the difference more explicit).

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. Apparently [`zoo` means infinity in M](https://tio.run/##y/3/39D5yIb//wE)

Answer (score 4):

## 315. [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 147 bytes, [A004166](https://oeis.org/A004166)

```
very simple :)
>"HTRF"4(1&>:!#v_1v <-- this loop here
  @.$<--out^\*3 \-< <-- calculates 3^n
 >;#_^#:/a\+%aO<\;#z<-- and here the digits are summed
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzJCsIwFEX3@Ypno@JAlFIXdqC4EneCuAwtsX22gXSgSQr687F2d8/lcF74tm2FLDyz/jNP50YcPqBl0yuEaEtS7/Z8XL3Txl@n0YKOuT9CwhiYWmpQXddDjQMSgMthOf2dNRnfBcBZMmuFUIVVwqCGIGsJpDHNMxodBd@vxD3hMf3@NdGWc2fKIpSykkaDmFDbpsHSuZD8AA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000147)

Comment: dagnabbit, I had a snobol solution all ready, I was just testing it :( [here it is, looks like it's correct.](https://tio.run/##TZDNDoIwEITP26eYY@tPpEEvxPIqBgVJE2gNlKQ@PW4joLfZfJ3Z2Y7O3313nmfqq3irbWvDCHPJMkHrUA1D9ZY/rFZ01SWMFuRgrHtNQYQk2yCdgsMRmoqn9Er0U5dThBH04Kw3C5tGdEHGw18uIvZfU@AdoX/BfA175NhhWRrLLSc9OUFvXZnBDE1fD5LRQWeKCmmV8GS5YgoX5GE8q8VgSyrG1JH8FPgEhqJxNc0zf8EH "SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe well, I got ninjad on the previous sequence - I was working on a Trefunge solution and I had the Bernoulli numbers working, I just had to add the reciprocals of prime divisors.

Comment: Again, a trailing newline is necessary. So `v` = `↓`...

Comment: Looks like I have to post the next answer. 38 hours left.

Answer (score 4):

## 332. [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 852 bytes, [A000766](https://oeis.org/A000766)

```
(d in (q ((x xs) (i (e x (h xs)) 1 (i xs (in x (t xs)) 0

(d vec (q ((x y z) (c x (c y (c z (
(d + (q ((x y) (i x (c (a (h x) (h y)) (+ (t x) (t y))) (

(d map (q ((f xs) (i xs (c (f (h xs)) (map f (t xs))) (

(d sub (q ((exp pat rep) (i (e exp pat) rep (i (e (type exp) (q List)) (i exp (c (sub (h exp) pat rep) (sub (t exp) pat rep)) ()) exp
(d qt (q ((x) (c (q q) (c x (

(d - (s 0 1
(d adj (c (vec 1 1 0) (c (vec - 1 0) (c (vec 1 - 0) (c (vec - - 0) (c (vec 1 0 1) (c (vec - 0 1) (c (vec 1 0 -) (c (vec - 0 -) (c (vec 0 1 1) (c (vec 0 - 1) (c (vec 0 1 -) (c (vec 0 - -) (

(d sum (q ((ls) (i ls (a (h ls) (sum (t ls))) 0

(d sol (q ((ve pre n) (i (in ve pre) 0 (i n (sum (map (sub (sub (sub (q ((aj) (sol (+ VEC aj) PRE N))) (q VEC) (qt ve)) (q PRE) (qt (c ve pre))) (q N) (qt (s n 1))) adj)) (e (h ve) 1

(d main (q ((x) (sol (vec 0 0 0) () (a 1 x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVPLbsIwELzzFXu0hSLF/YWKW4WqHnpPwYigkCbYRQk/n@7s2gEL4WRnd2ZfTmz7uWvDsCzmSG1PZiRjJpqCJdOS8TSROcO05IBMgc8eaFS03myYefeHTJ3pwdwDQg5s8PEgg5jtGiHa4jeNyFucM6uZrQhbnGzzU@SvzaDkU64MdTD9tFZnEHPKZWVi@PtRop8GGppINz/kzhJkgSXIxHkQhwXrow3RSjRCkU7kzhrwVBM0lijD/GcIVYwxtS6D4dcxT0iKrFiCanJ4b44XicFAHf9qu5pVaToGCm9Velnw1VuY8Fal98WskfnVrErTlcGVmGncV@200y11IW1YbPFGvK/3Jvx2Srh7Gm6eel0O3zAFOA5An8hyD2TczwPs5gJ5aG3pe/dOsD@/drSXmzACwzOyqgLsVIDbSJnUsU9w4JwOGC8EHo8umM1b0gu5fis5sw6jliVYtO1oWowEvi1II1n@AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000852) Intentionally chosen to be easy. (somewhat weird, too)

... It was (not) fun learning this language.

Defines a function `main` which calculates the required function. [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp) doesn't support reading from standard input.

Brute force approach. That's why it's terribly slow.

---

... There is `library` to load? In an esoteric language? Surprise!

Comment: No line has a trailing `)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for using my language. :) Sorry your learning experience was painful... If you have suggestions on how I can make tinylisp more approachable, I'd love to hear them! ([Chat room here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52509/appleseed-and-tinylisp))

Answer (score 4):

## 335. [Python 2 (Cython)](http://cython.org/), 620 bytes, [A000157](https://oeis.org/A000157/)

```python
from itertools import*
from math import*
from functools import*
n=int(input())+1#offset 1
a=0#answer
for p in permutations(range(n)):
 for i in range(2**n):#inversion
  v=[0]*(2**n)#visited
  c=0#number of cycles
  e=1#all is even
  for x in range(2**n):
   if v[x]:continue
   w=1#1 if this cycle is even
   while 1>v[x]:
    v[x]=1;w^=1
    x=reduce(lambda x,y:x+x+y,[1&(x>>s)for s in p])^i
   e&=w;c+=1
  a+=2**c*(1+e)
print(a//(2**n*factorial(n)*4))

#Come on... it's not that hard.
#Time complexity: 4**n*factorial(n)
#Memory complexity: 2**n
#(which is actually order of magnitude
#faster than the naive algorithm)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBbqMwFLz7K55kqYuhm5aqe6Eilz3vbW9RKrnmESzhZ2QbAl@ffSaXTS8g5s2bGY@ZtjR4evtp9vft1gfvwCYMyfsxgnWTD6kUO@x0Gh6RfibzSKTWUiosTXMqlKpq6fs@YoJa6PZVaopXDKL3ASawBBMGNyedrKdYBE0XLEipRkBm2My4g29lSaqRlhYMkckCYGlPr@fyPpGLjZy5Y9iwC83uCwP4HsxmRowMY1tLPY5gI@CCeT87rN8dGAfbw3Jaz43xlCzNmLErr9d5kgZW2FX/k4LrYBmoj/teBnaFtv64frb1/r22AbvZYDFq99VpWJ@3Zq3Wans@1U/FejxGlQPFvZSz@rR5C5/a64epdgldtRzRlEVdoRJTyC3rl5c9d9lrvoVg9cjtle9KCSF/e4fg6XA48G3@iEA@cXidYNChOwj51/LceDeNuNq0NfD@XUjIP@h82B5Y2U7Igg9shtwA82fudQMfunvlTl/IprlDIXsd@UfKtsQP5JFdEPR4YYs0OHW7/foH)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000620/)

---

Originally intended to work in Python3, but Python 3 (Cython) raises an error "deallocating None".

Sorry for using Python, but programming on mobile is not easy. Posted 2 days ago in chat while waiting for someone else to post, probably with another language.

The next sequence has some chemistry-related things, but the recurrence relation is easy to implement. Ideally I hope someone will explain what the sequence is about. (I don't even explain most of my own answers...)

(Side note: Syntax highlighting fails for some comments)

Comment: Well done! You can compute `c` (and `e`) without explicitely looking at all possible inputs using linear algebra similar to what I did in answer no. 178

Comment: Talking of "what the sequence is about", what's A000157 *really*? It's obviously not what the title says, but equivalence classes of some kind.

Comment: I actually didn't read the paper, and I think the description of the other sequence is easier to understand, and my first try got it correctly. So I just calculate and halve the other sequence.

Comment: @PeterTaylor After having read 3 papers in the A370 sequence I still can't find any reference to this sequence. No idea.

Answer (score 4):

## 364. [Wenyan (文言)](https://github.com/wenyan-lang/wenyan), 2534 bytes, [A001669](https://oeis.org/A001669)

```
吾有一術。名之曰「開方本源圖」。欲行是術。必先得一數。曰「甲」。乃行是術曰。
　批曰。「「西人謂之曰「巴斯噶三角」者是也。」」
　吾有一列。名之曰「層」。充「層」以一。
　為是「甲」遍。
　　吾有一列。名之曰「下層」。
　　吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「上廉」。
　　凡「層」中之「廉」。
　　　加「廉」以「上廉」。名之曰「下廉」。充「下層」以「下廉」。
　　　昔之「上廉」者。今「廉」是矣。
　　云云。
　　充「下層」以一。
　　昔之「層」者。今「下層」是矣。
　云云。
　乃得「層」。
是謂「開方本源圖」之術也。

吾有一術。名之曰「指數」。欲行是術。必先得一列。曰「天」。乃行是術曰。
　批曰。「「形式冪級數之指數者也。不計其常數項。」」
　夫「天」之長。名之曰「階」。
　吾有一列。名之曰「地」。
　吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「甲」。
　為是「階」遍。
　　若「甲」等於零者。
　　　充「地」以一。
　　若非。
　　　減「甲」以一。施「開方本源圖」於其。名之曰「開方本源」。
　　　吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「乙」。
　　　吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「和」。
　　　凡「開方本源」中之「廉」。
　　　　減「甲」以「乙」。加其以一。名之曰「丙」。
　　　　加一於「乙」。昔之「乙」者。今其是矣。
　　　　夫「地」之「乙」。名之曰「項」。
　　　　夫「天」之「丙」。乘其以「項」。乘其以「廉」。
　　　　加其於「和」。昔之「和」者。今其是矣。
　　　云云。
　　　充「地」以「和」。
　　云云。
　　加一於「甲」。昔之「甲」者。今其是矣。
　云云。
　乃得「地」。
是謂「指數」之術也。

吾有一術。名之曰「序列零零壹陸陸玖」。欲行是術。必先得一數。曰「甲」。乃行是術曰。
　批曰。「「OEIS之序列A001669者是也。」」
　加一於「甲」。昔之「甲」者。今其是矣。
　吾有一列。名之曰「天」。為是「甲」遍。充「天」以一也。
　為是六遍。
　　施「指數」於「天」。昔之「天」者。今其是矣。
　云云。
　夫「天」之「甲」。名之曰「乙」。
　乃得「乙」。
是謂「序列零零壹陸陸玖」之術也。
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A002534)

Time to write some [Classical Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Chinese).

You can try it on [this Online IDE](https://ide.wy-lang.org/). Add the following snippets to the end to print the first 20 terms. Uncheck "Print Hanzi" in the settings to show the results in Arabic numerals.

```
吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「甲」。
為是二十遍。
　施「序列零零壹陸陸玖」於「甲」。書之。
　加一於「甲」。昔之「甲」者。今其是矣。
云云。
```

Answer (score 3):

## 40. [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 3416 bytes, [A000001](https://oeis.org/A000001)

The rules seem to imply hardcoding the first 1001 cases is fine.

**EDIT**: I’m editing this post to give some commenters the chance to adjust their vote on it.

```rust
static COUNT: [i32; 1001] =
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2,
1, 15, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 51, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 2, 2, 14, 1, 6, 1, 4,
2, 2, 1, 52, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 15, 2, 13, 2, 2, 1, 13, 1, 2, 4, 267, 1,
4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 52, 15, 2, 1, 15, 1, 2, 1,
12, 1, 10, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 231, 1, 5, 2, 16, 1, 4, 1, 14, 2, 2, 1, 45,
1, 6, 2, 43, 1, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 47, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 16, 1, 2328, 2,
4, 1, 10, 1, 2, 5, 15, 1, 4, 1, 11, 1, 2, 1, 197, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 13,
1, 12, 2, 4, 2, 18, 1, 2, 1, 238, 1, 55, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 57, 2, 4, 5,
4, 1, 4, 2, 42, 1, 2, 1, 37, 1, 4, 2, 12, 1, 6, 1, 4, 13, 4, 1, 1543,
1, 2, 2, 12, 1, 10, 1, 52, 2, 2, 2, 12, 2, 2, 2, 51, 1, 12, 1, 5, 1,
2, 1, 177, 1, 2, 2, 15, 1, 6, 1, 197, 6, 2, 1, 15, 1, 4, 2, 14, 1,
16, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 208, 1, 5, 67, 5, 2, 4, 1, 12, 1, 15, 1, 46, 2, 2,
1, 56092, 1, 6, 1, 15, 2, 2, 1, 39, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 30, 1, 54, 5, 2,
4, 10, 1, 2, 4, 40, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1045, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 23, 1,
14, 5, 2, 1, 49, 2, 2, 1, 42, 2, 10, 1, 9, 2, 6, 1, 61, 1, 2, 4, 4,
1, 4, 1, 1640, 1, 4, 1, 176, 2, 2, 2, 15, 1, 12, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 228,
1, 5, 1, 15, 1, 18, 5, 12, 1, 2, 1, 12, 1, 10, 14, 195, 1, 4, 2, 5,
2, 2, 1, 162, 2, 2, 3, 11, 1, 6, 1, 42, 2, 4, 1, 15, 1, 4, 7, 12, 1,
60, 1, 11, 2, 2, 1, 20169, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 1, 44, 1, 2, 1, 30, 1,
2, 5, 221, 1, 6, 1, 5, 16, 6, 1, 46, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 10, 1, 235, 2, 4,
1, 41, 1, 2, 2, 14, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 775, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1,
51, 13, 4, 1, 18, 1, 2, 1, 1396, 1, 34, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 54, 1, 2, 5,
11, 1, 12, 1, 51, 4, 2, 1, 55, 1, 4, 2, 12, 1, 6, 2, 11, 2, 2, 1,
1213, 1, 2, 2, 12, 1, 261, 1, 14, 2, 10, 1, 12, 1, 4, 4, 42, 2, 4, 1,
56, 1, 2, 1, 202, 2, 6, 6, 4, 1, 8, 1, 10494213, 15, 2, 1, 15, 1, 4,
1, 49, 1, 10, 1, 4, 6, 2, 1, 170, 2, 4, 2, 9, 1, 4, 1, 12, 1, 2, 2,
119, 1, 2, 2, 246, 1, 24, 1, 5, 4, 16, 1, 39, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 16, 1,
180, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 2, 49, 12, 1, 12, 1, 11, 1, 4, 2, 8681, 1, 5, 2,
15, 1, 6, 1, 15, 4, 2, 1, 66, 1, 4, 1, 51, 1, 30, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 205,
1, 6, 4, 4, 7, 4, 1, 195, 3, 6, 1, 36, 1, 2, 2, 35, 1, 6, 1, 15, 5,
2, 1, 260, 15, 2, 2, 5, 1, 32, 1, 12, 2, 2, 1, 12, 2, 4, 2, 21541, 1,
4, 1, 9, 2, 4, 1, 757, 1, 10, 5, 4, 1, 6, 2, 53, 5, 4, 1, 40, 1, 2,
2, 12, 1, 18, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1280, 1, 2, 17, 16, 1, 4, 1, 53, 1, 4,
1, 51, 1, 15, 2, 42, 2, 8, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 44, 1, 2, 1, 36, 1, 62, 1,
1387, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 6, 4, 15, 1, 12, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 840, 1, 5, 2,
5, 2, 13, 1, 40, 504, 4, 1, 18, 1, 2, 6, 195, 2, 10, 1, 15, 5, 4, 1,
54, 1, 2, 2, 11, 1, 39, 1, 42, 1, 4, 2, 189, 1, 2, 2, 39, 1, 6, 1, 4,
2, 2, 1, 1090235, 1, 12, 1, 5, 1, 16, 4, 15, 5, 2, 1, 53, 1, 4, 5,
172, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 137, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 24, 1, 1211, 2, 2, 1,
15, 1, 4, 1, 14, 1, 113, 1, 16, 2, 4, 1, 205, 1, 2, 11, 20, 1, 4, 1,
12, 5, 4, 1, 30, 1, 4, 2, 1630, 2, 6, 1, 9, 13, 2, 1, 186, 2, 2, 1,
4, 2, 10, 2, 51, 2, 10, 1, 10, 1, 4, 5, 12, 1, 12, 1, 11, 2, 2, 1,
4725, 1, 2, 3, 9, 1, 8, 1, 14, 4, 4, 5, 18, 1, 2, 1, 221, 1, 68, 1,
15, 1, 2, 1, 61, 2, 4, 15, 4, 1, 4, 1, 19349, 2, 2, 1, 150, 1, 4, 7,
15, 2, 6, 1, 4, 2, 8, 1, 222, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 30, 1, 39, 2, 2, 1, 34,
2, 2, 4, 235, 1, 18, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 222, 1, 4, 2, 11, 1, 6, 1, 42,
13, 4, 1, 15, 1, 10, 1, 42, 1, 10, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 11394, 2, 4, 2, 5,
1, 12, 1, 42, 2, 4, 1, 900, 1, 2, 6, 51, 1, 6, 2, 34, 5, 2, 1, 46, 1,
4, 2, 11, 1, 30, 1, 196, 2, 6, 1,10,1,2,15,199];

fn count(i: usize) -> i32 { COUNT[i] }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVfLbhUxDN3nKwZWrQRS7MTJhAo27GEDq6oLhEC6ElxQe7uh4tvLzMROTmaQqmoeGT@Oz7F97x8fLs/PD5cvl9PX6f3Hzx8@vZluT4FvJvLe301v3a1/NZH9MfyX7aJdt@cU4ZEdcuuL9sVyUQ/pUTp@rqbrTdLDrjtshporNU8B4lpvqrHFEKe83jmMT6@9HQv2KDU3ZrdeWZyO9Jk3O80pB4LcKYEjwnNRNlhSjS@gWzO4nsr4SY07qR@eN2wjRqKoYHo04Fuy3aUGXagF4gbVcjNjxUO9EzmWPttHYpFUAxHJEjK8Ueg6MA11klhDYTyomWnN@6v2pwQiIKPTT3NGOgk43oBIu9pGoJ3rpWMLkP1sPlY2Cbyi0VAC5kvyBXMmBDAUKFX9HzThqB42XD1QOfrxmx6EjwJFVMKGmk5snFzeF6SVXlWrxcixxkvodUtGHaUhBsoJiyOICLrlhbJukCxVqkk7zgOaXqtRsD4CnYBScxsa1ROmFXcFzmbdJd/00dXrKTVsYotUU4nIaW9EW9NjGgW8kic1Kgx078UMVqwNWNp1Pv5fhXMeOlc37YQGKaF@KZTqPsSjgGPvG45GJRE0IpH/SphH/Ja@2JtuP8hKJE1L8@8EiWO1nCTsPp6NksnSm43uJVaHclCyU5oPXboLPnsQCmqw83BVLxXIhrWWHKFPa5sIeNBEUiGZPdaiC7l0njN26hrTnGYYJG5sXjgiUjoOU2shQ@9qAyeaEDTOVV3BbIcEiYS9V7HWypt6cKav3/Z0GKXcgOalxROM4YLUltwQEhjEq/WAW4Mh6GBGzMdeyIB73k1iCcASmx/SBhcbw4ZRPKhfVa2sD3M@1ljZKjsY2rE5QpVc3180R/HxqOak5QIVScfGybA@0TBhGAU8I131xHHPIl88BzmM1w3M2HzziOnWSTIf@pS6DghVREEtzWPoJbLbnTaJhBbAQG0zud3277ZFTXaTVQNJwcOsK2153ABPEEjvWrptAPoeN7ODmruJzAJbZsEuFk2Rst@7bKrMiAe30cytCLg@UAnDeCfxffY5ZTnuNuqSGYa9IF4BzYVGkKgjTAnK8EOAu72IXGyT2eHWNyDZJbSTy1L6EoftxsEQQXkV73HJJegkYdiCEpZ36JxUEuDUmzbJ3Y1z38/T11@P58vV6c30@HD68@16ev1uWn44TU/1Z9Tt6W76@7wc@/nldL66Xh7/vj@dLz/OL65ePv19@Uo/X3rU9fXNcvIf)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A003416).

Comment: Hardcoding in a language as dedicated to computation as rust... you earned my downvote.

Comment: "Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." I wouldn't necessarily upvote this because hardcoding isn't interesting but I don't think it deserves downvotes just because it isn't a creative solution

Comment: Note that counting finite groups of order *n* is a *highly* non-trivial problem, and any serious attempt to write an answer here that isn’t O(silly(n)) would take hours/days of coding, and get beaten to it by some bullshit Mathematica-oid that has a built-in for it, which, surprise, _absolutely_ would cache the first 1001 cases too.

Comment: Well then, seeing your point I will reverse my downvote, but apparently I can't un-downvote until this post is edited again.

Comment: I see your point with that, and though I don't like having languages being "wasted" to downvotes, I do see your point with the built-ins. If you edit the post I'll revert my downvote.

Comment: @Cowsquack and HyperNeutrino: I’ve edited the post

Answer (score 3):

## 48. SOGL, 3 bytes, [A000194](https://oeis.org/A000194)

```
.√Ρ
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000003)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing There's no way I can't solve it in 2 days

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing you don't need to worry about not solving it until a couple days have passed :P

Answer (score 3):

## 53. [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/), 34 bytes, [A000484](https://oeis.org/A000484)

```
alert Math.round Math.cos prompt()
```

[Try it online!](http://coffeescript.org/)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000034)

Comment: @StepHen The next one is super easy too

Comment: Man, the next one is so easy, too bad I can't post yet... This would be `....I2%:)O@` in Cubix (could be shorter but 9 and 10 are already taken)

Comment: @BlackCap yup I got it in :P

Answer (score 3):

## 54. [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 196 bytes, [A000034](https://oeis.org/A000034)

```
using System;
namespace A000008
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(1 + Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) % 2);
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9C8JAEET7@xXbCDnEEGMjpBIrQSFoYSEWy2UJB8md7J6CSH77mQ@Mr5hieDNGVsYzxfgU62q4vCVQWyiHLckDDcEuG9iqj4Ie06AIlOxrxnZspn5AAgZr4OVtBSe0LpHA/eftDsi16Nn7L3r23olvKL2yDXS0jpI1LOHgwiZPS2Sh5GecCatR0BoWkOtivunUlF2M2Rc)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000196)

Comment: lol the next one literally has a builtin in Jelly xD

Answer (score 3):

## 56. [Pony](https://www.ponylang.org/), 138 bytes, [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041)

```
fun f(n: U64, q: U64 = 1): U64 =>
  if n>0 then
    if n>=q then
      f(n-q, q)+f(n,q+1)
    else
      0
    end
  else
    1
  end //a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzNDoIwEITvPMUcuwH5SdQDSbl59OgDNNgqiVkoFIxPXysS1MTL7uT7JtO1/PBe1a7tcVQNRwDrO@peK6eF5qnEgSeCrIIBAkjb0aVd37ATRuwoHVzIF0E0F@ZjRoYRXOK03yaw84dEQUt6bwGNAVc53FXzQhYm7S/Ea25jwxbFISU2LmiV@jbor2b@EXyO/lSKaNXIMuX9Ew) (Thank you for adding Pony Dennis!)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000138)

Comment: Try this: http://playground.ponylang.org/

Comment: I add most languages by request. Assuming this is one, I'll look into Pony.

Comment: @StepHen Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you, I appreciate that

Comment: [One Pony](https://tio.run/##K8jPq/z/PzG5JL9IwTcxM49LQSEvtVwhuSg1sSRVIzWvzErBNa9MU8HWDiijoAAU0MsvLdErKMrMK9FQ8kjNycnXUQjPL8pJUVTS/P8fAA), as requested. In the future, if you find a language you'd like to see added to TIO, please don't hesitate to leave me a message in http://talk.tryitonline.net.

Answer (score 3):

## 60. [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 5 + 2 = 7 bytes, [A000059](https://oeis.org/A000059)

+2 bytes for the `N` and `o` flags.

#### Code:

```
x4m>p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/7/CJNeu4P///7p@@f8NDQA)

#### Explanation:

```
x      # Double the number
 4m    # Raise to the power of 4
   >   # Add one
    p  # Check for primality
```

Used with the following flags:

- `N`: Find the Nth number that satisfies each line of code
- `o`: Shift the sequence by 1 (`N = N + 1`).

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000007)

Comment: Can't believe that we haven't had A7

Answer (score 3):

## 61. [√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿](https://github.com/SatansSon/UnprintableName), 5 bytes, [A000007](http://oeis.org/A000007)

```
I0^o
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000005)

Answer (score 3):

## 64. [LiveScript](http://livescript.net), 152 bytes, [A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108)

```
f = (n) ->
  ns = [1]
  for i from 0 to n-1
    ns.push 0
    s = 0
    for k from 0 to ns.length-1
      s += ns[k]
      ns[k] =  s
  ns[ns.length-1]
```

[Try it online!](http://livescript.net)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000152)

Comment: Great, I don't even understand how 2 becomes 32 in this one

Comment: @ETHproductions Would you rather have had A151?

Comment: ...no, sorry to complain :P You could have golfed it though

Comment: Oh, it's 0-indexed. That makes more sense I suppose

Comment: @ETHproductions They are considering `0` to be a square and they care about order, for small `n` this is just how many binary strings of length 16 are there containing `n` ones.

Comment: @WheatWizard You have to account for `-1`s as well though, hence why 1 is 32 as opposed to 16.

Comment: This is quite apparent from the g.f. presented in the maple code: `(sum(x^(m^2), m=-10..10))^16`

Answer (score 3):

## 65. [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 371 bytes, [A000152](https://oeis.org/A000152)

```
function A000152(n)
	integer :: n, i, a, sum, index, A000152
	integer, dimension(n+1) :: gf
	gf(1) = 1
	do i=2,n+1
		gf(i) = 0
	end do
	do a=1,16
		do i=n+1,2,-1
			sum = 0
			index = 1
			do while (index * index < i)
				sum = sum + 2 * gf(i - index * index)
				index = index + 1
			end do
			gf(i) = gf(i) + sum
		end do
	end do
	A000152 = gf(n+1)
end function A000152
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDRbsMgDHyGr/Bj2hAJIm3SqvKwT0ENYZaKiWiq7e8zE5q12QMx8Z3vDo8pz9lRF8Z6WaacQnYRokOSGKcrXnAGSuSlQJp98BlOJyAFjs@n1tq89VIMCchqZT6kEI7AbkhDB@5MmUePypEUngYYkizl1WoZ73SZMdFucG@I7Kngdo98pcH/vNg/iAoGjJ5urNNQaw5lMIxShLHhHwtmDYq2V4xyLu5j6eu/XAV31ijzzvDKZabqVVfogr0rW4g1QZVcid9fePXQ1PaxBoQzYHn@Nli@LfQMF2PoYMeuzE231rbqb@GeiWtti6R84lt97KXyyiLWff9f8bL8Ag)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000371)

### How it works

It uses the following gf:

```
(sum(m=[-infty,infty], x^(m^2)))^16
```

Answer (score 3):

## 66. [Yacas](http://www.yacas.org/), 43 bytes, [A000371](http://oeis.org/A000371)

```
f(n):=Sum(k,0,n,(-1)^(n-k)*Bin(n,k)*2^2^k);
```

[Try it online!](http://www.yacas.org/yacas_online/yacas_online.html)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000043)

Answer (score 3):

## 70. [Elm](http://elm-lang.org), 1134 bytes, [A000333](https://oeis.org/A000333)

```
import Html exposing (text)

f n s = let l = takeWhile (\x -> (s + sqrt (toFloat x)) <= n) (List.range 1 (floor (n*n)))
        in List.map (\x -> [x]) l 
        ++ (List.concatMap (\x -> List.map (\y -> x::y) ( f n (s+sqrt (toFloat x)) )) l)

t n = List.length(List.map List.head(group(List.sort(List.map List.sort(f(n+1)0)))))

main = text (toString (List.length (t 5)))


takeWhile : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
takeWhile predicate list =
  case list of
    []      -> []
    x::xs   -> if (predicate x) then x :: takeWhile predicate xs
              else []

dropWhile : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
dropWhile predicate list =
  case list of
    []      -> []
    x::xs   -> if (predicate x) then dropWhile predicate xs
              else list

span : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> (List a, List a)
span p xs = (takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)

groupBy : (a -> a -> Bool) -> List a -> List (List a)
groupBy eq zs =
  case zs of
    [] -> []
    (x::xs) -> let (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
              in (x::ys)::groupBy eq zs

group : List a -> List (List a)
group = groupBy (==)
```

[This is much prettier in Haskell](https://tio.run/##TY4xb4MwEIV3/4onxGCEckqkThGwtGMydeiQRpUlTIxibGobhaH/ndqQITed3r1331PC36XWy9IPo3UBHyIIOvU@sKfwbk1wVtPZGtEy1sHA4w8a1Q5B3OWX6rUE/56xa8A9SvjfGJsLVDVMgcuB6MqwTo1BjBgnJ2O@LME1mqbGlk0nPh8LEBIkhy@fnxgLUdjCSoqWbs5OI/lYj5KWlrzjpjwU@2UQffJ21p1/wEOVN5c90du1iB83UGtjnXEKn8GdEifT0tyCOiJLnbyyj1hslRL7xUqYzMO61sfQyk3W@dWRZcs/), but it has been used.

[Try it online!](http://elm-lang.org/try)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001134)

Comment: `but it has been used.` by you :P

Answer (score 3):

## 71. [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 401 bytes, [A001134](http://oeis.org/A001134)

That was quite an experience, using a language I've never tried before which is based on a bunch of programming paradigms I've never experienced before...

```fs
let isprime p =
  let mutable q = 2
  while q * q < p && p % q > 0 do
    q <- q + 1
  p >= 2 && q * q > p

let isA001134 p =
  let mutable i = 1
  let mutable g = 2
  while g <> 1 do
    g <- g * 2 % p
    i <- i + 1
  i * 4 = p - 1 && isprime p

let A001134 n =
  let mutable q = n
  let mutable result = 113
  while q > 0 do
    result <- result + 4
    if isA001134 result then q <- q - 1
  result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRjoIwEEXf@YobE3zQkFDkySgJn@JmCzaBtkCN/j1724JhjQ80zJ2Z3jPTZsp6o808d9JBTXZUvYTFNQG80j/c7aeTGHBFQe15VyE68Luwbr/nkTKokOPXsAI@k/E4QjC0qNjp62JTBZsk0avOcyFO5Rc3RTfxobX/CFpcKojVsfWOLe8vyGKDpLykFgjFVMl@i4xNZHkPGllWEv11bv2hjXJ6dM4jitNmJZsNLBUkWP6OKCNVs5l7ybm71OvOsoAbE@FF@puKUI0Z8aJnDmdQvJ18jWdc73wFlcNp12js0vqMtN6xc5j/AA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000401)

Answer (score 3):

## 77. [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 51 bytes, [A004147](https://oeis.org/A004147/)

```
m32&gM9784&gM7571840&gM11140566368&gMvvcv1+[R<v]v_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/19hILd3X0tzCBEiZm5obWpgYAFmGhoYmBqZmZsZmFkBeWVlymaF2dJBNWWxZvPX///@NAQ)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000051/)

Comment: According to this answer, the number of 5-state Turing machines which halt is 32. :p And then it just keeps cycling through the same four numbers

Comment: @PeterOlson actually according to this answer the number of 4-state halting machines is 32, but it's irrelevant because the numbers are incomputable, and unknown beyond n=3

Answer (score 3):

## 78. [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 12 bytes, [A000051](https://oeis.org/A000051)

```
        2«*‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8yrTMus@P9fAQqMDq3WetQw4////8YA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000012)

Note: TIO says 15 bytes but that's because I haven't asked Dennis to configure Anyfix to use the Jelly codepage yet.

Answer (score 3):

## 79. [Commentator](https://github.com/SatansSon/Commentator), 13 bytes, [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012)

```
 */
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU3NK0ksyS/6/19BS18BDv7//28KAA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000013)

A space increments the accumulator and `*/` outputs it as a number. As the program has outputted, the spaces at the end are essentially no-ops.

Answer (score 3):

## 86. [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 40 bytes, [A000097](http://oeis.org/A000097)

```
1w×ḍΣ¦¦ȯ¦u⟨:l0₁,*¤⟪¤;3<×\?⟫†¦ȯ¦u⟩¦e¦l:!+
```

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000040)

Answer (score 3):

## 87. [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 16 bytes, [A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040)

```
>1><><><><><><
```

Output is wrapped in braces `[]`. Yes, those are random filler bytes (that increment and decrement continuously), but I like to think of them as fish having fun with code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/3@7D3Andhh/mTp1uZ4OA//@bAgA)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000016)

Comment: i don't know, I think it looks like a fish double date `><><><   ><><><`

Comment: You can replace `1` (get last 1 elements) with `` (get greatest element) if you want output without braces. Also, you can use `Q` as a filler (terminate program) or a space character.

Comment: @Okx Why do you want no fish dates?

Answer (score 3):

## 90. [Open Shading Language (OSL)](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage), 66 bytes, [A000201](https://oeis.org/A000201)

```
shader abc(int i=1, output float o=1){o=floor(i*((1+sqrt(5))/2));}
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000066)

Answer (score 3):

## 93. Clojure, 35 bytes, [A000093](https://oeis.org/A000093)

```
#(Math/floor (Math/sqrt (* % % %)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1nDN7EkQz8tJz@/SAHCLi4sKlHQ0FJQBUFNTc3/mlwaBUWZeUDB3MQChTQFjaLEvPRUBUMDkCQA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000035)

Answer (score 3):

## 98. [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 153 bytes, [A001772](https://oeis.org/A001772)

```
&v >1 >1+:00g\%kvv>1\>1-\2*\:kvv
 #   vw\-1g00: < >$v ^       < $
>0p^ >$01g1-:01v> #> > 1+vv-1*b<
^>1+01p         ^ ^:     <>0
               >p  k^.@zz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCsJADETv@xUDrR5aIoknXZbghyw5FOoeCtKLEfvz62Lx4GMOM0My03x/PspM1wut76@t9ehQaRojc8mHxV0lq1A@Dzm2FNAB8FcmKcwRCdo7DDsJfVBerZUsRSiyuKJTKGR0JxmmFKyts6z4YbC4fysH/KPtbLHTbdtqZXwA)
The two `z`s after the @ are nop's that never get executed but I added in the make the bytecount correspond to an easier sequence. Becuase of what I think is a quirk of the interpreter and the fact that TIO doesn't provide a trailing newline, input needs to be given with a trailing space.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000153)

Answer (score 3):

## 100. [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 20 bytes, [A000030](https://oeis.org/A000030)

Yaay, the 100th answer! 0-indexed.

```
                  `h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/XwEDJGT8/29oCQA)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000020)

Comment: @StepHen **EDIT** Sorry, fixing

Comment: @StepHen How is this 1-indexed? Inputting `0` gives `0` as it should

Comment: @StepHen Fixed, haha

Answer (score 3):

## 110. [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 442 bytes, [A000081](http://oeis.org/A000081)

```
from strutils import parseint
import math

proc A000081(index: int): int =
 if index <= 0: return 0
 elif index <= 2: return 1
 elif index == 3: return 2
 elif index == 4: return 4
 else:
  var n: int = index - 1
  result = 0
  for k in 1..n:
   var t: int = 0
   for d in 1..k:
    if gcd(d,k)==d:
     t = t + (d * A000081(d))
   result = result + t*A000081(n-k+1)
  result = int(result / n)
 return

echo A000081(parseint(readline(stdin)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFNbsMgEEb3nOJbQtykdhpFlVUWPYplcINsgwU4yu1dIBilZYFg3psZfrSat22wZobzdvVqclDzYqzH0lknlfYk7@fO3whZrOnxXYfx2VClhXy0CBJLMziBGpDC@OKoW1jpV6tRE8jpFZ0Lav4gzvFR0Pk/uhR0icjJlgD3zkLn/lk9xqpBdesUg6E7BmMxBozmdNIxLeX5PS8qyRHZGZMTr/PTCyreRsa5eMYQEzwqUIFDeQzBWKSlaV5U8Idd0cexatjryUJzmjfv0AE9r0eI7G@mlN6/IqidmJSW1HmhNGNs266/)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000442)

Answer (score 3):

## 113. [Arcyóu](https://github.com/Nazek42/arcyou), 228 bytes, [A000049](//oeis.org/A00049)

```
(: grp (F(d) d))
(: q (# (q)))
(: t (? q (] 
 (r * (* (_ 2 3) q))) 2))
(: a 0)
(f x (_ 1 t) (grp
 (: b 0)
 (f y (_ t) (grp
  (f z (_ t) (grp
   (? (= (+ (* 3 (* y y)) (* 4 (* z z))) x) (: b 1) 1)
  ))
 ))
 (: a (+ a b))
))
(p a)
```

This is slow for terms past about the fifth, but Arcyóu is implemented in Python, which does support arbitrary precision numbers.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5BCsJADLz3FQNeEr3YVi8F6c1fiGwterQtFbr7@XWmBUHIJpuZJDNhesT3J2dr8JoG2NV6R@9eEBhhO9joWzfDWkE3FLAJexjjjgq1QzOotrmAI@sTi9gSs8N4mTsNOlEgF8X9GCHpH5GWXWAHqdRKEZEa/JyUEpIkF9/Ols7gGh2sb7XB5YCOrXwNCJ7z@Qs)

[Next sequence](//oeis.org/A000228) (let's try some geometry ...)

Comment: The next one ought to be done in Hexagony.

Comment: Does anyone have tips or pseudocode for the next sequence? Couldn't find anything specific on the OEIS.

Comment: why do you keep doing hard next-sequences ;_; xD

Comment: Because I think this challenge is progressing too fast. Actually, this is only my second hard sequence, and the first one was accidental; I didn't realize it was going to be hard.

Comment: This one isn't actually hard; just find a language with only 32 bit numbers and hardcode.

Comment: @ppperry FWIW I am strongly opposed to hardcoding anything that is computational :P and still, even if it's the second one it's still very very hard ._.

Comment: I managed to decypher the name, I believe. It's about thr number of different "tetrominoes" with n pieces, but on a hexagonal grid. Read [Polyhex](https://en.wikipedia.org/Polyhex_(mathematics)) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @NieDzejkob [Your link was 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhex_(mathematics))

Comment: @HyperNeutrino tfw you are too lazy to copy a link... I wonder what that /wiki/ part is for

Answer (score 3):

## 122. [MIT/GNU Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), 2057 bytes, [A000525](https://oeis.org/A000525)

So I'm implementing A000081 [again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140044/56725)...

```
(define (add f g)
  (stream-map + f g) )

(define (scale c f)
  (stream-map (lambda (v) (* c v)) f) )

(define (adddiag sf)
  (let ((f0 (stream-first sf)))
    (cons-stream (stream-first f0)
         (add (stream-rest f0) (adddiag (stream-rest sf))) ) ) )

(define (mult f g)
  (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (v) (scale v g)) f)) )

(define (prependzeros n f)
  (if (= 0 n) f (cons-stream 0 (prependzeros (-1+ n) f))) )

(define (intersperse f n)
  (cons-stream (stream-first f)
           (prependzeros n (intersperse (stream-rest f) n)) ) )

(define (iterate fun init)
  (cons-stream init (iterate fun (fun init))) )

(define (from n)
  (cons-stream n (from (1+ n))) )

(define (scanl fun init s)
  (cons-stream init (scanl fun (fun init (stream-first s)) (stream-rest s))) )

(define (expx f)
  (cons-stream 1
           (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (s g) (scale (/ 1 s) g))
                    (scanl * 1 (from 2))
                    (iterate (lambda (g) (mult f g)) f) )) ) )

(define (eu f)
  (expx (adddiag (stream-map (lambda (n) (scale (/ 1 n)
                                                (intersperse f (-1+ n)) ))
                             (from 1) ))) )

(define gf000081s (cons-stream 1 (stream-rest (eu gf000081s))))

(define gf000081 (cons-stream 0 gf000081s))

(define (recip1 f)
  (let ((msf (scale -1 (stream-rest f))))
    (cons-stream 1 (adddiag (iterate (lambda (g) (mult msf g)) msf))) ) )

(define (div1 f g)
  (mult f (recip1 g)) )

(define (pow7 f)
  (let* ((p2 (mult f f))
         (p4 (mult p2 p2))
         (p6 (mult p4 p2)) )
    (mult p6 f) ) )

(define (addconst c f)
  (cons-stream (+ c (stream-first f))
               (stream-rest f) ) )

(define gf
  (let* ((p2 (mult gf000081 gf000081))
         (p3 (mult p2 gf000081))
         (p4 (mult p3 gf000081)) )
    (div1 (mult p4 (addconst 64
                             (add (add (scale -79 gf000081)
                                       (scale  36 p2) )
                                  (scale -6 p3) ) ))
          (pow7 (addconst 1 (scale -1 gf000081))) ) ) )

(define (f n) (stream-ref gf (+ 4 n)))
```

In debian, MIT/GNU Scheme is in the package `mit-scheme`.

Here's how to use it when the program is in a file `ps.scm`:

```
$ scheme --load ps.scm
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
[...]
1 ]=> (f 20)

;Value: 90039381031273
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A002057)

Comment: Man, I wanted to do this one. I mean, I implemented A000081 [first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139176/69481)...

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had waited long enough...

Answer (score 3):

## 130. TI-Nspire CAS Basic, 90 bytes, [A000482](http://oeis.org/A000482)

```
Define f(n)=
Prgm
:Disp polyCoeffs(taylor((−ln(1-x))^(5),x,n),x)[1]*((n!)/(5!))
:EndPrgm
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000090)

[Code in Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdgzI.jpg)

Fun fact: I tried to implement 3 other sequences, but was too late as other answers had been made

Comment: Pretty straightforward implementation from Oeis page, also hooray for first actual answer

Comment: Also next sequence has [closed form](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/exact.htm) :o

Comment: I know that feeling. I tried to implement 2 sequences, only the third got through.

Comment: Next sequence is pretty straightforward

Comment: Yeah, fractional factorials will take a while to figure out.

Comment: Or do these square brackets mean "round"? There aren't any normal brackets inside them...

Comment: square brackets are the floor function

Comment: Duh, I should've read the notes at the top...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65006/discussion-between-husnain-raza-and-niedzejkob).

Answer (score 3):

## 134. [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 277 bytes, [A000643](https://oeis.org/A000643)

```
i
0
⛽
i1i1
⛽
1⛽
10
⛽
2
tt
➡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///D/MlLP8yftCYTRAA5m7hADAMoDyg1cSnXo9l7uZDVbASJgtiGCGU9XSimoMlOmAI0YNYMmEFwGYjAlAYcBoIkUByDYg5E1gjJqavAskCZZiCeBVS@HNnwEoTjJq5GFtiIrK3h0byF////twQA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000277)

**Explanation:**

In contrast to Emojicode, Emoji is an esoteric programming language. Emoji is similar to GolfScript and CJam in that it uses a stack as the primary memory.

```
		Implicitly push all arguments as string. Stack: "7"
		Floor. Normally  would be used to get a float, but using
		floor gives an int, which (since the interpreter is written
		in Python) is a bignum. Stack: 7
i		Store to variable i. Stack:
0		Push "0", to string, duplicate. Stack: a(1) a(0)
⛽...⛽...	While(...) do ... (let's look later in the loop)
i		(in while condition) recall variable i. Stack: a(4) a(3) i
		Duplicate. Stack: a(4) a(3) i i
1		Subtract 1. Stack: a(4) a(3) i i-1
i		Store i-1 to i for next iteration. Stack: a(4) a(3) i
1		Is greater than 1? This means that the outer loop will be
		repeated n - 1 times, where n is the input.
		Stack: a(4) a(3) true
1		(in outer loop) Now we will calculate 2^a(3) - push 1.
		Stack: a(4) a(3) 1
⛽...⛽...	While(...) do ... (now a(3) is the loop counter, let's assume
		we are at the last iteration of this loop.)
		Swap. Stack: a(4) 2^(a(3)-1) 1
		Duplicate. Stack: a(4) 2^(a(3)-1) 1 1
1		Subtract 1. Stack: a(4) 2^(a(3)-1) 1 0
		Swap. Stack: a(4) 2^(a(3)-1) 0 1
0		Is greater than 0? This means that the inner loop will be
		repeated a(3) times. Stack: a(4) 2^(a(3)-1) 0 true. Notice
		that after true is popped, the two values are swapped compared
		to the beginning of the condition evaluation. This has to be
		fixed both in the inner loop and after it.
		(in inner loop) swap. Stack: a(4) 0 2^(a(3)-1)
2		Multiply by 2. Stack: a(4) 0 2^a(3).
		The loop ends. Stack: a(4) 2^a(3) 0
		The counter is now always 0 and has to be discarded. Since
		there is no such instruction, an empty if is used instead.
		Stack: a(4) 2^a(3)
		Swap. Stack: 2^a(3) a(4)
t		Duplicate and store a(4) in t. Stack: 2^a(3) a(4)
		Add. Stack: a(5)
t		Restore a(4) from variable. Stack: a(5) a(4).
		The loop ends here. Stack: a(7) a(6).
		Swap. Stack: a(6) a(7).
➡		Print a(7). The stack is discarded at the end of the program.
```

Emoji aren't fixed-width in a fixed-width font, so spaces don't work for alignment. Fortunately, tabs work, but different emoji fonts might slightly break it.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ I have a feeling that you might get the bounty when it's finally awarded :P

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Unless someone posts an answer in Malbolge, a. k. a. you are probably right. Have you seen 99 bottles of beer in this?

Answer (score 3):

## 143. Excel, 120 bytes, [A000782](http://oeis.org/A000782)

```
=2*FACT(2*A1)/(FACT(A1)*(FACT(A1+1)))-IFERROR(FACT(2*A1-2)/(FACT(A1-1)*(FACT(A1))),0)
```

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000120)

Input is in cell `A1`. It just implements the function listed on OEIS:

```
a(n) = 2 * C(n) - C(n-1)
C(n) = (2n)! / (n!(n+1)!)
```

Technically, only `n > 0` should be valid so the `IFERROR` bit could be dropped since it only errors on `n < 1`. I left it in for artistic license and to have what I think is a more interesting next sequence.

Answer (score 3):

## 148. [Python 2 (IronPython)](http://ironpython.net), 173 bytes, [A000695](https://oeis.org/A000695)

```python
def to_b_4(k):
 r=""
 while k>0:
  r=`k%4`+r
  k //=4
 return r
n=input()
i=j=b=0
while i<=n:
 b=set(to_b_4(j))
 if not("2"in b or"3"in b or"4"in b):
  i+=1
 j+=1
print(j-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NCsIwEITveYolICRI6Y85ieurtARTuolsSkwRnz6mKl6Gj2GGmfWVl8hDQylyKTc3Q46jHY0K@iwgoZQCngvdHYRrV51qTeFgpmOqHKBt0dSYy1tiSIKReN2y0oLQo8VOfLt0Qa5liw@X1W/Aay2AZuCYlRwkMViISZ7@ZD603wA6Yi/A77om4qx80@tSzBs)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000173)

Comment: I'll tackle this with OCaml...

Answer (score 3):

## 150. [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 125 bytes, [A001993](https://oeis.org/A001993)

```julia
function A001993(n)
 m=zeros(15,15)
 for i=1:14
 m[i,i+1]=1
 end
 m[:,1]=[1;2;0;-2;-4;1;3;3;1;-4;-2;0;2;1;-1]
 (m^n)[1,1]
end
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000125)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsMgGIPvPoVHZQrGtoNWPOw5pIOxtfCPVYdrL3t5p4eRS/KFkOfxotu5lPWI951S5BdjMI6diJLxzX@XnD4Cg8JQ85oyJ48Jfe0CKTph9mB8iY8GJlVjgLPOOG2d7h1cV4VmdaO2ecyMi@0aZUAdsDou70xxF/9rGCnLDw)

The next one is easy, and all languages are back on the table, so somebody may have to re-work the stack snippet to allow for multiple uses (I don't know enough javascript to tell if that's already there or not).

Implements the matrix product formula given in the OEIS page. It was pretty fun learning a bit of Julia; it's quite similar to Matlab.

Comment: Yay more Python :D :D :D

Comment: I've also had a bit of fun learning new languages for this challenge. Except for INTERCAL.

Comment: @KSmarts You have been warned. By your own program.

Answer (score 3):

## 154. [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog), 262 bytes, [A001344](https://oeis.org/A001344)

```
module OEIS1344 (input c, input [99:0] n, output reg [99:0] r=0, output reg v=1'b1);
reg [99:0] i,f;
always @ (posedge c) if(v)begin f=n-((n>0)?1:0);v=(f==0);i=f-1;r=(n*(n+3))+((n==0)?2:1);end else begin v=(i==0)||(i==-1);f=v?f:f*i;i=i-1;r=v?r*f:r;end 
endmodule
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000262)

The Verilog module above calculates OEIS A001344.

The code below is the same code but prettified, and a testbench module added to allow you to run the code in a Verilog simulator such as modelsim.

I have verified inputs up to the 22nd element in the sequence, beyond which OEIS runs out of examples, and shortly afterwards the numbers start overflowing 100bit arithmetic. I believe that is allowed as per the rules about assuming input and output numbers will never overflow the language. Originally I had used 32bit arithmetic which caused overflow at 13, but without changing the byte count (just 3 numbers from 31 to 99) we can get up to 22-ish.

When simulating, the input number is clocked in on the rising edge. `v` may go low if it is going to take more than one clock cycle to calculate. Once `v` is high after the clock edge that loaded the number, the output `r` can be considered a valid number of the OEIS A001344 sequence.

The code is actually making use of the related OEIS sequence, [A028387](https://oeis.org/A028387) which calculates `n + (n+1)^2`. By multiplying the `n+1`'th element of that sequence by `n!` we arrive at the A001344 sequence. All that is required is a little fiddling around with the value of n to make it 0-indexed as per the requirements and we have our result.

To do this in Verilog is a little bit of a pain as it requires a factorial. The simplest approach is to use an iterative approach over n clock cycles to calculate the factorial and output the final result.

I should probably point out that both the OEIS1344 module and its testbench are very naïve approaches to get the job done. But since joining PPCG I've wanted to be able to use Verilog in an answer, and I found a way to shoehorn it into this one.

---

The following is an example output from ModelSim:

[image: Testbench Output Example]

The following is the testbench code:

```
module OEIS1344_test;

reg c = 0;
always begin
    #10 c = !c;
end

reg  [99:0] n;
wire [99:0] r;
wire v;

OEIS1344 dut (
    .c(c),
    .n(n),
    .r(r),
    .v(v)
);

reg  [99:0] i;
initial begin
    for (i = 0; i < 23; i=i+1) begin
        n = i;
        @(posedge c);
        while (!v) @(posedge c);
    end
end

endmodule

module OEIS1344 (
    input c,
    input [99:0] n,
    output reg [99:0] r = 0,
    output reg v = 1'b1
);

reg [99:0] i,f;
always @ (posedge c) begin
    if (v) begin
        f = n - ((n > 0) ? 1 : 0);
        v = (f == 0);
        i = f - 1;
        r = (n * (n + 3)) + ((n == 0) ? 2 : 1);
    end else begin
        v = (i == 0) || (i == -1);
        f = v ? f : f * i;
        i = i - 1;
        r = v ? r * f : r;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

## 160. Bash, 315 bytes, [A000778](https://oeis.org/A000778)

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()
array[0]=1
i=1
read n

while [ $i -le $(expr 2 * $n + 2) ]
do
    let array[$i]=array[$(expr $i - 1)]*$i
    let i=i+1
done

echo $(expr ${array[$(expr 2 * $n)]} / ${array[$n]} / ${array[$(expr $n + 1)]} + ${array[$(expr 2 * $n + 2)]} / ${array[$(expr $n + 1)]} / ${array[$(expr $n + 2)]} - 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/RCsIwDEXf8xUR@7BuSO3e@yWjD50rNDA6qYKK@O21XacyGAYCN@Se27Q3Fxfjfid68qJPA4AJwTxUxYvojlpJoNTBmgE9wM3RaLFDRnhIglX2fg7YYo3MY4MtRw3DBJhqtFcsKYy0WlTxZxol1zWjr5UUNTKx3gLYk5s@2ey5QstTXL9Q/FZ@PS5gPkhmZ7MdMt/7n9xezVT@QIxv)

[A000315](https://oeis.org/A000315)

Comment: It'll take a moment to figure this out, but I can already see that this is related to sudoku.

Answer (score 3):

## 166. [Scratch 2](https://scratch.mit.edu), 638 bytes, [A000114](https://oeis.org/A000114)

[image: code as image]

Or, when written as text in the ScratchBlocks2 format:

```
when green flag clicked
ask [] and wait
set [a v] to ((answer) + (2))
if <(a) = [2]> then 
  say [3]
else 
  set [b v] to (((a) * (a)) / (2))
  set [d v] to [2]
  repeat until <(d) = (a)> 
    if <((a) mod (d)) = [0]> then 
      set [c v] to [2]
      set [prime v] to [1]
      repeat until <<(prime) = [0]> or <(c) > ([sqrt v] of (d))>> 
        if <((d) mod (c)) = [0]> then 
          set [prime v] to [0]
        end
        set [c v] to ((c) + (1))
      end
      if <(prime) = [1]> then 
        set [b v] to ((b) * ((1) - ((1) / ((d) * (d)))))
      end
    end
    set [d v] to ((d) + (1))
  end
  say ((b) - ((b) mod (1)))
end
```

[Next sequence](//oeis.org/A000638)

Comment: Note for next sequence: as with previous similar sequences, you cannot hardcode. You must compute, since it has to theoretically work for `n`s up to `1000`.

Comment: Can we hardcore sequences if we have to?

Comment: Also good resource for future things http://vixra.org/abs/1409.0048

Comment: @HusnainRaza If you can somehow get a 1000 values of the next sequence, sure.

Comment: The next sequence is a programmer's nightmare in terms of documentation...

Comment: what documentation

Comment: Well, a week of waiting yet again...

Comment: When everyone gives up we can always "use" Magma (totally no copy-paste from OEIS)

Comment: @GrzegorzPuławski alernatively, we can reverse engineer Magma and copy the necessary functions to some other language

Comment: @NieDzejkob oh that sounds much more fun

Comment: @HusnainRaza yes, you can hardcode, ***iff*** your program works for the first 1000 entries.

Comment: I wonder, if I got another function in Magma other than SubgroupLatices() that produces the same sequence, would that still be considered copy from OEIS? (after packaging into a function)

Comment: Magma is proprietary, so there's now way of finding out the innards of the function...

Comment: @ppperry how do you convert the block format into the text format? I have the next sequence in Scratch 2 but I don't know how to get it in text

Comment: I've forgotten how I posted this, actually.

Answer (score 3):

## 167. [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/), 101 bytes, [A000638](https://oeis.org/A000638)

```c
a000638:=function(n);if n eq 0 then return 1;else return#SubgroupClasses(Sym(n));end if;end function;
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000101)

You're probably thinking "This is taken from the OEIS site!", but hold on. While checking Magma documentation, I found something interesting [here](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/623). One of OEIS descriptions of this sequence is `number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of symmetric group S_n`, and the documentation speaks of a build-in! And it's a different one than the one used on OEIS `SubgroupLattice()`, this one is `SubgroupClasses()`. So it happens that both functions create the same amount of subgroups (possibly how the math of this works - I'm not sure), but `SubgroupClasses()` is actually THE correct way. Thus I felt that this answer is eligible.

[You can try it here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

**Code usage:**

Just paste the function and then call it by `a000638(5);` or any other number instead of `5` (note, anything higher than `11` will time out). You can also use this to output 11 first integers in the sequence:

```c
for i := 0 to 10 by 1 do a000638(i); end for;
```

**Code explanation:**

```c
a000638 := function(n);           // Create a function taking one argument
    if n eq 0 then                // If argument is 0
        return 1;                 //     Then return 1
    else                          // Otherwise
        return #                  //     Count and return the number of
               SubgroupClasses(   //         Conjugacy classes of subgroups of
                   Sym(n)         //             Symmetric group of order n
               );
    end if;
end function;
```

Answer (score 3):

## 190. [COBOL (GNU)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/), 725 bytes, [A001182](http://oeis.org/A001182)

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.  A001182.
       AUTHOR.  KSmarts.

       DATA DIVISION.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  Num1                                PIC 999   VALUE ZEROS.
       01  Num2                                PIC 999   VALUE ZEROS.
       01  Iterator                            PIC 999   VALUE ZEROS.
       01  Result                              PIC 9(6)  VALUE ZEROS.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.

       ACCEPT Num1.
       MOVE Num1 TO Iterator
       ADD 1 TO Num1
       MOVE 1 TO Num2
       PERFORM Summing Iterator TIMES
       DISPLAY Result.
       STOP RUN.

       Summing.
           COMPUTE Result = Result + (Num1**2 - Num2**2)**.5
           ADD 1 TO Num2.
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000725)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVJRa4MwEH7vr7jH1qGo0LE@7CEkqQutJiTRsb11o5RBrWD197toNUvLYIPe05Hv7rvvvstn9VEd/cOp7Tq4BCM002zNMNKMZ0BYwZRJgtmIC8kTiVKfkQAAhWEUPcUWRLl@4dIAG1Xu6uYczCaEII0csun5lcsNyxJfaS5RQkFRrN1pYQSQtWUEf4RgGFarlckKtM0pvFPJ1S1LfD8La/b1rqnq@1jk/twem39omT8ublicM2BKckl/MRVhTIUefLNjU17Qi5Oa2y1sAyEwAH3BVcf0Gtu5VK65TEG1Zfl1OvwYollKlb02U2KL3sZFrQhzZQEyd6SONLaiD8xTkWs6ufQ8JQ8w7/V5Xgz@oMlkC88Llm6zu4r5l10XLb8B)

COBOL was originally designed with ease-of-use as the goal. We've come a long way since then.

Comment: Does anybody know what the symbols in the rightmost column of the table [here](https://oeis.org/A000653/a000653.pdf) mean? 'Cause [A000722](https://oeis.org/A000722) is easy to solve but I don't know how to narrow it down to [A000725](https://oeis.org/A000725)...

Comment: @icrieverytim I think it's the same as the comments: Equivalence classes "under action of permutation of variables on the domain and permutation and complementation of the range."

Comment: Why are there like three different sequences around the next one with the exact same description?

Comment: @HusnainRaza They all have the same title, but different descriptions in the comments.  It looks like they are equivalence classes under different transformations

Comment: Is this impossible

Answer (score 3):

## 195. [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 210 bytes, [A000589](https://oeis.org/A000589)

```
5+::6+}2*}5 -{2[\]b*$,n;
//?={:{:/?= 0:  /
:\      >    ~~1v
\{:}-12[v   /~]{ 22[v/~]*$32[v
v       <           <        >
            /:2=    ?/\
            ?
>:?\~11>*l2\
-1:/ v$\?- /
     >  :1) ^   v,$]~ /
```

[Try it here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) - input given as initial stack
[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000210)

Fixed previous version. Byte count changed so I decided to delete and repost.
For some reason, doesn't work on TIO.

The code has 3 parts:
[image]
Red - computing main sequence;
Orange - computing binomial using factorial;
Blue - computing factorial;

Answer (score 3):

## 196. [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 56 bytes, [A000210](https://oeis.org/A000210)

```java
int f(int n) {return (int)Math.floor((n+1)*(Math.E-1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxD4IwEIVn/RU3XjU0MBrj6MjEaBwqFCzClbQHxhh@e22Jy73ce@97vVpUZidNffM6hWl@DKaGelDeQ6kMwXe/@5ueFUdZrGlgjBFW7Ax1tzso13mRmrsNSSFcgPR7m0Bxjkn18axHaWeWU8R4IEw92WKR5yJV1hBtaDFdinNO8@wI0i9KxU/ZDtY6RDoW4oCbc82KiK5hDeEH)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000056)

Comment: Not like it matters very much, but I think you should say this is Java 9.

Comment: @NieDzejkob EDIT oh I thought that Java 9 was all taken and that Java 8 was still available mb

Answer (score 3):

## 200. [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 189 bytes, [A000092](https://oeis.org/A000092)

**Note:** byte count includes the +3 bytes for `-lm`.

```
f(x){Lr=0,d=0,n=1;O;d<x+1;n++){Lc=0,m=ceil(sqrt(n))+1,i=-m,j,k;O;i<m;i++)Oj=-m;j<m;j++)Ok=-m;k<m;k++)c+=i*i+j*j+k*k<=n;c-=lround(sqrt(n*n*n)*4.18879020478639);c=abs(c);Fc>r)d++,r=c;}Tn-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzrSgMxEIXfpaDktmVjS7tlNoJ//FUoiC@wTlyby6aYVFiQvrpxFmUYznznHKacL/mK9ek4Q8EhjWx1F@1K3c8cXv7Okc2cw60u@n3MplWWNhkNJ7D9LDUkKSlBcieD7y6y8pmvLHEutXKmmZRXgcqun8BR9eTJA0/kFwoLBaJAhNI44aQXXgYRepMAGxPz5SvZ/6@ChovtWnfd/tA@tNt9t9scOKAZ3gpDDs/4mLmVUmWDcHtNja510/7gGIePUps4/QI)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000189)

Yay, 200th answer.

Comment: For the next sequence, x < n (modulo implies it but it wasn't immediately obvious to me).

Comment: Well, that's 200. I'm not sure whether to be glad or astounded that anyone still cares about this challenge :P

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing that means that you came up with an interesting challenge. You should be proud.

Answer (score 3):

## 201. [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 213 bytes, [A000189](https://oeis.org/A000189)

```
from strutils import parseint
import math

proc A000189(index: int): int =
  result=1
  for x in 1..index-1:
    if x^3 mod index == 0:
      result = result + 1
  return

echo A000189(parseint(readline(stdin))+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5LCsMgFNx7illGQoNCoTTgohcphGiIEDU8XyC3t2Kbbob5MUz0oZSFUkBmOthvGT7siRj7RNn5yOKnw8SrEDulGS@llH6qzkfrzhG1JBvCCIBcPjY2utIlEc4aQA9D6970WG3ALzjfd4Rk0XwYA/WNrgGYi/TQbZYPikK4eU3/A9fHjtxkNx9dl9n6KGWvZSmPDw)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000213)

Comment: Darn I had a Brain-Flak solution coming :P Oh well it was nowhere near done anyway xD

Answer (score 3):

## 204. [Positron](https://github.com/alexander-liao/positron), 53 bytes, [A000096](https://oeis.org/A000096)

```
f = function {
      return ( $1 * ( $1 + 3 ) ) / 2
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcw7DoAgEATQnlNMYeGnUPxbmHAXIwnNYhAq49nRaFxninnVbHY33lmKUWOGDrR4YwmHwBO3@uAIKRKJ/J0CDbK7JWpxxs0Z8kqrSnySrJrVsFpWx@pZA2tkTf9zFS8)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000053)

shout out to all the New Yorkers here! xD

**N.B. The next one can be hardcoded because it is a finite sequence**

Comment: I'm a new yorker :D

Comment: Is there a Mathematica built-in for the next one?

Comment: @KSmarts `TrackStops@"NewYorkBroadway"` (jk idk but I wouldn't be surprsed :P)

Comment: If I find the Mathematica built-in, would you guys be okay with me using Mathematica for this? :P

Comment: @icrieverytim no

Comment: I'm afraid we might need you to save the challenge again...

Answer (score 3):

## 205. [Commata](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 109 bytes, [A000053](https://oeis.org/A000053)

*Due to the fact that the proper name breaks the snippet, it has been changed. The proper name is [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata)*

```
14 18 23 28 34 42 50 59 66 72 79 86 96 103 110 116 125 137 145 157 168 181 191 207 215 225 231 238 242 ↺•
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYzBDcMwDANXuRFMyZLtcYK@g346QF8dpGNknCzi6EEcCRD3ep/n8Tn2VkcTc2zinW5EIxaZDGMsZrISNUdqleoWyAfqxSjmLIfQEtYGpsDqY17bS17S@3fd3//euz0)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000109) (wtf)

Hello darkness,,, my old friend.

Comment: On all of these graph theory sequences, I understand exactly what is being asked, but only have a very vague idea of how to actually calculate it. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Extended by Brendan McKay and Gunnar Brinkmann (Gunnar.Brinkmann(AT)ugent.be) using their program ["plantri"](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/)

Comment: The sequence are the first numbers of even rows of [this table](http://www.numericana.com/data/polyhedra.htm), which can theoretically be generated with plantri, an (almost) open source program, but I don't know what options to use to do so.

Comment: @NieDzejkob, if you want to reimplement the relevant parts see http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/plantri-full.pdf - although that might be overkill. For code golf the answer has to be theoretically correct but not necessarily fast: generating every possible graph on n vertices and filtering would be a valid approach.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Given that the sequence is labeled as "hard" and there is no formula, I'm not sure if there is a more efficient (known) method than brute force.

Comment: How can you test if a graph is planar given an adjacency matrix of said graph?

Comment: @HusnainRaza [from math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1444332/243672) there are a few linear-time algorithms

Comment: @HusnainRaza You can implement an algorithm on your own, or you can just use Mathematica. (`PlanarGraphQ`)

Comment: would people be ok with me using mathematica http://www.strawpoll.me/14084506

Comment: @HusnainRaza it's not against any rules of challenge or meta, go for it. You can add who inspired/helped your answer (like KSmarts) if you want

Comment: @HusnainRaza SageMath, Magma, etc. have already been used, and I think this is a reasonable sequence to use math software on. Maple has a graph theory package with an `IsPlanar` test, if you'd prefer.

Comment: sorry, way too hard and dont have enough time, can someone take over?

Comment: `f[x_] := Length[GraphData["Triangulated", x]]` works up to x=9...

Comment: @Stephen go, go, go, don't give up

Comment: @HusnainRaza I'll work on it this afternoon if there still isn't an answer

Comment: Bad news. [Mathematica's `GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html) requires internet access. It also doesn't seem to have all graphs.

Comment: [Progress so far](https://tio.run/##VZBPTwIxEMXvfIpJSIjE3SBoPKiYJSYYEw4IGA9NQybLsFttu6RbImjkq6/TBRWaHvpnZt7vPYM@J4NepVhV3ilh51KQJlPOJdz0oQGvyufiy0A485rhO4lhoRcjVXoxKTx6GtHSR1B3RTBBm5G4iMBCDD0pIxhozTe5g1HxQW7mFFesNTr1STuIu98RGDiHmUNbroqShJGy0cjIZg5XeSlozt1M07kFgrs@nNmwY@i2250eMzag5uaCBMbkzJqRVGHLZIyLicpyLx745tH6gXO4FV1GZaqTMSyIWj/@CsoQQ7A/ZVOpFy@WB4rB4g1Tsum2rgtyR5DBYQRTNDSj0kN8D09lYQq3ylVa1z/zN4NYnkeLwwvb/JMMckON3pMVRyy1rQPGPlrisLo8bB9GM@zaBXSgB62Q3VJsTvAPIpeb@Jr7xhotuj1B0oRWC6bKrDT9v8hq7JT1yTK5qn4A). It seems to conflict with OEIS's definitions though...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino wtf you made so much progress and you didn't tell us anything ._.

Comment: @icrieverytim ;_; that was one hour's worth of work lol

Comment: Pls work we only have until tomorrow ;;

Answer (score 3):

## 208. [Befunge 93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 75 bytes, [A000389](https://oeis.org/A000389)

```
&:5-v
vp00<v`g00<
    v_:v
    >1 >/v:
>:1-:v v*<^_$5432***/.@
^    _$> \:^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KVLeMq6zAwMCmLCEdSHIpAEFZvFUZmGFnqGCnX2bFZWdlqGtVplCmZRMXr2JqYmykpaWlr@fAFQdSFK9ipxBjFff/v5EJAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000075)

Since it has been pointed out that MATLAB <s>might be</s> is overkill for such a simple sequence I decided to give Befunge a try, and free MATLAB for future use.

Hoping it's not against the rules I'm changing the language of my answer maintaining the **same bytecount**.

Comment: You used MATLAB for a sequence that could've been done in 23 bytes of Befunge. I think that's a little bit wasteful.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Erik using jelly for 2,0,0,0,0,0,0... though xD also i cri everytim using all the pythons lol

Comment: @HyperNeutrino LOL, right. BTW, I managed to golf it down to 21 while just thinking about it instead of listening to the history teacher.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Remember that this is not code-golf.. And also that **your bytecount must be unique** so 21 and 23 bytes answer are not valid at this point.

Comment: @Cinaski The point is that using such a useful language for something trivial enough to be solved in a short Befunge program is wasteful of MATLAB.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino the point is to starve useful languages off in trivial sequences so people have to use languages no one has ever heard of in the last 15 or so, which is fun :P

Comment: @Stephen given Hyper's had to save the challenge twice now, I think he'd prefer to have all the easy ones ready for any really difficult sequences :P

Comment: @Stephen If Proton didn't exist, the challenge would have died because I couldn't have solved it in anything. I mean, KSmarts did get a (possibly working) Mathematica answer, but still... Without Python, this challenge would have died 3 times by now ._.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino the problem is not that there aren't enough languages, but that there aren't enough languages with builtin, easy-to-use arbitrary-precision integers.

Comment: @Stephen That's true; mainly the thing is though that I don't know many languages to save the challenge so unless other people help with that the challenge would die lol

Comment: @NieDzejkob If you don't mind to share I'm really curious to see your 21bytes solution. It was my first time with Befunge and it was quite challenging for me to golf this from ~140bytes (of the first working solution) to 75.

Comment: @Cinaski Sure. `&:1-:1-:1-:1-3k*'x/.@`

Comment: @Stephen It's really frustrating when I'm working on a solution to a simple sequence in a more difficult-to-use language and someone beats me with something more practical, though.

Comment: @KSmarts, it's even more frustrating when people change history unnecessarily. IMO the edit to change the language is against the spirit of [tag:answer-chaining], and OP should revert it. Also, everyone should stop complaining when someone else uses a language they wanted, or leaves a next sequence they don't like. The challenge is designed to die. If you don't like it, don't play.

Answer (score 3):

## 210. [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 76 bytes, [A000100](http://oeis.org/A000100)

```
 "This is dummy text. Can be replaced with whatever you want!"l{s.pMfq3eST./
```

[See the first few terms.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=+%22This+is+dummy+text.+Can+be+replaced+with+whatever+you+want%21%22l%7Bs.pMfq3eST.%2F&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10&debug=0)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000076).

### Explanation

- (leading space) : Makes the interpreter ignore the next command.
- `"This is dummy text.... !"` : Pushes a dummy String, which is ignored.
- `l{s.pMfq3eST./` : The thing which does the actual job.

  ```
  ./     @ Integer partitions.
  fq3eST @ Filter the partitions with maximal integer `3`.
  .pM    @ Get all the permutations of each.
  s      @ Flattens.
  {      @ Deduplicate.
  l      @ Length.
  ```

Comment: lol the next sequence is almost the same as the previous :P

Answer (score 3):

## 211. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 78 bytes, [A000076](http://oeis.org/A000076)

```
2sm©ÝDâεDDн2m4*sP4*+sθ2m5*+}Ùʒ®›1s-}gqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fqDj30MrDc10OLzq31cXlwl6jXBOt4gATLe3iczuMck21tGsPzzw16dC6Rw27DIt1a9MLiQX//5sBAA)

## Explanation

```
2sm©ÝDâεDDн2m4*sP4*+sθ2m5*+}Ùʒ®›1s-}gqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq  5
2                                                                               5, 2
 s                                                                              2, 5
  m                                                                             32
   ©                                                                            32 [Copy to register]
    Ý                                                                           [0, ..., 32]
     D                                                                          [0, ..., 32], [0, ..., 32]
      â                                                                         [[0, 0], [0, 1], ..., [32, 31], [32, 32]]
       ε                   }                                                    For each pair [x, y]
        D                                                                       [x, y], [x, y]
         D                                                                      [x, y], [x, y], [x, y] # yes I realize I can triplicate
          н                                                                     [x, y], [x, y], x
           2                                                                    [x, y], [x, y], x, 2
            m                                                                   [x, y], [x, y], x^2
             4                                                                  [x, y], [x, y], x^2, 4
              *                                                                 [x, y], [x, y], 4x^2
               s                                                                [x, y], 4x^2, [x, y]
                P                                                               [x, y], 4x^2, xy
                 4                                                              [x, y], 4x^2, xy, 4
                  *                                                             [x, y], 4x^2, 4xy
                   +                                                            [x, y], 4x^2+4xy
                    s                                                           4x^2+4xy, [x, y]
                     θ                                                          4x^2+4xy, y
                      2                                                         4x^2+4xy, y, 2
                       m                                                        4x^2+4xy, y^2
                        5                                                       4x^2+4xy, y^2, 5
                         *                                                      4x^2+4xy, 5y^2
                          +                                                     4x^2+4xy+5y^2
                            Ù                                                   Now we have a list of all numbers formed by this; uniquify
                             ʒ     }                                            Keep numbers `n` where the result of the codeblock is 1
                              ®                                                 n, 32
                               ›                                                n > 32
                                1                                               n > 32, 1
                                 s                                              1, n > 32
                                  -                                             1 - (n > 32)
                                    g                                           Length; final number of numbers formed
                                     qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq  `q` terminates the program
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000078)

Comment: wait, x to the power y is `m` in 05AB1E? Why?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing

Comment: @icrieverytim yeah? What?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Good question. I don't know either lol

Answer (score 3):

## 217. [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/), 174 bytes, [A000411](https://oeis.org/A000411)

```
L[a_, s_] := Sum[JacobiSymbol[-a, 2k + 1] / (2k + 1)^s, {k, 0, Infinity}]
d[a_, n_] := L[-a, 2n] * (2a / Pi)^(2n) / Sqrt[a] * (2n - 1)!
A000411[n_] := Round @ N @ d[6, n + 1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NasMwFIT3OsV0J7ky/iFkEQi0yxZTQr0UtnmJWypSy22sLELIOXqUHiAHc17kRPDQaJ5m@DryXx8debuhUUZCgE/bkHQKSxTNMaaTzPlx/ofM6Xr9WIUad3P43XlJLP@uFmJk6kGISI2FoUZjaCoslij3nXmlTb@25aFb998mJo18i0dkFRJOBqnqQeO41Ug1XtynddYfTpVoQ5Obmoop6ipEASjByqo60CQoGcbQtLqzPKdpOssyc8u/93vX4glvPK2Zc2@AGFc76zx7t@@s8vEC)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000174)

Note that this takes *30 seconds* for `n = 2` on TIO. [Paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1967-21-100/S0025-5718-1967-0223295-5/S0025-5718-1967-0223295-5.pdf) that was both useful *and* useless at the same time.

Comment: I found that paper very useful in creating the solution that I just now finished, more than 20 minutes late. It defines a recursive relationship, so you don't have to use infinite sums or Jacobi symbols at all. I'll have to save it in case another "Generalized Triangular Numbers" sequence comes up.

Comment: Might want to add a version number

Comment: Rather than struggling with the paper you could just have looked at [my Python code](http://oeis.org/A000061/a000061.py.txt) on OEIS.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Unfortunately all versions of Python have been used (*cough* i cri everytim)

Comment: (though actually the logic there would've been really helpful nvm)

Comment: @Stephen Wait, why?

Comment: brackets fixed :P

Comment: @PeterTaylor ...I was not clever enough to look at the other sequences relevant to this one. >.<

Comment: @HyperNeutrino no they aren't

Comment: o wtf I tried lol

Comment: @KSmarts You and I see the paper *very* differently. :P In any case, sorry for ninja'ing you twice. Please find another opportunity for using Funciton, it's a really cool language.

Comment: @icrieverytim so other people can use other Mathematica versions

Answer (score 3):

## 218. [ExtraC](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/extrac), 702 bytes, [A000174](https://oeis.org/A000174)

```
long N be readint
long R be 0
for(long A be 0 AND not(A times A greater N) AND increment A)do
  for(long B be A AND not(A times A plus B times B greater N) AND increment B)do
    for(long C be B AND not(A times A plus B times B plus C times C greater N) AND increment C)do
      for(long D be C AND not(A times A plus B times B plus C times C plus D times D greater N) AND increment D)do
        for(long E be D AND not(A times A plus B times B plus C times C plus D times D plus E times E greater N) AND increment E)do
          if(A times A plus B times B plus C times C plus D times D plus E times E equals N)do
            increment R
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

print(R)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJBDoMgEADvvGKPerNPQODqwR9YXQ2JokVM@nsLqC1NS5qmNVGZJc5wEK9GV/W69qPqoIAzgsaqkcoQPyndJCPtqBPP1DPQgoMaTULByAFnO@7sZwY1FKnflKrWOKAyQNNmJAB3Q@4M9I1h6pfZ7m6Yx4X5JgyUzCnzz0qPbEcWL7CjEDS4a7CvGx75jjye5I9kEBUuyn@NehQ7ivgZRHgGANn@KYiXpepn23vSQ1Augzmqhryuj9X2dk93k0nbPzUp03U9ZfYiNw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000702)

Comment: Oh god this verbosity

Comment: BTW, I think `sorta(less)` is supposed to work as `<=`, but it doesn't, so I had to use `not(... greater ...)`. Also, I didn't bother removing the repeating expressions, because I would rather have simplicity and this is not codegolf.

Answer (score 3):

## 221. [Pony](https://www.ponylang.org/), 670 bytes, [A000107](https://oeis.org/A000107)

```
fun b(n: U128): U128 =>
  if n == 0 then
    return 0
  elseif n == 1 then
    return 1
  else
    var result: U128 = 0
    var j: U128 = 1
    
    while j < n do
      var d: U128 = 1
      var t: U128 = 0
      while d <= j do
        if (j % d) == 0 then
          t = t + (d * b(d))
        end
        d = d+1
      end
      result = result + (t * b(n-j))
      j = j+1
    end
    return result / (n-1)
  end

fun a(n: U128): U128 =>
  if n == 0 then
    return 0
  elseif n == 1 then
    return 1
  else
    var result: U128 = 0
    var i: U128 = 1
    while i < n do
      result = result + (a(n-i) * b(i))
      i = i+1
    end
    return result + b(n)
  end
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000670)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVIxbsMwDNz9ilsKSDXiVpmKIO7WsWMf4EZKI8GQA1l20Ne7lGwrgZrO1USQxyPvqHNnv6fm4DuH90bbArDqgoNTjVdM2XGHNzty1K9UAcbGQe/wIbYvqPEcc5eTbhU09jXEFrKLSYB6q27w1dlp61nDNK96T/EX43yBaOLQpShmuJyOg8UnszM/X8eEyfoIi5omwp@UjQ1O@cHZuINqe7UixC@EWBBJgFP90PpMRSiYlJt3upFnsCf@JC6gZYaesznvSiCDP@bKEDUxgwdInimbnycKjxJM4pFckcm16FWKJcFkKYq8Mouk4hIQkY9EdmMSlaG6uR7g1rWl7QnUIAI@1ItwoeYfL6Qzz9Pfuz3OHem080bzqF//9f3uqC@DX6v4afoB)

Comment: I wouldn't have waited much longer before sending a boring variation of [No. 122](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141287) as solution

Comment: [next sequence is also known as Ordered Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number)

Answer (score 3):

## 223. GolfScript, 88 bytes, [A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110)

```
{
 # Recurrence a(n+1) = sum a(k) * binomial(n, k)
 [1]{..,({[.(;\);]zip{~+}%}*+}@*-1=
}
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzgKCnsKICMgUmVjdXJyZW5jZSBhKG4rMSkgPSBzdW0gYShrKSAqIGJpbm9taWFsKG4sIGspCiBbMV17Li4sKHtbLig7XCk7XXppcHt%2BK30lfSorfUAqLTE9Cn0KCn4%3D)

[Next sequence](//oeis.org/A000088)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea what the O(...) mean in the first two formulas for the next seq?

Comment: @NieDzejkob [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: @ChristianSievers have you seen that formula? The Big O notation is used for describing computational complexity, this was in the middle of a formula, which would obviously make no sense.

Comment: @NieDzejkob See the introduction and the section "Matters of notation"/"Other arithmetic operators" in the wikipedia article. It means there is a missing term of order O(...).

Comment: @ChristianSievers Oh that's right, sorry. That would also mean the formula is not usable for computing the sequence. Not that it matters anymore.

Answer (score 3):

## 224. [Racket](https://racket-lang.org), 1232 bytes, [A000088](https://oeis.org/A000088)

```
#lang racket

(define (partsm n m)
  (if (= n 0)
      '(())
      (for*/list ([k (range 1 (add1 (min n m)))]
                  [r (partsm (- n k) k)] )
        (cons k r) ) ) )

(define (parts n)
  (partsm n n) )

(define (fact n)
  (for/product ([i (range 1 (add1 n))]) i) )

(define (c2 n) ; ways to choose 2 elements from n
  (* n (sub1 n) 1/2) )

(define (cycHash cl)
  (let ([h (make-hash)])
     (for ([i cl])
       (hash-update! h i add1 0) )
   h ) )

(define (halfes ch)
  (for/hash ([(l m) ch]
             #:when (even? l) )
    (values (/ l 2) m) ) )

(define (centralizerSize ch)
  (for/product ([(l m) ch])
    (* (expt l m) (fact m)) ) )

(define (fixp ch n)
  (for/sum ([(l m) ch]
            #:when (= (remainder n l) 0) )
    (* l m) ) )

(define (s2orb hch n)
  (for/sum ([(hl m) hch]
            #:when (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder n hl)])
                     (and (= 0 r) (odd? q)) ) )
    (* hl m) ) )

(define (edgeOrbs ch)
  (let* ([hch (halfes ch)]
         [order (apply lcm (hash-keys ch))])
    (/ (for/sum ([k order])
         (+ (c2 (fixp ch k)) (s2orb hch k)) )
       order ) ) )

(define (f n)
  (for/sum ([ch (map cycHash (parts n))])
    (/ (expt 2 (edgeOrbs ch)) (centralizerSize ch)) ) )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTBctsgED3XX7GdHLq447GjYzqZXHvroUePDxhQYIRABimJ@/PugmQiK4ns0Rhpee/te4sDF43qL5c7y90zhLxarVCq2jgF2PHQxxYctGwFgKYGfKTVLq3S9QORXX9j7cN6a03sAfcNYCBEBfeAXEq6t8ZlHMYO04b5tQ@FDDdU1zD6HoCVUhTeRWggMMifpUhwWWER7G5rai76qYRkbrvg5SCSULMU6kggA3O7XVQJ8Be88nOE3oPQ3kcFFSirWuWIvg6eaBP@mtgxDscEBffbaoF0Fr951CBsFmNVEqHJHt6ojaY3xL4qfmaBwh6KD5hKNkMnea@@gwYDWfSOjVbphTWa21pFkls6T/sJFS1FQc8XWdw9vGpF8tWLck9gJ1TAF24HwsEtWKCG2mUEgjwI3Jp/Kvyl25zw3erCOYGuieet6yE/HhOi8Vgg1@atoz2z7OLQftnAVf8jpapabpxUgeKgRnall/VIeEsTKx@OoD8j0rlcf0VFCW6u9uzxlAYUT4PvDVmynYvQlr3neHshdzKJ3uXdXsonOE1OTJL1J5qVfFZ/wrHES0rWaZioiVnwh9U32PuQNCDvOnsGK9ppjhp1zjVXYZTvrPMG8ra5aPyZz0JJpSGVM@/SslSPnB/y/GCwyNNPcNPJKOd5rioPSnXbM/t07kbCC0oTO8vPI3Z9PeXVjv6ALv8B)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001232)

Yes, it was Burnside's lemma time again! Symmetric group acts on `n` nodes, inducing an action on the possible edges and on the possible graphs. Count the orbits of the last action, yada yada. Run through the elements by conjugacy classes represented by partitions of `n`. Number of graphs fixed by an element `g` is 2 to the number of orbits of edges under the action of the cyclic group generated by `g`. So use Burnside's lemma again and find the number of edges fixed by each `g^k`. An edge is fixed if its endpoints are on fixed points or on points that are interchanged by the group element. Feel free to ask for more details!

Answer (score 3):

## 227. [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 861 bytes, [A004903](http://oeis.org/A004903)

**Thanks to user202729 for C++ help :)**

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <algorithm>
# include <vector>
# include <math.h>

std::vector<int> getsums(std::vector<int> values, int times) {
	if (times == 1) {
		return values;
	} else {
		std::vector<int> results;
		for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
			std::vector<int> subs = getsums(values, times - 1);
			for (int j = 0; j < subs.size(); j++) {
				results.push_back(subs[j] + values[i]);
			}
		} return results;
	}
}

// This method is O(log_8(n)) I think.

int main() {
	int input; std::cin >> input;
	int size = (int) pow(input / 8, 0.1) + 1;
	std::vector<int> values;
	for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) values.push_back(pow(i, 10));
	std::vector<int> sums = getsums(values, 8);
	std:sort(sums.begin(), sums.end());
	sums.erase(std::unique(sums.begin(), sums.end()), sums.end());
	for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) std::cout << sums[i] << " ";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLbsIwEDzHX7GiF0dAAPWCIOTeUy@9IYRCMIkhsVM/qNQq3079AkqBS2LvY3Zm1kXbDos6Z@Xp9AKUFbXeEkgpl0qQvMnQn2Bel1xQVd1Gj6RQXNyEmlxVSZUhJNV2NvMFKWUqg5IoqRuJ7xLHvNZEDgyGAkUbImP4QRHdAXY3WCxg4kKRIEoLFhrmKOqA1JK41B2qIFLXylZFOy4AW3QKCxjPzS8NGImk3wTHJtTv@xH3QFJvDIcL/TNbz21oqNkR1xl7P2NvZtjOy4T9ZUIUqCWtltV6kxcHbCuX@xX0A68lXXnYznw6CLqvkjrUITQawUdFJTREVXwL5vSOa16up5jFMbyBqig7JAhZVk1OGfa@Wh9Yq9UcnNSCMsiyEPJpS9mosHJiaPkXdkkYwXQA48Tsog8TU/pkkSbzwPCFQw1GB/Ov@t2QAUzGcfwI2Br/YAXTc7HkQmGbSjaktEIHriUhbIs9oruJXBL//DSjn5o8b/nf/@gFBROdIO8kNyalqWs1C7THHvTmqDudXqe/)

My first C++ program that actually does something interesting \o/

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000861)

Comment: very nice. I picked Gaia at random from TIO and saw your solution right as I was wrapping up! `4…10*¦8*Σ¦uȯ=` if anyone is interested.

Comment: note that `y` is not a vowel for the next sequence (otherwise `20` would be in it)

Comment: @Giuseppe Cool, nice answer! Sorry for ninja'ing you haha

Comment: If A000086 shows up, I'd be glad if ninjas let me post my Shakespeare-esque masterpiece.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Quick, now's your chance!

Answer (score 3):

## 228. [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 361 bytes, [A000861](http://oeis.org/A000861)

```
HoDoRHoDoR HODOR 000861(HODOR? ) {
  $HODOR: Hodor? = 0;
  $HODOR: HODOR?! = 0;
  hodor............ (Hodor? < HODOR? ) {
    HODOR?! = HODOR?! +1;
    $HODOR: d = HODOR?! % 10;
    $HODOR: h = HODOR?! % 100;
    HOdor!!! ( h==12 || ((h>20 || h<10) && ((d==1) || (d==2) || (d==3) || (d==5) || (d==9)))) {
      Hodor? = Hodor? +1;
    }
  }
  HODOR:: HODOR?! ;
}
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000361)

[Hodor!](https://tio.run/##XVHLCoMwELz7FRNoJUEoSUpLW7VePOQm9Bs85Cb0qn67jZtEYxeyzO7si4kd@uG7LGZohw85mK7tPpBSPu6KU9BAYMyAE0UvmLWnQQ1ZplkqZTFt16JLYuChr8JhKpLOiApVEhNn9wl3hpJH1v6xgTadW8cYA4eta6UxTeDcvrVcka2UFMhzl@odK4h1SG/ouqHbhp7CWTgbuxABxLPnzD9/3y5Nmc0L4XEOajCQXohBBb1HRRFXeTGd58ff8XVCuLk/)

Comment: NOOOO.... I was ninja'd....

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Hodor.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder same rip

Comment: If you read the title of the next sequence out loud, I'd assume you're having a stroke....

Answer (score 3):

## 237. [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 89 bytes, [A000341](https://oeis.org/A000341)

```
‘ḤŒ!s€2Ṣ€Ṣ$€QS€ÆPa/$$ÐfL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/3//1HDjIc7lhydpFj8qGmN0cOdi4AUkFQBUoHBQOJwW0CivorK4QlpPgqUgv///xsDAA)

## Explanation

```
‘ḤŒ!s€2Ṣ€Ṣ$€QS€ÆPa/$$ÐfL  Main Link
‘                         Increment (for 0-indexing)
 Ḥ                        Double
  Œ!                      All permutations of {1 .. 2n} (implicit range)
    s€2                   Slice each permutation into subslices of length 2
          $€              For each subconfiguration
       Ṣ€                 Sort each pair
         Ṣ                Then sort the entire thing
            Q             Then remove duplicates
                   $$Ðf   Filter pairings using the last three links as a condition
                 a/       All (reduce over logical AND because M doesn't have the ALL builtin)
             S€           Sums
               ÆP         Are Prime
                       L  How many pairings are there?
```

There are a bunch of spaces at the end

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000089)

Comment: Does M not have an identity function?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Maybe it does but spaces are better because they don't clutter the end

Comment: I'd say that you add those spaces to avoid [A000087](https://oeis.org/A000087).

Comment: @user202729 A87 is at the edge of feasibility in Shakespeare.

Comment: @user202729 I chose 89 because it looked nicer lol. Sometimes I decide to be nicer and sometimes I decide to make it a bit more challenging. In this case though, honestly 87 isn't really hard and I probably should've chosen it to keep a contiguous block of unoccupied bytecounts on the low end :P

Answer (score 3):

## 242. [FriCAS](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/FriCAS), 111 bytes, [A000230](https://oeis.org/A000230)

```
a: (Integer) -> Integer
a(n) ==
 i:=2
 repeat
  j:=nextPrime(i)
  if j-i = 2*n or n = 0 then
   return i
  i:=j
```

[Try it online here](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/SandBoxA000230)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000111)

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ack, I spent too long testing my [Pip solution](https://tio.run/##PcsxCoAwEETRfk8xhUJiFIyNEPAIhiD2sqVN2F49@7o2tvPnySmqZUsXoQmO22MZsSL27LEg0kO5fG2HKxtCsPl6CGxB0kQ1uVwgnnawwRt1EHNTxzAkqRL@iwlVnV8)!

Comment: @DLosc This seems to be the theme of this challenge...

Answer (score 3):

## 243. [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 112 bytes, [A000111](https://oeis.org/A000111)

```
1<<<<111<n2-0G*
[
 >&s0>l>lr>1>&s>lp
 [
  sp<l+sp<l>>
 ]
 <p<1&s>l<
 [
  sp<l*sp<l*sp<l+>>>
 ]
 <p<p<<,
]
p>u&p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxDoAwDAP3vCITQwtS05XIK49A/UGEIioGXl/ahXo4WT7b25poj4jolbd0BDqJsdQEg92QXmFO3FeurhYHAOJCrK4ytE4dfkTMl6uuVMjxLL63ltMH)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000112)

This uses the recurrence `a(n) = Sum_{i=0..n-2} binomial(n-2,i)*a(i)*a(n-1-i)`.

Using the recurrence for one value needs all the binomials from one row in
Pascal's tringle, and then the next value needs the next row, so we compute
one row from the previous one by addition, avoiding factorials and divisions,
so Ly will stay in the realm of integers and not switch to floats.

Ly uses an infinite strip of stacks, of which we're using seven.
For reference, let's call them, from left to right:
`count`, `vals`, `oldvals`, `oldvalsR`, `bins`, `oldbins`, and `oldbinsT`.
The stack that we are at in the beginning will be used as `oldbins`,
just because this is the rightmost that needs initialisation.
We can move between the stacks with `<` and `>`.

We initialise `oldbins` with `1`, the first row of Pascal's triangle.
Then we initialise `vals` with the first three values, which are all `1`.
Next, we read the input into `count` and subtract `2`, then `0G*` will
turn that into `0` if it was negative.

Now `count` tells us how many more values we need.
Next we'll have a loop with this loop invariant:
`vals` contains some initial values of the series, we are at `count` which
holds one nonnegative number that tells how many more values are needed,
`oldbins` contains the row of Pascal's triangle that was used for the last
value, and the other stacks are empty.

(We didn't really use the first row of the triangle, but we would have needed
it if we had computed `a(2)` from the recurrence. We don't start with only
two values, because there is no 0th row from which we can compute the first
without complicating the algorithm. We could also store the row we need next,
but then we would needlessly compute one row more than needed.)

The looping construct `[...]` loops while the stack is not empty and its top
element isn't zero. The outer loop will be terminated when `count` is zero,
all other loops will be terminated by empty stacks.

To prepare for the work in the loop, we copy the `vals` stack to the backup
cell using `&s`, then add a zero to this stack as initial value for the sum.
Then we store the value of the backup cell to `oldvals` (with `l`) and
also to `oldvalsR`, where we reverse it with `r`. Then we push the first
value `1` of the new row of Pascal's triangle to `bins`, copy `oldbins` to
`oldbinsT` and drop its first element there (with `p`).

We can think of the computation of `bins` as equivalent to this
Haskell computation:

```
[1] ++ zipWith(+) oldbins oldbinsT ++ [1]   where oldbinsT = tail oldbins
```

The inner loop then copies (`s`) the top element from `oldbinsT` to the
backup cell and drops it from the stack (`p`), and puts it on top of the
`oldbins` stack, where it is added to the former top element. This sum
is then moved (again with `sp<l`) to the `bins` stack. The loop body is completed by
going back to the `oldbinsT` stack. (Note that at the first iteration of
the outer loop, this loop will terminate immediately.)

After this loop, the remaining value from `oldbins` is dropped, and the final
`1` value appended to `bins`. Then `bins` is copied to `oldbins`.

The second inner loop is like this Haskell code:

```
sum ( zipWith3 (\a b c->a*b*c) oldvals oldvalsR bins )
```

Note that `bins` has one value less than the two other stacks, so we use this
to control the loop. In it, we move the top value to `oldvalsR` and multiply,
then move the result to `oldvals` and multiply again. This product is moved
to `vals` and added to the accumulated sum on its top.
(Remember that we already pushed a zero here.)

When the loop is done, we drop the remaining values from `oldvalsR` and
`oldvals` and decrement `count` (with `,`).

When the outer loop is done, we needlessly drop the zero from `count` and
output (and drop) the top element from `vals`. Finally, we delete this whole
stack with `&p` and explicitely end the program with `;`. We don't need both,
but if we didn't do either, implicit output would print all values from `vals`.

Comment: Oh yes, I was late for 4 hours this time... Anyway my Enlist code: [Try it online!](https://ptpb.pw/MsrE) (try on Python because Dennis hasn't pull latest version of Enlist, or at least I guess so)

Comment: @user202729 503 Backend fetch failed.

Comment: ↑↑ Explanation: That was O(n! * n) algorithm finding all permutation and count number of alternating permutation.

Comment: @user202729 Ah, I wondered what your approach was. What would your next sequence have been?

Comment: Very small byte-count (of course Enlist is an efficient golfing language). Probably the smallest available, but if I don't like that sequence I may pad with spaces.

Comment: @user202729 All those formulas and generating functions listed on the OEIS page, with sample programs in five different languages, and you decided to brute-force it. Good job.

Comment: @KSmarts Confusingly many formulas, not that easy to find one that is useful. (Otherwise someone would have answered earlier.) If you like brute-forcing, that may be the way to go for the next sequence.

Comment: @KSmarts I just suppose it was code-golf, because Enlist = golfing language. Also Enlist hasn't got complete built-in set, so using formulas may be harder than brute-force it.

Comment: @KSmarts Also: I found that formula too, but because [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40871440#40871440).

Comment: @ChristianSievers Well, the first one `E.g.f.: (1+sin(x))/cos(x) = tan(x) + sec(x)` is pretty easy to understand, imo, but tough to implement in most languages.

Comment: @KSmarts Well, "tough to implement" is not what I would call "useful". And one needs to know what e.g.f. means. BTW, the differential equation for the e.g.f. (it says o.g.f. but that is wrong) leads to a nice solution if you have lazy lists, but I didn't want to do generating functions again, when another nice and efficient way was available.

Comment: Somehow I didn't realize the comment (503 Backend fetch failed) is referring to my TIO link until now. I have no idea why though, and I don't keep the code. (I didn't intend to ping ChristianSievers by this comment)

Comment: Is there an algorithm or formula for he next sequence? Links?

Comment: Oh come on folks, you have done more difficult sequences than the next one!

Comment: @HusnainRaza An algorithm is described [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/posets.pdf). It's basically graph isomorphism for a certain subset of digraphs.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I've done the next one already, but don't want to post it, see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40971284#40971284

Comment: @KSmarts ↑ too. Other interested people had already been pinged in the next chat messages.

Comment: But question dies tomorrow :(

Answer (score 3):

## 245. [Java 7](http://openjdk.java.net/), 1272 bytes, [A001524](https://oeis.org/A001524)

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
	public static List<List<Long>> partitions(long val) {
		List<List<Long>> list = new ArrayList<>();
		if (val == 0) {
			List<Long> sublist;
			list.add(sublist = new ArrayList<>());
		} else {
			for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
				for (List<Long> ext : partitions(val - i)) {
					List<Long> sublist;
					list.add(sublist = new ArrayList<>());
					sublist.add((long) i);
					sublist.addAll(ext);
				}
			}
		} return list;
	}

	public static List<List<Long>> filter(List<List<Long>> partitions) {
		List<List<Long>> list = new ArrayList<>();
		outerloop: for (List<Long> sublist : partitions) {
			for (int i = 0; i < sublist.size() - 1; i++) {
				if (sublist.get(i) <= sublist.get(i + 1)) continue outerloop;
			} list.add(sublist);
		} return list;
	}

	public static long variants(List<Long> stack) {
		int variants = 1;
		for (int i = 0; i < stack.size() - 1; i++) {
			variants *= stack.get(i) - stack.get(i + 1);
		} return variants;
	}

	public static long A001524(long val) {
		long out = 0;
		for (List<Long> stack : filter(partitions(val))) out += variants(stack);
		return out;
	}

	public static void main(String[] args) {
		for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
			System.out.println(i + ": " + A001524(i));
		}
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTBbtswDD3HX0H0JDeIYRfrJakD5N6deix60BIlUKpIhkSn6wZ/u0vJcmsnTYvNB0umHsnHR8p7fuQzUwm93zy3rTxUxiLsyZjVKFV2vUiSqv6l5BrWijsHP7nU8DeZRKNDjrTcS4d33cvo3XIJFbcoURrtmCILHLlKvdvkDKloDyVo8QIra/lrOFuydEFguQVGnlCWkHfukw9XcJ6CQw@c@E3GNxsWjZ9FDCEbEMqJLtbWWGBSI0iCFwta7krPlHbTaczXgQZZxW@E@bA@T3AGMu0dLlH8B5L0REiABwlTSnF@tlKKEaN40iTx1YAVWFsNMXuTfNuxrVQoLPuik//RQFNTTGVMNYdTHXsN5mcZxn3JQ196eObkH8FSErwYdclPSg/ZCWQy9b0cWWAKBTVpbTRKXQt45xa0a@C0O3FcvhMyjreVXKMbFYh8/dzx87X0kDBqyYUivcuFEt/9r8uIi3XOhp@hyBHx3u8y@VWeF7c3P04uavgijQK75PwehKTUvTg34wuRktDed1p@SNPp4UNFZgT4lNTRyA0c6D/DHtBKvXt8Am53cTgCjcBtoFuRD5V6eHUoDhmFzyryR6WDLldzuKKlr1bG/4Fn0LRte/sG)

This isn't too slow though it probably could be improved. This sequence was fairly simple but 1272 bytes because Java.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A001272)

Comment: The only reason I didn't beat you to this is that my Python-based solution *was* too slow. It took more than a minute for A(3)...

Comment: @KSmarts Can I see your solution? How was it that slow D:

Comment: [Lots of recursion](https://tio.run/##ZZBBDoMgEEX3nGKWIDURuzPQxBvUM1hMzejYUE2Pbwe1tqYLks/Mm/8H6qEeaBrn@eYbuEo6oTOqENA2QJeMxaocFhD8OAWKUIonQKUXXBvFkO@eficycbwbIaJ7FfHNG62BIQBZc5yKLefMz@jRqtrDV4Upxy/upaTP3jb/m@cVexccZ8Dr3nYe8qS3FMucF6t7GRPUqL9tCOD4aI7uef1keX4iDSOoUubS5QPYhzn@DdZbdpgfoaVRlvKs1PwG).

Comment: @KSmarts [ಠ_ಠ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dnEU.png) that much recursion is 0/10 but regardless, nice :P

Comment: @KSmarts You might want to try memoization

Answer (score 3):

## 246. [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 240 bytes, [A001272](http://oeis.org/A001272)

```
import math

def p(a): return not (a < 2 or any(a % x == 0 for x in range(2, int(a**0.5) + 1)))

def A(n):
 m=n+1
 i=k=0
 while k<m:
  i= i + 1
  x=0
  for j in range(1,i+1):
   x = x+(-1)**(i-j)*math.factorial(j)
  if p(x): k=k+1
 return i
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000240)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BasMwEETv@oq5BLSyE6xAIZjokE8Rrt2sHUtGKET9elfbFnLbnWHfzgxxiOGZ953XLaaM1ee7Up/jhE176pHG/EwBIWZojyvOiAk@fNflgALn0GGqUgEHJB@@Rn1u65y1N6Y7fRAaWCL6Y950oF5hdaGxCuwW1ym87vwYsVzX6lQNLCd1LGL@wuc33LbcWGFAvqM0@mjJGM3HmYyEP01@yDGxf@iZBChNSm2yuEWe/hfiXcD8BnftRbBbkuw3zUT7Dw)

Comment: My Enlist code was late again. [Partial code](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40981064#40981064)

Comment: Since Coconut can execute nearly any Python code, there are now six Pythons to choose from ... :p

Comment: @JonathanFrech According to their homepage (linked in the header), **all valid Python is valid Coconut**. Have fun!

Comment: @KSmarts The only annoying thing from a golfing perspective is that this is [not entirely true](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/v6AoM69EwTAxL0VJUen/fwA), as -- for example -- the piece of code linked to can be [considered valid Python 2 code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwTAxL0VJUen/fwA).

Answer (score 3):

## 247. [Enlist](https://github.com/alexander-liao/enlist), 87 bytes, [A000240](http://oeis.org/A000240)

```
RṖ†eṢS=1§€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f8/6OHOaY8aFqQ@3Lko2Nbw0PJHTWuCFagI/v//bw4A)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000087)

---

Explanation:

```
 Ṗ           All permutations of
R            the ranges from 1 to n.
  †     §€   For each of them
   eṢ        Calculate the equality of that list with the sorted list (which is the range from 1 to n)
     S       Sum. Now the value is the number of fixed point of that permutation.
      =1     Return 1 if the number of fixed point is 1, and 0 otherwise.
         S   Sum of the values -> number of permutations such that number of fixed point is 1.
```

Comment: What is the next sequence? Definitely not A000011. Code snippet need to be changed.

Comment: According to OP's snippet, it's [A000087](http://oeis.org/A000087). (Not sure how accurate that is, though)

Comment: "your bytecount must be unique." Please change this to match that requirement.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh yes. Sorry. I thought the rule was "if the sequence is already used then the next sequence is the lowest unused one".

Comment: :DD :DDDD Enlist got used for something cool :D +1

Comment: @HyperNeutrino https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another/147244?noredirect=1#comment359085_146719 (it does work, but the link is dead) Definitely not for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

## 248. [Huginn](https://codestation.org/?h-action=menu-project&menu=submenu-project&page=&project=huginn), 904 bytes, [A000087](http://oeis.org/A000087)

```
import Algorithms as alg;

gcd( a_, b_ ) {
 u = integer( a_ );
 v = integer( b_ );
 while ( v > 0 ) {
    t = u;
    u = v;
    v = t % v;
  }
  return( u );
}

eulerPhi( n_ ) {
 n = integer( n_ );
 x = 0;
 for ( i : alg.range( 1, n + 1 ) ) {
  if ( gcd( i, n ) == 1 ) {
   x += 1;
  }
 }
 return ( x );
}

binomial( n_, k_ ) {
 n = integer( n_ );
 k = integer( k_ );
 x = 1;
 for ( i : alg.range( 1, k + 1 ) ) {
  x = x * (n - i + 1) / i;
 }
 return ( x );
}

A000087( n_ ) {
 n = integer( n_ ) + 1;
 z = 0.0 ;
 for ( k : alg.range( 1, n ) ) {
  if ( n % k == 0 ) {
   z += real( eulerPhi( n / k ) * binomial( 3 * k, k ) );
  }
 }
 z += real( ( n + 2 ) * binomial( 3 * n, n ) ) / real( ( 3 * n - 2 ) * ( 3 * n - 1 ) );
 z = z / real( 3 * n );
 if ( n % 2 == 1 ) {
  z += real( 2 * ( n + 1 ) * binomial( 3 * ( n + 1 ) / 2, ( n + 1 ) / 2 ) ) / real( 3 * ( 3 * n - 1 ) * ( 3 * n + 1 ) );
 }
 return( z );
}
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000904)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLfboIwFMbveYpzs6QoU8CLLSMu8Q12vywGtwpNoZgOHHHx2dk5LRaYRoOR87e/fp95kwmluk6Uh0rXsCmySos6L78hxafIEs/LPr8YpNsAdlvw4deDBtYgVM0zrqkAfuLBcZzb2dxPLgoODGuvENpR/NTY2STmlRYd7SvN1/BgwzN@Na8brRj24Kqz5/Gm4PotFwxUj6HGRyp7ZIu5EH/3lcaDBbzQHRY6VRlnEAU4M4cIxy2M2GOTuZ6gkg/rtaka0BbmGPU4@FggHGh7op1QVSnSgg4PQN6hkuOcHEijO6RyQkrdLcyAKXjEZiz5sASR3CbbhPh5frojFW3A4RPJtQjBccgbik3UUuiRJJ2coSfSSXPSYeQR0knsmMGg0gojGZi0P8g6GmfGnvjGmLpwLF2rSaMYtn2Io349Xe3k@m2V8u4W8djtEUVs1l3@KP9JhsoS4mAaTghXV1RDPHeUzj2GCGReV6YCg1Rnx967g0bnGDhPTek9@rAbzl0XhX8)

This uses the formula from the OEIS page, which is a little complicated, but not too hard once you break it down.

Comment: What is a map? Is it a graph? Wikipedia doesn't explain too well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Answer (score 3):

## 251. [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 269 bytes, [A000711](https://oeis.org/A000711)

```c
long p(int k,int n,int*a,int l){long s=1;if(n<1)return!l;a[l]=n;for(int i=1,c,j;i<=k;i++){for(j=0,c=1;j<=l;j++)if(a[j]==i)c++;s*=(i<5)?((c)*(c+1)/2):c;}for(int i=(l==0)?1:a[l-1];i<=n/2;i++)a[l]=i,s+=p(k,n-i,a,l+1);return s;}long a(int n){int a[1000];return p(n,n,a,0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEX3nIKmiuQB09iRuolxcxDKwjIhHXAHBGSFODu1HVWZxdjyn//n2RaLtfvuBrqnI0Na0p6HTqFnJt4drFGftVTYMiolTLflMdGbU6ZytSbVDlM0o5bc8k5hqXuFeQ5rUDotuPXmrtROdf7Vp5iqq7VGsHmu5kwzLD/hypiFjNlcwukMF6u2Vy5zWgu4yovfWMg6bKDTOe6IDMjnXI@s51QgN9z5DPWkTGe1RX4TowjWcJhKCiHq/5mRESfvE6C2/R3JukdzK@elweHj5ysJjl@DxGBNUl8vLuFJQtLzt1EMNU5ebtnh2KRH13zTgXsqhgAqjmzJtv8B)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000269)

## Explanation

```c
// Takes a partition a of the number k and returns how many different
// partitions it represents if the numbers can have many kinds, according
// to the specification of the sequence. For example:
// [1 1 1] =>
//    [1  1  1 ]
//    [1  1  1']
//    [1  1' 1']
//    [1' 1' 1']
//    [1' 1' 1"]
//    [1' 1" 1"]
//    [1" 1" 1"]
// Each different number in the partition can be processed separately,
// and the "score" will be the product of the scores of each number.
long score(int k, int length, int * a){
    long product = 1;

    for(int i = 1;i <= k;i++){ // A partition of k can contain numbers [1,k]
        int count = 0; // Count how many times the number i appears
        for(int j = 0;j <= length;j++){
            if(a[j] == i) c++;
        }

        if(i < 5){
            // i has 3 kinds. If you sort all the cases in ascending
            // "kind numbers", then the first Kind 2 (') can be in
            // (number of Kind >= 1, i. e. the variable c) + 1 positions:
            //    1  1  1
            //    1  1  1'
            //    1  1' 1'
            //    1' 1' 1'
            // Then, the first Kind 3 (") can be in (number of Kind >= 2) + 1
            // positions:
            //    1' 1' 1'
            //    1' 1' 1"
            //    1' 1" 1"
            //    1" 1" 1"
            // If you think about it, you'll get the sum of natural numbers
            // from 1 to (c + 1), for which there is a nice closed form
            // formula (look at sequence of answer number 1, don't forget
            // to rate the language choice ) (one problem Emoji solved
            // is ending a parenthesis with an emoticon).
            product *= ((c + 1) * (c + 2)) / 2;
        }else{
            product *= (c + 1);
        }
    }

    return product;
}

// A recursive function that enumerates all partitions of n, scores each
// and returns the sum of all scores. The partitions are generated at
// (a + level)
// Pseudocode algorithm:
// def partitions(n):
//     yield [n]
//     for i in range(1, n):
//         for p in partitions(n - i):
//             yield [n] + p
// Notice how we don't really need to check the whole range of [1, n)
// k is only relevant for scoring
// the partitions are generated at (a + level)
long partitions(int k, int n, int * a, int level){
    if(n < 1){
        if(l == 0){
            return 1; // l == 0 => this is the top level call, so include
            // the case of []
        }else{
            return 0; // doesn't happen, but I think this is the best
            // way to handle this edge case
        }
    }

    a[l] = n;
    long score_sum = score(k, l + 1, a);

    int start;

    if(l == 0){
        start = 1;
    }else{
        start = a[l - 1];
    }

    for(int i = start;i <= n/2;i++){
        a[l]=i;
        score_sum += partitions(k,n-i,a,l+1);
    }

    return score_sum;
}

long a(int n){
    // the longest partition of k is [1]*k, speaking Python,
    // so let's not bother with dynamic allocation
    int a[1000];
    return partitions(n, n, a, 0);
}
```

Comment: My Jelly code: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41118715#41118715

Comment: Please don't golf your answer, make it readable instead. This isn't even code-golf.

Comment: @user202729 but it's fun! OK, I'll add a readable version

Comment: My Jelly code is even more efficient than yours, and only at number of bytecount ~ 8.2% of yours.

Comment: @user202729 But is it more readable?

Comment: @ChristianSievers Certainly more readable to Jelly users who don't like scrolling the screen. Will add an explanation soon.

Comment: Why do you even have to pass the array `a` around? Why not just make it a global variable? Also `n<1` can be written as `!n` if you know that `n >= 0`.

Comment: @user202729 I could do that, but I didn't. No idea why. Don't ask. I don't like globals. `!n` is equivalent to `n != 0`, which you can see used in my code. However, <s>this part is partly a failsafe, which is why I didn't want to golf it that way</s> I just didn't notice :P **Edit:** ugh, how does one do strikethrough in Markdown?

Comment: No idea. I tried both ---abc--- (works in chat) and <s>abc</s> (works in main post). They doesn't work. __abc__ ___def___ ***ghi*** ← tests

Answer (score 3):

## 252. [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 251 bytes, [A000269](https://oeis.org/A000269)

```
A000081(n) = if( n<3, if(n<1,0,1) , 1/(n-1)*sum(k=1,n-1,sumdiv(k,d,d*A000081(d))*A000081(n-k) ) );

gfA81(n) = sum( i=0, n, A000081(i)*x^i, O(x^(n+1)) );

gfA269(n) = {Bx = gfA81(n); Bx^3 * (3-2*Bx) / (1-Bx)^3}

A000269(n) = polcoeff(gfA269(n+3), n+3)
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000251)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9RCoMwDIbfPUUek5qitTAm6oNeYDcQxpyjuFXZ2CiMnd21SE0g/An5v5Dl/DTytqxrm/s4KrQEDZgRwdaag7C14pwVAYPK0EpF4vV@4NQo9g17PZgPTjzwICJkINq1lROBzypJbmMbLwQEmCZnsAxx1ZBwvWE4oevRpop2W3EoN9@3c75GUAWd6zUIQC0L0TmCDFBJL3r9S5LA3Z3LfL/M13HEiEs1@eu@bs@HWUl/)

This uses the generating function formula, by directly computing values of the sequence A000081.

Comment: Does anyone have access to that paper? I don't see how we're supposed that in less than O(silly(n))...

Comment: @NieDzejkob I have it now. I can implement the sequence in Haskell with the usual stuff for handling generating functions plus three one-line definitions.

Comment: @NieDzejkob It doesn't have to be efficient.

Comment: @KSmarts if it's fast enough for small n that you can convince yourself that it works...

Comment: Rip challenge :(

Comment: @HusnainRaza 7 hours left, not all hope is lost.

Answer (score 3):

## 258. [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 329 bytes, [A000144](https://oeis.org/A000144)

```forth
: ODDQ 2 MOD ;
: EVENQ 1+ ODDQ ;
: DIVOK /MOD SWAP IF DROP 0 ELSE ODDQ THEN ;
: A2131 DUP 1+ 0 SWAP 1 ?DO OVER I DIVOK IF I + THEN LOOP NIP ;
: A186690 DUP A2131 SWAP EVENQ IF 0 SWAP - THEN ;
: ADVANCE DUP 1+ 0 SWAP 1 ?DO I 1+ PICK I A186690 * + LOOP 20 * OVER / SWAP 1+ ;
: A144 1 SWAP 1 SWAP 0 ?DO ADVANCE LOOP 1 ?DO NIP LOOP ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BDgExFEX3vuKuTdAOEcxCJlrRYNoZ1B8MO4n4/2rfK7Gweu3LO@fe/vF83Ue3Po0QVrBKtShxtArVYAXtddNCFrxPG2W83WOSDk7X2sFsoTrrIKAPJ813551u6Lgu5VRCXVxSCAYk1srCet3BZFt0GBSMHWyUNcYxLxfz@VKQgV2k4FaRysrRT6LydbPRfzNN2jiziYFf8zDmUmSZ3tRqkpkiV5jNID8aGoJsnySiOSDVpm8VpBCC2XF4Aw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000329)

This time I managed to remove the surplus elements from the stack with `1 ?DO NIP LOOP`.

Comment: Learn a new language just to use it twice...

Comment: @user202729 no, I learned it for a much larger project. It involves bootstrapping Linux from less than 1K binaries, and Forth is a good language thanks for its small interpreter.

Comment: I'm worried about the accuracy of the solution of the next sequence... [This Jelly solution](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcFvIoYWHlxUZ/P9vBAA "Jelly – Try It Online") only survive up to `n=13`.

Comment: and is non-esoteric. BF interpreter is also small.

Comment: But why don't you just use assembly?

Comment: @user202729 I am using assembly too, but to use it in place of forth, I would need to fit an assembler in 1K.

Comment: If the conjecture under the sequence's OEIS page is correct, this python code works: https://tio.run/##NZDBboMwDIbP9ClyhBA024mdBK1PUvUwaXRDmlLKusOenjmCKfIh8uff/@/l9/l5L7Rt79PNvLWlG0/NfDPlFWE06/T8WYu5gKuPXHIEDplczsHFlJKLUL@SOQo4LU8i10u5nprp63sazalpHueBbDsQk4doS48QEGLstLWcW4YgGGyxlgbvhXJiZRgxIUNn1dGAXd8iJUgedy76rMtFOdFhFt45Ui4G4Zx2jDJ6Dt6qgipDPuS8YkMADmmX6wUjA2LlOEj2dIChgj5yEtrBAOrOa4YhpSDBHxx3fQ2IKebqsGcB@e9JjXmccXl5bLf7amYzF7O@lY@p1VWjWda5PM3s9Pxzt/0B

Comment: @Husnain Raza This answer got deleted because of floating point inaccuracies, this is no longer the next sequence.

Comment: @HusnainRaza Which sequence are you referring to?

Comment: Apparently my comment above is correct. You do need big floating point for that. The answer to the next sequence (A000329) is deleted because of that reason. [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69065/discussion-between-mr-xcoder-and-peter-taylor)

Answer (score 3):

## 267. [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 338 bytes, [A002572](https://oeis.org/A002572)

```erlang
h(N,A,_) when A > N -> 0;
h(N,A,_) when A == N -> 1;
h(N,A,B) -> case erlang:get({N,A,B}) of
	F when is_integer(F) -> F;
	'undefined' -> 
		F = lists:sum(lists:map(
			fun(I) -> h(N-I, (A-I)*2, B+1) end,
		lists:seq(0, A-1))),
		erlang:put({N,A,B}, F),
		F
	end.

main([])-> {ok, [N]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
io:fwrite("~p", [h(N+1,1,0)]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BjoIwEIbP9CkmXOysxdA9YjDBAwkXXoAQQ2TAZqUghXgw@upYwN3L3jr/N1/np/5a6Nojc@5VN0wTu/BUROKEcL@QhggOkIJ3AH//j4ThiuQvOuI8ngtDQMu3QU0DfyzoidBWzIlXWZmT0gPV1PN4keI9czajLqlSmsrNHDHHbodwVWYwgRkbvr6aouMWOdWoebK49riXCOCRl@DXt4DjViKQLoVd@9h0476AyJOIOMefet34V09AvJCYOVbdMdYUSvMsR3vg0f4IyNL8aeuoNqh6KkruugLcV@laa87uvRqIu6/OxplttJVCCh9z3E2T9P03)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000338)

I first wrote this in Python, and then I <s>had</s> decided to find a language with bignums, because this sequence grows pretty quickly. I hope this will explain it pretty well:

```python
cache = {}
# Calculate the number of partitions of a/(2^b) into n powers of (1/2), with
# the exponent of at least b. You need at least a powers of (1/2) for the
# trivial solution of a*(1/2)^b, and you cannot write any of the fractions
# in that solution as a sum of smaller fractions if a = n.
def B(n, a, b):
    if a > n:
        return 0

    if a == n:
        return 1
    
    if (n, a, b) not in cache:
# We need more fractions - use 1/(2^b) from 0 to (a-1) times, and fill
# the rest with the recursive call of this function

        s = 0
        for i in range(a):
            s += B(n - i, # we used i fractions
                   (a - i) * 2, # use a higher power of (1/2)
                   b + 1)
        cache[(n, a, b)] = s

    return cache[(n, a, b)]

def A(n):
    return B(n, 1, 0)

for n in range(1, 2000):
    print(n, A(n))
```

Memoization in Erlang from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3315713/5863987)

Comment: +1 from me. I really don't understand your ability to port stuff that easily to new languages.

Answer (score 3):

## 268. [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 99 bytes, [A000338](https://oeis.org/A000338)

```
9 2/Q2+X*15 2/Q2+*-BQ1>*Q0q5*Q1q18*++
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=9+2%2FQ2%2BX%2a15+2%2FQ2%2B%2a-BQ1%3E%2aQ0q5%2aQ1q18%2a%2B%2B++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++&input=3&warnings=0&hex=0)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000099) <sup><sub>(quite tendious, yet doable I think)</sub></sup>

Comment: The next sequence is definitely doable. It looks more tedious than hard to me.

Answer (score 3):

## 269. [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 118 bytes, [A000099](https://oeis.org/A000099)

```
n:0
m:0
++a
W a {
  ++n
  Y -n\,n
  AA:{$+a*a<=n} MS yCPy
  VV:PI*n
  PP:AA-VV
  I ABPP>m {
    m:ABPP
    --a
  }
}
n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/z8qAKxeItbUTucIVEhWquRQUtLXzgGSkgm5ejA6I5ehoVa2inaiVaGObV6vgG6xQ6RxQCRQPC7MK8NQCqQgIsHJ01A0LAzI9FRydAgLscsEmKSjkWoG4YKaubiKQruWq5cr7//@/MQA) (times out for indices greater than 7)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000118)

#### Commented

Implements the definition of the sequence:

```
n:0            Index of helper sequences
m:0            Max value of |P(n)| so far
++a            Index of main sequence (++ because the definition is 1-indexed)
W a {          Count down until a hits 0:
  ++n           Increment index of helper sequence
  Y -n\,n       Yank inclusive range [-n, n]
  AA:           Sequence A(n) is:
    {$+a*a<=n}   Function: Square items of list, sum, and check <= n
    MS           Map-sum
    yCPy         Cartesian product of y with itself
  VV:PI*n       Sequence V(n) is pi times n
  PP:AA-VV      Sequence P(n) is A(n)-V(n)
  I ABPP>m {    If abs(P(n)) > current max value:
    m:ABPP       Max is abs(P(n))
    --a          Decrement index of main sequence
  }
}
n              Output index of helper sequence at the a'th maximum
```

Comment: Did you check that the Pi constant has enough accuracy to compute 1000 terms?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I *believe* it will. It's got about 16 significant digits, and if the series is ~= 0.0139 * n^4 (which is a pretty good fit for the first 200 terms), it should only require 11 significant digits to compute n = 1000. But I would have to compute that many terms to find out, and that would take days. Maybe I could write a C program to check...

Answer (score 3):

## 272. [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 129 bytes, [A010008](http://oeis.org/A010008)

```
	INPUT('READLINE', 5)
	IN = READLINE
	OUTPUT('PRINT', 6)
	EQ(IN,0)			:S(OK)	
	OUTPUT = 18 * IN * IN + 2	:(END)
OK
	OUTPUT = 1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9PTLyA0REM9yNXRxcfTz1VdR8FUkwsoqmCrABPj4vQPDQGrCgjy9AsBKjEDKnEN1PD00zHQ5OTktArW8PfW5ISpA2o1tFDQUgAaAia0FYw4rTRc/Vw0ufy9kRVxAcX@/zcAAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000129)

I think I could probably write another answer in SNOBOL; it took me a good ten minutes to figure out how to do I/O because I'm dumb, and I'm lucky the sequence was so stupidly easy.

Explanation:

SNOBOL is pretty old, so it has some weird quirks for someone who's been using more "modern" languages. First of all, you have to indent lines, because un-indented lines are labels. Control flow is purely through GOTOs, labels, and SUCCESS/FAILURE of a line. And I'm still not sure about how to write a comment.

`INPUT('READLINE', 5)` sets a variable `READLINE` that takes input from file 5, which is by default the keyboard/console input.

`IN = READLINE` reads a single line from the file as a string.

`OUTPUT('PRINT', 6)` sets a variable `PRINT` that prints to file 6, which is by default the console.

`EQ(IN,0)` tests for equality between the input and 0. The GOTO`:S(OK)` is the instruction "on `S`uccess, goto `OK`", so it jumps to OK, setting OUTPUT to 1, printing, and then hitting END.

Otherwise, it sets the output to `18*n^2+2` and jumps to the END, terminating the program.

Comment: I've heard that that kind of control flow is considered harmful.

Answer (score 3):

## 274. [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 1021 bytes, [A000123](https://oeis.org/A000123)

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE INPUT
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE OUTPUT
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS INPUT
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS OUTPUT
DO IT NOW A000123 INPUT
TALK TO THE HAND OUTPUT
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED

LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY A000123
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE INDEX
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE NUMBER1
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE NUMBER2
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE INDEX
GET TO THE CHOPPER NUMBER1
HERE IS MY INVITATION INDEX
GET DOWN 1
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER NUMBER2
HERE IS MY INVITATION INDEX
HE HAD TO SPLIT 2
ENOUGH TALK
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS NUMBER1
DO IT NOW A000123 NUMBER1
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS NUMBER2
DO IT NOW A000123 NUMBER2
GET TO THE CHOPPER NUMBER1
HERE IS MY INVITATION NUMBER1
GET UP NUMBER2
ENOUGH TALK
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
I'LL BE BACK NUMBER1
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVI9r9swDNz9K7hl6ZC46F5aZmwhkuiKVFyPRd/40AL9/0BKO3Fe0HwAHUUe7448/fjz6/f728/TyetGQHoe1UeqeprA9dmLRhTQTAQ@DUWriQsIKRSBMsBXD8FT@wjORZ/jO6tYJwOKwRkiZrkItAxeIfFYeRgx6dxGOcxwQGhKcj3wHr4VEvWcBDC18AHt8UigPUWry0iZrBkjtR6VwvRY@GL1qgy43W539eeLI8VwmLHGavSmdrPaItcQJVDK0SdTaasq2CHmkvETHCnbcTDTvoQwrdy2XSIzt5hxgY1czo@GWc9bLc/IytlNLswJtPS96vx5QyEYiAero8@PEkglNpR3/0aQGIbMTaDIz6fqV1MNOSwm7zcROvapmzcVnMDMoFx9kq5Xcz0PA@Wro95yAS8QJ8MeveKc5M1Yy2OCXUWJS9fDfP/nbPVLtiWydvE3BEu3viO9@w2ryfvvsHZejNVPx@r/P8itnmWw8txucP2Dlk8mGcgp7DlD4M67ym9CsN8JDbrDhxaKIgSEo8WOn6zZTKfTl78)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A001021)

Uses the recurrence relation `a(n) = a(n-1) + a(floor(n/2))`

Answer (score 3):

## 278. Java 6, 5692 bytes, [A000104](http://oeis.org/A000104)

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

final class Main {
	static final Set<Pair> offsets;

	static {
		offsets = new HashSet<Pair>();
		offsets.add(new Pair(0, +1));
		offsets.add(new Pair(0, -1));
		offsets.add(new Pair(+1, 0));
		offsets.add(new Pair(-1, 0));
	}

	static final class Pair {
		final int x, y;

		Pair(int x, int y) {
			this.x = x;
			this.y = y;
		}

		public String toString() {
			return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
		}

		public boolean equals(Object other) {
			if (other == null) {
				return false;
			} else if (other instanceof Pair) {
				Pair pair = (Pair) other;
				return this.x == pair.x && this.y == pair.y;
			} else {
				return false;
			}
		}

		public int hashCode() {
			return this.x ^ this.y; // Expect many collisions with this hashcode; it's mostly just to make sure the hashset actually checks for equality) //
		}

		public Pair add(Pair pair) {
			return new Pair(this.x + pair.x, this.y + pair.y);
		}
	}

	private Main() {}

	public static Set<Pair> rotate(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Set<Pair> result = new HashSet<Pair>();
		for (Pair pair : polyomino)
			result.add(new Pair(-pair.y, pair.x));
		return result;
	}

	public static Set<Pair> conjugate(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Set<Pair> result = new HashSet<Pair>();
		for (Pair pair : polyomino)
			result.add(new Pair(pair.x, -pair.y));
		return result;
	}

	public static List<Set<Pair>> variants(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		List<Set<Pair>> results = new ArrayList<Set<Pair>>();
		for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
			polyomino = rotate(polyomino);
			results.add(polyomino);
			results.add(conjugate(polyomino));
		}
		return results;
	}

	public static Set<Integer> x(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<Integer>();
		for (Pair pair : polyomino)
			results.add(pair.x);
		return results;
	}

	public static Set<Integer> y(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<Integer>();
		for (Pair pair : polyomino)
			results.add(pair.y);
		return results;
	}

	public static int max(Set<Integer> set) {
		if (set.size() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("max arg is an empty sequence");
		Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
		int max = iterator.next();
		while (iterator.hasNext()) {
			int value = iterator.next();
			max = max > value ? max : value;
		}
		return max;
	}

	public static int min(Set<Integer> set) {
		if (set.size() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("min arg is an empty sequence");
		Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
		int min = iterator.next();
		while (iterator.hasNext()) {
			int value = iterator.next();
			min = min < value ? min : value;
		}
		return min;
	}

	public static Pair corner(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		return new Pair(min(x(polyomino)), min(y(polyomino)));
	}

	public static Set<Pair> normalize(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Pair cn = corner(polyomino);
		Set<Pair> results = new HashSet<Pair>();
		for (Pair pair : polyomino)
			results.add(new Pair(pair.x - cn.x, pair.y - cn.y));
		return results;
	}

	public static boolean translations(Set<Pair> p1, Set<Pair> p2) {
		return normalize(p1).equals(normalize(p2));
	}

	public static boolean isomorphic(Set<Pair> p1, Set<Pair> p2) {
		for (Set<Pair> p : variants(p1))
			if (translations(p, p2))
				return true;
		return false;
	}

	public static boolean filled(Set<Pair> polyomino) {
		Set<Integer> x = x(polyomino);
		Set<Integer> y = y(polyomino);
		for (int i = min(x) + 1; i < max(x); i++) {
			for (int j = min(y) + 1; j < max(y); j++) {
				if (!polyomino.contains(new Pair(i, j))
				&&   polyomino.contains(new Pair(i, j + 1))
				&&   polyomino.contains(new Pair(i, j - 1))
				&&   polyomino.contains(new Pair(i + 1, j))
				&&   polyomino.contains(new Pair(i - 1, j)))
					return false;
			}
		}
		return true;
	}

	public static List<Set<Pair>> polyominoes(int cells) {
		List<Set<Pair>> results = new ArrayList<Set<Pair>>();
		if (cells == 0) {
			results.add(new HashSet<Pair>());
			return results;
		} else if (cells == 1) {
			Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<Pair>();
			set.add(new Pair(0, 0));
			results.add(set);
			return results;
		} else if (cells == 2) {
			Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<Pair>();
			set.add(new Pair(0, 0));
			set.add(new Pair(0, 1));
			results.add(set);
			return results;
		} else {
			for (Set<Pair> polyomino : polyominoes(cells - 1)) {
				for (Pair cell : polyomino) {
					for (Pair offset : offsets) {
						Set<Pair> variant = new HashSet<Pair>(polyomino);
						variant.add(cell.add(offset));
						if (variant.size() == cells) {
							results.add(variant);
						}
					}
				}
			}
		}
		List<Set<Pair>> output = new ArrayList<Set<Pair>>();
		outer: for (Set<Pair> r : results) {
			for (Set<Pair> p : output) {
				if (isomorphic(r, p)) {
					continue outer;
				}
			}
			if (filled(r)) output.add(r);
		}
		return output;
	}

	public static void main(String[] args) {
		boolean visualizer = true; // Change to `false` to not show visualizations
		int cells;
		List<Set<Pair>> polyominoes = polyominoes(cells = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
		System.out.println(polyominoes.size());
		if (cells != 0 && visualizer) {
			System.out.println();
			for (Set<Pair> polyomino : polyominoes) {
				Set<Integer> x = x(polyomino);
				Set<Integer> y = y(polyomino);
				int minx = min(x), maxx = max(x);
				int miny = min(y), maxy = max(y);
				for (int i = minx; i <= maxx; i++) {
					for (int j = miny; j <= maxy; j++) {
						System.out.print(polyomino.contains(new Pair(i, j)) ? '#' : '.');
					} System.out.println();
				} System.out.println();
			}
		}
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVhbT9tIFH4Ov@KUlYotQoBqpZUIsKqqSovUvUh9XO2qg5kkE5wZd2YMdqv8dvbM1Y6xE2hZlQfimfPNuc252UtyR45EQfny5vbhga0KITUscXNSapZPPjClp3uPtt9KSeoB2kfat/sbUYt@ypWmkmgh@1hlhHOKlL0Z4ySHLCdKwe@Ecfi6N1KaaJaBIyHv878Ik5cgZjNFtcJDAYHYkd@FC@D0Hrw27kSSThvAhNzcJAZiSMnJGA5P0630o230w9MxnGyhH0X6eq9jkLPVoKz@bpNxDdUYamPcyHLwO@anTi1ypBdMTSq0tJrGZY3L2iyNnFFRXuco6KOWjM9BC/eQ@POS6lJy2E/24RA8s0PYH0Nc12ad7nf5XQuRU8KBfi5JrpI/r5c00yD0gkrPms0gsWu4wIso89zvB5kzPEet1mug@AjNAcbRPTyjYmadEg5aBxXm3wUkjmDx0zbb4JELi8Sn16@DIWGvbksd0qljr3H6AiPpnbihHed5if96MVM4Pob3VWH8sSK8hkzkOVNMcAX3TC8szPLKkNcUmD5QsBJK5zUsS6XxjvDcLQVVSopgarEYT0Ayjc5GWLag2a2CmZDO/0xjPBwfd1S27jIhGP22qXeMzHjvzmPj5uKdu1J3@ZZ5Idkd0dQmpvGD3XPyfEg32SkF7tCk2ShEXosV48Ip0kJSVeZ6OGGNpY0ZcNbi5Awyxzvp5nQfe6NcYnrLHd5n4pD2meDLcv7jDAiX4Q15qgGmUp9H6ZdwRyQjXKthK7onHPNQPmP5b0FaNtmahNCTKf6cw8/4c3jo4yzKQbqPhUb0tLHbFcotpOYqGlAIyk2XqMFLveKazilaX22/z4jbdEO400B@xrV681wYTr9B4/oHalw/VWMTCCvinBs1wqrl9DS1HRcTxb6Y8omV@CTFMiPFvdX1Ks/pnORv5bxcUa7fVxktNFbMZB9ZApFzwJJpus2q0DVy/VxSbA/7VrcwUzRSmd9BRxiZYekc4PVEWtifcFppR7xfsJxiUAcKVt4/LDH0NDx8R/KS9h8fOcbm/6XH/WpXZ27VCVmkDLsSy@tLuxJHqZd3JTL9f1xpGZv/540rcTXgSsZ7XWkjPRMSJ8vhJOr2Q@P7ql1qxvY66vZWuqN7cCFX2Ji/bOkeTjdjpVdwswJ2m4v6zu6i@toLHKEGpsu4ZHfLvl7Tn/RhCtSScJUTE2cbjQZH3tbqzaa7o4eK03Ti58jW5psBHweZTImVkMWCZTslWv@0tm0Q@baIwtMwrm6YUYzN@XRjtpQu8DrT4rCOM4bZePPE8m3H@J4gaPqAGew7gNiEmcuWpEpxbjvFsRLzxtRjbDnAYkuO8KWH1x6@9HCs97CMcOuVV1HiBBuxxsFPNWHExrD0TsJBG2AX1kh7Fv7oGXjD/Dn6GOYW7w4MvQV073/30BWlUmW9ndE8V983bZmbsGx8xf/al9md2hAmqU4et1@4IstTz7KJVfPKMVhyRqYddN@PT9LHs5vpW89Q480LqtFHO/0mFZvc6Unldr3F@3am2LD1SdSUZ0PbKM8e0YK4bwcI8h8RIqTlEl@8et3SGaPxz6PdJI0K2AfHPY0gcwkB2EwWrbj1CdJ4zaMjh/Ve62fdzp5uyItSF6XeGfEIo/IMOm437c2rkfbfi/GdldAuYq1uIbGwx7sZmbLAOI4XVtx0U3t71BdxiWccX2u@7L6AOFpvebgT7Aarqxnp7NeXv/8xg5jXP/SKO6ZK2/rMsGUrjfmQ8G5B@JyabwKfbFn6ZB650KAWOPCFM65l@ZHMXtq0x@@tKEURj2PWXYj/EJd8rJWmqwnjqR3LsAv5guIJaO@kQGt0zpMWLx89nZr1CmuW@RLTGBny/DEzF1FPy7ZwjTsb6RNaaRxoq9hKx6Yn@pE@qTZRdeygFlV7VO1R3cZc2ZZsMVW7Iz/uybXtxhZZbzTjx95KdrdmHJsPfjpArx1MDkKurmHQ7dto6/AZaP3w8Mt/)

The TIO link links to the Java 8 interpreter but this answer works on Java 6 (tested locally thanks to user202729).

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A005692) - this one has enough terms to be hardcoded but please don't.

[Originally programmed in Python](https://tio.run/##bVTBjpswED3DV8zRTthoyXYvUXPtF/S2QpFLzK5TYyMDFWnKt6czNgFCkkNkPO@9mXkeuzo3X9a8Xa9HWcAf4ZQwTc0qq8@2VMbyXRw5Wbe6qWEPH1kcFdaBAmXACfMp2TdC3CAbUVXSHFktG1aKirH0BKsVKL45HMpWHw4JTMqcT9Jr1L6RcltWWnab3JpT@ykaiSTOgfJWPm/gZMRuWjduxDG1YKwrhVZ/5X0PucPy8YN9dBsnhfZyHcmNsAzryc0Ie4IAVcBA3@8hd1kCv@UZGVqUv44Cuh2GVSk@@VjbpYMXQNVHsT7U26CNtRaNsgZtT7HXbfDc02fdpJySzja2PCio2pbWVV8qf@QLc2b3GTxgMnM68ZQPeoXSWh6XIyC0HwBlGhYs4M8sjCNqf4b0bjxH0qabBolc92l4AqXohrWfrsXIEdKnGZBh7ZFRjqkdrBG@gvREO3hmOdrW3J@kMEe45Gv0K3@hv3V68stTD9/3E85r3sz8gQXJ0dqfrpXBsBEta5ZLjVUjjdLSmg7tdQcDyQ85z@7D6RS@vPaL4HYeTCBdxt8W8QS2fQLDkqXYF@@zZ3d4NtXmsQWc2nT0nnbuUN4WitiiwI4oxjAdeUhuoo3hNKJhvGBmKfxD40lwPbB7j8SetDRsIPhZ94UEneUDc4PFkW2bqm1mfbnZG0FkNU604/7YaRboXszujaMnZroUQTO0ENa3vG662SEQx5WjSafa5ybSnjIIYJx@1@v7fw)

Comment: Not enough. You need to support all `n` not "larger than 1000" - it means that all n such that `0 ≤ n ≤ 1000` need to be supported, that's 1001 terms. You are off by 1.

Comment: @user202729 lol oh. well, it's close :P In that case then, hardcoding it would require getting `1001` in which case one might as well solve it the correct way :p

Comment: rules for the next sequence can be found [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book29/files/unsolved.pdf) on page 13 since the OEIS page links to a JSTOR page and I didn't feel like registering there.

Comment: HyperNeutrino: Do you want to turn off the visualizer?

Comment: @user202729 No, I intentionally left it on. I don't think it makes the output invalid since it obviously gives the correct answer, but if you want, I can turn it off; I can easily keep the bytecount the same.

Answer (score 3):

## 295. [Unefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 133 bytes, [A000218](https://oeis.org/A000133)

```
#z3&#rz#;::/3*j$.@1-\:a%:*\a/:a%:*\a/:*++\#;r
print(*map(lambda x:'pHra ywe!NY'[int(x, 16)], '%x'%(3*7*8*1821847*279590039)), sep='')
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000133)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PclBC4IwGIDhu79isWzuU9O5ym0SdOzUPbLDohVFylhJ6p9f1KHT@8DbtebStVeTSpHa4Ufv8chn2I24UirjcJ/ONyytlQ4V1Dr7F@K4xpULrLu1rwgabaOHbk5njXpF7NZpNLzNZLcnh@/vE8RW9JggEvYkjDiUIICJgolFCUUplzLPuaQ0QU9j14RQ72XwAQ)

```
#z3&#rz#;::/3*j$.@1-\:a%:*\a/:a%:*\a/:*++\#;r
#z                                            Kind of serves no purpose...
  3                                           Starting number of the sequence
   &                                          Input the number of iterations
    #rz#;                                 #;r Set up a way to jump to the
                                              beginning
         ::/                                  Make a copy of the loop counter and
                                              divide it by itself. Since 0/0 is
                                              defined as 0 in Funge, this leaves
                                              1 on the stack when the loop
                                              counter is not zero, but 0 when it
                                              is
            3*                                Multiply the result by 3 to skip
                                              $.@
              $.@                             When the loop ends, print the
                                              result
                 1-                           Decrement the loop counter
                   \:a%:*\a/:a%:*\a/:*++\     Calculate the next element of the
                                              sequence.
```

Comment: +1 for a Python polyglot! (For anyone reading this, try running it in Python 3)

Comment: Befure running it, try to look and guess what it does. Should be easy to guess even if you don't know Python.

Answer (score 3):

## 300. [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 2407 bytes, [A000137](https://oeis.org/A000137)

```cs
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public class A000137 {

 // Expands the polynomial (1 / x^k)
 public static BigInteger[] ExpandReciprocalPowerK(int k, int max) {
  BigInteger[] result = new BigInteger[max + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
   if (i % k == 0)
    result[i] = new BigInteger(1);
   else
    result[i] = new BigInteger(0);
  }
  return result;
 }

 // Calculates p1(x) * p2(x)
 public static BigInteger[] PolynomialMultiply(BigInteger[] x, BigInteger[] y, int max) {
  BigInteger[] result = new BigInteger[max + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j <= max - i; j++) {
    if (result[i + j] == null)
     result[i + j] = new BigInteger(0);
    result[i + j] += x[i] * y[j];
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 // Calculates (p(x))^n
 public static BigInteger[] PolynomialPower(BigInteger[] x, BigInteger n, int max) {
  BigInteger[] result = x;
  if (BigInteger.Compare(n, new BigInteger(0)) == 0) {
   result = new BigInteger[max + 1];
   result[0] = new BigInteger(1);
   for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    result[i] = new BigInteger(0);
  }
  if (BigInteger.Compare(n, new BigInteger(2)) < 0)
   return result;

  BigInteger counter = new BigInteger(1);
  while (BigInteger.Compare(counter, n >> 2) <= 0)
   counter <<= 1;
  
  while (BigInteger.Compare(counter, new BigInteger(0)) > 0) {
   result = PolynomialMultiply(result, result, max);
   if (BigInteger.Compare(n & counter, new BigInteger(0)) != 0)
    result = PolynomialMultiply(result, x, max);
   counter >>= 1;
  }
  return result;
 }
 
 public static void Main(string[] args) {
  try {
   // Get Input
   int n = int.Parse(args[0]);
   BigInteger[] x1 = ExpandReciprocalPowerK(1, n);
   for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    BigInteger coeff = x1[i];
    x1 = PolynomialMultiply(x1, PolynomialPower(ExpandReciprocalPowerK(i, n), coeff, n), n);
   }

   BigInteger[] x2 = new BigInteger[n + 1], x3 = new BigInteger[n + 1], x4 = new BigInteger[n + 1];
   x3[0] = x2[0] = new BigInteger(1) - x1[0]; 
   x4[0] = new BigInteger(1);
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    x4[i] = x3[i] = x2[i] = x1[i];
   for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    x3 = PolynomialMultiply(x3, x2, n);
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
     x4[j] += x3[j];
   }
   BigInteger[] x5 = PolynomialMultiply(x1, x4, n);

   Console.WriteLine(x5[n]); // A000137 is not zero-offset
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
 }

}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVZdb9MwFH3Pr7g8gNK165J0Ew/9kGBCCMHQBA88VJ0UMrdz59qR7bAUtN9ermOnNGlSwgtPTuLj@3HuPddJ1HkiJNntMkX5Cr5ulSabsXf4NvycbYikiRp7Xpp9ZzSBhMVKwZsgCMLRa/jleXBxAe/yNOb3CvQDgVSwLRcbGjPwQ7iA/O6x54E7rXSscXlLVx@4Jisi5wt3@AtJaCpFErNb8UTkR59yDY8DMMsmznvoCqrnJFEZ0zAFTp4OdxANfQgXYzywFBIKSxRxwRiXydSYw6d@39oEukQIvIRHmCKmZz4523O6ODLvhz1jGAhT5G/QoIA@ewakM8kdFj8@W96uY5ZkLNZEQRr6mOQZpBGuJ/m63RN8g8ZoyrZ@ZT8fVPHb/0HiHrO2mLXDwDlQfNvjCrZLytDDemFY5xljlnio7TVTWof1p5CbCpzBdr4uYi5Y78a8nyLjvTvekfSiPU8wDrwT37mJ0pDxZ3t4LTZpLImPFo7S7tnutCx2qVpJUdDew5XChvXCdu/uzmlEmMbEaaxWmApRkIgMn2Rb5E8PlJFGn@4geobZDKKeycj6K01OJiZX/NLRznEhZsd1aNCk3RtAuZp@GJfzpokteAWnvL6oDafTXvMDh2Xms5nLvFkXUBfAD0Hv4Sam3Fda4qWA7RvLlbK5a7m1HKCY3hMNH3ia6SI97CeOweE6vI2lIr45hG1og6kKJ0Rgy/wPkYWGNo1cm/LD6VNtHbJcGoGF2LV2WBRuGsjK0Udd2G23kYlmYI3bRxecmSf1rKJjZfJCl1iX0Ym9y7a9wlM@slrOoxZN46zFpIPFGAr45T9Lnx8IH48Xokev1Hm1657WDmUpsm0ifoTZRnsOm28Pbu8Ney1gOG7Ojw4nfI34q/Y655fWnTl0LbgSjAy/SarJJ8qJn1/NOTaoaeby14Yq4ELDTyLFuVguFdFOOUmskwfARklIqqngQFy6x2ZJOSKxS553u10U/AY)

[Next sequence: A002407, Cuban primes](https://oeis.org/A002407)

Second .NET Core C# answer in the first 300 (Since TIO shows both .NET Core and Visual C# Compiler so I assume the two to be different).

Implementation of the algorithm(Mathematica) in the A000137 page in C#, courtesy to [Jean-François Alcover (2016)](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Alcover).

I tried to find the pattern, but failed to arrive an algorithm that solves it. Used Maclaurin series to calculate the expansion of 1/(1-p(x)) where p is a polynomial of x.

Added some lines so that it points to a nice one

Answer (score 3):

## 306. [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 2113 bytes, [A000145](http://oeis.org/A000145)

```python
def intsqrt(n):
 if n == 0: return 0
 counter, temp = 1, 1
 while counter < n:
  counter <<= 2
  temp <<= 1
 oldtemp1, oldtemp2 = 0, 0
 while oldtemp2 != temp and temp > 0:
  oldtemp2, oldtemp1, temp = oldtemp1, temp, (temp + n // temp) >> 1
 return oldtemp1

def factorial(n):
 if n == 0:
  return 1
 else:
  return n * factorial(n - 1)

def GenerateSquareSequence(n):
 s = 0
 for a in range(intsqrt(n), -1, -1):
  for b in range(min(a, intsqrt(n - a*a)), -1, -1):
   for c in range(min(a, b, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b)), -1, -1):
    for d in range(min(a, b, c, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c)), -1, -1):
     for e in range(min(a, b, c, d, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d)), -1, -1):
      for f in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e)), -1, -1):
       for g in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f)), -1, -1):
        for h in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f - g*g)), -1, -1):
         for i in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f - g*g - h*h)), -1, -1):
          for j in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f - g*g - h*h - i*i)), -1, -1):
           for k in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f - g*g - h*h - i*i - j*j)), -1, -1):
            for l in range(min(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, intsqrt(n - a*a - b*b - c*c - d*d - e*e - f*f - g*g - h*h - i*i - j*j - k*k)), -1, -1):
             if a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d + e*e + f*f + g*g + h*h + i*i + j*j + k*k + l*l == n:
              t = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l)
              u = []
              for m in range(0, 4096):
               v = [t[o] * (-1)**(m >> o) for o in range(0, 12)] 
               u.append(repr(sorted(v)))
              w = set(u)
              x = [eval(y) for y in w]
              for z in x:
               p = [z.count(o) for o in set(z)]
               q = 479001600
               for r in p:
                q = q // factorial(r)
               s += q
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZXPcqJAEMbvPEXvbRhIAm4qW0lFr/sAOVoeEAZBccABNPrybk9jgg6QmGQPdjl/vt/XPaPTxb5Kcvn7eIxEDKmsyo2qmLSfLEhjkDAeg/cESlS1kuBZEOa1rIRyoRLrAsbgu@BbsEvSTLytwTNIlLfD5zGMcEwKPUBBnkV6iOrTtxGyPFc7NKz36V/jRhjIqPkywYSQ9rbBPWOdcrqccIHRvIPV3N3RlA2Tic7iVNbbfsvSZxAHYZWrNMjMU0DTkwClIivF2YwEfi6EG/DtBvdXSKGCSrxs6kCJF7GphQxFwy510RbEuYIAzx5UIBeCtZfgwo2vP3ov7Zq3u9apZIHb3hhaBjywLzUkCjuieUeHcc7npprkUZ88HCBgDHnY4RBIDICiD1kYIx51iYSMh5HiCipGwUUPm@CLD@Hx1XyMMY/7XMgm@cxm8UUnjAu@6PUjw/QKw@RbnhgTnvQ7k/XySusfuGNMeTqQAyWxujqJ5Y/zwLjky6FsKJ3sK@ms/lNGGFd8NZiXfvU02yG2Q2yH2A6xHWI7xHaI7RDbIbaj2RgznumXUxpsqPDZ@7zOzDZkNcqmM2NSn@C6PUFsIffe44NZDsBWi6tpPsOHmmG9nLO17gK5TYj8AuGP7BmYhPo2KAohI6ZEoViZq0pEbGvbZpo7dCpFxWpz4VWnILbYH/aN6V6b7voqOuiV104RurlND7fUWNl55trvYJsk2OD@@z@Pnuc/eJ65qMVKi4uODwk3ulu2PU2Z5WD3cnDXexctj8bjggc58vRNFAp/swwvdqAX4r/1@A8)

[Next sequence: A002113: palindromic number](http://oeis.org/A002113)

Sorry for the counting by exhaustion algorithm (and the 14-layer for loop), but the sequence also counts representations with negative numbers into the total.

Comment: ... and for using Python.

Comment: (of course, anyone is free to use any language, just saying)

Comment: ... and for CamelCase function name.

Answer (score 3):

## 307. [Scratch 2](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 6060 bytes, [A002113](http://oeis.org/A002113)

[image]

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/196522903/)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A006060)

Relevant part:

```
"scripts": [[639, 148.5, [["letter:of:", 1, ["readVariable", "is_palindrome"]]]],
    [683, 370, [["readVariable", "counter"]]],
    [697, 365, [["readVariable", "n"]]],
    [59,
        92,
        [["whenGreenFlag"],
            ["deleteLine:ofList:", "all", "palindromes"],
            ["doAsk", "n: "],
            ["setVar:to:", "n", ["answer"]],
            ["setVar:to:", "counter", 0],
            ["doUntil",
                ["=", ["lineCountOfList:", "palindromes"], ["readVariable", "n"]],
                [["setVar:to:", "is_palindrome", "1"],
                    ["setVar:to:", "i", 0],
                    ["doRepeat",
                        ["stringLength:", ["readVariable", "counter"]],
                        [["doIf",
                                ["not",
                                    ["=",
                                        ["letter:of:", ["+", ["readVariable", "i"], 1], ["readVariable", "counter"]],
                                        ["letter:of:",
                                            ["-", ["stringLength:", ["readVariable", "counter"]], ["readVariable", "i"]],
                                            ["readVariable", "counter"]]]],
                                [["setVar:to:", "is_palindrome", 0]]],
                            ["changeVar:by:", "i", 1]]],
                    ["doIf",
                        ["=", ["readVariable", "is_palindrome"], "1"],
                        [["append:toList:", ["readVariable", "counter"], "palindromes"]]],
                    ["changeVar:by:", "counter", 1]]]]]],
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/jEc5W0SL

Comment: ... why is this one 1-indexing?

Comment: It seems too slow...

Comment: Could you make sure the offset is right? For instance, input 0 should give you an output of 0. I can't check this since something's wrong with flash in my browser. (since user202729 seems to be saying something)

Comment: I've managed to get Flash to work, and this is unfortunately slightly invalid due to the rules about indexing sequences. For example, for all numbers less than 10 the program should output the index. Changing `n` to `n-1` should fix this

Answer (score 3):

## 313. PowerShell, 146 bytes, [A001811](https://oeis.org/A001811)

```
function A001811($n){
    [System.Numerics.BigInteger]$a=1;
    for ($i=1; $i -le $n; $i++) {
        $a=$a*($i+4)*($i+4)/$i
    }
    return $a
}
```

[Online test suite](https://tio.run/##NY5BC8IwDIXv/oowelidmy0oCDJBb168eBQPo2RbYWul6xAZ/e0zm/Mdkhfy@JKXfaPramyaVFmH41j2RnltDZyFkAcpY2b4sALS4/7pPLbZrW/RadVlF11djccK3ZMVuTzOqdI6iJmmEZiGtEFgZrJJwuHHmUR5Vqwpl@z40rZMz@swV4e@d4ZyqzASEgtVT1jQBkSWyf0fhqq2EEeDCJCfYJAhgrSkc5t4@Z885wT5Ag)

[Next sequence: A000146](https://oeis.org/A000146)

Answer (score 3):

## 322. Mathematica (10.1), 150 bytes, [A000249](http://oeis.org/A000249)

```
Symbol[StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[72], FromCharacterCode[101], FromCharacterCode[97], FromCharacterCode[100]]][#(****)&][Round[BesselK[Slot[1], 5]]]
```

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000150)

A bit over-the-top due to the character requirement. Effectively the same as `Round[#~BesselK~5]&`.

Comment: I was confused by `(****)` for a bit, until I remembered that Mathematica comment is `(* ... *)`...

Answer (score 3):

## 330. [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 1854 bytes, [A000155](https://oeis.org/A000155)

```
Ye A000155 program.
Ajax, a of n minus four.
Brutus, a of n minus three.
Cicero, a of n minus two.
Dogberry, a of n minus one.
Isabella, input.
Miranda, counter.
Timon, a of n.

Act I: TBD.
Scene I: Taking input.

[Enter Isabella and Timon]

Timon:
       Listen to your heart! Are you worse than the sum of a big old cat and
       a pig?

Isabella:
       If so, you are me.

Timon:
       If so, let us proceed to Act II. Are you as bad as the sum of a furry
       black cat and a pig?

Isabella:
       If so, you are the sum of a beautiful trustworthy handsome pony and a
       coward.

Timon:
       If so, let us proceed to Act II.

[Exeunt Isabella and Timon]
[Enter Brutus and Cicero]

Brutus:
       You are a big chihuahua.

Cicero:
       You are a horse.

[Exeunt Brutus and Cicero]
[Enter Dogberry and Miranda]

Miranda:
       You are the sum of a amazing brave beautiful angel and a hog!

Dogberry:
       You are a pretty cute pony.

[Exit Dogberry]
[Enter Timon]

Scene II: The loop.

Miranda:
       You are the sum of Ajax and the product of a sunny sky and the sum of
       the product of Brutus and the difference between me and the sum of an
       animal and a delicious cow and the product of Dogberry and the sum of
       me and a toad. Am I as big as Isabella?

Timon:
       If so, let us proceed to Scene III.

[Exit Timon]
[Enter Ajax]

Ajax:
       You are the sum of you and a lantern.

Miranda:
       You are Brutus.

[Exeunt Ajax and Miranda]
[Enter Brutus and Cicero]

Cicero:
       You are me.

Brutus:
       You are Dogberry.

[Exeunt Brutus and Cicero]
[Enter Dogberry and Timon]

Timon:
       You are me.

[Exit Dogberry]
[Enter Miranda]

Miranda:
       Let us return to Scene II.

Scene III: TBD.

[Exit Miranda]
[Enter Isabella]

Act II: Finishing up.
Scene I: Output.

Isabella: Open thy heart!
[Exeunt]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVNT@MwEL37Vwx3FJUDFy6oLItUiRWH5YJWHKbJJPGS2JE/tnT/fHccx96mtBVUldLU9vOb997Yduh2uxeC5WKxuLq@hsHoxmBfiOVvfL8EBF2Dgl4qb6HW3hTiznjn7cGQaw1RIb7Jkow@HNvoQtzrZk3GbA/GtOJVK4tr6jq8BKkG7wrxQxpUFb@X2itHvOmz7LVKawshlqWD1Q08390X4mdJisY3fJOqSSDi1/ewFhI6MCSMOK8i4t0IiJ9HaR0pcBq2XCK0hMZdwNJQeIeNNpa4QuQZLYH1fWCBsJYN6K6CEl3ATmAIg2xuRa4q77KqwbI2ARIZuufKD3hMMzpywNqwFSVRFWiN5a6KTAktrLEKjxmj2rPCCWzdYfmWyH2a1bxCQu9k7Ttwxlv20bh2CyxEZXVPMGi1jeAJrNQbNNWX6wpevRNbfdSsyceYu3EgxoxtjP/lfV6mIqI3ZStbj/xl/LjiyMQ2mLtH4Mgu0/4pwePYlFCmMP36AD0TEnv8G6K5NviH9mRF1VA3@dPq5kLkPjlCdTDk3BZK76L0kbV0mVmmmlI@dUZoDWbTaT0UnyIcen9kFf5juyrPPo2FWK/Yc/u2zcNxSQI7WLCnZhipZF2TIVUGDdyGuOc4RnMkfs2dpGSPSZ6KOllKzWgcsmPkZv58ZDZthBw7rLiTeliNbcRB4UfK3e2no5u0XWUb5nENGrIF4XFO6rHvRl4dhnXqjENRzb2wZp9yHM/0yokWGI@hE32UJP16fxw/Z2d7nsju6c56jB5wF3ij9i0o/ic93QkT@qEuyebX6Qbh6Q9SSduG5vTD3l3y5F28RfKBCU9DuCPCATjeD0mS193uaiH@AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001854)

Comment: Just when I was almost finished actually implementing the Bessel functions...

Comment: I just realised that I forgot to fill in the act and scene titles...

Answer (score 3):

## 346. [C++14 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 3780 bytes, [A000162](http://oeis.org/A000162)

```cpp
// oeis

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#define NDEBUG
#endif
#include <cassert>

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using v1=std::vector<char>;
using v2=std::vector<v1>;
using v3=std::vector<v2>;

template<class Ar>Ar zip(Ar const& a){
	Ar result(a[0].size());
	for(size_t y=a[0].size();y-->0;){
		result[y].resize(a.size());
		for(size_t x=a.size();x-->0;)
			result[y][x]=a[x][y];
	} return result;
}

template<class Ar>Ar rot1(Ar a){ // rotate cw, assume
	// row-major, row counts down, columns count right
	std::reverse(a.begin(),a.end());
	return zip(a);
}
template<class Ar>Ar rot2(Ar a){ // reverse of rot1
	a=zip(a);std::reverse(a.begin(),a.end());
	return a;
}

template<class Fn>auto each(Fn f){//f must have type (T -> T)
	return [f](auto&& ar){
		for(auto& elem:ar)elem=f(std::move(elem));
		return ar;
	};
}
auto zipeach=each(zip<v2>);

template<class Fn>auto twice(Fn f){//f must have type (T -> T)
	return [f](auto&& ar){
		return f(f(std::forward<decltype(ar)>(ar)));
	};
}

template<class Ar>std::vector<Ar>allrot2(Ar a,std::vector<Ar>& result){
	// calculate all (4) rot of the 2D array (a) and append to (result).
	result.push_back(std::move(a));
	for(int i=3;i-->0;)result.push_back(rot1(result.back()));
	return result;
}
auto rot1each=each(rot1<v2>);

std::vector<v3>allrot(v3 a){
	std::vector<v3>result;
	for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
		/*
		auto r2a=allrot2(a);
		result.insert(result.end(),
			std::make_move_iterator(r2a.begin()),
			std::make_move_iterator(r2a.end()));
		*/
		allrot2(a,result);
		a=rot1each(a);
	}
	a=zipeach(rot1(zipeach(a)));
	allrot2(a,result);
	a=each(twice(rot1<v2>))(a);
	allrot2(a,result);
	return result;
}

void pr(v3 const&a){
	for(v2 const&plane:a){
		for(v1 const&row:plane){
			for(int x:row)std::cout<<x;
			std::cout<<'\n';
		} std::cout<<'\n';
	} std::cout<<"=======\n";
}

// given a v2, return something with its size but all zeroes.
v2 zero(v2 x){x.assign(x.size(),v1(x[0].size())); return x;}
v3 pad (v3 x){// pad left and right with an all-zero v2.
	x.insert(x.begin(),zero(x[0]));//at begin
	x.push_back(x[0]);//at end-now begin is a zero()
	return x;}
v3 trim(v3 x){//the array (x) must not be completely empty
	auto it=x.begin();auto p0=zero(x[0]);
	while(p0==*it)++it;
	x.erase(x.begin(),it);
	while(x.back()==p0)x.pop_back();
	return x;
}

template<class Fn,Fn f>v3 ap3d(v3 a){ // apply for all 3 dimensions
	a=f(a); // x y z -> [x] y z
	a=zipeach(a); // [x] z y
	a=zip(f(zip(a))); // [x] [z] y
	a=zipeach(a); // [x] y [z]
	a=zip(f(zip(a))); // [x] [y] [z]
	return a;
}
auto pad3d =ap3d<decltype(&pad),&pad>;
auto trim3d=ap3d<decltype(&trim),&trim>;

std::vector<v3> expand(std::vector<v3> cubes){
	std::vector<v3> result;
	for(v3&cube:cubes){
		cube = pad3d(std::move(cube));
		size_t const nx=cube.size(),ny=cube[0].size(),nz=cube[0][0].size();
		for(size_t x=nx;x-->0;)
		for(size_t y=ny;y-->0;)
		for(size_t z=nz;z-->0;){
			if(cube[x][y][z])continue;
			if(
				(x&&cube[x-1][y][z])||(x!=nx-1&&cube[x+1][y][z])||
				(y&&cube[x][y-1][z])||(y!=ny-1&&cube[x][y+1][z])||
				(z&&cube[x][y][z-1])||(z!=nz-1&&cube[x][y][z+1])
			){
				result.push_back(cube);
				result.back()[x][y][z]=true;
				result.back()=trim3d(std::move(result.back()));
			}
		}
	}
	return result;
}

int main() {
	std::vector<v3> a={{{{1}}}};
	int n;std::cin>>n;
	++n;//1-based indexing ==> 0-based indexing
	--n;while(n-->0){
		a=expand(a);
		std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
		a.erase(std::unique(a.begin(),a.end()),a.end());
	}
	long long ans=0;size_t constexpr NCUBEROT=24;
	for(auto&cube:a){
		assert(!cube.empty());
		auto rots=allrot(std::move(cube));
		assert(rots.size()==NCUBEROT);
		++ans;//i==0
		for(size_t i=1;i<NCUBEROT;++i)
			ans+=rots[0]==rots[i];
	}
	assert(ans%NCUBEROT==0);
	std::cout<<ans/NCUBEROT<<'\n';
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVd7b9s2EP/b@hRsi6VS/Y6LFYhMD036wIChA4YWKJAaKSNRNleZUiXKkZz6qy@7I6mHE2cbMAO2xXuQx3v87hSk6XAVBHd34zFJuMgd55mIZMgjcvX@t1/PLz5/vnrz9vzTe@cZ0ITk5INdchmKCIRlEBchJ/OA5TnP1MJpaHOR5CrjbLNoSVseqCTrEFi8SjKh1iDkFLmQK7Kd0lyFZ2dGdB6sWbbwa97pAW87bTmzQ84pcBzFN2nMFJ8HMVhHXmeL1xnZidSFvyCRuTohzLt1erDMeF7EymWXk@UoFzvuep7v9KIkc3F1pUhFOzy/Gg4XEx91e0bzslqO4Am5rLNBd4eS1hy/NOrAb9UvyyUcUS7hERT3YJEqMmkN8539I9fJEjXF@8BFCMQQliBBgpsBAZliw52ept4MN@zPJBvgI9y9kConYXIjB7CIi43MDZFkYrVWTk/7MuNbnuV4oWu@EtL1BmwEYTc3s@ahN5mH5j1m3WnXOrMjSSJtt9Nj1G7wnw9kx1zxTi5YoRLCWbB230kSebfjcUQ2Ra7Imm05UVXKifuRDBfko9fsdRktXdQ7gTzIdDAxXJpCeMw3Z0DFfxq52r5NsuUuEkxsa4syjBeapW2AC6EZVNsCC8xFz3/UZHUjAv6/bLaMyLVWwh1uWBbOQx7EuIcLcgv80VbvH0mlbvXAksVxE7vBPd6JTUo8HYIasDgocDMCSsR96WFsMcRqzcnpGzAzYxWBIBMmQ8LSFEJK4Oau3WXk2CIYpUW@vrpmwbeOu1lTiALSU9CZL0zxPNDRlWCpmuB186atI@12FG7DhKs6TgcwMrOOcLczAxX3uPWuHQMnvpi/9Pt9oYMzfgE/5sRTRmuvMps/2lYhEThry3W@DxAZjA/YN36FjrgSimcMjnVho7o@/l3QlI8@7sUYTaktGFjvI4fR2h3Gsr0tzMY3br1gZq9juzDjSpPPjUM9s@MxhYcAt01ESNIMnW3gWbscXbs9tRTIWsnPWFOs26llAK6daaZmNfEoz4DhaQ8BwKn5vPQblxnC8y/yOdL25CHxgPaUms8X@VRbC6m/ElsOAAB9aVDjdZ5suFpjS7qBtkYE4CyCPrkulK6PHc8Sno8cuBE@4s1K77YcQRmKlXRL2yIG26lbdpqR59cHlP7eAQelLCToqBJhQ69iHildYhrDzfFM4qFDPAmMhEor63QrG4zVZuBZcMh4zBTRDBRta0uzDRcyaiihiWgpInK4vt6hhShrocrEprEQscACQekZkJMJHgXhAyjiiscVAVBSlWPKRSjamOhrSjqhrakQnJu1iLkLVPpCKA8KDuuwHEHyQwtprydUK1xaYKA0nXhwvyQ11@ukY3m8vwwQoReIAukstGiAHQ3gDAyHbNPBnZFQbLjMBaQkVkSE2Y9iJanIDpEcGjw@dgvMiiBnR6q6J0au6Yxey73cLRv@fc0Kuf@kWy2NRLeNGreycBYSivdqW8YJUL0B/sIcZfoURHMW3hdDKsjh3@IhdhJeppCQ7n1yUFzz/AiakgM43c5OUPCske7hE6HG4k6LQLKBODtpaUQgsqTIqQtKVnrZ1tRA7mpKZ7K7P7PJsjOtHcyDsqrHwEPOjsqdv2sHxJ6ItIlmtoMgeGCfErLgvuXiX88tT06M2HBaC/744ZZPwIThtOb1OzyjVtUsYKCmUatArWrVgNefHqjtOixggCaq7UBtd6AGPNDUo6q5zcNmrf3vd3mmqJoLU5XZyx4KUJNUnVA@bN897Eb43R/rGAjxG4Z1To6kE6O38Jnu4QM7oaw0g2Yg5GIhgdbvS0C16fAaMCMkAl58SoRuShdkco/o9IZD6RsckRhd7Q7oeibHTUvXu@cJ4OvRGbbHLDxpuUKK78WxaberAteOEzBJ/zCZw3zRzXI4PSMfLj6dv/3j94/09KWtHT0h6uoxrdK8nLlPdEFomK0NssNQbmeTo2VltVHMlgml9ZlaoN8Hy8CRgtLJYTEIOoV5qBbWYxHGFMT7OHTkUHnUPIilnTzMYSDxU3MvOsFjOr0YuOOaW3frvXN397PjvCtkoACAWUwu@v0n5OvjU/nX0WjkOBf6xQcblCw21zzD0TXKOCdpElcafEwvfUUCHsfQus95wAp4i0EVeD2NYy5XHLLyeyEgNSFhUuj1cCaA1WRYp48@6hzeEEOew7uZrBJ4mf6GjXQNX5DGHe3ojkuBXRF6idIvNb84fwVRzFb53RC8QIN@f/rqbw)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A3780). I didn't check what it is, but hopefully easy.

Comment: To the next answerer: is the "28-term linear recurrence" proven? If not, you'll need to verify the results up to n=1001, and for that, you need a program that actually computes the sequence.

Comment: aw, man, the challenge is over :(

Comment: @NieDzejkob When OEIS has a formula without something like "conjectured" near it, I see no reason to doubt about it.

Comment: @ChristianSievers Well, "gives a 28-term linear recurrence on his web page" is different from a published paper.

Comment: @NieDzejkob It's from the the person who is the author of everything related to this sequence that is mentioned at the OEIS entry. But yeah, it's not a peer reviewed reult.

Answer (score 3):

## 349. Kotlin, 774 bytes, [A000607](https://oeis.org/A000607)

```kotlin
val primes = mutableListOf<Int>   (2)
val prev   = mutableListOf<Double>(1.0)
fun sequence(n: Int): Double {
    if (n < prev.size)
        return prev.get(n)
    var sum = 0.0
    for (k in (primes.last() + 1)..n) {
        var prime = true
        for (p in primes)
            if (k % p == 0) {
                prime = false
                break
            }
        if (prime)
            primes.add(k)
    }
    for (k in 1..n) {
        var divsum = 0
        for (p in primes) {
            if (p > k)
                break
            if (k % p == 0)
                divsum += p
        }
        sum += divsum * sequence(n - k)
    }
    val res = 1.0 / n * sum
    prev.add(res)
    return res
}
fun main() {
    println(sequence(readLine()!!.toInt()).toInt())
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLboMwELz7KyaHSnajUtJjlOTUS6VI/QanmMoCFmpsDq34dmpsSBPSSvWJfc3sLFPUttQ0DJ0s0RhdqRZ7VM7KU6mOurWv@e6F7AEAfxIsdqnOh8uu59r54MA3SSpY7git@nCK3hSnLTyE2CK24Iv5cegcnLALcEmrP5UI6fEZZZ2hWHlXllMsddKgdZVnTpM0ZPLagBfQBB53T0rZWi6wxkYkCYmJa54OTX7eGqfOhQDSjCAR42ePec0Cd2iw97yXgPObQXNZtuqmejJKFlfZnl1ih@lrykmKzDJexEq/ULv5RVumu@k4fytbbB/4cUAh/rH24hA3ExP/eo@G3UqdSlPT/YU58IArlaPFTHChdxIeQWO3q1i8jHfEeBcz/6bJKj5mfXBdJTXxWaiXTbYkfmbzqrKjJsXFapXY2tuSC3H@YP0wbNL0Gw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000774)

Nothing special here other than caching values because of the immense amount of recursion. (Side note -- this is my first Kotlin program!)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Just an FYI, your header links to A008472, not A000607

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oops, fixed! :p

Answer (score 3):

## 363. [Iota](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota), 1669 bytes, [A000324](https://oeis.org/A000324)

```
***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii**i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii*i*i*ii
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001669)

This is a pure lambda calculus function that, given `n` (0-indexed) as a Church numeral, computes the `n`-th term of A000324 as another Church numeral. (Also works as a function in Lazy K, which is just a union of multiple minimalist lambda calculus-related languages.)

I don't know of any online system that can test this function directly, but you can test a human-readable version of this program on [Ben Lynn's online SK compiler](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/sk.html):

```
true = \x y -> x
false = \x y -> y
is0 = \n -> n (\x -> false) true
n0 = \f x -> x
n1 = \f -> f
n2 = \f x -> f (f x)
n5 = \f x -> f (f (f (f (f x))))
pred = \n f x -> n (\g h -> h (g f)) (\u -> x) (\u -> u)
seq = \x -> is0 x n1 (pred x (\y -> n2 (pred (pred y))) n5)
n3 = \f x -> f (f (f x))
n4 = \f x -> f (f (f (f x)))
main = seq n0  -- try giving n1, n2, n3 instead
```

The SK compiler's output (without the number argument) was then fed into [this Python program](https://tio.run/##7VI9b4MwEN35FbfZFxpU1A2JX5CxY5QBgRGuU4NsU6W/nh7YGFCljpmKBbq79@7rmeHbdb1@myZbMsvDUQq5omMV0sPJxcUOuNpeG1kLukXnmNqFD1nxtRsverh@jkyuLAUD53lDPLcXHnf921JhDGTZOAzCcEwGI7XjFpNGtDBUxgpyigTqbtTKQgnXWwKNGFxH9msCWjycbB7eaXsD8qUGqUHo8VOYyoV0kC3UUJbAOCtCflpCToi4RwwjdvYYIaEX1Z/LLP2WWaijvYbuhUzz24weKu2p0b7mxdlz/UZZRYvrhkcCrl38VlQ5ASPcaHTICBKt2nil6l5/CeP8sjSFXaZ4pylCLjtJfyTbES6/CDP8r/UsB4MT8LvQ3CcjnCFHSIGx7KOXFA6S@0qLHn4Cud7U@jdvl4PT9AM) to yield the corresponding Iota code.

Comment: :( - I was trying to get [Icon](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/) to work / understand [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage/blob/master/doc/introduction.md)

Comment: I actually had an [Idris answer](https://tio.run/##y0wpyiz@/z9NwUrBL7FEQdcORHGlKUQp2CoYAmmNYIUoTSDbFMIGojxNEL@gKDVFQQNCpkGFNRW0sIv/z03MzAPa4OmvoKHJBebYKqTkcykAlWfmlfjkgdRGaaLywTZjikGEsYpDpXDJwaQ1/wMA) too, but I didn't feel like bowling it :P

Answer (score 3):

## 369. [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 163 bytes, [A001015](https://oeis.org/A001015)

```
;you know what is this
`y
;activate y
?^7
;active = ARG to the power of 7
`x
;activate x
oy
;output x!
y:0
;x is 0, why active?
;[X]HTML can't be parsed with regex
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000163)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc0xC8IwFATg/f2Kc3JxKDgUDFKcdKiLOAiiNLbRBqEvtK@m@fUxooPjwd13ummci1EFHvHs2MO3WmAHSGsHqgIpXYt9aTEIVFzzXzZYY3PYQjgVDRx704PvyKma/iYTcRJ4FDcKwozCKiMVPny2SE8BX6wgdT5ddsd9iVp3c8EtkbofTANvpUVvHmaKMS7f)

Comment: @alephalpha fixed, now post

Comment: Isn't the next OEIS sequence supposed to be the same index as the number of bytes of your code? In this case wouldn't it be [A000163](https://oeis.org/A000163), not [A049084](https://oeis.org/A049084)?

Answer (score 3):

## 373. [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/), 907 bytes, [A000170](https://oeis.org/A000170)

```hs
-- generate all possible col number lists
powerSet : Nat -> List (List Nat)
powerSet n = index n (iterate (liftA2 (::) (enumFromTo 1 n)) (Nil :: Nil))

-- symmetric difference
symDiff : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
symDiff Z m = m
symDiff (S n) Z = S n
symDiff (S n) (S m) = symDiff n m

-- given a pair of row and col numbers, unless the rows are equal (the same cell),
-- the cols and diagonals must not match
isOKPair : (Nat, Nat) -> (Nat, Nat) -> Bool
isOKPair (i1, n1) (i2, n2) = i1 == i2 || (n1 /= n2 && symDiff n1 n2 /= symDiff i1 i2)

-- attach row numbers to the list of col numbers
enumerate : List Nat -> List (Nat, Nat)
enumerate l = zip (enumFromTo 1 (length l)) l

-- is this board a valid N-Queen solution?
isNQueen : List Nat -> Bool
isNQueen l = all id (liftA2 isOKPair (enumerate l) (enumerate l))

-- count all N-Queen solutions
a000170 : Nat -> Nat
a000170 n = length (filter isNQueen (powerSet n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPLbtswELzrK@YUkICNWOoLEOAGKYoCRQOnRXrqjZZoewE@XJJK2iL/7i7lh2xDF0o7S@7ODJfUBoq73XSKtXY6qKShjMHWx0hLo9F4A9fZpQ4wFFMstv5FhyedUGOhEqYf8cA4RL8yIocdDnOQa/Uf/hOU9tWFoVW6ryDqWkJorv0lePvTo4STjCzIoObaZKQsCuYV/1qrU6AGLa1WOmjX6ILBzxwNJIbPKfcLlgnYUyyeuAOjc/DPFcqrlZw5oo7P5eZretYOCltFAX6F4F@gXHtmS5ygc0bHiLTROR@hgob@3SkDkbGoLPuojZGTXDJDfDz2dVpSa@8UR7Zj/5xPsCo1m4Li47fvuWnNlqg06a3NCi@jT96bYa@gcgJXshyq@KfKiqjEnNcKr68QrsTtnBO4uRmklhm4HbTzCar23quUVLPpVR/UIvleQR6GbMiZEUW@zP0l1ziOwzAgJ95n@wwT/EfbqzkQRrt12oAnAKbnQdldXpZehZav41kZarGY/ug0X0/0pkvk3R07sdhDlwQOLh1yuWmeca5wHMbBwTNu8jLaO9L4zqX@@HX3WKjZbFZ@mF0M5QnMj@GgS6zI8GvAiZEYnoyUO6soC/j6CCGLPpij9QWwDeTSA28/1pzJMbQcRatR9M0o@nYUfTeKvpe7/w)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000907)

Another I-language into the mix. Idris (especially Idris 1 on TIO) is pretty much Haskell with dependent types and a bit stripped down library. `Nat` is a Peano natural number type, and all arithmetic functions on `Nat` are defined recursively by pattern-matching into `Z` and `S n`, which is demonstrated in the function `symDiff`. The other parts of the code just use various Prelude functions to complete the job.

Answer (score 3):

## 398. [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), 176 bytes, [A000498](https://oeis.org/A000498)

```
inputVariable = 0
InputBox( inputVariable )
Sum( nCr( inputVariable + 5 , k0 ) * ( -1 ) ^ k0 * ( inputVariable + 1 - k0 ) ^ ( inputVariable + 4 ) , k0 , 0 , inputVariable + 1 )
```

Takes input through the input box.

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/k5rb8dxk)

[Next Sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000176)

Comment: We don't even got no formula for the next one :/ no idea how to do it

Comment: @Steffan well it says in the "Comments" section, `Consider the Dirichlet series L_a(s) = sum_{k>=0)} (-a|2k+1) / (2k+1)^s, where (-a|2k+1) is the Jacobi symbol. Then the numbers d_(a,n) are defined by L_a(2n)= (Pi/(2a))^(2n)*sqrt(a)* d_(a,n)/ (2n-1)! for a>1 and n=1,2,3...`. So i guess that's technically a formula you can use (except i have absolutely no idea what it means lol)?

Comment: that dont make one bit of sense

Comment: @Steffan well i just chose the lowest byte count available :|

Answer (score 2):

## 63. [Haxe](https://haxe.org), 108 bytes, [A000057](http://oeis.org/A000057)

```
function(a,n=3){while(a>0){var i=0,x=0,y=1,z;while(y>0&&i++<=n){z=x+y;x=y;y=z%n;}i==n++&&a-->0;}return n-1;}
```

[Test it online!](https://try.haxe.org/#53d7A)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000108)

Comment: @geokavel Sorry, I keep forgetting to do that... :P

Comment: Aww crud and I had the Catalan numbers ready for cQuents, but I used it for Fibonacci instead :/

Answer (score 2):

## 83. Bash, 53+165265=165318, [A000014](https://oeis.org/A000014)

```
#!/bin/sh
read index
head -"$index" a.txt | tail -1
```

requires that a.txt (https://hastebin.com/eroterefov) be in the same directory

[next sequence](https://oeis.org/A165318)

Also, this is my first post to the Code Golf Stack Exchange, please let me know if I messed up in any way.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Wouldn't the next sequence be [A165318](https://oeis.org/A165318)?

Comment: This would be an invalid answer, correct?

Comment: @HusnainRaza It is, but nothing good will come from deleting an answer this far from the end of the chain.

Comment: If the values of the next current sequence (A000066) are not even known past n=13, how is one supposed to write a program to calculate them?

Answer (score 2):

## 84. [Boo](https://boo-language.github.io/), 330 bytes, [A165318](https://oeis.org/A165318)

```
def f (n):
  cnt = 0
  i   = 1
  while true:
    i++
    isPrime = true
    for k in range(2, i):
      if i%k==0: isPrime = false
    if isPrime == false: continue
    divs = 0
    q    = i-1
    for k in range(1, i):
      if q%k == 0: divs = divs+1
    if (divs & (divs - 1)) != 0: continue
    if cnt == n: return i
    cnt++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBJDsIwDLzziuFQlCggNRwj9Q98gSUBqyWFtIXnFydNESBOtmbxjHxo23E8WQcH4aVZAEffo0LJGwG8ad6eF2os@jDYqGBGqWl2u0BXy6rIJci1ATXII@z92YrtGiQnE8sdqKirqjQfTrdvuska6RnOuMGx9T35fPxEjy6XA@5I/Wij/wXrn@B7UcerHJ2PxKH0HCwSuspzAy0llkn@VYCV6T8VvEGw/RA8KDEMKzXGEvQuAVGuoUtpcAvENidIji8)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000330)

Comment: cQuents code for next sequence (lang already used): [`$0:z+$^2`](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XAqkpbJc7o/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## 85. [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org), 97 bytes, [A000330](https://oeis.org/A000330)

```javascript
function f(i:number) {
 let s:number=0;
 for(let j:number=0;j<=i;j++){
  s+=j**2;
 }
 return s;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrBCgIhEADQu18xR10hIjpl/kyiodjMMjMeYtlvtw2Cro@n7zVL4rrqnGVg0koIxdYbjtcjs4PNQM8K8oN4DgYKsf1i@2O7xxqa9@74ID62ZbkcczfAWQcjSDD7TIRCPZ86PW2xV@fmBw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000097)

Comment: Back to partitions again? Fine...

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

## 88. [Go](https://golang.org/), 386 bytes, [A000016](https://oeis.org/A000016)

<sub>For those using graduation script, SE translates tabs into spaces.</sub>

```c
import . "math"
func gcd (a, b int) int {
    for b != 0 { c := b; b = a % b; a = c }
    return a
}
func phi (n int) int{
    r := 1
    for i := 2; i < n; i++ { if gcd (i, n) == 1 { r++ } }
    return r
}
func f (n int) int {
    s := 0.
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        if (i % 2 == 1) && (n % i == 0) {
            s += (float64(phi(i)) * Pow(2., float64(n) / float64(i))) / float64(2 * n)
        }
    }
    return int(s)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/XkA7dB5kes)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000386)

Comment: Can anybody explain the difference between all these sequences with the same name but different values?  [A000033](http://oeis.org/A000033), [A000159](http://oeis.org/A000159), [A000181](http://oeis.org/A000181), [A000185](http://oeis.org/A000185), [A000222](http://oeis.org/A000222), [A000386](http://oeis.org/A000386), [A000425](http://oeis.org/A000425), [A000426](http://oeis.org/A000426), [A000450](http://oeis.org/A000450), [A058085](http://oeis.org/A058085), [A058086](http://oeis.org/A058086), [A058089](http://oeis.org/A058089), [A058090](http://oeis.org/A058090)

Comment: @EngineerToast the difference is the offset (what that means exactly I dunno)

Comment: @StepHen Ah, thanks! I hadn't noticed that. [These tables](https://books.google.com/books?id=eNsoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=%22menage+hit+polynomial%22&source=bl&ots=B7IuZLTCFF&sig=Vp27xP5YtC8QwZVwLj23QaSKPLI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6yZad-qTVAhUkzIMKHX3gCJoQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22menage%20hit%20polynomial%22&f=false) may prove relevant, then. I believe the coefficients on OEIS are given in the form `k,n`. I *think* they're related to seating couples at a table.

Answer (score 2):

## 92. [Thue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_(programming_language)), 93 bytes, [A001733](https://oeis.org/A001733)

```
0::=~7
1::=0
2::=0
3::=~10
4::=aa
5::=~12
6::=~13
7::=~21
8::=aaa
9::=88a
a::=~1
b::=:::
::=
b
```

This does hardcode the values, but that shouldn't be a problem, as it is not possible to encode a number in base -1.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000093)

Comment: 7 in base -1 is 1010101010101

Comment: How is that true?

Comment: The `n+1`-th last digit has place value `-1 ** n`, so since `-1 ** n` is `-1 if n%2 else 1`, every other digit is `1` (technically that's not in the sequence so you're not wrong :P but just being a nitpick xD)

Answer (score 2):

## 94. [Befunge 93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 27 bytes, [A000035](https://oeis.org/A000035)

```
>  &   v
v  2   <
>  % . @@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/305BQU1BQaGMq0xBwQjIsOECiqgq6Ck4OPz/bwIA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000027)... How about a REALLY easy one??? :P

Golfed solution: `&2%.@`

Comment: cQuents for A000027: `$` (1-indexed)

Comment: @StepHen Jelly and Anyfix for A000027: `‘`

Answer (score 2):

## 96. [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 236 bytes, [A000478](http://oeis.org/A000478)

```lisp
(defun power(m n)
  (let ((result 1))
    (dotimes (count n result)
             (setf result (* m result)))))
(defun solve(n) (+ (- (/ (+ 7 n (* (+ 6 n) (+ 6 n))) 2) (* (+ .5 (/ (+ 6 n) 4)) (power 2 (+ 5 n)))) (/ (power 3 (+ 6 n)) 6)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dDoIwDIXveYpz2WnwBxWfh0AxS8ZG2NDHnx2b2Js253z96432c4w08LhazO7DC02wqgLIcADRwn41AVeVNFEHF/TEHtS71QZYZCC7e5DnMBYLdMD0w1JUZZ135s1kFegIqkHnVDxlpDRI1SJbKSuFRhX99CjoBtzFou1wNH9abUiWb7uMVpxI86JtLyem9QJ1i@da28AvgeXfbqiNtpymxMsX)

Some code copied from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631145/lisp-sum-of-power). This is a trivial conversion of the formula specified in the comments of the sequence into lisp.

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000236)

Comment: Perhaps I'm disobeying my own advice, but the next sequence shouldn't be *too* hard.

Comment: Max Alekseyev, can we get a formula that's not just `>=`? xD

Comment: @StepHen You're twelve years too late to ask ...

Comment: @StepHen Why don't you just do what the original researchers did, and write an exhaustive search program on IBM S/360 cards?

Comment: @ppperry, there's no way to do A000236. Its description doesn't tell us anything. `Maximum m such that there are no two adjacent elements belonging to the same n-th power residue class modulo some prime p in the sequence 1,2,...,m (equivalently, there is no n-th power residue modulo p in the sequence 1/2,2/3,...,(m-1)/m).` Its formula is completely useless. `a(n) >= 2^n - 1` I don't want to start a rollback war, so if you'd like to kill the challenge completely, go ahead.

Comment: @MDXF The papers in the "links" section provide more information. There doesn't appear to be a simple way to do it (with the algorithm I'm working on, I doubt more than the first 2 or 3 terms will fit in TiO's time limit), but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

## 99. [Spaced](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/spaced), 30 bytes, [A000153](https://oeis.org/A000153)

```
$<2?$: $*f($-1) + ($-2)*f($-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5ITE5N@f9fxcbIXsVKQUUrTUNF11BTQVsBSBtpgrlGmv///7cAAA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000030)

Answer (score 2):

## 103. [VB6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), 713 bytes, [A000158](http://oeis.org/A000158)

```
Function A000158(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, x3 As Long
    A000158 = 0
    n = n + 3

    x1 = 1
    x2 = 1
    x3 = 1
    While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x1
        While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x2
            While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x3
                A000158 = A000158 + 1
                x3 = x3 + 1
            Wend ' x3
            x2 = x2 + 1
            x3 = x2
        Wend ' x2
        x1 = x1 + 1
        x2 = x1
        x3 = x2
    Wend ' x1

    ' no need to return; VB6 will return the value of the variable A000158 (same name as the function)
End Function
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000713)

This is a function which takes `n` as an input and returns a value back to the caller. Used in the manner of `answer = A000158(input)`.

VB6 shares a lot of the syntax with VB.NET, but use completely different compilers (and some different syntaxes).

VB6 longs are actually 32 bit integers.

Unlike C based languages, the `/` is floating point division. Integer division is handled by `\`. So `1 / 2` will give `0.5`.

The `^` is actually exponent, and not xor like a lot of languages. I believe `Xor` is the VB6 xor.

VB6 has an implicit variable inside their functions that share the same name. So instead of saying `Return <value>`, you assign the return value to the function name. In this instance, I set the variable `A000158` with my return value. After execution, the value of `A000158` is given back to the caller.

**Example usage:**

I created a new form in the VB6 IDE, dropped two text boxes and a button in it (didn't change the form field names).

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Text2.Text = A000158(Text1.Text)
End Sub

Function A000158(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, x3 As Long
    A000158 = 0
    n = n + 3

    x1 = 1
    x2 = 1
    x3 = 1
    While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x1
        While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x2
            While x1 ^ (2 / 3) + x2 ^ (2 / 3) + x3 ^ (2 / 3) <= n ' x3
                A000158 = A000158 + 1
                x3 = x3 + 1
            Wend ' x3
            x2 = x2 + 1
            x3 = x2
        Wend ' x2
        x1 = x1 + 1
        x2 = x1
        x3 = x2
    Wend ' x1

    ' no need to return; VB6 will return the value of the variable A000158 (same name as the function)
End Function
```

Type a value into TextBox1, hit the Button1, and watch TextBox2 get populated by the result.

Answer (score 2):

## 105. [Windows Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Windows_NT), 193, [A000267](http://oeis.org/A000267)

```
@echo off

:SquareRoot number

set /A number=4 * %1 + 1, last=2, sqrt=number/last
:nextIter
   set /A last=(last+sqrt)/2, sqrt=number/last
if %sqrt% lss %last% goto nextIter
echo %last%
```

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000193)

Takes the input number as a command line argument, and prints the result.

Run by saving the above as a .bat file, and execute with windows command prompt (if anyone knows of an online interpreter, I'm happy to update).

Uses an iterative method of computing square roots (Newton's method, I think?). It finds the floor of the square root, which is just what we need for this sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## 106. [Objective-C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 45 + 2 = 47 bytes, [A000193](http://oeis.org/A000193)

```c
int f(int x){ return (int) round(log(x+1)); }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrLCoAgEAB/ZQmCXcpDh059jZmKYWuYRhD9eva4DAwzYZy1Sm7XQgnlJdviOMEiHSOda3zFYFXnqjXYEw3Xnw1@POiEqFOODJ8TxJB5Qh8sHk33znCVcivjpd2K8MsD)

I don't really know Objective-C, but I got something working. Needs the `-lm` flag (no clue why, but it doesn't work without it).

Does what it says on the tin - rounds the log of the input. Note that it adds `1` to the input to make the sequence `0`-indexed.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000047)

Comment: The `-lm` flag would be to link against libm, which contains `log`. I base this explanation entirely on pain I've experienced in the past when figuring out how to compile C programs.

Comment: Note for the next sequence (particularly for people who can see comments on the self-deleted attempt): courtesy of http://www.jpr2718.org/pell.pdf , when searching for solutions to `x^2 - 2y^2 = N` it suffices to consider `0 <= 2y^2 <= N`, so `x^2 <= 2N`. This is a consequence of the smallest non-trivial solution to `x^2 - 2y^2 = 1` being `(3, 2)`.

Comment: Why was the attempt deleted?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Something with int overflow - [screencap of comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXVlI.png) on deleted answer

Comment: Uh, is there a language that uses BigInts as it's primary type? I only know Haskell, but it has been used already

Comment: @NieDzejkob I know Python/Ruby and any esolangs written in them use arbitrary precision integers by default. You could also just import a BigInt package in, say, Java.

Answer (score 2):

## 109. [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 81 bytes, [A000032](http://oeis.org/A000032)

```
,>+>>++>+<<<<[>-<-[>>>>[-<<+<+>>>]<[-<+>]<<[->>+<<]>[->>+<<]<<-]>>>>.<<<]>[+.--]+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRBb5swFL7zK97oIVAgSzJpB2SQtq6Hau126GUaQpUJzuIVjGVM22zab8@eISZNy2GahR728@fve/bzs9zpbSNW@zP4qCgXm259D1dCMyUVQ@ucwUUjd4r/2GpYLZZLuGUFbTWnAj7TVlLFEXLTlHzDWQnFDr5w9ukX@3nfFLBpFIiuLpiCq7dfgYoSHnABLSoGa1ZV8MhLvXUcXstGaWh3reNcXF5f391efb@EBN6thuHNh284WsH5ORynI1g6Tsk2wB5o1VHNvHVTMj92AEwHTEtgXTEqOulVvNUDwEdAoeia1VQioOh4VdrxgHAMBYbXhj2T1Crsx9jBBdkiD2GBn4E9brnZy4ACAhUTxzBMIHVtdp30kOyAy51@km@O8wm4qTusgVErSHCLg8tgbQTJoGIC9OMh0DmVkonSW/iT1OQVdQKL55zEjFnVstHTn@4EVXBC1WYHfG62eOoIYGklnnkJjBnt9RaTKtE/q0STKqndjhWbVMnc/kq@lMCziMeUJuNdOWZvgiqfpHrzP1RzNwapuNDeKZs/BQ7d@PURmbWKPt5xITvt@f7hKA83cgimv1tD/dgSGe8tFn6nBGx4hQ@AV9G6KCk8xfCEzJDN5rMQZqExmTG5McSY1JjAmGiWD7XjHzQmqswoaVbLu97darq@D58XZoYUv/@YxJlnRDYt17wR4bh9jIXh48LUSelPJDl@KWOrxXL60xm1VxDX4OOUvGKRjfTs2Y6Z7cEmCZb8JcD6DaYHHw/cYhxnfNJc192HaZCmQZAGBFuWRiTKUmxZREhAcCrNCfYD/OE/NbA8tR1CotyA56T3BvMoyoM9svr7938B)

Input with raw bytes, or Unicode codepoints, whatever your interpreter supports. Requires large cells for larger inputs. TIO uses Python with an interpreter modified to do input in numbers instead of raw bytes to make testing easier. I probably could golf it down further, but I'm lazy.

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000081)

Comment: Is it really BF if you change how input works? :P

Comment: @StepHen I changed it only for convenience, officially I just used base 256 instead of 10 for I/O.

Answer (score 2):

## 117. [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail), 106 bytes, [A001156](//oeis.org/A001156)

```
$'g'
 -13{f}#
$'f'
 \  /(y)(x){f}(z)(y)s(y)(x)-@
  -*(!z!)(!y!)(!x!)(y)(x)g<
 @-(z)a2(z)a{f}a----#-q0(x)-@
```

The function named `g` defined at the top is the function that computed the sequence. `f` is a helper function that you shouldn't call directly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMzPn/X0U9XZ1LQdfQuDqtVplLRT0NyItRUNDXqNTUqNAECmpUaQLZxRC@rgOXgoKuloZilaKmhmIliKhQ1ITIpdtwKTjoApUnGoEIoNZEXSBQ1i00AOv8/x8A)

[Next Sequence](//oeis.org/A000106) (more math! Yay!)

Answer (score 2):

## 118. [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 128 bytes, [A000106](https://oeis.org/A000106)

```
1<n
[>&sy0>lr>l
 [&s>lrysp>l[:lf%:[pp0f10]p![p:0]p1-]p
  <<<0>>[sp>l*sp<<<l+>>]
  <p<*sp<l+>>]
 <<f/<1-]
>&s>lr[sp<l*sp<l+>>]<<u
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000128)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xCgMxDEP3fEU63A0tR501CP2IyZrJFHOhQ77@6pTSyZaeJWzzugpeSbmPKbSTlrLuI7Y5nKbV@lbVXXqR5jf1GqMczVPOAITUdXcfHsoeZFvAsYyfBPoTEUn89uoifwy84wP5AA)

Easy: just compute values for `1` to `n+1` of A000081, then convolve. You may notice that I'm not using Ly's indexing operator `I`, I'm more thinking in terms of what Haskell calls `zipWith`. It's a pitty that the division makes Ly use floating point.

The next sequence is a bit simple, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

## 119. [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 139 bytes, [A000128](https://oeis.org/A000128)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000139)

```
define f(x) {
	a = 0
	b = 1
	for (i=0; i<x; ++i) {
		aux = b
		b = a + b
		a = aux
	}
	return a
}
n = read()
f(n+5) - (n+1) * (n+2) / 2 - 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgFETX/59illop0ZSukhxGEwU3FqQBoeTs9pvVG2behL33I6ZcIpJqGj8mjw2WKQgcU/pUqLzZBXltC4zJt0T@bCIESUP0MHceX1mYLqYav2ct8HxxkbpGfyjNSRXz1nhC6DQeg7PGhFm6V@/O/gE)

Comment: If only I had known that such a nice language was still available...

Answer (score 2):

## 120. [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes, [A000139](https://oeis.org/A000139)

```
ttQ:pw2*Q:p*3G*:p2*w/&
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000022)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6Qk0Kqg3EgLSGoZu2tZFRhpleur/f9vCgA)

Comment: How the heck was **MATL** not taken yet?

Comment: @ScottMilner MATLAB is also free, somehow.

Comment: @BusinessCat As is Maple. In that case, people may just be avoiding the accusation that they copied the code from the OEIS.

Comment: @KSmarts I've been tempted several times, though...

Comment: Since PyPy is considered a separate language, C (tcc) and C (clang) are untaken.

Comment: Next sequence also has Mathematica code for someone who has an unused version of it (Mathematica 11?)

Comment: @HusnainRaza I don't see any mathematica code on that page, are you sure?

Comment: @NieDzejkob this was for a000022

Comment: @KSmarts I would rather the chain was continued than you using the OEIS code.

Answer (score 2):

## 125. [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), 655 bytes, [A000796](https://oeis.org/A000796)

```java
import java.math.*;I=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();D=I+9;O=BigDecimal.ONE;T=O.add(O);N=BigDecimal.TEN;C=new MathContext(2*D,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);z(a,b){return a.subtract(b,C).abs(C).compareTo(O.divide(N.pow(D,C)))>-1;}bsqrt(c){x=O;do{x=x.add(x.pow(2,C).add(c.negate(C),C).divide(x.multiply(T,C),C).negate(C),C);}while(z(x.pow(2,C),c));return x;}s=BigDecimal.ZERO;a=O;b=bsqrt(T);for(int i=1;z(a,b);i++){g=a.multiply(b,C);a=a.add(b,C).divide(T,C);b=bsqrt(g);s=s.add(T.pow(i,C).multiply(a.pow(2,C).subtract(g,C),C),C);}print(T.multiply(a.pow(2,C),C).divide(O.subtract(s,C),C).multiply(N.pow(I,C),C).toBigInteger().remainder(BigInteger.TEN).toString());
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLBauMwEL3vV@QoNa5IeluECts4SwNbCxpDoZdlbKuOFltyJaVxEvLt2bFjEh96kj3z3pv3hskUGL9RVXU@67qxLkz@wRewGsKG3fGVMGo3WedgjHJkvfdB1Uwbyoxqw8oEQnksVtOfXIonXcYq1zVUTCZLngrJoCiIpDwZ99Jlwhe96guOWFgTUIk83MXRq92aQpvyxRaKPf/68/tvLN8Syg8EoowenQpbZybA/DYLDvJAsmhBGWSe4JPbugGnUkskK/SXLhRJWGN3JEYQpY/3c37K/KcLJKfHVkheWHza3mLbAx96NfzNMVwJQaFsVxrUWlZvq6Cbak/S6NIZw/hpt9GVIoeRWpRTygfbLT/58Rrel6@SA/rIxMVWSvmHdUSbMNFiPoTmejqlx1LAbXgXGonQW81GBjtXV7WSci98j0l7P7pDXkXglvi6zfKSqs/SOPSBzG8Io4nyRvZD50q4LH81lIPF6HguqsQrosypGrQp8PtW7g6jA64Dzi4Jbu58ns9msx//AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000655) (easy sequence again)

BeanShell is just an interpreted Java with weak typing, so a high byte count is expected. I probably could golf it more by omitting the MathContext in some BigDecimal calls, but this would have to be tested empirically, which, with the probability of introducing inaccuracies for higher inputs is, in my opinion, not worth the risk. Also prints the input for some reason. This is probably unfixable: [input test on TIO](https://tio.run/##S0pNzCvOSM3J@f@/oCgzr0TDM68kNT21SK8gsag4FcjRyEstVwhOTszLSy3SCK4sLknN1cvM09TLS60o0dDU1DbUtP7/39DAwIALAA).

Square root implementation heavily based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306433/5863987), the pi calculation itself on [this Python + mpmath article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/06/03/calculating-pi-with-agm-and-mpmath/).

Answer (score 2):

## 126. [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 156 bytes, [A000655](https://oeis.org/A000655)

```scala
object Main extends App{
	val a=Console.readInt
	if (a == 0) { print(1) }
	else if (a == 1) { print(3) }
	else if (a == 2) { print(5) }
	else { print(4) }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcmxCoMwFAXQOfmKO@pSatUxQ@nUoR/x1CdEwkswQQrit6c4tFm6nhNHcpSzHxYeE15kBfxOLFPEPYRdq40cyDy8RO/4sjJNT0la2RkVwRhca@wIq5VUNTUOrdhFxq@b0u2fvpXuS3@pO@nIuf0A)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000156)

Answer (score 2):

## 128. [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 82 bytes, [A000058](http://oeis.org/A000058)

```
def a
a = { n,i=0G,x=2G -> 
	if (i == n) {
		x
	} else {
		a(n,i+1G,x*x-x+1G)
	}
}
```

The `G`s indicate `BigIntegers`. Simple recursive implementation that counts from `a(0)` to `a(n)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgFAXX/lO8pZZBtWrz23oOIQ0hLCrCiM5u0m6GYeZ9Xa8758l5WLJgPIg6cGt04t6gGUEieMgAZkSFh4RIJF645XC/WVmGuitDlZpUQJVMb972EE9YOaj8AQ)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000082)

Comment: D: you monster! My language! +1

Comment: `a={n,i=0G,x=2G->(i==n)?x:a(n,i+1G,x*x-x+1G)}`. I love groovy so much O_O ;_;. I'd KILL for it to be slightly more competitive.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn JS is basically the same, just shorter but without the arbitrary precision, and Python is basically the same, but longer because of `lambda` and no `?:`

Answer (score 2):

## 135. [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 29 bytes, [A000277](https://oeis.org/A000277)

```
*1*1*1*1*1*1*1+5-*2⌊√+5*4⁰*3⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X8sQGWqb6moZPerpetQxS9tUy@RR4wYtYyDx//9/UwA)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000029)

Answer (score 2):

## 136. [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree), 232 bytes, [A000029](https://oeis.org/A000029)

The program contains unprintable characters, so here is the xxd:

```
00000000: 7573 6520 4d61 7468 3a3a 4e75 6d53 6571  use Math::NumSeq
00000010: 3a3a 546f 7469 656e 743b 7573 6520 504f  ::Totient;use PO
00000020: 5349 583b 246e 203d 2069 6e74 2824 5f29  SIX;$n = int($_)
00000030: 3b69 6628 246e 297b 2474 203d 204d 6174  ;if($n){$t = Mat
00000040: 683a 3a4e 756d 5365 713a 3a54 6f74 6965  h::NumSeq::Totie
00000050: 6e74 2d3e 6e65 7728 293b 666f 7228 2464  nt->new();for($d
00000060: 203d 2031 3b24 6420 3c3d 2024 6e3b 2464   = 1;$d <= $n;$d
00000070: 2b2b 297b 6966 2821 2824 6e20 2520 2464  ++){if(!($n % $d
00000080: 2929 7b24 7320 2b3d 2024 742d 3e69 7468  )){$s += $t->ith
00000090: 2824 6e2f 2464 292a 322a 2a28 2464 293b  ($n/$d)*2**($d);
000000a0: 7d7d 7072 696e 7420 2473 2f28 322a 246e  }}print $s/(2*$n
000000b0: 292b 2824 6e25 322b 3329 2f34 2a32 2a2a  )+($n%2+3)/4*2**
000000c0: 666c 6f6f 7228 246e 2f32 293b 7d65 6c73  floor($n/2);}els
000000d0: 657b 7072 696e 7420 313b 7d65 7869 7423  e{print 1;}exit#
000000e0: 8025 6b1b 0000 0000                      .%k.....
```

The bit at the end is just to have a CRC of 0, the rest is standard perl.

No TIO link because it uses the Math::NumSeq::Totient which isn't installed on TIO.

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000232)

Answer (score 2):

## 140. MATLAB, 918 bytes, [A000052](http://oeis.org/A000052)

```matlab
function q = intToNum(N)
function o = g(N)
n=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10+(0:9),(2:9)*10];
e={'zero';'one';'two';'three';'four';'five';'six';'seven';'eight';'nine';'ten';'eleven';'twelve';'thirteen';'fourteen';'fifteen';'sixteen';'seventeen';'eighteen';'nineteen';'twenty';'thirty';'forty';'fifty';'sixty';'seventy';'eighty';'ninety'};
    if N<=20
      o=e{N+1};
    elseif N<100
      if mod(N,10)==0
        s='';
      else
        s=g(mod(N,10));
      end
      o=strcat(e{(N-mod(N,10))==n},s);
    elseif N<1000
      if mod(N,100)==0
        s='';
      else
        s=g(mod(N,100));
      end
      o=strcat(g(floor(N/100)),'hundred',s);
    elseif N>=1000
      o=strcat(g(floor(N/1000)),'thousand',g(mod(N,1000)));
end
end
[~,I]=sort(arrayfun(@g,0:9,'un', 0));
R=0:9;
R=R(I);
S=10:99;
[~,I]=sort(arrayfun(@g,S,'un',0));
R=[R,S(I)];
S=100:999;
[~,I]=sort(arrayfun(@g,S,'un',0));
R=[R,S(I)];
q=R(N);
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLLTsMwELz3K3yzQxeRlGcpRly55NAeqx6i1kksFRscpxCq8utl7TihEgUJIsU7@5jZyUMvbbYR@31eq6WVWhFNOClYGg0Un8eQwAjO4QIu4Qqu4QbGkMRDFt@OI2AjPE@SeDEZCL6l78JoOqFaCTztq8O2NMJlua6NC3Ljskq@uVNshMIoZFFajEq2xLa4Dl37KtaeZEtprPA1p9ZBmQeEoh1y1IC9eAudfoAoqmzTiTZeMkTUa4Ja02s1nVLT6TR0NxkQvGRO0js@in1CiOZimw6T0BTrSviBJO4GMH3SK5biW4w476qEVJzSScgc7aBRsJ4R9SNq1W@srFlmloktS0@/JjlXO6ii70aOOPmHld@9FCxfa21YeuYngZa1Whmxot8c3fMDS8f5XsCWuq4yhQoHHrCDcm6/u@cf8LjgFX5JlhmTNfhDs4cC8FcFWisKxHueciy4MGWPmM5w/@0YCz@wZy03UOdTmCFt0fIc8e/MF9ws1XNtGaVRtN@75/gE)

[next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000918)

To run properly in matlab, this needs to be saved as `intToNum.m` which is +10 bytes. However, this should also work in Octave with minor modifications (as in the TIO link)

Comment: I was a moment away from posting an answer in Erlang :( IT'S FUNCTIONAL. DO YOU KNOW HOW FRUSTRATING THAT WAS? +1 anyway

Comment: @NieDzejkob yeah sorry about that...at least you'll be set for, oh, I don't know, [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A005589), if Erlang hasn't been used up by then...

Comment: Does `round` round or floor? Because if it rounds then it looks like it will give incorrect results. I always generate the sequence up to a 1000 (or as far as you can reasonably go) and I compare it with the txt files from the OEIS. Did you?

Comment: @NieDzejkob oh good call. I fixed that and a couple things and triple-checked the output. This is definitely correct now (and the spacing allowed me to fudge a bit to keep the byte count the same).

Answer (score 2):

## 141. MOO, 39 bytes, [A000918](//oeis.org/A000918)

```
return $math_utils:pow(2,args[1])-1-1-0
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000039)

Comment: Oh lawd, you get 2^n-2 and give the next person THAT? I've been 1 minute late to the easy party like 9 times on this one. I mean not hard... But difficult in Groovy the one language I wanted to use xD.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Oh come on, it's really not that hard.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I misread it at first I thought it was the number of primes less than `2^n-1`. Still, only sad because groovy is shite at primality.

Comment: Invalid. alephalpha answered it the 66th time.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder fixed

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn but Groovy was used already

Comment: A00039 is a(2*n) for [a(n)=A000025](http://oeis.org/A000025), implemented in Pyth [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133788/67312)

Comment: @NieDzejkob was it by me?!?! *cries*

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn no I took it sorry :P

Comment: I always get MOO and COW confused...

Answer (score 2):

## 142. [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 782 bytes, [A000039](https://oeis.org/A000039)

```erlang
p(N) -> lists:usort([lists:sort(E)||E<-f(p(N,N))] ++ [[N]]).
p(1,_) -> [[1]];
p(N,M) -> 
    Extra = [ [lists:sort(Y++[X])||Y<-p(N-X,M)] || X<-lists:seq(1,N-1)],
    if N == M -> Extra; true -> [[N]|Extra] end.

f([])  -> [];
f([H|T]=L) when is_integer(H),is_list(T) ->
    case is_flat(T) of
        true  -> [lists:flatten(L)];
        false -> f([e(H,E) || E <- T]) 
    end;
f([H|T]) -> f(H) ++ f(T);
f(H)    -> [H].

e(A,B) when is_list(B) -> [A|B];
e(_,B) -> B.

is_flat(L) when is_list(L) -> length([E||E<-L, is_list(E)]) < 2;
is_flat(_) -> true.

rank(P) -> lists:max(P) - length(P).

score(P) -> (1 - abs(rank(P) rem 2)) * 2 - 1.

a(0) -> 1;
a(N) -> lists:sum(lists:map(fun(P) -> score(P) end, p(N))).

main([])-> {ok, [N]} = io:fread("", "~d"),
io:fwrite("~p", [a(2*N)]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBauMwEL37KwafRo0c1rksNM5CAwYfXNNDDilCBG0ip6aJnZUcWlhvfz07kuJsWJ00M2/eeyONNgfV7hNtt6Y59ZdLdMKKQfIDDo3t7ePZdqZHEQJ/z9kw5FlSIwF5xZiEyQSEqKRkU2pO@ca3C5FKOXds/NknIqCTf/ZGwQIE3FO@TiZiLYn3NUuoIVlTi4RhgHWWXGH6FzFXScok90RNDRUsFvDsqD3rHHpz1kG6koPPSdDtbhpFNQrJwNfIE0XFsJKLksHHm26hsZum7fVeGywYp8hp4sq59lpbZbUD1Qfl013t0@54Sc8bfDpIr1ssGemMoFodrDdGwhoLnjM3Ww5ZAiuy5XHk82aMBWzB3MvWpOgqFEFQKiRNpPGJL//5946X4eGfhiWJa9zwkFgSfHRf/tdShq/W7b5/Q5H7ny35rZwzMpPBbH4jCJ/rxiZWo9p3fLnblqP69PHI@EIrEdltZ/QVhikV1U@LY6vRR5gxBg8wo0pKcIXfPDSd0/V@Fe35iKPMCetze@W88dMbcnDry5zsUTWt@3ZC/O7eOdBS/KHNa7rH2mi1wzjmEH/tYsYjl/swTa8x/jpRWiicPVQ0@/Ry@f4X)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000782)

Partition function from [here](http://mijkenator.github.io/2016/04/29/erlang-python-partition-algorithm/).

Answer (score 2):

## 144. [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), 68 bytes, [A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120)

```scm
(define(e n)(cond((< n 1)0)((+(e(fx/ n 2))(remainder n 2)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7CoAwEAWvsuVbJPhpbLyMJC@YwlViCvXyMeAUA9PM5TfudM1vrQiMyQiKKfxhAVjEZNRBgQ5EvPvWkyoy9zVZYP67IT8VZ2YpjztzsiLtNavWDw)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000068)

Comment: +100 rep if someone does the next one in Beatnik

Answer (score 2):

## 145. [Phoenix](https://github.com/senselogic/PHOENIX), 271 bytes, [A000068](http://oeis.org/A000068)

```php
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743570/7605753
function is_prime(n){for(var $i=n>>1;$i&&n%$i--;);return!$i&&n>1;}
$n = readline();
$j = 0;
$k = 1;
while (1) {
 $m = pow($k, 4) + 1;
 if (is_prime($m)) {
  if ($j == $n) {
   echo $k;
   exit();
  }
  $j += 1;
 }
 $k += 1;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RboMwDEXf8xWellWJui4gYGiL6K9MiAXhAg4KaalU8e0spNIeLPseX/l66qwhvG/ba@f9NH8rNfu66e3NuHawy0djR1Wr7KvMs6JMVPmZFGWRsfZKjUdLgPPP5HA0guSjtU7cagccKzqfU83xcKA3jqeTltoZf3X0ElnYrYwTVOBM/TsgGSE145cAktD70FPNlg4HAyKV8GDAxwAnuwjev0Mu4bg7AFsQ/x/wUUZrpPuxCjg9CZims8B7Hec7@j0PYA0VjMcYt6sQ/RTrtuV/)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000271)

Answer (score 2):

## 146. [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/), 121 bytes, [A000271](http://oeis.org/A000271)

```lisp
(de a (n) (cond ((= n 0) 1) ((< n 3) 0) ((< n 4) 1) (T (+ (* (- n 1) (a (- n 2))) (* (- n 1) (a (- n 1))) (a (- n 3))))))
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000121)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclBDkAwEIXhq7zlGyJBxYpbuECDRROZNrh/tWppVv/7JrjVH@4KMXLbYUEVcPW6gZyhaAVdEk6pjeRZeii@gDVYgU2yDLZkLyJ/3r3@DSPvRYbT6X1ofoxpPw)

I also implemented [A000179](http://oeis.org/A000179) in PicoLisp to try and do sums on it, but this was faster.

I'm running out of Lisp variants to work on!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lisp-family_programming_languages

Comment: @Stephen I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

## 147. [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 695 bytes, [A000121](http://oeis.org/A000121)

```
defmodule A do
 def p(n) do p(n,n,[]) end
 def l(t,m,s) when m > 1 do p(t,m-1,s) end
 def l(_,_,_) do [] end
 def r(t,m,s) when m <= t do p(t-m,m,[m]++s) end
 def r(_,_,_) do [] end
 def p(0,_,s) do [s] end
 def p(t,m,s) do l(t,m,s) ++ r(t,m,s) end

 def f(n) do f(n,[1,1]) end
 def f(n,l) do
  if Enum.at(l, -1) >= n do l else
   f(n, l ++ [Enum.at(l, -1) + Enum.at(l, -2)])
  end
 end

 def n(l) do
  Enum.sum Enum.map(l,fn n -> if n == 1 do 1 else 0 end end)
 end

 def a(0) do 1 end
 def a(n) do
  fb = f(n)
  score = fn l -> if length(l -- fb) == 0 do if n(l) == 1 do 2 else 1 end else 0 end end
  Enum.sum Enum.map(p(n), score)
 end
end

{n,_} = Integer.parse IO.gets("")
IO.inspect A.a(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLNioMwEL73KYaeEoxiutdV6KGHnvYBRIpbYyskUzEpu7Dss7uTxG5t2UVCMjNfvp@g0v1nP05Tqzpzaa9awRbaywqohoEhp8LvAkVVc1DYxpFmThhhOXycFYKBEmREUjuVfrCAHgR9gamq7/3xieK1ADdzpIYmlamTZEk0/kM0sJz6Nvbtw2BWoMGv4SS5K3tkhHZzVNpFJYVcZvU9zcOrQN/BDq8maxzTAlLJoSwAgwAobRVBAp5KEqqesMnD5Q2vOeGDzt0JsptWwNqriQfTDHSrQ1JLS@8DoSjiq8sgDbln8Ysv@RqW8xl0C9TEsCTRvUMRstPZHi@j8iWS@SihFZ7cmVGZEpR7wdxz9bPNm4FNNCCjgQcvf@bwP5aIgrPX4PcLxeGbHOzRqZMas6EZiWr/lp2Us2y95is692gHdXSwzXyMaZIvPw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000695)

Answer (score 2):

## 153. [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 1344 bytes, [A000136](https://oeis.org/A000136)

```
  Find the index of e in the list by comparing the elements with c
 e Element cElement Element➡➡
  i⏩0 c eii
  ⚡
 


☯
  Checks whether a permutation is a possible way to fold stamps
 p➡
  k⏩0➖p 1
   r⏭k 2➖p 1 2
    cab➡a b
    Ap k c
    Bp r c
    Cp➕k 1 c
    Dp➕r 1 c
    ◀A B◀B C◀C D◀B C◀C D◀D A◀C D◀D A◀A B◀D A◀A B◀B C
   
  
  
 

  Iterates over the permutations
 n➡
  an
  cn
  i⏩0 n
   a i i
   c i 0
  

  i 0
  r 1
  ◀i n
   ◀c i i
    j 0
    i 2 1jc i
    ta j
    a ja i
    a i t
    ☯a➕r 1
    c i➕1c i
    i 0
   
    c i 0
    ➕i 1
   
  
  r
 



 i10
  ☯➕1 i 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTdatswFL7vU5xHSHKz6/xssMdQHHVRnNjG1tb1ri2MkG52POZ2IYWYwkhXWLMOBoXBXsZP4DfIzpEsWxnbhSTr@6Qjfec7Mp/5E@H4I77fl3n6vszjr9jmR1DmH3/CC@GNQI454Mjfgn8M9KmQqYgkDE/B8WcBC4X3SqF8ymfckxGcCDkGh8Kk12WeJRyeawocim8m1VhsbvG8D8gs1Gf8rczXF/oiGCK7EMXyvoWxMmxXhCMaX2J7cIDj8Avx38QJIrEl9LGgpiLESbG@pdvgXHXYp/Ni9d0S2x9zx8WbjzkqCYFBwMPZa8mk8D0QEQF@FInhlMMJOwXpw7E/HUEk2SyIlNK5VvvuR6DzmK5JRiPOqHFJTbG5JkEBtCtGUWGxfMBNOxc6zQLomCWkYKsyyCj08DB@UuarGwbDSrZe3dXpyZIAXHKkgnsNHFpwv4aLzZWLRzfUwKZCm0IjkoXVaH5ZfD7rQg/7HvSx78PAYmoM@wF0LabG9H6LqTG93xiN2hMjuPHb2I5sXPle2fxS8pBJHoH/Bl2morV8PvTx0avza1VjvMXcZ0@2xTjeeUe1O/8jqzoGr3E8fWIgQJiJg5OWUaDHXY3sMOk6zjmmQNhhYkqQeQcURNgVs5uoEMar1Q1VmICOLj21wNp7UD3SEAwmFUhXnjSwsGAB0jonvqe3gI@MmWN04VgHKMWItq3z61tr4VA95E@WoiZReiVGECo3/6iA8K9nvzw3b17dcSu0R@RZhkbTLyH7Qq3dqi1fnWlSKXpERXRlvEG7ZQXf75/9AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001344)

I was going to use something esoteric, but then I changed my mind. Pretty self explanatory, I don't think an explanation is necessary.

**Note**: for inputs larger than 7, you have to specify a heap size larger than 512 MB during the compilation of the Real-Time Engine. For example, use `cmake .. -DheapSize=1073741824` for 1 GB. If you run out of heap space, the VM segfaults, probably because someone does not check for NULL after malloc.

**Edit:** make this faster and less memory-hungry. Now I wonder whether the garbage collector is working properly

**Edit almost 2 months later:** this code had to work around a bug in the implementation of the ⏩ type. Now that this bug is fixed and TIO updated, I had to offset the range parameters again. I also managed to add some comments, all while keeping the bytecount the same.

Comment: It segfaults for `n=7`? oookay.

Comment: ... which makes this answer invalid.

Comment: @ppperry "fixed"

Comment: This isn't at all self-explanatory.

Comment: `I was going to use something esoteric` o_o You don't consider *Emojicode* esoteric?!

Comment: @INCOMING *Emoji* (the stack based language) is definitely esoteric, but Emojicode is object oriented and stuff. Believe it or not, but there is real software written in Emojicode, ~~in contrast to Haskell~~.

Comment: @NieDzejkob So Emojicode is a "normal" language with esoteric syntax?

Comment: @KSmarts I'd say "uncommon" and it's more about the vocabulary rather than syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## 157. [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 376 bytes, [A002466](https://oeis.org/A002466)

```
int f(int n)
{
    int i = 0, s[100] = {0};
    s[0] = 1;
    s[1] = 1;
    s[2] = 2;

    while (i < 97) {
        if ((i % 5) == 3) {
            s[3+i] = s[i] + s[2+i];
        }
        else if ((i % 5) == 4) {     
            s[3+i] = s[1+i] + s[2+i];
        }
        else {
            s[3+i] = s[i] + s[1+i] + s[2+i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    return s[n];
}
```

It's like an obnoxious Fibonacci! 0-indexed.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000376)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBCsIwDEDv@4qgCC1VWTdFZM4fGR5k6zQwq6wTD6PfPtMWRQXRHtq8JH0tKWeHshzGqMvmWinYmK7C8/y4HVB3UDO3ax71EdBygJBDPAVTyDjeUdzHNvNFU3iWD5JvlDhKssjj7YiNAoawgfWKQ5D7B2pglJ7AkkOeQ/paC55UoDOZgg7hvMTZs8c@I9UY9albkM4Xvzml@Mf660s/LShESNswjlZ111bTBU3tdjjtUTPeX1oad81Gk2o0rZmUnGd2uAM)

The function for this sequence said this:

```
a(1) = a(2) = 1, a(3) = 2, a(5*k+2) = a(5*k+1) + a(5*k-1), a(5*k+3) = a(5*k+2) + a(5*k+1), a(5*k+b) = a(5*k+b-1) + a(5*k+b-2) + a(5*k+b-3) for b=-1,0,1
```

It's completely unhelpful. However, I noticed that the integers in the sequence were usually the previous three terms added together, but more obnoxious. Here's my work:

```
1.  1,    1,    2    -> 4    (ok)
2.  1,    2,    4    -> 7    (ok)
3.  2,    4,    7    -> 13   (ok)
4.  4,    7,    13   -> 17   (no) sum does not include second value
5.  7,    13,   17   -> 30   (no) sum does not include first value
6.  13,   17,   30   -> 60   (ok)
7.  17,   30,   60   -> 107  (ok)
8.  30,   60,   107  -> 197  (ok)
9.  60,   107,  197  -> 257  (no) sum does not include second value
10. 107,  197,  257  -> 454  (no) sum does not include first value
11. 197,  257,  454  -> 908  (ok)
12. 257,  454,  908  -> 1619 (ok)
13. 454,  908,  1619 -> 2981 (ok)
14. 908,  1619, 2981 -> 3889 (no) sum does not include second value
15. 1619, 2981, 3889 -> 6870 (no) sum does not include first value
```

So for each five terms, the last two would be calculated differently. The modulo's and `if`-statements in the `while` loop of the code handle that.

Comment: Isn't next-seq a PPCG challenge lol

Comment: It's a casewise formula. E.g. `a(5*k+2) = a(5*k+1) + a(5*k-1)` says that if `n % 5 == 2` then `a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-3)`.

Comment: And this code doesn't calculate it correctly. Input 10 should give 197 and gives 137.

Comment: Guessing the formula was a very bad idea... should I edit to correct this or make it a new answer? After all, the order is already ruined... @PeterTaylor what do you think?

Comment: @NieDzejkob, the explanation of what it *should* do matches up with the formula given in OEIS: the problem is that the code doesn't implement it. MD XF can almost certainly fix it without changing the byte count, although it might be necessary to muck around with whitespace to achieve that.

Comment: There's also the problem of segfaulting for n > 100 - keep only the last 3 numbers or allocate this array dynamically

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed it, now calculates correctly.

Comment: The posted code is not the same as the code in the test link, and moreover it doesn't fix the out-of-bounds array access pointed out by Nie.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fixed. And after index 37, `int` won't be large enough to store the values, so it won't work anyway.

Comment: Since now different compilers are considered different languages, you should declare what compiler this uses. Just some formal stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## 161. [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 208 bytes, [A000315](https://oeis.org/A000315)

```ruby
size = gets.chomp.to_i
puts (1..size).to_a.permutation.to_a.permutation(size).to_a.select{|x| x.transpose.all? {|y| y.uniq.size == y.size} and x[0].sort == x[0] and x.transpose[0].sort == x.transpose[0]}.size
```

Note that this is an extremely slow implementation. I might make a faster one eventually and post it as a side note (so as to not change the bytecount)

Also, this is my first Ruby program :D

[Try it on Repl.it!](https://repl.it/LSo3/16)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000208)

Answer (score 2):

## 162. [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 448 bytes, [A000208](https://oeis.org/A000208)

This is the third time that I've implemented A000013 in this challenge.

```julia
function EulerPhi(n)
  x = 0
  for i = 1:n
    if gcd(i,n) == 1
      x = x + 1
    end
  end
  return x
end

function A000013(n)
  if n <= 1
    return 1
  end
  x = 0
  for d = 1:n
    if n/d == n÷d
      x = x + (EulerPhi(2*d) * 2^(n/d))/(2*n)
    end
  end
  return x
end

function A000208(n)
  x = 0
  if n <= 1
    x = 1
  elseif n/2 == n÷2
    x = (A000013(2*n) + A000013(n)) / 2
  else
    x = A000013(2*n) / 2
  end
  return Int(x)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBbsIwEEX3OcVfegJSEiNVCMGCBYvuOEGlCidgFA3IJFJu1gNwsHScOC7pCi9sz/jP/De@trX9/uj7quVTY2@MQ1uX7nixiikBOuyQy1ndHKzciw1LBNgK55NRdsmEnaSH5CjvsAhxySaZdlc2rWN0iQ@T6LbPZRWr0UyaMrZTt1BRxBavLGbOwpnxGPz8Mf9IVJxHp4aQQn8pURNlkhhc3@bU@Xr@KXNenx1g60c5IOmApOOzmsb11gL3Nz0hgw7FUT5Th/dXyE9uVEeeFOjvzko4cRYrov4X)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000448)

Comment: doesn't Julia have a mod operator? It's probably `%`, but I get that using `÷` is fun, too!

Answer (score 2):

## 164. [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 1000 bytes, [A000227](https://oeis.org/A000227)

```
$0:R_e^$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XAKig@NU5FU2EUjIJRMFzB//8GAA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A001000)

### Explanation

```
$0           0-indexed
  :          Mode: Sequence - output whole sequence, or nth item for input n
   R    )    Round - closing paren added if absent
    _e^$     e to the power of the current index
             Spaces for padding
```

Comment: I really like the next sequence!

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or is the formula for the next sequence completely incorrect?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm getting completely wrong answers too, so I'm guessing there's a mistake in the formula.

Comment: somebody had better tell David Wilson...

Comment: @Giuseppe is there a way to contact users of the OEIS?

Comment: @NieDzejkob yeah but you have to be a user yourself

Answer (score 2):

## 165. [Forth](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 114 bytes, [A001000](https://oeis.org/A001000)

```
: C 4 * 5 - s>f fsqrt f>s ;
: A 1+ dup 2 < IF 1+ ELSE dup dup * swap dup C dup dup * 4 / 1+ -rot * -1 * + + THEN ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITvPsUctTW6CRWh1UKpEQPFCPVeBIneqknFx68bvbjL/nzDsuN6P9zFzcUxTmG1aVERSSLCFmrOsJYcmI05amRIsIJAKB1cePoBrgwoJjkqyBTX1wMKG5h9JN20@ivFShDel99a/4kZlvFU@H5gEpJbynk@6CMKtuxA2FkY/r9AY@2JzRShGz8)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000114)

This could have been golfed to 106 by moving `C` into the function `A`, but that OEIS sequence looked harder for the next person. Or it grew faster, anyway.

#### Explanation:

In the previous answer, people were unsure of the algorithm for this one. It looked difficult, but the OEIS page stated: "This is the same sequence (apart from the initial term) as [A071111](https://oeis.org/A071111)." So, I used that sequence, then used an `IF THEN ELSE` to output `2` if the input is `1`.

I added one at the beginning of the function because the sequence has an offset of one. This makes it zero-indexed.

The algorithm:

```
a(n) = n^2 - n*c(n) + floor(c(n)^2/4) + 1, where c(n) = floor(sqrt(4n-5))
```

The comments on the page for A071111 also state the results for `a(100)` and `a(1000)`, and mine are the same.

Answer (score 2):

## 169. [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), 84 bytes, [A000261](https://oeis.org/A000261)

```scm
(define (a n)
(if (< n 1)
 n 
 (+ (* (+ n 1) (a (- n 1))) (* (- n 2) (a (- n 2))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoAgDER3vqLjVcMgiZs/Y7RGBhuCLPrzSFns8HL3rvd2yiW@8a0VuxxRhbCSskM8CAspTewaHWEkDEZT9gTfI3P3VsLvA/erSFlKeXzKUYutc5Mf)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000084)

Comment: Note that you *could* hardcode the next sequence since there are 1000 terms. However, might want to wait until everybody gives up...

Comment: @icrieverytim I don't think anybody will give up, the next sequence, while it looks intimidating, is relatively straightforward.

Comment: I tried the next sequence once and it was not particularly easy. I never got around to finishing because a 3-chain of answers got deleted because of an integer precision issue with a Java-based language.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino why wasn't that answer just fixed?

Answer (score 2):

## 170. [Python 3 (PyPy)](https://docs.python.org/3/), 204 bytes, [A000084](https://oeis.org/A000084)

```python
n=int(input())+1
a=[0,1,1,2]
p=[0,1,3,7]
for m in range(4,n+1):s=sum([d*a[d]for d in range(1,m)if m%d==0]);u=p[m-1]+2*sum([p[k]*a[m-k]for k in range(1,m-1)])+s;a+=[u//m];p+=[s+u]
print(2*a[n]if n>1else 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5BCoMwEAXQvafIppAYxYwtFCrpRcIshGgbbMZgzKKnt9EuSpnNX/w3/PBenzOdt420o5U7CmnlQkgoem1UBflaLMI3n6srFuO8MM8csaWnx8AvFUkQt6hj8tzYsjcW94r9VaDywo3Mn6zWCkWXdDC@BpRteaBgJszO19Mhpz9Zg0AhY9dLbVLTeOxCTlGmvGrZJ7eZEub/dIfhFQcGYttAKfUB)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000204)

4 Pythons down, 2 to go. Wait, there's Python 0 but no one used it in the first 150 answers. 3 to go.

Ported the second Maple program for [A000669](https://oeis.org/A000669). Next sequence is Lucas numbers - as easy as Fibonacci, but nicer.

Answer (score 2):

## 172. [Python 1](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/), 55 bytes, [A000541](https://oeis.org/A000541)

```python
S=0
for s in range(-~input()):S=S+s*s*s*s*s*s*s
print S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/zvbKukpPQ/2NaAKy2/SKFYITNPoSgxLz1VQ7cuM6@gtERDU9Mq2DZYu1gLCXIVFGXmlSgE/wfqtU6tSE1WKs/IzElVcLYCcRSclf4bcBlyGXEZc5lwmXKZcZkDAA)

Next Sequence: [A000055](http://oeis.org/A000055)

Answer (score 2):

## 173. [Python 2 (IronPython)](http://ironpython.net), 257 bytes, [A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055)

```python
c={0:0,1:1}
def b(n):
 if n not in c:c[n]=sum([sum([d*b(d)for d in range(1,j+1)if j%d==0])*b(n-j)for j in range(1,n)])//(n-1)
 return c[n]
def a(n):return 1if n==0 else b(n)-(sum([b(k)*b(n-k)for k in range(n)])-(b(n//2)if n%2==0 else 0))//2
print a(input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwEEX3nGI2Jh2F0LIk4SSEBdCiBR1IKQtjPDtOq1E3XfT/ee8vd3@Zqcism2nf@@ohS5mqUj0TbQboBGGZgB2AgGYPlqAv@5qaat1uoo6PPnZC4zA70CF3LZ2NUOl4Ush340FXlWyQS5SNsTb@1wgbzHPOFCbgjN8cK1gQ9W3Qfz5VGMEoMNfVxGGZiP5OTG/6FOnTjx7YmeAoz4uwhQ7FFyCRtUWyOEuePZaWzQvEfVdSyhc)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000257)

2 versions of Python on the wall, 2 versions of Python. Take one down and pass it around, 1 version of Python on the wall.

Caches the results of `b` because it seemed like it would take forever to compute for big n without it. Didn't test whether it does anything useful, but it probably does.

Answer (score 2):

## 176. JavaScript (ES6), 184 bytes, [A000122](https://oeis.org/A000122)

```javascript
function A000122(n) {
 if (n === 0) { return 1; }
 squares = [];
 for (i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
  squares.push(i*i);
 }
 if (~squares.indexOf(n)) {
  return 2;
 } else {
  return 0;
 }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NDsIgEITvfYo5Uo0NxWPl4BP4AMZD04LSNFChGBODr470L/G2szs7X6arX7VrrBrGgzatiFF63YzKaJwppSVjROf4ZFASRINzDpo0rBi91SgrhAzu6WsrHDiutyqDNBZEJUUrKJw4jiwN@/2cs5mLwbsHUTuVp4@w5H@3m9KteF9kQi8/K41NVojeif8tnQNCnLHdgu0mbJkKpHEFN0Y704uiN3eyVevyRA/xBw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000184)

Answer (score 2):

## 188. [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 105 bytes, [A000321](http://oeis.org/A000321)

```
def a
a = { n -> 
	if (n == 0G) { 1 }
	else if (n == 1G) { -1 }
	else {
		-a(n-1G)-2G*(n-1G)*a(n-2G)
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/JTVNIZErUcFWoVohT0HXToGLMzNNQSNPwdZWwcBdEyhqqFDLxZmaU5yqAJcwBEvoImSquTg5dRM18nSBMrpG7loQlhZIxMhdk4uzlqv2f0FRZl6JQqKGkZnmfwA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000105)

Comment: Oh c'mon, not this "sequence sans formula" stuff again...

Comment: @icrieverytim read der papers

Comment: a) There's so *many* papers and b) I don't understand half the stuff they have there. :P

Comment: Nooo, I was writing a solution in Shakespeare... whatever.

Comment: @icrieverytim There's a mathematica program; perhaps that could be decoded to get a useful formula

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Free_polyominoes_enumeration Pick a language, any language, no need for cri

Answer (score 2):

## 189. [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 1182 bytes, [A000105](http://oeis.org/A000105)

Three parts - the function (824 bytes) + comparer class used in function (273 bytes) + imports (85 bytes)

```cs
n=>{var t=new Func<P,P>[]{p=>new P(p.Y,-p.X),p=>new P(-p.X,-p.Y),p=>new P(-p.Y,p.X),p=>new P(-p.X,p.Y),p=>new P(-p.Y,-p.X),p=>new P(p.X,-p.Y),p=>new P(p.Y,p.X)};Func<P[],P[][]>r=l=>new[]{l}.Concat(new int[7].Select((x,i)=>l.Select(p=>t[i](p)).ToArray())).ToArray();Func<int,P[][]>k=null;k=a=>a<2?new[]{new[]{new P(0,0)}}:k(a-1).SelectMany(l=>l.SelectMany(p=>new[]{new P(p.X-1,p.Y),new P(p.X+1,p.Y),new P(p.X,p.Y-1),new P(p.X,p.Y+1)}).Where(p=>!l.Contains(p)).Distinct().Select(p=>r(l.Concat(new[]{p}).ToArray()).Select(o=>o.Select(c=>new P(c.X-o.Select(q=>q.X).Min(),c.Y-o.Select(q=>q.Y).Min())).OrderBy(q=>q.X).ThenBy(q=>q.Y).ToArray()).Aggregate((m,o)=>(m==null||string.Concat(o.Select(x=>$"({x.X},{x.Y})")).CompareTo(string.Concat(m.Select(x=>$"({x.X},{x.Y})")))<0?o:m)))).Distinct(new C()).ToArray();return k(n).Length;}

class C:IEqualityComparer<P[]>{public bool Equals(P[] f,P[] s)=>f==s?1>0:(f==null|s==null)?1<0:f.OrderBy(p=>p.X).ThenBy(p=>p.Y).Zip(s.OrderBy(p=>p.X).ThenBy(p=>p.Y),(a,b)=>a==b).All(x=>x);public int GetHashCode(P[]l)=>l.Aggregate(0,(a,b)=>a.GetHashCode()^b.GetHashCode());}

using System.Collections.Generic;using P=System.Windows.Point;namespace System.Linq{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTtbts2FP3Pp2CCoSARhbO7dm1tU0HibW2BBjPaAKlneAAt0zYRmpJJuonh6NXnXerDldJg0w@KvDw89/sm7jxxyWHrlFniLzvn5ZoNU61l4lVqHHsvjbQq6aMSMeIV5laZeXrv2ChVxvcRMmItXSYSWZN8UmaD9gjDl2jhHL4s9nuEyuOw9/H3zVZo5XfDdJ0JK@1gNJnG@2w70yrBszTVuEA4AnK8iMLqKI8XnLuLbtzpEdiZrdaPrvzTi@6g01uwP@1c2qsdyXicsa@U3aykqY9jyv5SGXH/A4qIiGagS3A@o@xSa/LA4wfar4wDn/F76T8ItxqmcxkM1IDW7HK5tHIpvCSdIwVrIunfs/aZ9nOEkPPCA@@3VM3xtVCG0CJaZcRw4/tja5IBqI@CDTFeYH4wPN5/ExZ7buR9CRhFo3gy3YMzQTQi4FJ0HtyMjqJwDLJxWzaOnoE9g3rC9gxZzZX3S5Mm05BByLDlusCAgTqHYjOJ8CS8AY8mb6bsiwzVR8hDpIqYVmcg9hM1JRmFZKWX1oodRK@x7x9jU@q5K4qif8cFJGHw8qJUeVzBxE7UoXneuyPivEsrPdfC7Ij@rrc4Z7XBR2/Pu2VUjoKzp4JwBNq24KxLc8puV9LKQHqig/8eEu4Kv35TzisDztKG15boRpRCWvNmBGpkyuO03id1EhKw9Cjd8HgTSv061FeUgHntq3F1BZx1d9RPqu6oYQ3t3yuerKMUEkbWVVc@Om9hZtS2H3VBJ/10SvYP7GsewTrO6SnwVEPgJiXtZ@v/fEYHnYu0t6a0Gbzg@pC0SsNKv7UG3xFD2Sdpln7Vzw8wtpqtVeqFKsy2MNGaN/crpSUmpLjCHINpLtWSfZZiDnMudDE@4Th4jV@8KBmC4PSUtnjarRy@MEgMMMKfjYR1stTBbqxah9nww4Na9a1VXha6F@DTE2CO2rsc5YcO6qKX6Bf0Cr1Gv6I36C16h7qdf5KFFkt3@NnKBdSkSWSvmuxXwkk21/pf)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A001182)

I accidentaly deleted the extended version after I golfed it.... Also the code has 2 unneeded spaces added because [A001180](http://oeis.org/A001180) was not fun.

Answer (score 2):

## 193. [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 160 bytes, [A000326](https://oeis.org/A000326)

```
HODOR! = HoDoRHoDoR( HODOR? ) {
	HOdor!!!(HODOR? == 0)
	HODOR:: 0;
	HODOR = 1;
	Hodor! = 2;
	hodor = 3;
	HODOR:: HODOR? * (hodor * HODOR? - HODOR ) / Hodor! ;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY@xDoMwDETn8hUXqYMNakvpRohYGLJF4hs6sEXqivj21EmMWKy7c/Jsb/Ebfyn5sITVwMHHJa6lEEo4g7E3Nx/knTGGNHQOPedY3Diit6oF8c46YzNvELNlI/pjrw@KaUG1257JowqZ@oJSbHPUBfcDdK@E2pM9ZPSpJwyX6TpGQT@lkt5H2mROfw)
[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000160)

It's a little inefficient, but please don't hold it against Hodor. He is a little slow, but he's a beautiful gentle giant.

Answer (score 2):

## 202. [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 50 bytes, [A000213](https://oeis.org/A000213)

```
bc+d+$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$111
```

`$`s are filler.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z8pWTtFW4VoYGho@P//f1MA)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000050)

Comment: dagnabbit, I had a Cubix solution all ready, I just needed one pad byte to get to 53 :(

Answer (score 2):

## 209. APL (Dyalog), 100 bytes, [A000075](http://oeis.org/A000075)

```
{
    dims ← 1 + 2 * ⍵
    table ← ∘.{+/2 3×⍺ ⍵*2}⍨ ⍳dims
    uniq ← ∪ (dims*2)⍴ table
    +/ (××(2*⍵)≥⊢) uniq
}
```

using `⎕IO←0`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLjSgGQ1F2dKZm6xApCpYKigrWCkoKXwqHcrF2dJYlJOKlj4UccMvWptfSMF48PTH/XuAklrGdU@6l0BZG0GaebiLM3LLISqXaWgARLTMtJ81LtFAWwKF6e2voLG4emHp2sYaQF1az7qXPqoa5GmAkgbV@3//2kKh1YAzTI0AAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000100)

Comment: Ugh. I was about to test [this](https://tio.run/##dU@7CsMwDNz9FYI@hgS3kry0xoh@iMlQSD0Eipc6FPLvrpuQkAw5EKdD6E56tq/PO7T6ftPxO7Y5JwBI7FQhqMCP7EGPDEBKzuTFDrAgRaKaAhGs4DZCJcbOHB08LoE2owJJSjpC7qIEwtALUSwVuKrspDF4bc1pmPOYSx7z4r5xa2AHYq7IHIU52KrHcnGNFNO83UT8v4H7b6ysDhMfXJOzUT8). I think this is the theme of this challenge.

Comment: @NieDzejkob yea, was hit the same way a few times. they should have set some way to reserve spots

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some other [answer-chaining] question do that.

Answer (score 2):

## 212. [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 79 bytes, [A000078](http://oeis.org/A000078)

```javascript
a = n => n < 3 ? 0 : n == 3 ? 1 : a(--n) + a(--n) + a(--n) + a(--n)

// balloon
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxDsIwFEP3nMJjoii0FRsQOMunBBQI@VWCkKqKs4dfdjzYfh58pzfVscTp5eoUL6E8OT/C3BrBI8MfxQ7Y4oQeu3XwPxgESDuXDezfolTX4UwpMed25QId5bTfI8rlsKa1BouCaORcOYVN4psmHY1Rn/YF)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000079)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder he copypasted the codegolf submission from TIO to edit it later. Common practice if you don't want to get ninjad

Comment: Give a guy some time. :P

Comment: I was just looking at the code snippet, and it looks like Groovy has already been used twice.

Comment: @KSmarts Oops...

Answer (score 2):

## 213. [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 117 bytes, [A000079](http://oeis.org/A000079)

```
v   v2<
    * \
    \ -  did you know that comments in befunge start and end with nothing?
      1
>&1\>:|
      >$.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwFAX3OcVbFBdCCkqRtpS0B8kmNqkJxZ9Sv4rQu6cSXTzmzWZa9xqpc/Jylp8l35QmAFN9EytQQmdqSMAGiyWOeFOcwd4wnrHvHfGAQGi3FAY2X4YhC7duDuxBkX2g7p5TQCVUUWl1/e2uDsdHSs1J/AE)

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000117)

Comment: Wait, I thought it was one of these selfreferential sequences like "OEIS sequences that contain their own index number"

Comment: lol no meta sequences pls

Answer (score 2):

## 214. [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 383 bytes, [A000117](http://oeis.org/A000117)

Because of sequence relationships, I've implemented A000013 four times now.

```julia
function EulerPhi(n)
  x = 0
  for i = 1:n
    if gcd(i,n) == 1
      x = x + 1
    end
  end
  return x
end

function A000013(n)
  if n <= 1
    return 1
  end
  x = 0
  for d = 1:n
    if n/d == n÷d
      x = x + (EulerPhi(2*d) * 2^(n/d))/(2*n)
    end
  end
  return x
end

function A000011(n)
  return (A000013(n) + 2^(n÷2))/2
end

function A000117(n)
  return A000011(2*n)
end
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000383)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NDoIwEIX3PcUsWzSB1oWJkYUL957AxFDQGjKQhibcjANwsDr8FMW4sYt2ZvLmva9PV5qb94XDrDEVwtmVub08DEfBAFpIIaG3qCwYquUBqQMwBdwzzc0WBaQ0HoeTvIXN3OeoWbht3jiL0LKhZUvaKaEjd1MYmSIcg9u8IReLTxa9ZsFYDxjYd/qLhC//UZEWEIG6clILEdNgTP2DU06cs4a/4Slo8O07Rcbqx66U@9Vu8BsZSO5ra7DhQSrJx78A)

Comment: ...Dammit, all these n-nacci sequences and I can't answer. ;-; 37 minutes left...

Comment: @icrieverytim I was well on my way with a Funciton tetranacci when you posted yours. Serves you right.

Answer (score 2):

## 215. [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 95 bytes, [A000383](http://oeis.org/A000383)

```
'this is just a random string for padding aagghhhh need at least 80 chars!'xT6Y"i:"t-5:0)sh]GQ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X70kI7NYAYiySotLFBIVihLzUvJzFYpLijLz0hXS8osUChJTUkDsxMT09AwgUMhLTU1RSCxRyElNBGqxMFBIzkgsKlZUrwgxi1TKtFIq0TW1MtAszoh1D9T8/9/QAAA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000095)

```
'...'x                 string and delete from stack
T6Y"                   push 6 ones
i:"                    iterate user input number of times
   t-5:0)sh            dup, index last 6, sum, horzcat
           ]           end loop
            GQ)        copy user input, increment, index (return)
```

Comment: Sorry @NieDzejkob :( but you couldn't have answered anyway, your hour wasn't up!

Comment: Yeah, right. And you ninjad me by 4 minutes anyway. I just didn't notice your answer and then after posting mine, the page reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

## 219. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 127 bytes, [A000702](https://oeis.org/A000702)

```
load("ratpow")$
p(n):=num_partitions(n);
q(n):=ratp_dense_coeffs( product(1+x^(2*k-1),k,1,n) ,x)[n];
a(n):=(p(n+2)+3*q(n+3))/2;
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000127)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLDoIwEEX3fAUhLmZojVB2Nn6JUTKhJWmgD2mJ@PUV2N57zrG0GUs5z54UVAul4L8VXooADu8Pt9o@0JJMMt7FfZLF5zwOsFfaRd0PXo9jhDIsXq1DgpZtbxD1dG2RT7zlDku@4dO9ZEGnC3ubCWRdvbdYh3gTMisTw0w/sDTp2cQEB8sdb7hoEGX@Aw)

This uses the first formula on the OEIS page, with a built-in for *p* and the generating function for *q*. It's basically the same as the Mathematica code.

Answer (score 2):

## 220. [Visual Basic .NET (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 107 bytes, [A000127](https://oeis.org/A000127)

```vb
Function A000172(n As Integer) As Integer
n += 1
Return(n^4 - 6*n^3 + 23*n^2 - 18*n + 24) / 24
End Function
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BCsIwEETPyVfMsVWqaRX10oOIoqAeVPBWsO0igbCBNBX/PqaI4GV5M@zuMK86a6yjcLJtbwh7MsZKce1rnB6ak1QKsbMOGiUUbhaFio7YWO6socndaU9HzZSslVL5skh0Opyc6e2l2HKL@Cnsem68tozfUqQOB/b0JJf@sWSMS@TyQr53nHA1R4bFiKsZxihmEYpo5KsRD3qeYhqnHGJ@EWEQ3y7hAw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000107)

Note that the implementation of VB.NET on TIO does not have BigIntegers (I tried it and it wants a .dll) so I can use `You can assume that neither the input nor the required output will be outside your languages numerical range, but please don't abuse this by choosing a language that can only use the number 1, for example`.

Comment: Maple and Mathematica for the next sequence seem to be using a formula not mentioned in the formula section.

Comment: Why do so many of the sequences'  formula sections say `G.f. A(x) = Sum_{n>=1} a(n)*x^n = x / Product_{n>=1} (1-x^n)^a(n)`? That's a definition of the generating function. It's not helpful.

Comment: @KSmarts The first equation does nothing but implicitly saying that the first value is zero and introducing the name `a`, but the second is unique to this sequence. It allows to incrementally compute the series. If you see it many times maybe that is because A000081 appears so often...

Answer (score 2):

## 234. [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 512 bytes, [A000141](https://oeis.org/A000141)

```rust
fn a(n: i64) -> i64 {
    let mut ret = 0;

    for a in !n..-!n {
        for b in !n..-!n {
            for c in !n..-!n {
                for d in !n..-!n {
                    for e in !n..-!n {
                        for f in !n..-!n {
                            if a * a + b * b + c * c + d * d + e * e + f * f == n {
                                ret += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBDoIwDL3vKwon2IRAYjxI8F9QWbIEq5lwIvt2bIVFjQra5KVb30vXdrXdtR0GjVBFuAWzWceQ7NhDL4CsqVs4dS1Y8iVkhbhH9dlCBQYhwDRNApzEntp/pjx9@E57yXFe4mX1ssxL9W9SNqOpOUlQ1IkkKCpZEhTVJQmKHpYERVkloSxhKScbz1CVkBezSif@Y96jr5HHbTy58QupmM4iu0I4XoBTZTCKpzZ4YoYnlqVpnj31drEG2waDKOxduKKtMXE8pXXDDQ)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000512)

Nice byte count, eh?

Comment: I know how to code the next sequence, but idk what language to do it in :(

Comment: @HusnainRaza I posted a bruteforce solution with a broken equivalence checker in Squirrel (the embeddability of Lua, typing of Python and the syntax of C) in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40692106#40692106), feel free to salvage stuff.

Comment: @HusnainRaza I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition that this margin is too narrow to contain.

Comment: @NieDzejkob But the equivalence checking is the hard part, isn't it?

Comment: @KSmarts yes, but the point is an easy to use language with the boilerplate serving at least as a good syntax example.

Answer (score 2):

## 238. [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 429 bytes, [A000089](https://oeis.org/A000089)

```
HAI 1.2

I HAS A INPUT
GIMMEH INPUT
INPUT IS NOW A NUMBR
INPUT R SUM OF INPUT AN 1

I HAS A COUNT ITZ 0
I HAS A INDEX ITZ 1
I HAS A TEMP ITZ 0

IM IN YR LOOP
TEMP R PRODUKT OF INDEX AN INDEX
TEMP R SUM OF TEMP AN 1
TEMP R MOD OF TEMP AN INPUT

BOTH SAEM TEMP AN 0
O RLY?
 YA RLY
  COUNT R SUM OF COUNT AN 1
OIC

BOTH SAEM INDEX AN INPUT
O RLY?
 YA RLY
  GTFO
OIC

INDEX R SUM OF INDEX AN 1
IM OUTTA YR LOOP

VISIBLE COUNT
KTHXBYE
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000429)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVC7bsMwDNz5FfcFRdytUyDHSkTEEg092rhr2y1A/n9ybEl1BXQRyOPd8aj74/71@P5ZFqMY3csrEcOoAAV2U4p0YWu1qU1@wQFOPlaGS7b3FfQIyULOhQnl0P1ZnSS5VRc/cWjsB33LWLdjUdup0ojtSsHsMYpMlCcek5chXWPZs@nXPbn4JdQQucsZKm5laPFyDvUSDYLSdh8cSODH@UiY1VYQavjdurTZW/jUejSJNvd/Rpd4lqIpzObLqrDbrpYUo9oPp3cO3I@67KVrNLd@1svy9gQ)

This just directly counts the solutions. None of that Legendre symbol nonsense.

Comment: Mathematics is never nonsense.

Comment: @user202729 That code looks like nonsense to me :P

Comment: @user202729 I just meant that it seems to over-complicate the problem. Finding the divisors of *n* and computing the product of a modified Legendre symbol of those divisors is not simpler than just counting, imo.

Comment: @user202729 [Actually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense)...

Answer (score 2):

## 240. [CHICKEN Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/), 256 bytes, [A000346](https://oeis.org/A000429)

```scm
(define (factorial x)
(cond
((< x 2) 1)
(else (* x (factorial (- x 1))))))
(define (choose n k)
(cond
((= n 0) 1)(else
(/ (factorial n) (* (factorial k) (factorial (- n k)))))))
(define (a000346 n)
(- (expt 2 (+ 1 (* 2 n))) (choose (+ 1 (* n 2)) (+ n 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8xDoMwDEX3nMKj3Qo1oVWn9jAoGBFBHQQMuT11qAqIbP/p59mefMsfLnwbfMeyLFhzE4QBm8rPcQxVD4kM@ii1QXxBgpLAKeF@0tZFwaGKhWZH6zObyrcxalmg201vjTabVpHB21EjlM0H0NFpSnadx1TW2vvjqb@NNpDTMEMJeAWXbaVyom2ZPxa9h3KS394LDmOQebc5q/AL)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000256)

Comment: `2*>U2XmX¹>c-` *crying* +1 though lol, despite making mine no longer matter.

Comment: Nice bytecount!

Comment: I hope I will finish my Trefunge program before someone else finds an easier language for this sequence...

Comment: @NieDzejkob I found a bunch of easier languages. Go to tio.run, deselect "recreational," and you'll get a whole list of them!

Comment: @KSmarts actually, this doesn't work. Haskell still shows up on the list.

Answer (score 2):

## 249. [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/), 171 bytes, [A000904](http://oeis.org/A000904)

```lisp
(de a000904 (n)
 (cond
  ((= n 0) 0)
  ((= n 1) 3)
  ((= n 2) 13)
  (T 
  (+ (* (+ n 2) (a000904 (- n 1)))
     (* (+ n 3) (a000904 (- n 2)))
	 (a000904 (- n 3)))
  )
 )
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoNADETP3a@YY6alEF0vHvoX/kBRDwsSF@3/b3cVFQzJwCRvEkM/T2GNKckw4quqrTYQo4P0sw0OEPnAoMx9uorwl6uJarcdir4gz6LbRc6n7y3IAuY6EH9H6oI8bku/5/LQMUlcgv0mu6CWTH8)

[next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000171)

Woo! eleventh page!

Comment: Eleventh? I don't see deleted posts (except my own) and I'm on the 9th...

Comment: @NieDzejkob yeah, the eleventh page if you include all deleted posts.

Comment: "Eleventh page" is not as important as "301 answers". If the 301 number is not counting deleted posts, then "all languages available again". I was actually quite disappointed to see that 301 is counting-deleted.

Comment: Yay! No formula!

Comment: @user202729 From Wolfram Mathworld: "*The number of self-complementary graphs on n nodes can be obtained from the "graph polynomial" P_n(x) derived form Pólya's enumeration theorem used to enumerate the numbers of simple graphs as P_n(-1).*" This is the method that the given Mathematica code uses, because of course Mathematica has a built-in for that.

Answer (score 2):

## 255. [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 454 bytes, [A000098](https://oeis.org/A000098)

```perl
sub part {
 my $S;
 if ($_[1]==0) { $S = 1 } elsif ($_[1] < $_[0]) { $S = 0 } else { $S = part($_[0],$_[1]-$_[0])+part($_[0]+1,$_[1]) }
 $S;
}

sub partsum {
 my @a = (0..$_[0]);
 my $S = 0;
 for my $i (@a) {
  $S += part(1,$i);
 }
 $S;
}

sub A000097 {
 my @a = (0..$_[0]//2);
 my $S = 0;
 for my $i (@a) {
  $S += partsum($_[0]-2*$i);
 }
 $S;
}

sub A000098 {
 my @a = (0..$_[0]//3);
 my $S = 0;
 for my $i (@a) {
  $S += A000097($_[0]-3*$i);
 }
 $S;
}
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000454)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9fC4IwFMXf9ykO4YPL1KlERQn2GXqMCAMFoT@i9RDhZ193bvaPhNoetrt77vmdlVm1H0tZX3Yo0@qMG8PhCms1Zyhy2NZ2HWziWHDc6BExAjTI9vWjhwXoFJuHQGhB1tXK1W4lo3bA1XLn@e4EusPRsJbcMNblqS8HEylJycwWnqfn5yanItI9P1VtXcBOUq5GVM8xeAIUauLdfylozSZf/X0//AtBOfVn3HDYz5r2sKKfWSazYUUfLPnqHQlqKSNtgbIqjucuCBlweBjQbuQd)

There's a lot of redundant subroutine calls, so memoization would speed this up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

## 257. TI-NSpire CX Basic, 144 bytes, [A000562](http://oeis.org/A000562)

```
Define a562(n)=
Func
:If n=4 Then
:  Return 9
:Else
:  Return ((27)/(8))*n^(4)-((135)/(4))*n^(3)+((921)/(8))*n^(2)-((539)/(4))*n
:EndIf
:EndFunc
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000144)

Uses Plouffe's conjecture mentioned in the OEIS entry, note that this is different than TI-Nspire CAS Basic as they are two different models of calculator. Next sequence hopefully is easy.

This allows the language to be used again before the 300th.

Comment: Ugh, the next sequence is gross.

Comment: What if the conjecture is false? Don't you need to prove it?

Comment: The formula `a(n) = 27/8n^4 - 135/4n^3 + 921/8n^2 - 539/4n, n>4` does not seem to be labeled as a conjecture.

Comment: @user202729 alternatively, he can verify the results for n up to a thousand.

Answer (score 2):

## 263. [Visual Basic .NET (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 493 bytes, [A000091](https://oeis.org/A000091)

It is a multiplicative function. Using a simple prime checking function.

Now VB .NET was used twice.

```vb
Function IsPrime(p As Integer) As Boolean
 For i = 2 To p - 1
  If p Mod i = 0 Then Return False
 Next
 Return True
End Function

Function A000091(n As Integer) As Integer
 n += 1
 If n = 1 Then Return 1
 If n Mod 9 = 0 Then Return 0

 Dim ans As Integer = 1
 If n Mod 2 = 0 Then ans *= 2
 If n Mod 3 = 0 Then ans *= 2
 While n Mod 2 = 0
  n /= 2
 End While
 For i = 5 To n
 If IsPrime(i) And n Mod i = 0 Then
  If i Mod 3 = 1 Then ans *= 2 Else Return 0
 End If
 Next
 Return ans
End Function
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJPT8JAEMXP3U/xwqlV0RbDgUMPqBB7wBgl4VxgkE3KLNm2xm9fZ4sLFOxpOv9@b177veyvjKVmZtZ1QXilojAq@KyXmOWaw0gFwdRYaKSIMTcYxpIJng2XpqD7hdUVheNYnlES6ii6Lvbu0HPpN/qpVDDhNWR5M615VWnDyMp3q3cU7jEukXFFX2QjFz8Z2ZGzgscPHH6PPhIFZBsJRbMXtiXGB1W1ZUzzoiSFludzc1uTcmzPVeqowKvnSwV/sQLjNnVUgbLgkg7O552Y0ZWYWCm86B1yLs9WIu2MDU5jru9Gbj2rPv5XXWy1fK2zcfGE8dDW3J1t/eTd0HnH7VJvuJYbpZEvXDx4q4/kpEvGRMw9Hdeyss2F29LcMbtxL4cfrPkF)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000493)

I chose a simple sequence. The smallest unused sequence until now is [A000099](https://oeis.org/A000099).

Comment: As far as I can tell, [A000064 has been used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/one-oeis-after-another/148987#comment364103_148987)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks, fixed. (I sorted the snippet by sequence number and there are no A000064. Did something get wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

## 264. [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 102 bytes, [A000493](https://oeis.org/A000493)

```powershell
function A000493($n) {return [math]::floor([math]::sin($n))}

# Please, let's get this to 102. Please?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEAXv/YoHKjYgYbVe7EX8A@8iUmRrAnEjyRYPtd8eEdTjMAPziE9O2XEIpfSDXNVHwYGItrumnovBmFiHJDjdO3Xntu1DjKn@UfbyqcxUVTMcA3eZVwisy4wbK9T5DI1Y08Z@9b6QtQ3htcD4/1zMVN4)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000102)

Comment: We've already had [64](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133801/66833)

Comment: ...I looked at the last answer and it said 64. >.> Padding, hang on.

Comment: Actually, there was [95](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144908/75905). However, it seems that the MATL submission missed the sequence number in the title, so it isn't shown in the snippet.

Comment: @totallyhuman well, we got the shit together :P

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ugh, the snippet should warn about ill-formatted answers.

Comment: I just noticed that the bytecount of this answer is a palindrome of the bytecount of the other PowerShell answer :)

Answer (score 2):

## 266. [UCBLogo](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html), 2572 bytes, [A000636](https://oeis.org/A636)

```
; ------ helper function ------ (unrelated to the problem)

; minimum of two numbers
to min :x :y
    output ifelse :x<:y [:x] [:y]
end

; clone an array
to clone :arr
    localmake "ans (array (count :arr) (first :arr))
    localmake "offset -1+first :arr
    repeat count :arr [
        setitem (#+:offset) :ans (item (#+:offset) :arr)
    ]
    output :ans
end

; ------ coefficient list manipulators ------

; apply (map binary function)
to ap :func :x :y
    localmake "ans arz min count :x count :y
    for [i 0 [-1+count :ans]] [ 
        setitem :i :ans (invoke :func item :i :x item :i :y)
    ]
    output :ans
end

; zero-indexing zero array : f(x) = 0
to arz :n 
    localmake "ans (array :n 0)
    repeat :n [setitem #-1 :ans 0]
    output :ans
end

; polynomial multiplication
to convolve :x :y [:newsize (count :x)+(count :y)-1]
    localmake "ans arz :newsize
    for [i 0 [-1+count :x]] [
        for [j 0 [min -1+count :y :newsize-:i-1] 1] [
            setitem :i+:j :ans (item :i+:j :ans) + (item :i :x) * (item :j :y)
        ]
    ]
    output :ans
end

; given arr = coefficients of f(x), calculate factor * f(x^n)
to extend :arr :n [:factor 1]
    localmake "ans arz (-1+count :arr)*:n+1
    repeat count :arr [
        setitem (#-1)*:n :ans (:factor*item #-1 :arr)
    ]
    output :ans
end

; calculate :const + :factor * x * p(x)
to shift :p :factor :const [:size 1+count :p]
    localmake "ans (array :size 0)
    setitem 0 :ans :const    ; 1+...
    repeat :size-1 [
        setitem # :ans (item #-1 :p)*:factor
    ]
    output :ans

end

; calculate multiplication inverse (1/p(x))
to inverse :p [:n (count :p)]
    localmake "one arz :n
    setitem 0 :one 1

    localmake "p_1 clone :p
    setitem 0 :p_1 (-1+item 0 :p_1) ; p_1(x) = p(x) - 1

    localmake "q (array 1 0)
    setitem 0 :q (1/item 0 :p) ; q(x) = 1/p(0) (coefficient of x^0)

    repeat :n [
        make "q ap "difference :one (convolve :p_1 :q #)
    ]

    output :q
end

; ------ define functions ------

; calculate r(x) first n coefficients
to r :n
    localmake "ans {1}@0
    repeat :n [
        make "ans (shift (ap "sum ap "sum
            convolve convolve :ans :ans :ans ; r[x]^3
            convolve :ans (extend :ans 2 3)  ; 3*r[x]*r[x^2]
            (extend :ans 3 2)  ; 2 r[x^3]
        ) 1/6 1 #)
    ]
    output :ans
end

; calculate R(x) first n coefficients
to BigR :n
    localmake "rn r :n
    output (extend
        ap "sum
            convolve :rn :rn ; r[x]^2
            extend :rn 2     ; r[x^2]
    1 0.5)  ; /2
end

; main function
to main :n
    localmake "Rx bigR :n+1
    localmake "inv_1_xRx inverse shift :Rx -1 1 ; 1 - x*R[x]
    output item :n+1 (extend (ap "sum
        :inv_1_xRx
        convolve
            (shift :Rx 1 1)   ; 1 + x*R[x]
            (extend :inv_1_xRx 2) ; 1/(1 - x^2 * R[x^2])
    ) 1 0.5)
end
```

[Try it online! (at Anarchy golf performance checker)](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

Paste the code there, and then append `print main 10` at the end.

Although Logo has been used twice, UCBLogo only once and FMSLogo only once. In other word, programming languages that has multiple versions tend to have more advantage in this challenge. Next time it will probably be [Elica](http://www.elica.net/).

---

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A002572)

Comment: Probably the next answer is "using the recurrence formula in the Mathematica code". I don't like that, if anyone do that please also include formula proof.

Comment: Sorry for "just using the formula"... but I promise I will add mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## 270. [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 103 bytes, [A000118](https://oeis.org/A000118)

```
←→-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1+*1=⁰0*±⁰≠*8Σu†ΠṖp⁰*<1%4⁰*32Σu†ΠṖp/4⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhEdtk3QNtQ0pwdpahraPGjcYaB3aCKQedS7Qsji3uPRRw4JzCx7unFYAFNOyMVQ1AdHGRsgy@iCx////mwIA)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000103)

Ignore the madness that precedes the actual code, it’s just fluff to make this 103 bytes.

#### How it works

<s>Husk does not have a “divisors” built-in, so</s> (`Ḋ` has been implemented) this was actually fun to  solve.

- First off, it computes the divisors of **N** using prime factorization (prime factors, powerset, product of each, deduplicate) and sum them up. Then, it multiplies the result by 8.
- After that, it computes the sum of **N / 4**’s divisors, and multiplies it by 32 if **N** is divisible by 4, or evaluates the whole thing to 0 otherwise.
- Takes the absolute difference between the above terms.
- For handling the special case of 0, this just multiplies our result by the sign of **N**, and adds 1 iff **N** is 0.

To put it simply, it calculates **(N==0 ? 1 : 0)+sgn(N)(8σ(N)+32σ(N/4)(N%4==0 ? 1:0))**.

Comment: I was just about to post a solution in Actually...

Comment: @NieDzejkob Oh sorry for ninja’ing again. At least it was nonetrivial for me, Husk doesn’t have a divisor built-in so...

Comment: `Ḋ` is divisors in Husk

Comment: @H.PWiz It has been added recently right?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder don't be sorry, it's not your fault

Comment: "KEYWORD hard" for the next sequence :(

Comment: @Giuseppe I can change it if the community wants me to :-)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder don't, I almost got it

Comment: @NieDzejkob Good luck! :-) (I won’t change it)

Comment: Rip challenge :(

Comment: @HusnainRaza If I'm counting right, we still have a day and eight hours left...

Comment: @Husnain There’s still one day and a few hours left.

Comment: We can't hardcode, we can't use Mathematica (because it has nothing for this)... It's gonna be really hard...

Comment: @HusnainRaza I said that I will solve it means I will solve it. Don't push me.

Comment: @totallyhuman There is a [C program](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) that does it already.

Comment: Anyone else want to do this? ChristianSiever has a better algorithm?

Comment: @user202729 Didn't even start seriously thinking about it

Answer (score 2):

## 273. [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 123 bytes, [A000129](http://oeis.org/A000129)

```
2¬1+³ⁿ1 2¬-³ⁿ-2¬d/¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/3@jQGkPtQ5sfNe43VACydcFMXSArRf/QMgU6gf//TQE) <sub><sup>(note the trailing spaces)</sup></sub>

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000123)

I didn't want to nearly-kill the challenge again, so I chose A000123, which isn't *that* hard.

Implements **a(n) = ((1+√2)<sup>n</sup> - (1-√2)<sup>n</sup>) / (2√2)**, rounded to the nearest integer (because there are small floating-point inaccuracies).

Comment: I was working on 6502 asm for 272 when this was posted

Comment: @Tornado547 I feel ya. It's tough to get an answer in when the sequences are so simple, but you'll have lots of chances!

Answer (score 2):

## 275. [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 113 bytes, [A001021](https://oeis.org/A001021)

```
> Input
> 12
>> 2*1
>> Output 3
Rather than add a bunch of spaces,
I think it'd be better to actually have
words.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCgMhEATvvqJvgRACa@7e9xTID2bVMJJFxRmz5PXGhYaCKvrgJDU2GcNhzbWrcViscQ72upx4dp0WD/Mi5digTBkUAghbz55R3pBKPsrNrLOm/EHSS8AW51TPSwF57bTvPzB9ozlKC3Ifw/4B)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000113)

### How it works

The parser automatically removes lines that don't match any of the valid regexes, meaning that the code that actually gets executes is

```
> Input
> 12
>> 2*1
>> Output 3
```

Which is executed non-linearly way (as most Whispers programs are), and runs as follows:

```
Output ((12) * (Input))
```

Where `*` is exponentiation (raising **x** to the power **y**)

Comment: What are the rules on using languages newer than the challenge?

Comment: @KSmarts Just so long as it isn't specifically designed for this challenge (or violate any other standard loophole), it's the same as posting an answer with a newer language on any other question.

Comment: What is this sorcery?

Comment: Does this still work if you change `acually` to `actually` and remove the duplicate `!`?

Comment: This language reminds me of LLVM IR...

Answer (score 2):

## 276. MATLAB, 188 bytes, [A000113](http://oeis.org/A000113)

```matlab
n=input('')+1;
F=factor(n);
psi = @(x) x*prod(1+1./unique(F))-(x<2);
i=sum(F==2);
j=sum(F==3);
if i > 5
i = 3;
else
i = floor(i./2);
end
if j > 1
j = 1;
else
j = 0;
end
psi(n) ./ (2^i*3^j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NCoMwEITveYq9uVGqjdKD2JSefAxBNMIGm1g1xbdPk/7cZphvdscOe/9S3htJZnE7JgnPRMNaOfXDblc0vGHLRiDhjgeHI11WO6LIRF44Q0@nsOX8hMe1DCDJzT2wlTIa/TdVTCYguMGFxUtVw9S8qY@eZhu@UF7EijJjJHUgBdMhFT8y6vM3D2PCKMgLwLKjtOo0976u6zc)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000188)

As this is a carefully written polyglot with Octave, it will run on TIO.

Implements the formula with Dedekind's psi function listed in the notes.

Oddly, there's a dead link for transformation groups on [this OEIS wiki page](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n#cite_note-0) and I'm not entirely sure how to count transformation groups!

Answer (score 2):

## 279. [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 2852 bytes, [A005692](https://oeis.org/A005692)

```
program beans

integer :: n, first_move, last_move, new_move1, new_move2, turn_count, win_accomplished, cycleq

integer, dimension(270,1000000) :: current_paths, next_paths
integer :: next_path_count, current_path_count, path_iter, move_iter, cycle_iter

read *,n
first_move = 2*n+1
turn_count = 0
win_accomplished = 0


current_paths(1,1)=first_move
current_path_count=1


do while(.true.)
  
  turn_count = turn_count + 1    !current path length

  if (first_move == 1) then
    turn_count = 1
    exit
  end if

  next_path_count = 1


  do path_iter=1,current_path_count
    
    cycleq = 0
    last_move = current_paths(turn_count,path_iter)
    !print *,'prince'
    !print *,last_move
    !print *,'prince'

  
    if (mod(last_move,2)==1)  then
      if (last_move>1) then
        if (mod(turn_count,2) == 0) then
          cycle
        end if
      end if
    end if

    if (last_move==1) then
      if (mod(turn_count,2) == 0) then
        win_accomplished = 1
      end if

    else if (mod(last_move,2)==0) then
      new_move1 = last_move/2

      do cycle_iter = 1,turn_count
        if (current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter) == new_move1) then
          cycleq=1
        end if
      end do

      if (cycleq == 0) then
        do cycle_iter=1,turn_count
          next_paths(cycle_iter,next_path_count) = current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter)
        end do 
        next_paths(turn_count+1,next_path_count) = new_move1
        next_path_count = next_path_count + 1
      end if

    else 
      new_move1 = 3*last_move + 1
      new_move2 = 3*last_move - 1

      cycleq=0
      do cycle_iter = 1,turn_count
        if (current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter) == new_move1) then
          cycleq=1
        end if
      end do 

      if (cycleq == 0) then
        do cycle_iter=1,turn_count
          next_paths(cycle_iter,next_path_count) = current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter)
        end do 
        next_paths(turn_count+1,next_path_count) = new_move1
        next_path_count = next_path_count + 1
      end if


      cycleq=0
      do cycle_iter = 1,turn_count
        if (current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter) == new_move2) then
          cycleq=1
        end if
      end do 

      if (cycleq == 0) then
        do cycle_iter=1,turn_count
          next_paths(cycle_iter,next_path_count) = current_paths(cycle_iter,path_iter)
        end do
        next_paths(turn_count+1,next_path_count) = new_move2
        next_path_count = next_path_count + 1
      end if

    end if

  end do 

  if (win_accomplished==1) then
     exit
  end if


  do path_iter=1,next_path_count-1
    do move_iter=1,turn_count+1
      current_paths(move_iter,path_iter) = next_paths(move_iter,path_iter)
      next_paths(move_iter,path_iter) = 0
    end do
  end do
  
  current_path_count = next_path_count-1

end do


print *,turn_count-1

end program beans
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VbbjpswEH2fr5h9WgjOFtOHaleivxJRcBIkYrLG2Wy/PrUN@AZRK620qqqiKBoPczlzZoy974UUFd8e9qNwu51FfxDVCX@wig8ALZfswAS@vCAnuG/FIHen/o0R7CorcnY1EnViQVBeBN/V/YVLgteW76q67k/nrh2OrCFY/6w79moTEGzaE@ND2/Ok@JYTmpsn1YnrixCMy925ksdBp3if5ADdrJ1T@l6zzsit1Ok0yEk0UIwMIFjV4IZwcKViicWGZxRcQUqVQ1yTUQIEaBNKaFq6WLBEVVLl1PR4PbYdS56kuLCnFBDVL0joLTKkqJ6HKZgpCzvGD/IIyq3dY@LDL5GmKI@Mg/YKglKjYu@tVALjjfLVESIyjaHWK5iWwpKSZTEmnPkb@2s40Us7LUoTMuSNiY2dGp@Hs1ANVt141ELNHkOtDXnHGCYkmo5T3yRuYIu0LBUljpPRyBp89/nyQ3hYi1QTm0eGU912PVG6WDiqo9QGWITrjzKvTCMN846Ju4HdYSSMaPe0CmTtvhQwvVaT4LaNzkUcwoC2sNnOx2u2LsemWyf0taT3OW168NiaB29JUYC5XEXsjX4ANtoQ6WKKVwsLIKvssJLEgcjoWhpLzNLZbs5Yk91v/Up3v27c5nSe9kMeWWz1pyDoTP5XjgT@n4nfzMTndrH4l7v4kSYWH9/YVvZI04TFZ0J0uETH/vJ8j9Jvx@TKyF6eAq6zGVxIoLtp@ZPhU7VmAQtC78TJIeiDFQBXroBLTlVRMB8iMN8hXE3z6@BafLvR/PkX)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A002852)

I originally wrote a similar program in [Python](https://tio.run/##vVVNb9swDL3rVwgoBkfNx2J1KbAADrDLdhl22i0wAnVWGqE25VnKimLob88o2VXsWs1uFRA5oh6fnkiarp/sQcPN6aSqWjeWWlVJYpeZey7cNGGEkELuqTngvjR296hgAmxNKA61p5Blabtwo5H22ABdegMiQcH9zpsy@kODDHbZ/M6@itK0Fj/Vwh5Mtt1CnpMWd1ClpD@bozwfAPJx1wHzYAx/9rrxNFRBS7cmYW8EdqMUeKNK/5Gozzls52lO3kTjdYPDB44XpwKKs2nTC0TfRcLEcTPnslxTekW/KQEYbPEgDf2lwTa6XNDv2hg6InDDQRQc5eW79NUNkhJF@4ijtCzIi2l3iFZ2VNirDDv0PH0TiTlHkMtnFHLXSPFwWfRgIcvX@ehUjjhc0fioBPRHHrvtC45uaJvaYOjqKR6FWhgz2pBY23F4KOGFqGsJhY/@dPtyVs4ux8ATYw2dS1cZqoti5lT/P@e6Tmc4cczEzXXgmKKxt5yncWeMEfq/RzTwmJxFNcRF8fcRxXvZIT0BXXkP2cYFTc56kBxTEA6KsraNDjvdkLduFNhJIqvaPiUsciTpteL@K0pI5/p3veHPOK3cdPucLLBxVgI3IJklHKYpPr6sbj/zhDHimiq48DYC7uWEr7rmH7gc1Sf/C0Qwo/waXFUNvhvexlib2KuWAKIYQmw6@Aq1YJvO7ZKR0@kf). It properly compiled in [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon) but I wanted to see if I could write it in Fortran first and save Pyon/Python for harder sequences.

The program relies on the fact that if Jack moves to an odd number then the Giant gains control and will be able to use a never-lose strategy. It starts with a the Giant's fist move `[n]` then enumerates all the possible games until the first win is found which must be the shortest one since moves are added to each possible game pathway once per iteration of the main loop. If Jack loses in one particular game or if the Giant takes control then that particular game pathway is abandoned which helps save on memory and time.

The first term in the sequence doesn't make any sense to me since it isn't a win for Jack but I hard coded it in anyway.

[The paper OEIS references](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689400) helped me understand the sequence. They suggest an algorithm to us on a computer (they calculated the first 525 terms of the sequence by hand) which I didn't use because it seemed a little more difficult to implement but it would probably be faster and much less memory intensive.

Because of memory limitations, the program won't actually work on all the terms but is fine for terms up to at least 119 (n=109). Note that the two arrays declared at the top have 270x10^6 elements. This allows in the algorithm for 10^6 branches of possible game paths of length 270 moves. None of the first 1000 terms are bigger than 263 so this is still valid for the challenge.

The next sequence (terms in the continued fraction of Eulers constant) looks pretty hard, but maybe that's just because I don't know how to do it of the top of my head. I promise I didn't engineer my byte-count to pick this, it's just what I ended up with.

Edit: [It seems calculating the terms doesn't seem too hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) once you have the actual [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) (which is irrational [edit: apparently this is actually not known]). Here are some resources:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)
- [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)
- [A paper I found on Google](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gamma.pdf)

Comment: `119 (n=109)` Huh?

Comment: NOTE There has already been a deleted answer that hardcodes. Don't do this again if you don't want downvotes.

Comment: @user202729 Haha sorry to disappoint you. I know what a continued fraction is just didn’t know how to calculate it off the top of my head. I agree the next one isn’t that hard

Comment: @user202729 I mean terms of value at least 119, which occurs at n=109

Comment: [R script](https://goo.gl/REHGCk) for the numerator and denominator of the rational approximation of gamma; just need to find a language/library with arbitrary precision rationals/integers to compute the next sequence.

Comment: @Giuseppe it kind of hardcodes the sequence to get a number from which you can compute the sequence. Don't you think that's a little pointless?

Comment: @NieDzejkob yeah, but I don't know that non-hardcoding in a sufficiently precise value for `gamma` will result in an accurate enough answer. I suppose one of the many different series approximations would probably work but then you may be forced to find a sufficiently powerful approximation for `log(n)` at some point.

Comment: Although the mathworld article does have a formula (25) for gamma that can be computed purely through infinite sums of rationals, but it might not converge very quickly.

Comment: http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/formulas.html

Comment: Mathematica, Pari/GP, and Magma all have trivial solutions. Of course, they've all been used.

Answer (score 2):

## 283. [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 384 bytes, [A000126](https://oeis.org/A000126)

```
³4+ý³-2-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9BmE@3Dew9t1jXSVRgFAwL@/zcHAA)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000384) (This one is trivial, the hexagonal numbers!)

If this were code golf, I could solve this in 6 bytes: `4+ýa‹‹`.

This one was really just **Fibonacci(N + 4) - N - 2**.

Comment: Please let me do the next one in Hexagony!

Comment: Wait, I still need to wait 45 minutes... I'll try anyway

Answer (score 2):

## 287. [Scratch 2](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 7437 Bytes, [A001118](https://oeis.org/A001118)

[image: A001118]

[Try it online](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/195317746/#player)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/jY8YZKrD) is the text version of the full program.

Below is the portion of the program that represents the code blocks in the image. The full text is much longer, dealing with things irrelevant to this challenge.

```
        "scripts": [[275.8,
                75.2,
                [["procDef", "Power %n %n", ["Base", "exponent"], [1, 1], false],
                    ["setVar:to:", "presult", "1"],
                    ["doRepeat",
                        ["getParam", "exponent", "r"],
                        [["setVar:to:", "presult", ["*", ["readVariable", "presult"], ["getParam", "Base", "r"]]]]]]],
            [539.1,
                73.2,
                [["procDef", "Binomial %n %n", ["a", "b"], [1, 1], false],
                    ["call", "FactLoop %n", ["getParam", "a", "r"]],
                    ["setVar:to:", "bin", ["readVariable", "result"]],
                    ["call", "FactLoop %n", ["getParam", "b", "r"]],
                    ["setVar:to:", "bin", ["\/", ["readVariable", "bin"], ["readVariable", "result"]]],
                    ["call", "FactLoop %n", ["-", ["getParam", "a", "r"], ["getParam", "b", "r"]]],
                    ["setVar:to:", "bin", ["\/", ["readVariable", "bin"], ["readVariable", "result"]]]]],
            [286.7,
                244,
                [["procDef", "FactLoop %n", ["n"], [1], false],
                    ["setVar:to:", "count", ["getParam", "n", "r"]],
                    ["setVar:to:", "result", "1"],
                    ["doUntil",
                        ["<", ["readVariable", "count"], "2"],
                        [["setVar:to:", "result", ["*", ["readVariable", "result"], ["readVariable", "count"]]],
                            ["changeVar:by:", "count", -1]]]]],
            [44,
                71,
                [["whenGreenFlag"],
                    ["doAsk", ""],
                    ["setVar:to:", "nseq", ["answer"]],
                    ["setVar:to:", "sum", 0],
                    ["setVar:to:", "i", 0],
                    ["doRepeat",
                        5,
                        [["call", "Power %n %n", -1, ["readVariable", "i"]],
                            ["setVar:to:", "term", ["readVariable", "presult"]],
                            ["call", "Power %n %n", ["-", 5, ["readVariable", "i"]], ["readVariable", "nseq"]],
                            ["setVar:to:", "term", ["*", ["readVariable", "term"], ["readVariable", "presult"]]],
                            ["call", "Binomial %n %n", 5, ["readVariable", "i"]],
                            ["setVar:to:", "term", ["*", ["readVariable", "term"], ["readVariable", "bin"]]],
                            ["changeVar:by:", "sum", ["readVariable", "term"]],
                            ["changeVar:by:", "i", 1]]],
                    ["say:", ["readVariable", "sum"]]]]],
```

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A007437): Inverse Moebius transformation of triangular numbers

Comment: +1 for using Scratch and for giving us an easy sequence. [Solved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151730/59487) in Swift 4 :)

Comment: Scratch is verbose. (depends on how is the number of bytes counted)

Answer (score 2):

## 290. [Hy](http://hylang.org), 337 bytes, [A000149](https://oeis.org/A000149)

```
(import decimal)
(setv ctx (.getcontext decimal))
(setv ctx.prec 500)
(setv iterations 2800)

(defn factorial [n]
  (reduce *
    (range 1 (inc n))
    1))

(defn exp [n series-terms]
  (sum
    (list-comp
      (/ (decimal.Decimal (** n k)) (factorial k))
      (k (range series-terms)))))

(defn A000149 [n]
  (int (exp n iterations)))
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000337)--here's a nice easy one so you can break out the obscure esolangs. ;^)

We implement the exponential function by taking partial sums of its MacLaurin series: `e^n = Sum[k=0..inf] n^k/k!`. For values far away from 0, the series converges more slowly, so we need to calculate a lot of terms to get an accurate result. Trial and error showed that 2800 terms was sufficient for n=1000. The `decimal` module provides arbitrary-precision arithmetic; 500 significant digits gets us up to n=1000 easily.

Answer (score 2):

## 292. [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 132 bytes, [A000130](http://oeis.org/A000130)

```
ọ0D¦1C1=
┅f↑¦Σ2÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@HuXgOXQ8sMnQ1tuR5NaU171Dbx0LJzi40Ob1cYAPD/vzkA)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000132)

The next one should not be too hard (there is a näive approach to generate all the integer partitions, and for each partition P check if P is of length 5 and that each element in P is a square :P). I have solved this in [Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X784t9CwOFc/JVtbOyzBtyQ4MME3OBDEBLGAXL2CrOzgQKP//80B) first, then got a much more efficient [technique](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X784t9BQW19PO8UQRMQb6hUEBxr9/28OAA), which I then ported to Gaia.

### How it works?

```
ọ0D¦1C1= | Helper function.

ọ        | Compute the incremental differences (deltas).
 0D¦     | For each, calculate the absolute difference to 0 (absolute value).
    1C   | Count the 1's.
      1= | Return 1 if the result is equal to 1, 0 otherwise.

┅f↑¦Σ2÷  | Main function. Let N be the input.

┅        | The integers in the range 1 ... N.
 f       | Compute the permutations.
  ↑¦     | For each permutation, apply the above helper function called monadically.
    Σ    | Sum.
     2÷  | Halve and implicitly display the result.
```

Comment: This one has useful and easy to calculate g.f., but note that `(1)²` and `(-1)²` are different ways. You can implement FFT if you like.

Answer (score 2):

## 298. [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 1008 bytes, [A001460](http://oeis.org/A001460)

```
# Define a factorial macro f; expects the accumulator in register a and the loop number
# (> 0) on the stack
[
 d        # Duplicate the loop number
 la * sa  # Load accumulator, multiply by loop number, store back in accumulator
 1 -      # Decrement loop number
 d 0<f    # Duplicate; if greater than 0, call the macro again
] sf

# Define a wrapper macro F; expects the argument on the stack, and can handle 0
[
 1 sa   # Store 1 in the accumulator register
 d 0<f  # Duplicate argument; if greater than 0, call macro f
 s_     # This leaves a 0 on the stack; store in register _ to get rid of it
 la     # Load accumulator onto stack
] sF

# Main program
? sn         # Read input and store in register n
ln 5 * lF x  # Load n, multiply by 5, take the factorial
ln 2 * lF x  # Load n, multiply by 2, take the factorial
ln lF x 3 ^  # Load n, take the factorial, raise to the 3rd power
*            # Multiply the last two results
/            # Divide the first result by the product
p            # Print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPBbtswEETv/IoBcmkDFZUT5OSgvQQ@tUDR9la0wZqkZCIUKZBUnHy9u6RkV7IRVCeBmuHsvl0peThc4UE3xmkQGpLJB0MWHcng0ayhX3otU0TasUDKoRsssQbGIejWxKQDG8mporDe93BDt9VBXOHdJ9Tv4V35FBPJJ/FLQGF6OHjorZGU9IUZlnCNSFn1xZOaZ1fgl2R6@4rt69xVcYgPGltOygXOPAIrfDjFahl0p11aRirU981ZYWuYBm3QlPtMO3KoK0iytlQ8UqKWjBO/ERshZjD3gfqeXaNoc4YytEOpYE6nKhwlh3CQshp15rUqGLioH6W5Ve7sfBrHUZyamLM9Zr3dyzRtgfg4Ifq5MxFW07OO3Eq9KHM9YZ6vwCOSR6sTglHwDUwqIxwvOx8g38bqcSEY2yZj@8oM0QffBurEZ0SHf2vyXbPfuH5IBdBluhPW4Y4Xxm7wckp0y0W5q5DoaVy106Jn481/jDdvGYvpFn/mxktlhUAm6gwon98Ghd7veVbXmD1M4BhZ/gWKCWnvucfI51F8XIofzLNRU5AJrB11udx8xiDVIJPol65vwbh0OKzqvw)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A001008)

Comment: The next one seems to be doable in Unefunge...

Comment: The next one is a lot easier if you have a built-ins for finding lowest common multiple and simplifying fractions. The series is the numerator of the simplified fraction `Sum(LCM(1...n)/n) / LCM(1...n)`.

Answer (score 2):

## 299. [Unefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 137 bytes, [A001008](https://oeis.org/A001008)

```
&1+3p01p12p2g3g::/1-:/d*j:0p%0g\0f-8-j$:3g\/:1g*1p\2g\/1g+1p2g*2p1g2g::/1-:/d*j:0p%0g\0f-8-j$:1g\/1p2g\/2p3g1-:3p:/0ab*-3-*j1g.@ unefunge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xDsIwDAV3voIBGFKZ@NlL8cSHZAHRWspQecnA14cUsbLdcCdd25a1bb7QbaZ4f7H3CyYNRkBCXN0sgyy/UjWOM3vhlWaqJ1Mv2eAJUWQgfMIIkgRc/lfY1dgDCfXhaFjmxzORUqrw6/3Yfle9g/nwAQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000137)

Due to the way PyFunge handles input, the input to this program has to be followed by at least one newline.

### Explanation

I'm calculating GCD twice, both times using the Euclidean algorithm, which is a simple one-liner in Python: `while b: a, b = b, a % b` (the result is left in `a`). Here is it implemented in Unefunge:

```
::/1-:/d*j:0p%0g\0f-8-j$ Stack: a b
::/1-:/d*j               If b is equal to 0, skip to the $ at the end
          :0p            Save b in a temporary variable
             %           Stack: a%b
              0g\        Recall b and swap. Stack: b a%b
                 0f-8-j  Jump to the beginning
                       $ Drop b, which is now equal to 0.
```

In the explanation of the whole program, I'll replace this snippet with a `G`. The program uses its first 4 bytes as variables, since the programs in Unefunge can easily modify themselves.

```
Byte no    Letter   Purpose
    0               A temporary variable used in the GCD algorithm
    1         n     The numerator of the partial sum
    2         d     The denominator of the partial sum
    3         i     The loop counter
```

This should be enough to understand the whole program.

```
&1+3p       i = int(input()) + 1
01p         n = 0
12p         d = 1
            The main loop starts here
2g3gG:      gcd = GCD(d, i) # Stack: gcd, gcd
3g\/:                       # Stack: gcd, i // gcd, i // gcd
1g*1p       n *= i // gcd   # Stack: gcd, i // gcd
\2g\/1g+1p  n += d // gcd   # Stack: i // gcd
2g*2p       d *= i // gcd   # Stack empty
1g2gG:      gcd = GCD(n, d) # Stack: gcd, gcd
1g\/1p      n //= gcd
2g\/2p      d //= gcd
3g1-:3p     i -= 1
:/0ab*-3-*j If i is not 0, loop
1g.@        print(n)
```

Comment: Note that there must be a trailing newline after input.

Comment: I recall Hyper asking about Series parallel numbers on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384766/series-parallel-numbers-explanation-for-oeis-a000137), are you sure it hasn't occurred before?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder the snippet doesn't complain, and you know it would. An ill-formatted answer is also out of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The related sequence [A000084](http://oeis.org/A000084) has been done before. And maybe this one came up in a now-deleted answer?

Comment: @KSmarts [Issue already solved](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42067269#42067269)

Answer (score 2):

## 303. [APL (Dyalog)](https://dyalog.com/), 203 bytes, [A000135](https://oeis.org/A000135)

```
{n←1+⍵⋄++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++≢⊃{{(n≥⍵)/⍵},⍵,⍺+0,⍵}/(2÷3)*⍨1+⍳⌊1.5*⍨n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQb/04BkdR6QMNR@1Lv1UXeL9iAGjzoXPepqrq7WyHvUuRToXE19IFGrAySAeJe2AYhVq69hdHi7sabWo94VID9tftTTZahnCuLm1f7/n3ZoBVDMyAAA)

using `⎕IO←0`. After removing fillers (`+`, conjugate in Dyalog APL but it doesn't change the result becuase we're dealing real numbers here):

```
{n←1+⍵⋄≢⊃{{(n≥⍵)/⍵},⍵,⍺+0,⍵}/(2÷3)*⍨1+⍳⌊1.5*⍨n}
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000203)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first post!

Answer (score 2):

## 304. [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 143 bytes, [A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203)

```clj
(defn sigma
   [num]
   (reduce +
      (filter
         (comp zero?
            (partial rem num))
         (range 1
            (+ 1 num)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5LDsMgDET3PcUsibIpJ@hBqi4s4kRUGJALm16exkrVj1d@o3mWQyr3rjyGW3jNeMRN6ATgmrvcbHHKSw@M2cB4jamxvsmCUKTiyVou39DyStoiJSgL9mvT9OMo5Y3h/4UZ/ijuM1zVmBucUD2@@kjwZyu8AA)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000143)

Answer (score 2):

## 305. [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 145 bytes, [A000143](http://oeis.org/A000143)

```javascript
p=Math.pow
a=(n)=>{q=!n/16;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){if(!(n%i))q+=p(-1,i)*p(i,3)}return q*16*p(-1,n)}
//Filing out characters to get to nearest empty ch
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7BbsJADATQe77CHCrZCRACEpdlOfbWjzDpEoxS72ZjQBXi29PQ0zvMSDNXvvPYZkm20vgdpin5L7bLOsVHwR6V/PE5@IXWzd4V55hRfOPk4NVJVdFTzrhA/RCiofIJV81SqEwoyx29crBbVhjKZl/@R0qvoq4/pRftIN4M2gtnbi3kESxCF@yNBs5hNAg/yX7nyjSvAt45wwk8bNzMAbZv5wPQRh1jH9Z97JDxROSmPw)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000145)

If you by chance consider comments cheating here's the same code ungolfed with the same length

```javascript
a = function(n) {
	q=!n/16;
	for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
		if (n%i==0) q += Math.pow(-1, i) * Math.pow(i, 3)
	}
	return q * 16 * Math.pow(-1, n)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1LDoIwFEXH7SquA5OWn6IJE@gSXERB0BryCuXjwLB2LEx0dJKbc3NeetZD5Uw3xmTv9bpqKDQTVaOxJEjiw1mvDnRKs5yzxjoI4400h0GhQJ5huFvMNBB0NEqdJXqECjc9PpPOvkWcRjASwW8xEa6Ss4UzV4@TI38IkGb/ynYiyZd1j87aofThc@5R4LJxC1eWBtvWSWsfQotSynz9Ag)

Comment: Why would anyone consider this cheating?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Because comments simplifies changing the length of the code. I myself don't think it's that important but you never know.

Answer (score 2):

## 310. [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 148 bytes, [A000699](http://oeis.org/A000699)

```
L?>b1*tbsm*y-bdydtUb1;*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1yh
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%3Eb1%2atbsm%2ay-bdydtUb1%3B%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1%2a1yh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0)

[Next Sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000148)

I am going to *regret* using Pyth that soon. Implements a recursive function **y** that:

- Checks if its argument, **b**, is higher than **1**.
- If that is true, then it returns **(b-1) * Σ<sub>d=1</sub><sup>b-1</sup> y(d) * y(b-d)**.
- Otherwise, it just returns **1**.

Answer (score 2):

## 316. [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 1808 bytes, [A000147](https://oeis.org/A147)

```pascal
{ ''' }
Type
	Num = Integer; // may change this to LongInt or big integer.
Const
	maxN = 1010; // Why using dynamic array?
Var
	ans, i, n, m, n0: Num;
	a: Array [1..maxN, 1..maxN] of Num;
Begin
	read(n0);
	inc(n0); // because input is 0-indexing.
	if n0 > maxN then
	begin
		writeln('Input too large!');
		halt;
	end;
	{ Let a[i, j] (a[i][j] in other languages. Pascal multidimensional
	array indexing looks nicer) be the number of rooted tree with
	(i) nodes, height at most 2 and all rooted subtree with its
	root being a child of the root has at least (j) nodes. }
	for m := 1 to n0 do
		a[1, m] := 1;
	{ Because if the tree only have a node, there is no rooted subtree.
	BTW, Sublime Text doesn't support Pascal well. }
	for n := 2 to n0 do
	begin
		a[n, n-1] := 1;
		for m := n-2 downto 1 do
			a[n, m] :=
			// When there is no rooted subtree of size (m).
			{ (line comment is FP's extension. TP doesn't have this)
			(TP = Turbo Pascal) }
			a[n, m+1]
			{ When there is a subtree of size (m), the remaining
			part is a tree of order (n-m) and each rooted subtree
			has at least (m) nodes. }
			+ a[n-m, m];
	end;
	{ From OEIS page: A tree of diameter 5 is formed from two rooted trees 
	of height 2, with their roots joined. }
	ans := 0;
	for i := 1 to (n0-1) div 2 do
		{ Assume one of the tree has order (i), then the other 
		has order (n0-i), where (n0) is the input. }
		ans += (a[i, 1] - 1) * (a[n0-i, 1] - 1);
		{ -1 because there is exactly one tree of height < 2
		and order = i. }
	if n mod 2 = 0 then
	begin // Assume both of the rooted subtrees has order (n div 2).
		i := a[n div 2, 1] - 1;
		ans += i * (i+1) div 2;
	end;
	writeln(ans); // ln = line.
End.
{ ''',



print(__import__('base64').b64decode(b'Tm90aGluZyBpbnRlcmVzdGluZy4uLiB0aGlzIGlzIG5vdCBQeXRob24u').decode('ascii')) }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVrb9s2FP0s/Yq7T5IWW7WMtMDiZUNdtEOAoMtaox1mGAEl0RIzkRRIKo4T7Ldn91KPuMUwA7Yl8T7OOfehltmCNfN9Wzw/P0EURfBPuDm2PAw@dhIu4Uo5XnGzglevQLIjFDVTFQdXCwtOw7VWFZqANpCLCkRvnYbvtLIuDCR7@IhBskW28BG@1kforFAVlEfFpCiAGcOOv4ZfmAkDpuwMxAzUDCT@Li4AMazw@QW8JTPYZmlKIWcwXOxA73ujNa@ECgPDWRmrRYJeQhX@ivLmvGCd5Yiv7Rwg9MVcqJI/IJIULfeYDH4Bj9bVHOPkfbjgYITjjYqjK@/ptIaGmYr/EFGKoGaNw3@uSvx9gmvugG2Rwd0OYrzYbfFCKNAY1KCjqjpWcZvCjVcdZNc4UQrJlRVasQapep4jNmi0/tuCEgU3CZIgcKA6mWM0JG60drwEZziHg3B1GMQiAaVLjjrWXFQ1wnEgtXWwBKZKYE0zetkunxxBOIva4QEmobwM6yyakpJQSn9SM0vRGs4wXHw3JEqxX4I9ll/CBRaaegK1LDWKw7YZFnLnn3t51mMV@qg@vVbNEUPfc8xJAWd0ZDjVSOnvsGKp1puvM/jc5Q2KBhv@4DAVtypyaNO22rhR2gNvmgmbIgzLE2xjedkWe03NswnkCxU1X6LpQaFT1vPprT0huvPtzNX/4CX5rHjkEMskJZcniBuhOBRaYs19I364iSwgj74FUtjcTIy8KjRoCfnGeHIJm87keuCYEL0R1Vm26zN8i4n9F5ZZX1QumVBYbfJrmXG9/WisTYldFqu5THzrcFbU3/Ejx2@7Qp52RRCc4TRgABLtZEo@GC3h9/dXn6HFacDZnnKWgknuMO1rwoKlkJhsT@buoE/b3UIYoP3Q48tZ38XIShhvZuFOo9Clx4FrhQq6WPXNIKZGxfUwzxLMeg/LvsRP8NbaTlJb8rH5PTiiOSgiev28yMNkh70Oo2S4XNDm4GtAK4jIkLHfPr00hOns0i8JXGY7mAMC@ZHuyXt6tPKY5tm0wKbC8gdWOBwdAjrKN8jxMyx9hnIAdAnCJ6U1h8ugRLKoxumioxU5EM@R0enYv1TbnoqgetV8W3tBEXj/aMS@emEpiJk4G6WeWmFcrmjWr@lGITKakDR8r8o09C@kWYif1uCrJb69FZKG/PY2jnJm@ZvzKEnzN@clL7Dr4jzayJ8W7Lem@@u4bnP1qSnkl8fS359312JNZ49X/vv6vny3/oP/@Unny/MOwwwxIhwtIaKEhuv5OVv@Cw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A1808) Easy, just implement generating function.

Answer (score 2):

## 317. [Python 3 (Cython)](http://cython.org/), 652 bytes, [A001808](https://oeis.org/A001808)

```python
from itertools import zip_longest

def mul(a, b):
	return list(map(sum, zip_longest(*[[0] * i + [e * f for j, f in enumerate(b)] for i, e in enumerate(a)], fillvalue = 0)))

# a(x) - b(x)
def sub(a,b):
	return list(map(lambda v: v[0] - v[1], zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue = 0)))

# a'(x)
def polyderiv(a):
	return[i*x for i,x in enumerate(a)][1:]

# (f(x)/g(x))', first n terms
def fracderiv(f,g):
	return sub(mul(polyderiv(f),g),mul(f,polyderiv(g))),mul(g,g)

f = [1]
g = [1,-11,54,-154,275,-297,132,132,-297,275,-154,54,-11,1]
F = 1

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
	f, g = fracderiv(f, g)
	f = f[:n]
	g = g[:n]
	F*= i + 1

print(f[0] // g[0] // F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJRb4MgEMefy6e4ZA8Fh6m2a5qZ9LVfwpgFW3AsiAbRtPvy7qDb2mXbg/zxDu5@/9P@4l87u0mPUedZua4F7aXzXWcG0G3fOQ/vun8xnW3k4Ak5SQXtaKjgULOCLJz0o7Ng9OBpK3o6jC2/v0GTsswqSEDDI5QSNwpU5@CN40ZbkHZspRNe0ppVMaM5yJ8ZwSo8rY2ZhBkl7CFjjBHyAIKeGaRQo0SwYawR7E8uI9r6JGAqYAo8KUpe/SQNlv7ps/zq0HfmcpJOTwj13aXUyfkT/fyLvMyLKtSgCmusGlzYMnRxgwcLOOt2iJWVE8drZcWbOwfBUxj4rbNieICHmOK3aIOsMdhglhCF@OiQNFF5mud8@4SCy3q35en6ecfzzTo@8SVGQzoeyznePeDdnBCLoq2n2vajpziRaDUYdQInR22gVRxCq3sXgByLwKHKwlZkEfLNdXtI9vGHwOq9C7VV@CirFeavemDznGfZBw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000652)

Answer (score 2):

## 319. [C (8cc)](https://github.com/rui314/8cc), 292 bytes, A001688

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long f) {
    if ( f == 0 ) 
        return 1;
    return(f * factorial(f - 1));
}

unsigned long long a(int n) {
    return factorial(n) * (pow(n,4) + (6*pow(n,3)) + (17*pow(n,2)) + (20*n) + 9);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d",a(4));
}
```

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000292)

Answer (score 2):

## 320. Java 7, 308 bytes, [A000292](https://oeis.org/A000292)

```java
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(new Main().BinomialCoefficient(new Long(args[0])+2, 3));
  }
  
  static long BinomialCoefficient(long n, long k){
    return n==k || k<1?
        1
      :
        BinomialCoefficient(n-1, k) + BinomialCoefficient(n-1, k-1);
  }
}
```

Easy enough; calculates the Binomial Coefficient of `n+2` and `3` as stated in the OEIS sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fY69DsIgFEZ3n@KOJbaN6OZPTHTVydF0wBYbhF4aoBqjfXaktXFqJBDIPV8O343dWaJrjrdCep8rZi0cmcDXBKBuLkrkYB1z4bprUUAVUHRyRmB5zoCZ0pIuCXB6WserVDcurQN1CiPkj14VkXQnUFeCqb3m16vIBUfX44PGMuos51lGpvMYFoSsgq8NJ@zhZxVSMKboAcbfgByaGO4ag4CbjYT3G@Sabvt5t@jwWv4mo80SGgcdTP/QhA5FW@89nX0A)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000308)

Answer (score 2):

## 321. [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 249 bytes, [A000308](https://oeis.org/A000308)

```
#lang racket/base
(define sub-one (λ (n) (+ n -1)))
(define sub-two (compose sub-one sub-one))
(define sub-thr (compose sub-one sub-two))
(define A000308 (λ (n) (if (< n 4) n (* (A000308 (sub-one n)) (A000308 (sub-two n)) (A000308 (sub-thr n))))))
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoJADEX3nuInLmw1xEFQMXHjUQYYlAgzhMEYz@YdvBIORkGJXbTpz@v/rWVyVk3bTgupj6hf2zKWVk0oVVmuFewl9oyb9LiDNIMW0PB8Zv5BmqsBJaasjB1u3nOMnur/qPP4Qg9CiEBEQ3CegfYuPGTXaA7qiY@JZh6p3Vt/VPeBU7tqKc1tVcgbqJRVHzojHysECLHGBltE2MEXHf8E)
- [Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000249)

Answer (score 2):

## 323. [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 238 bytes, [A000150](http://oeis.org/A000150)

```lisp
(defun catalan (n)
  (if (zerop n) 1 (/ (* 2 (+ n n -1) (catalan (1- n))) (1+ n))))
(let ((n (read)))
  (if (= n 0) (print 0)
    (if (evenp n)
      (print (/ (catalan n) 2))
      (print (/ (- (catalan n) (catalan (/ (- n 1) 2))) 2)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsIwELz3K@a4awmaXjz5MaFNIRDWEKMHfz5uYqsIsrAs89iZOYZbqpUWv94FsysuOgEJDwCFFfT0@ZogDAs6gg6YQCNEx1gGfRzWqIgVsWM/eKDoC4iUy94tDdleXtR8UmXKQYpeim@Mf3hpYR3Brmi5e44WmfgPb34k31qdEthuey/mWs8v)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000238)

Answer (score 2):

## 324. [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon), 559 bytes, [A000238](https://oeis.org/A000238)

```
import fractions,itertools
global fractions,k,R,itertools;# ugh
R=[0,1]
p=lambda a:[i*x for i,x in enumerate(a)][1:]
A=lambda a,b:list(map(sum,itertools.zip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=0)))
m=lambda p,q,n:[sum((p+k*[0])[i]*(q+k*[0])[k-i]for i in range(k+1))for k in range(len(p+q)-1)][:n]
for n in range(len(R),int(input())+2):
	P=[]
	for k in range(1, n):P=A(P,[fractions.Fraction(x,k)for x in[0if i%k else R[i//k]for i in range(n)]])
	f=[0,1];F=1
	for i in range(n):f=A(p(f),m(f,p([x*2for x in P]),n));F*=i+1
	R+=[f[0].numerator//F]
print(R[-1]-m(R,R,len(R))[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwEDyHr7BUVfKCSSBHIg65cEZcLatyWpOuMLbDo6L9eWrybHqzd3ZnZmfdtzXzjK2z3UDqTr4PaE3PcFDdYK3ug6O2B6n/QA2rHvDuhYzHz6DKecJSEbhcy/bwIYnMOIYTqW1HkE0EDVFmbFUnB0UlCJ5mItjfm9kh09gPtJWO9mP7oF//oHvT1hyVR30bq1HrL6lHlScAELQ3CsdOzGTcD1PqoibkiQCOIqSn26eJUZztLGY66SlpE6UAS6151LQynuAEcepdZkYEC26e8QoYmoGiceNAAaItZMGqzLkIVv/YUkYMZGW@pyXj9wjXxfVFJ9acDSwJ8QRrgq8NUbpXpOK42TT/HRsQArzKJe5dkacXyaeWrPZ6jtbAWlozR/kUbm8ipBTADMCuCHOM/HQV5bz2Aa2v57HdZlP4Q3bLhhWPUxG3tPInvywOSwXmOU1@AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000559)

I initially wrote an answer that calculated A000150 in Befunge, then KSmarts answered, before Christian Sievers noticed that I've made that mistake. I took my code from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151720/55934), added a call to `mul` to calculate a different sequence, and golfed it all a lot.

Comment: TIO doesn't seem to like the `# ugh`

Comment: @ChristianSievers ugh, fixed

Comment: Is that a bug in Pyon?

Comment: @ChristianSievers There are many bugs in Pyon that I don't intend to fix. The language was made in about half an hour and I don't plan to spend more time on it because it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 2):

## 325. [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 385 bytes, [A000559](https://oeis.org/A000559)

```perl6
my $n = get+3;
my @s = 0..$n;
my $result = 0;

for @s -> $k {
  $result = $result + stirling($n,$k)*stirling($k,3);
}

say $result;

sub stirling ($n, $k) {
  my @a = 0..$k;
  my $s = 0;
  for @a -> $j {
    $s = $s + ((-1)**($k-$j) * binom($k, $j) * $j**$n);
  }
  return $s / ([*] 1..$k);
}

sub binom ($n, $k) {
  my $l = $n-$k;
  return ([*] 1..$n) / ( ([*] 1..$k)*([*] 1..$l) );
}
```

An operator in square brackets is a reduction operator over a list. So `[*] 1..$k` is `$k` factorial.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BisIwFEX3@Yq7eIsmtToiDEIZ8T8GFxWqtE2fQ9IuRPz2Tl7SqcIsEnKT3PPOT@3s5zT1dxDjC9d6yHelCvHoQ/xYr4ljJFf70Q5yVyp1uTn5UBxAHR4Kb89/pxx@aJxt@JoRr6jT5pW71U6X6qmUrxZyoPrxvJQgrUDXES8@1ezTlemCfJIBok0Vbdr4HekxbDmyrNhqY8LQgloNg3PDt14ckDK1xhBrAT3DcvUwOpbuBtm3OWErM2fdIBjr/@zIyjwukt3MWOqsBfaOM8vZagh8mva/)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000385)

Answer (score 2):

## 327. [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 439 bytes, [A000205](https://oeis.org/A000205)

```
(load library)

(def x^2+3*y^2
 (lambda (x y)
  (add2
   (mul2 x x)
   (* y y 3))))

(def _sum-of-squares?
 (lambda (n x y)
  (if (equal? n (x^2+3*y^2 x y))
   1
   (if (less? n (x^2+3*y^2 x y))
    (if x
     (_sum-of-squares? n 0 (inc y))
     0)
    (_sum-of-squares? n (inc x) y)))))

(def sum-of-squares?
 (lambda (n)
  (_sum-of-squares? n 1 0)))

(def A000205
 (lambda (n)
  (length
   (filter sum-of-squares?
    (1to (pow 2 n))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BTsMwEETv@Yo5rosqOa7gWvEjRS52wJLjhDgRzteHzaopiBbsy3r3zYx3DGmOIffLQrGzDjGcBzvMqqrI@QblZB4Ou/lkKlC07dlZUAGPAbLOcZuLdooGBUXJa4eZ70HxuZi85Kndd80@f0x28Pn4wythcwsNyDMQj0icseXKXIxrcV@x6HP@ixKiSAX6HcwazUB6vdLQF9UdVMCiVvZ7l39WkTXu@NQcctU/a62NfrzRRZ/exndZsQlx9MNt0jqrxw7Ud58wSPIttVBr@80WpBl44u4X)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000439)

This is pretty slow, but it should work for any input, given enough time and memory.

The main function, `A000205`, generates all integers from `1` to `2^n`; filters the list, keeping numbers of the form `x^2+3*y^2`; and returns the length of the resulting list.

There's probably a better way to check whether a number is of the form `x^2+3*y^2`. Here's the algorithm I used (see the function `_sum-of-squares`):

- Start checking at `x=1`, `y=0`. At any point, if `x^2+3*y^2 == n`, stop and return `1` (truthy).
- If `x^2+3*y^2` is less than `n`, increment `x`.
- If `x^2+3*y^2` is greater than `n`, reset `x` to `0` and increment `y`.
- If, when `x` is `0`, `x^2+3*y^2` is still greater than `n`, then there are no `x` and `y` that will make the equation work. Return `0` (falsey).

Answer (score 2):

## 328. [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 222 bytes, [A000439](https://oeis.org/A000439)

```
def lin(n):return     n        :enddef
def sqr(n):return lin(n)*lin(n):enddef
def cub(n):return sqr(n)*lin(n):enddef
def hyp(n):return sqr(n)*sqr(n):enddef
def seq(n):return(hyp(n)+18*cub(n)+83*sqr(n)+114*lin(n))/24:enddef
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LDkAwEEX3vsJSNUKxEH/jUdGESZUu@vX1mEk0YRazOuee1WV9t6vB@1FO8aIgAdYaeVgD8X34r2sljBcS3di@mQBDKSU3wAbbBxhKP9js9BejRBiV24slKHHRpFjhTUUOF6KmCsvLmia8NgqOZ0QUzJ8)
- [Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000222)

Comment: is the first line just to make the bytecount work? :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino ... functionally relevant code formatting!

Answer (score 2):

## 329. [Yacas](http://www.yacas.org), 155 bytes, [A000222](https://oeis.org/A000222)

```
/* compute the series A000222 with yacas */
f(n) := Sum(k,2,n,Bin(2*n-k,k) * (n-k)! * (-1)^k * Bin(k,2));
/* only the space between ! and * is necessary */
```

Put it in a file and load it with `Load("a000222");` - alternatively,
there is an online demo of yacas [here](http://www.yacas.org/yacas_online/yacas_online.html), you can paste the definition, press Shift+Enter, then input something like `f(10);` followed again by Shift+Enter.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000155)

I can explain the series and the formula, but there is a big gap between these explanations:

The crossrefs entry of A000222 says it is a diagonal of A058057.

The comments of that series describe `n*n` matrices where the main
diagonal from `(1,1)` to `(n,n)` and the diagonal below from `(2,1)` to
`(n,n-1)` have `x` entries and the remaining entries are `1`.

The permanents of these matrices are polynomials in `x`.
A058057 gives their coefficients.
A bit of experimentation shows that A000222 consists of the coefficients
of `x^2`.

It follows that A000222 gives the number permutations of `{1,...,n}`
that have exactly two positions `i` that are mapped to `i` or
(if `i>1`) to `i-1`.

That doesn't seem to help efficiently computing the series, I rather feel
I have reconstructed the problem to which the permanent is the answer.

I had exciting ideas how to compute the permanent in the quotient ring
`Z[x]/(x^3)`, because doing it in `Z[x]` is unnecessary work, but there
is an easier way.

The maple code for A058057 starts with a definition that expresses the
polynomial as the sum of `k` from `0` to `n` of an integer expresssion
in `n` and `k` times `(x-1)^k`.
I don't know where this comes from, it might be explained in Riordan's
book mentioned in the references.
This book has come up often, I think I want it!

Anyway, the coefficient of `x^2` of the last term is
`(-1)^k*binomial(k,2)` for `k>=2` and `0` otherwise, which leads to
the formula used in the program.

Comment: The expression of the polynomial as a sum is related to the [ménage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem). Judging from the permutations that come up, I think it might have to do with the variations that allow for some (in this case, two) couples to sit together.

Comment: @KSmarts Yes, if there is a meeting of the heterosexual binary couples' society with `n` couples sitting at one side of a long (not round) table where the women sit first at the odd numbered chairs, there are that many ways for the men to sit such that exactly two couples sit together.

Comment: Now I see why the formula is true. I thought it was somehow derived from the permanent, but it can be obtained in exactly this form by simple combinatorical arguments. The fact that it is a polynomial in `x-1` already suggests that is might have come from an application of the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

## 331. [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 766 bytes, [A001854](https://oeis.org/A001854)

```python
# grow all roted trees on n labeled nodes
def grow(nodes, tree = (), r = ()):
	used_nodes = tuple(j for j in nodes |> range if any(j in k for k in tree)) or (0,)
	available_nodes = tuple(j for j in nodes |> range if j not in used_nodes)
	if not available_nodes: return tree |> sorted |> tuple,
	for node in used_nodes:
		for new_node in available_nodes: r += grow(nodes, (tree, ((node, new_node),)) |*> (+))
	return r |> set |> sorted |> tuple

# calculate a tree's height
def tree_height(tree):
	tree, lengths = tree |> list, {0: 0}
	while tree:
		for v in tree:
			if v[0] in lengths: lengths[v[1]] = lengths[v[0]]+1; tree.remove(v)
	return lengths.values() |> max

# implement A001854
def A001854(nodes): return (nodes, sum(map(tree_height, grow(nodes)))) |*> (*)
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLbsIwEDyTr1iJQ22wUJBaCVGB1O9AEXJhgYBjI8cJrUq/nXo3CdDHpSfvK7Mzs1m5lbNVuFz6sPXuBNoY8C7gGoJHLMFZsGD0K5pYsm6NZbLGDc8KThUPwgyEVOD5ldOkV5W4XvJALIXqaFDsYeM87CG3DRCc5@C13SLkG9D2XXDrwFMHCglYSoipSJVMerrWeaRi8D/A@1gL1LoxilCxQeUfiFPwGCrfbCaU0nmyIka8SSU92kSz3xGj4KaDp2XX/Y0Nw9k34wStiQ/n6vqxVFH0eTAHMZSRakvJMx8Mf9BKkj6stFlVRgcEzewfSthhvt0FPhdVlk3OS@lCzXKDdht27GWr2eRlUPCRTiH9THqnXW6Qe53GujsNFcjIepFmVGuhpl2wqBfjLIvItzzNsuH4mb8eeSxcjaK@SWznRrU2FZZCEptCv5G8vIg6C7QBXtJ0PHl6ZFlt3Pgpr9fr/C2rQhT6KO7Uq7sDSNn5PJAXmmvhVPPziLGCiZSdJfQefW7D5Qs)
- [Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000766)

Comment: Oh and I tried doing it the way that required nth derivative of some crazy function

Comment: @IQuick143 Brute. Force.

Comment: @IQuick143 `f=\sum_{k>=1}k*(s_k-s_{k-1})` where `s_0(x)=x` and `s_{h+1}(x)=x*exp(x)` is not that crazy...

Answer (score 2):

## 333. [Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 219 bytes, [A000852](http://oeis.org/A000852)

```swift
import Foundation
{typealias N=NumberFormatter;var i=$0+1,k=0;while i>0 {k+=1;let F=N();F.numberStyle=N.Style.spellOut;if "eo".contains("\(F.string(from:NSNumber(value:k))![" ".startIndex])"){i-=1}};print(k)}as(Int)->()
```

My previous [Physica submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/155444/3) was invalid, because it didn't handle numbers like **14000**. This is also compatible with Swift 4, and `var f=` needn't be included in the byte count.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xbsMgFEXn@iso6gBKg3DVKYSMlrLQIWPbgSbQPBmDBc9JI8vf7rrpdJdz7r3lCh5f5xm6PmUkTRriySKkWF1sJl6PeOudDWALMdoM3ZfLTcqdRXRZ/SGgn@Sqfm61VNczBEdgJ8nYrnStglsKtWFcNSLe1QPegtNG3FOU3oXwNqACT6hLVBxTRAuxMPrBGlEwQ/xmPqduYw7/2@xiw@A2LeeP75TQhbEZ9/Hkfj455SOsdT1Nql9EZC2fbGH7iHy9Y3z2aTlLIBImhdi@SD5WD54Br6b5Fw)

[Next sequence.](http://oeis.org/A000219)

Comment: You seem to have forgotten your chain number (probably 333).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Whoops sorry fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## 338. [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 287 bytes, [A000154](https://oeis.org/A000154)

```
...........)...........
..........1)1..........
.........)2)7).........
........35)228)........
.......1834)1738.......
......2)195866)24......
.....87832)3549957.....
....6)562356672)979....
...4156448)186025364...
..016)3826961710272)8..
.4775065603888)2011929.
826983504W)IEsm........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc49CsJQEATgPjeZRt7@7zuAhSewTiUBtYix8PRPg4TEn62GjxnYaRz66@l@7sdherS2Ww@b3K2RQP8cjMCvi4E58e2UoqCQ/HQGVUt3sG49I4UhprVarO4wZzH3YNSoiyuZqyYovbCJ69sLOSTZq1NQ4dcmZ9cIK25eJDPBhahy3XVzMcWKHnHY3y7L/63ZEw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000287)

The previous sequence is erroneous, so hardcoding the terms listed in OEIS should be allowed as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

## 340. x86_64 assembly (nasm), 206 bytes, [A000209](https://oeis.org/A000209)

```
extern printf
section .data
fmt: db "%d", 10, 0
section .text
global f
f:
    push rdi
    fild qword [rsp]
    fptan
    fstp st0
    fistp qword [rsp]
    pop rsi
    lea rdi, [rel fmt]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf wrt ..plt
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/bagMhEH2frxgChZamkryV/ZU0hMmqW8FVM07Tzddb3W26FOKDeDxzLkM5m/Hsb29D35eiXBDjT/kWhCYMMbGxbgJlJjEcMHHlLShNQmBH6VBlqX8Dbp70R9iAkjoJavDx7NGC7QDrSV/5E1m7GVjnNV6@I2tMwnjgnI4LkYTC8sqSMMvz7uVX0fAjSYoJOS@@3lDL2OKhFlvoMV6RadriboY9eX9foWE2An@rkUR3Lz6SC9CubrWZnWvW6/txNZtF/2dq3spbeNSj5ZZS9vsf)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000206)

The only reason I'm printing instead of returning the result is that I needed to get a higher byte count.

To test save the code below in `a206.asm` and run

```
$ nasm -f elf64 a206.asm
$ gcc a206.o -o a206
$ ./a206 11
-226
```

Test code:

```
extern printf
section .data
fmt: db "%d", 10, 0
section .text
global f
f:
    push rdi
    fild qword [rsp]
    fptan
    fstp st0
    fistp qword [rsp]
    pop rsi
    lea rdi, [rel fmt]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf wrt ..plt
    ret

extern atoi
global main
main:
    mov rdi, [rsi+8]
    call atoi wrt ..plt

    mov rdi, rax
    call f

    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## 348. Rust, 607 bytes, [A000824](http://oeis.org/A000824)

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use std::io::*;
fn main()->Result<()>{
    let mut stdin = stdin();
    let mut s = String::new();
    stdin.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
    let n=s.parse().unwrap()+1;
    println!("{}", a(n));
    Ok(())
}
fn a(n:u32)->BigUint{
    let part_a = helper(3,3,n);
    let part_b = helper(2,3,n) * 3u32;
    let part_c = helper(1,1,n) << 1;
    (part_a + part_b +part_c)/6u32
}
fn helper(r:u32,s:u32,n:u32)->BigUint{
    let one:BigUint = 1u32.into();
    let part_a = &one << (r << n); 
    let part_b = ((&one << n) - &one) * (&one << (s * (1 << (n - 1))));
    (part_a + part_b) >> n
}
```

[Try it on the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&code=use%20num_bigint%3A%3ABigUint%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3A*%3B%0Afn%20main()-%3EResult%3C()%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20stdin%20%3D%20stdin()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20s%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20stdin.read_to_string(%26mut%20s)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20n%3D%20s.parse().unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20a(n))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%7D%0Afn%20a(n%3Au32)-%3EBigUint%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20part_a%20%3D%20helper(3%2C3%2Cn)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20part_b%20%3D%20helper(2%2C3%2Cn)%20*%203u32%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20part_c%20%3D%20helper(1%2C1%2Cn)%20%3C%3C%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(part_a%20%2B%20part_b%20%2B%20part_c)%2F6u32%0A%7D%0Afn%20helper(r%3Au32%2Cs%3Au32%2Cn%3Au32)-%3EBigUint%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20one%3ABigUint%20%3D%201u32.into()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20part_a%20%3D%20%26one%20%3C%3C%20(r%20%3C%3C%20n)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20part_b%20%3D%20((%26one%20%3C%3C%20n)%20-%20%26one)%20*%20(%26one%20%3C%3C%20(s%20*%20(1%20%3C%3C%20(n%20-%201))))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(part_a%20%2B%20part_b)%20%3E%3E%20n%0A%7D%0Afn%20stdin()-%3E%26%27static%5Bu8%5D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%2219%22%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000607)

I used the num_bigint crate to get arbitrary precision integers. Since the rust playground doesn't support stdin I created a drop-in replacement method- simply change the number in-between the 2 quotation marks to change the input. The code can make it up to a(18), which  has 473,473 digits, before it times out if you do a release build. The sequence is calculated based on the formula found on the OEIS (after adjusting to a 1-index and using bitshifts for the \$2^n\$s):

$$\text{Let } b_n(r,s) = \frac{2^{r\cdot2^n} + (2^n-1)\cdot2^{s\cdot2^{n-1}}}{2^n} \\
\text{Then, } a(n) = \frac{b_n(3,3) + 3b_n(2,3) + 2b_n(1,1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

## 350. [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 166 bytes, [A000774](https://oeis.org/A000774)

```
*Π¹→ṁ\ḣ
" Explanation
"
" *Π¹→ṁ\ḣ
"    →      1 plus
"     ṁ\     sum of reciprocals of
"       ḣ     the range [1..N]
" *        times
"  Π¹       the factorial of N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X@vcgkM7H7VNerizMebhjsVcSgquFQU5iXmJJZn5eVxKQD6mCiAA8hXAwFChIKe0GCKoAFICZhSX5irkpykUpSZnFhTlJyfmFAO5UEVAZTsWg@mSjFSFosS89FSFaEM9Pb9YkGVQJQolmbmpYGNBtsPEgOrTEpNL8osyE3NA5vv9///fyAAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000166)

It was surprisingly tricky to get the explanation to come out to the correct length.

Answer (score 2):

## 351. [Quipu](https://github.com/cgccuser/quipu), 178 bytes, [A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166)

```
" 0  1  2  3  4"
"--------------"
 \/ 1& 2& 1& 3&
 1& ++ ^^ ++ []
 ++ 0& -- 1& 1&
    []    [] ++
    %%    ** /\
    4&    2&
    ==    []
          --
          1&
          ??
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720sDSzoHTBgqWlJWm6Fjc3KSkYKCgYKigYKSgYKyiYKHEp6aIAJS6FGH0FQzUFIzUQaazGBaK0tRXi4kBkdCwXiDJQU9DVBUkYAuWBIDoWSmprg_mqqiBSS0tBPwbMN1EDkUYQxba2EMVgDgTo6iJxoGZCgL09xOVQDyxYaAZhAAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000178)

Based on [Aaroneous Miller's factorial answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/234986/9288).

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237281/9288) is a golfed version.

Answer (score 2):

## 353. [Tampio (imperative)](https://github.com/fergusq/tampio), 260 bytes, [A000197](https://oeis.org/A000197)

```
Pienen Luvun kertoma on
  riippuen siitä, onko se pienempi tai yhtä suuri kuin yksi,
  joko yksi
  tai pieni luku kerrottuna pienen luvun edeltäjän kertomalla.

Luvun edeltäjä on se vähennettynä yhdellä.

Luvun kaksoiskertoma on sen kertoman kertoma.
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000260)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLrYNADEX3VOECEI0ki9eCpVjCzGAjxo5EP3RCYTxPkMhHWWTnz7nXH8NxYuV9/2MSErj63QUSzaYjgkoDMDNPk0evMNu2tlFNCoVgqpKQgyHD0kcPivvMkJwFllS4DfmgQdck4gpWFUP25HXMrGYueHhJlOt4ulEOt2Fbz1Vyxq5prh/tWKUuct/WnkTIbJEoLn0AeVtPQcJUlMvzqhCdzmfQNfslYMzKRoYoLZhnLUfycP20qve9Mgl/gTSPX6EB3zihfHzgDez2fw)

Yes, a Finnish programming language, even though I don't speak that language.

Thanks [@fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq) for making this awesome language, and writing a detailed introduction.

The code above compiles to the following JavaScript code:

```
Number.prototype.f_kertoma = function() {
 var pieni_luku = this;
 return ((this<=(1)) ? ((1)) : ((pieni_luku*pieni_luku.f_edeltäjä().f_kertoma())));
};
Number.prototype.f_edeltäjä = function() {
 return (this-(1));
};
Number.prototype.f_kaksoiskertoma = function() {
 return this.f_kertoma().f_kertoma();
};
```

The first two functions, `kertoma` (factorial) and `edeltäjä` (predecessor), are directly taken from fergusq's factorial example in the introduction.

The sequence is defined in the third function: `kaksoiskertoma`. Since I don't speak Finnish, I can't find a suitable name. Kaksoiskertoma actually means the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) (\$n!!=n*(n-2)*(n-4)*\cdots\$), while A000197 is literally applying the factorial function twice.

Answer (score 2):

## 356. [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 703 bytes, [A000244](https://oeis.org/A000244)

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE loop
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE x
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE p
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS p
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
GET TO THE CHOPPER loop
HERE IS MY INVITATION p
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET i
ENOUGH TALK
STICK AROUND loop
 GET TO THE CHOPPER i
 HERE IS MY INVITATION i
 GET UP 1
 ENOUGH TALK
 GET TO THE CHOPPER x
 HERE IS MY INVITATION x
 YOU'RE FIRED 3
 ENOUGH TALK
 GET TO THE CHOPPER loop
 HERE IS MY INVITATION p
 LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET i
 ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
TALK TO THE HAND x
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLNboNADITvPMXcco76Al3AZK3sD10vQRyr9oIUNVVPeXtqQFXbiKY35Pl2PLZ5/ni7nF9fponzTiA29pk9FZYGVDaxZG8EORHhfLm8F0PsIJTRCboWjyGiTbF05OPWk/GWZzimegu93qD7Lehu/4OWVU4woniEN0n0RR3BGSH2BaM3Ic@SkeOMwqDsQmURGzx1JJljEJhQ4xu15kTIlrzWpadEKnpPNZtMbliaKqWAZo1tS2ndk1USLPADOJw4m9lb0zjlY9NAoidIJuNRUghaHQsKsTtYZOOOhWapjjApdppmccRGq7HAdqNxxZc94qfvlsv1LxcVdEs7lRqeB3/432uN@tf0uDf@L@/KsnPF/PnVwc53Wf@S5SYlUUCm5DnoKepp2n8C)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000703)

Answer (score 2):

## 361. Excel (Insider Beta), 272 bytes, [A000215](http://oeis.org/A000215)

#### Define name times2 as a LAMBDA function, 224 bytes

```
times2=LAMBDA(x,y,
 IF(y=0,
    x,
    LET(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),
        b,MID(x,a,1)*2,
        times2(
          CONCAT(IF(INDEX(b,1)>9,1,""),
                 RIGHT(b)+IF(a=LEN(x),0,INT(INDEX(b,a+1)/10))),
          y-1))))
```

#### Cell A2, 15 bytes

```
=times2(1,2^A1)
```

#### Cell A3, 33 bytes

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)&(RIGHT(A2)+1)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnWxCAsond9jCPypQ?e=WyWOwE)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000272)

Answer (score 2):

## 362. [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 324 bytes, [A000272](https://oeis.org/A000272)

```
    ^           ^
   / \         /?\
  /set\       ^---^
 ^-----^     /!\ / \
/n\   /#\   ^---/out\
---  ^---  /?\  -----^
    / \   ^---^     /0\
   /   \ /n\ / \    ---
  /line \---/out\
  -------  ^-----
          /^\
         ^---^
        /n\ / \
        ---/ - \
          ^-----^
         /n\   /2\
         ---   ---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NDsIwCMfvfQrMzg3TF9iLEBKjTVzipnHz4NNXKC0dB8rHnx/0/ftcl/ket9sjLSlnEGPoxkEcAnkBJ5ISbmlvNY4xikwfCUx0Ih0KuKoIB6oyfH13ChJYWmgANhjAN3EHjWQHgDSUVk8RgV7xnNcE5OCKavii8buZesa@sLSM67nyIB4KDddHoP7schCVvepzPo9/)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000324)

Answer (score 2):

## 367. [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 187 bytes, [A000202](https://oeis.org/A000202)

```python
N
Count i while _%60/48 {
  _/60*10 + _%60-48
  _*60 + N
}
_/60

_/8 * 13 + (_%8+1) * 8/5

Count d while _/10^d {
  Count i while 9/(_/10^d) * (d+1-i) {
    Write _/10^(d-i)%10 + 48
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCgIxEET7/YppArmEIwmeIdb219oZvItgQBTkxELy7TGJZ2GzsG92Zuc0z9OU80j7@/O2IOJ1idczPLNaDQ5vAryyWhgN2Wg/uMqErWCkRFWmMh0EzKZA7pmTpiurU1tag8MvWBl9DC33/@NO8a9WjTxI08eunQGHR1xWJw8Fs1am9UiUcrb2Aw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000187)

#### Explanation

The top and bottom sections are merely code for inputting and outputting a decimal integer, respectively. The line by itself in the middle is what computes the sequence. Observe that *i* in the OEIS definition is the same as the zero-based index integer-divided by 8, while *j* (adjusted for zero-indexing) is the remainder of that division, i.e. the index mod 8. After some trial and error, we discover that we can map *j* to the numbers 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12 by a simple linear function.

```python
_                   # The sequence index
 /8                 # int-divided by 8 (i)
   *13              # times 13
      +             # Plus
        _%8         # the index mod 8 (j)
       (   +1)      # plus 1
              *8    # times 8
                /5  # int-divided by 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## 368. [Reason](https://reasonml.github.io), 1015 bytes, [A000187](https://oeis.org/A000187)

```ml
type expr =
  | Const(int)
  | X
  | Cos(expr)
  | Sin(expr)
  | Add(expr, expr)
  | Mul(expr, expr)
  | Div(expr, expr);

let rec eval_at_0 = (e: expr): int =>
  switch (e) {
  | Const(c) => c
  | X => 0
  | Cos(_) => 1
  | Sin(_) => 0
  | Add(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) + eval_at_0(f)
  | Mul(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) * eval_at_0(f)
  | Div(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) / eval_at_0(f)
  };

let rec deriv = (e: expr): expr =>
  switch (e) {
  | Const(_) => Const(0)
  | X => Const(1)
  | Cos(e) => Mul(Const(-1), Mul(deriv(e), Sin(e)))
  | Sin(e) => Mul(deriv(e), Cos(e))
  | Add(e, f) => Add(deriv(e), deriv(f))
  | Mul(e, f) => Add(Mul(deriv(e), f), Mul(e, deriv(f)))
  | Div(e, f) =>
    Div(
      Add(Mul(deriv(e), f), Mul(Const(-1), Mul(e, deriv(f)))),
      Mul(f, f),
    )
  };

let rec iter = (f, a, n: int) => n > 0 ? f(iter(f, a, n - 1)) : a;

let egf: expr =
  Div(
    Add(Cos(Mul(Const(2), X)), Cos(Mul(Const(4), X))),
    Cos(Mul(Const(5), X)),
  );

let a000187 = (n: int) => eval_at_0(iter(deriv, egf, 2 * n));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPBTsMwDL3vK3ysIYN0gECdBkJwQuLEZbep6pJRqcqmtgwQ8O0jdrImXafd4veenWc7qVXerM1u135vFKivTQ2zEcAvPK1N0yalaZHDuQebhDQOeytNFD0ulxwJCNjrRzXAnsttjE1Ho0q1UKsC1DavFnm7kDCDRGWOz8B6gNm9zW0@y7Z4txTCT@SxQEtD4WzSUXZeF0ylnVsXy@BXgGaou5qKn0ehjho5Kj4birnDo@LLQ/Ff1P5S1eW237rbx4neXUPuLDGMwCEphq2xkNpw1DhFwSHfamnh1okY7bbLCSJXC4cTpCDI3EnjkemRsF9TeysqyhtO0gLAAB/gRJ2DDntlUfh0YjTnMHC4jLJVNe3CSnIBhl8h2zdgHxA8gE5IsudhDCkiZJD7Gmqls/CdOttkmkYYbE6syzn6yQb42sHeXZ@78SmW2n@fXEqZ3t2S48hreGzslacgyJqAiX24BnG6e2kuqvUq8QWSK8L@AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001015)

The exponential generating function of the sequence is \$(\cos(2x)+\cos(4x))/\cos(5x)\$. Here I compute the sequence using symbolic differentiation. Very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

## 370. [Swahili](https://github.com/malcolmkiano/swahili), 490 bytes, [A000163](https://oeis.org/A000163)

```
shughuli a000163(n) {
    wacha s = []
    kwa i = 0 mpaka n {
        s = s + 1
    }
    kwa i = 2 mpaka n {
        kwa j = 0 mpaka s/i {
            kwa k = i mpaka n {
                s.weka(k, s/k + s/(k-i))
            }
        }
    }
    wacha t = []
    kwa a katika s {
        t = t + 2 * a
    }
    kwa i = 0 mpaka 3 {
        kwa j = 1 mpaka n {
            kwa k = 0 mpaka j {
                t.weka(j, t/j + (t/k) * (s/(j-k)))
            }
        }
    }
    rudisha t
}
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000490)

Swahili is a programming language in Swahili.

Answer (score 2):

## 371. [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 224 bytes, [A000490](https://oeis.org/A000490)

```factor
:: A000364 ( n -- m )
    n [ 1 ] [
        -1 swap ^ neg n iota [| i |
            -1 i ^ i A000364 * 2 n * 2 i * nCk *
        ] map-sum *
    ] if-zero ; flushable
    
: A000490 ( n -- m )
    dup A000364 16 rot ^ * ; inline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU4xasNAEOz1iikTgYTkGEPkKqQIbtyEVEKB82VlLT7tyXcnQoL/rpxtoSJTLMzu7My0Sgfrpo/33f6tgrFaGY8TOSGDXoUub0fRga34G4Wn80ii6U5zbfsDi4oWrD0GRyH8DI4lYJvs9hWO1rRTVeGlKIqnzRoPEGQZejwmiBDUKNGgvrErshL@Ww34hNAx3tkGhfoCxmXRzDqOIl6cU6yi/Do5Tnk9IV0emlh2yPzYz7sG3Ga/5Cy2aM3oO3UwlCT3muvn4n/Nr3FYcsoNnA0xOo3PLIaFprKYey4GecwgpbvpDw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000224)

Answer (score 2):

## 372. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 170 bytes, [A000224](https://oeis.org/A000224)

```
ɾ²$%UL

#       | | \ / \ /  _  |
#       \ /  |   X  /_\ |
#        v   |  / \ | | |__
#             
#   Terse, elegant and readable.
#   https://github.com/vyxal/vyxal
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvsKyJCVVTFxuXG4jICAgICAgIHwgfCBcXCAvIFxcIC8gIF8gIHxcbiMgICAgICAgXFwgLyAgfCAgIFggIC9fXFwgfFxuIyAgICAgICAgdiAgIHwgIC8gXFwgfCB8IHxfX1xuIyAgICAgICAgICAgICBcbiMgICBUZXJzZSwgZWxlZ2FudCBhbmQgcmVhZGFibGUuXG4jICAgaHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL3Z5eGFsL3Z5eGFsIiwiIiwiMzQiXQ==)

[Next Sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000170)

My program's only six bytes, so I had to add some advertising :P

```
ɾ      # 1...n
 ²     # Squared
  $%   # Modulo n
    UL # Count unique
```

Answer (score 2):

## 374. [Halfwit](https://github.com/chunkybanana/halfwit/), 1091 bytes, [A000907](https://oeis.org/A000907)

```
n+:+R*;?>+<*>*<+*>b<>{<?>M<+e?>M<N+R*;**/NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoYWxmd2l0IixudWxsLCJuKzorUio7Pz4rPCo+KjwrKj5iPD57PD8+TTwrZT8+TTxOK1IqOyoqL05OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTiIsIiIsIls1bl0iLCIiXQ==)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001091)

Issue is, I can't include any nice formatting because that isn't included within the codepage. So, I have to include a large amount of NOP `N`s as padding. Uses the formula from the OEIS page.

Answer (score 2):

## 375. [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 231 bytes, [A001091](https://oeis.org/A001091)

```factor
:: A001091 ( m -- n )
    [
        [let
            1 4 :> ( a! b! )
            m [
                b :> c
                b 8 * a - b!
                c a!
            ] times
            a
        ]
    ] 42 [ call ] dip drop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU@xDoIwFNz5imNTEwwYBiyJiZNhYTFOhKFAVWJLm9LFr68FhUj0hpd79@4ueVdaG6nt5ZzlJwIua8p7CGrueDDdMQ6lmTFPpdvOIPWynOAm@dUSgmMYRuE@wgoCQYAOaw8OxThHxpmZlwERYpCDC1Aflf/xTxBfyQnVYK//yAk2oAhcy8@xdu0LsYRpBesXGp230nt74h0KuO@5402r0GipkNpkfnNrXw)

Really had to stretch this one to make it long enough from my initial draft of 42 bytes. It's silly, but not *overly* so, at least until the last line.

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000231)

Answer (score 2):

## 376. [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 235 bytes, [A000231](https://oeis.org/A000231)

```
(d 2pow (q ((count acc)
 (i count
  (2pow (s count 1) (a acc acc))
   acc))))

(d a000231 (q ((n)
 (a
  (2pow
   (s (2pow n 1) n)
   1)
  (s
   (2pow
    (2pow (s n 1) 1)
    1)
   (2pow
    (s
     (2pow (s n 1) 1)
     n)
    1))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY49DsMgDEZ3TvGNZoM0F0J0QaqcVCSqenrqn6B2qQdk4@dnH43fj9b3MeiOZd9eoCeI6nbygVJrDKAGKwNATnT/QI6gopSRgsITSYPoSkppuWU3sprKdCgqGvexitjGs77UrT2571YDDbnIX8iG/sCXXUqLQfO0NY4P)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000235)

We use the formula from the OEIS page, modified to not use multiplication or division:

$$2^{2^{x}-x}+2^{2^{x-1}}-2^{2^{x-1}-x}$$

Then, we implement \$2^n\$ by repeatedly doubling an accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

## 378. [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 494 bytes, [A000258](https://oeis.org/A000258)

```factor
DEFER: stirling

: (stirling) ( n k -- x )
    [ [ 1 - ] bi@ stirling ]
    [ [ 1 - ] dip stirling ]
    [ nip * + ] 2tri ;

MEMO: stirling ( n k -- x )
    2dup { [ = ] [ nip 1 = ] } 2||
    [ 2drop 1 ] [ (stirling) ] if ;

: stirling2 ( n k -- m )
    2dup { [ = not ] [ nip zero? ] } 2&&
    [ 2drop 0 ] [ stirling ] if ;

: bell ( m -- n )
    [ 1 ] [ dup [1,b] [ stirling ] with map-sum ] if-zero ;

: A000258 ( n -- m )
    dup [0,b] [ [ stirling2 ] keep bell * ] with map-sum ; flushable
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZLPToNAEIfjlaf4nZq2lgbQaqUxamI1PbQmGk8NB6BLuyksuCxR2_okXnrRd6oP4TO4sNo_NBEOwMzO982w-_4ZuL6I-XLlPj70Brc2poQzEiJyxQR-HHmUuTKfNtNJzIXuU-5nVCAiUUxnBCl5ygjzSYqEEyFeE06ZKIqb3GVjGe9ovYGNcRwGH5kI9PbXwfd196Z7byMVlIeUjTXNRvXvo4YqGKbQdbygpkFeQ3mb0OHAo5frKjil5Igm-0kmg3UcyrQlOJXNaP1u_27j3rdZoyzBXJaeyyIFMIv3N1iLxS_WGvE4j-crtlp3QIPcseFb_wpYLNaSGeHxhdJUKjsao1izGW0t8UgYFvydn6W6yiVDs-GVSp-p3NbITfQ0iwqSnnsV7sowDKvVLhMLkqFIw63BHHlUSKKaqJfRHQRhlk5cLyRq21eNuRzEhIUjHKOFE5yijTOYhpx4uHY7OQFNVbNcqucP)

Last Factor answer until 450 answers!

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000494)

Answer (score 2):

## 379. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 180 bytes, [A000494](https://oeis.org/A000494)

```
∆sṙ
##############
#####    #####
### LOOKS  ###
### LIKE   ###
### I HAVE ###
### TO     ###
### MAKE   ###
### THIS   ###
### 180    ###
### BYTES  ###
##############
   ########
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiOTAgyoAgxpsiLCLiiIZz4bmZXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjI1xuIyMjIyMgICAgIyMjIyNcbiMjIyBMT09LUyAgIyMjXG4jIyMgTElLRSAgICMjI1xuIyMjIEkgSEFWRSAjIyNcbiMjIyBUTyAgICAgIyMjXG4jIyMgTUFLRSAgICMjI1xuIyMjIFRISVMgICAjIyNcbiMjIyAxODAgICAgIyMjXG4jIyMgQllURVMgICMjI1xuIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyNcbiAgICMjIyMjIyMjIiwiIiwiIl0=)

This is a very simple formula: \$ \large a(n) = \lfloor\sin(n)\rceil \$.

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000180)

Answer (score 2):

## 383. [Wenyan](https://github.com/wenyan-lang/wenyan/), 1002 bytes, [A000241](https://oeis.org/A000241)

```
吾嘗觀「「算經」」之書。方悟「取底」之義。

吾有一術。名之曰「減之取半」。欲行是術。必先得二數。曰「甲」。曰「乙」。乃行是術曰。
 批曰。「「減甲以乙，半之，捨其餘數即得。」」
 減「甲」以「乙」。除其以二。名之曰「丙」。
 施「取底」於「丙」。乃得矣。
是謂「減之取半」也。

吾有一術。名之曰「甲零零零貳肆壹」。欲行是術。必先得一數。曰「甲」。乃行是術曰。
 注曰。「「即OEIS序列A000241也。完全圖之交點之數也，故人嘗尋其通解而不得要領，今解皆臆測也。」」
 吾有二數。曰一。曰零。名之曰「積」。曰「減」。
 為是四遍。
  施「減之取半」於「甲」於「減」。乘「積」以其。昔之「積」者。今其是矣。
  加「減」以一。昔之「減」者。今其是矣。
 云云。
 除「積」以四。乃得矣。
是謂「甲零零零貳肆壹」也。
```

[IDE](https://ide.wy-lang.org/) [Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A001002)

Uses the conjectured formula

$$\operatorname{A000241}(n)=\frac14\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}2\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}2\right\rfloor$$

because the underlying problem remains open.

Add this snippet to show the first 13 terms (from 0 to 12)

```
吾有一數。曰零。名之曰「試」。
為是十三遍。
 施「甲零零零貳肆壹」於「試」。書之。
 加「試」以一。昔之「試」者。今其是矣。
云云。
```

Answer (score 2):

## 388. [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 192 bytes, [A001984](https://oeis.org/A001984)

```lisp
(define (f n)
; AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  (list-ref '(
      7
     23
     71
    311
    479
   1559
   5711
  10559
  18191
  31391
 307271
 366791
 366791
2155919) n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc4xCsMwDAXQPacQdKg9FCKrjmI65SihtUto8ODm/q5lDZn7l8cXfFBZn5941Mu@5jcULeYV05YjmATZDg9Y/sgAYPbte9xKTHA1rUpYdaQydgnVOwcRve967nccteOMQTohiTSykz1NE4dTJ2sMtn1sa3vc2foD)

Since the sequence is erroneous, I hardcoded it.

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000192)

Answer (score 2):

## 390. [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 191 bytes, [A001001](https://oeis.org/A001001)

```clj
(defn divisors
  [n]
  (filter
    #(zero?
     (rem n %))
    (range 1
      (+ 1 n))))

(defn a001001
  [n]
  (->> n
    (divisors)
    (map #(* % (reduce + (divisors %))))
    (reduce +)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1NCoNADIX3c4oHRYiVgrPqzh6kuBAnlikaZdQuenkbO9MaQnj5e1/bj8818LaR407g/MvPY5gNcJdaK3W@XzioAk705jDevhoUeIAgy3MT20YeDBuXoAIWkmsYE52bsrSah/GlqiDx90dNVkMzKeuMbIe4tWUUx81O/DPTVgcbTcHLAkocXHX2AQ)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000191)

Answer (score 2):

## 392. [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 212 bytes, [A000374](https://oeis.org/A000374)

```
def order(k, n)
  m = 1
  loop {
    return m if k.pow(m, n) == 1
    m += 1
  }
end

def a000374(n)
  (3..n).sum { |d| n % d < 1 && d.odd? ?
    (1..d).count { |x| x.gcd(d) == 1 } / order(2, d) :
    0 } + 1
end
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZBBTsMwEEX3PsVXJSqbhsGmSKCqVY-CSsaBqsSOTKy2anISNl3AjdhwG-ykXXk08_-bP_76DvH1eD7_xLa6e_77ZVvBB7ZB7go4JYAaK5j0fnjf4JQKINg2Bpcm2wo7avxe1lmM1ajMntlY9sI6FiJTN1rr-dOjHKByTuQUfcYaJ3TcweEGjCUMplMweeY11gNLGiJWVPro2iw-dDjQW8mSx4XocX-J_FAgNReDTaf-LGVI-y-33WaS0VqR3ZTvwylN2CboNdmLUQUmmIh-dFx_5R8)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000212)

Answer (score 2):

## 396. [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 185 bytes, [A000424](https://oeis.org/A000424)

```
A_{000424} \left(  i_{nputVariable}  \right) = \left( i_{nputVariable} + 1 \right)!^{2} \cdot \sum_{m=1}^{i_{nputVariable}+1} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{m} \right)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqnkuv9vdj)

[Next Sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000185)

Comment: How on earth u do the next sequence

Comment: @Steffan Lol how am I supposed to know, I didn’t even look at it yet

Comment: lol I always try to choose a byte count that has a sequence that isn't impossible

Comment: desmos is duplicated

Comment: @ThomasPeng If you read the rules, you will see that: `Every 150 (valid) answers, the number of times a language may be used increases. So after 150 solutions have been posted, every language may be used twice (with all previous answers counting towards this).` Currently, there are about 400 answers, meaning that Desmos can be used 3 times in total. This is the 3rd answer in Desmos, so it is completely valid to use Desmos (though now Desmos can't be used again until 450 answers).

Comment: @AidenChow I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## 397. [Go](https://go.dev), 498 bytes, [A000185](https://oeis.org/A000185)

```
import ."math"

func fact(n float64) float64 {
  res := 1.0
  for i := 1.0; i <= n; i++ {
    res *= i
  }
  return res
}

func binomial(n float64, k float64) float64 {
  return fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n-k))
}

func A000185(ki int64) int64 {
  s := 0.0
  k := float64(ki)
  n := k + 5.0
  for j := 0.0; j <= k; j++ {
    s += Pow(-1.0, float64(j)) *
         (2.0 * n * fact(k - j) / float64(n + k - j)) * binomial(n - k + j, n - k) * binomial(n + k - j, n - k + j)
  }
  return int64(Round(s))
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJLTsMwEBXbnGKUld00wUW0qihZcIPCDUxpiuPGrlJHLFBPwqZC4hAcBY7BCRiPnVCQ8Gaex28-b8Yvrxt7fN_JlZabNTRSmUQ1O9s6SKvGpW-dq_L559lXdBZpI91jmiRVZ1ZQyZVjBqqtlW52yXsAzwlAu97DVQmTQuClsi2oeF0gui7BoM0yogbyqASFlwPFuq413pscYql7ZWyj5Pan3Bj0f5UpOjTH4RwYQc1hFJ255nzIfCOEmMynTCtQhpKRoVQkQZAE7WEsg1yOLuNdGjKYDiLrGLBAhCI12kHkHrISlvaJ5TiF8ZCr5tgYEeiwi0Jgo6ZvVkMOtVfR8w0WDE4v6GQuOfVSj4Hgn8cYEx89j_8eNolmd7YzD2zvxxNW_3FLQ_Ifg3ESMuwyRAhOC4XZ6T7x6xTLFglbw_r5Kh4qxsTHY7Df)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000498)

Since \$A000185(n)\$ = \$A058087(n+5,n)\$, I used the formula by [G. C. Greubel](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:G._C._Greubel) on OEIS to calculate A058087+

$$A058087(n,k) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\frac{2n(k-j)!}{n+k-j}{{n-k+j}\choose{n-k}}{{n+k-j}\choose{n-k+j}}$$

Therefore:

$$A000185(k) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\frac{2(k+5)(k-j)!}{2k+5-j}{{5+j}\choose{5}}{{2k+5-j}\choose{5+j}}$$

Answer (score 2):

## 399. [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 279 bytes, [A000176](https://oeis.org/A000176)

```
D(b,n)=(-1)^(n-1)*if(b%4==1,sum(k=1,(b-1)/2,kronecker(k,b)*(b-4*k)^(2*n-1)),sum(k=0,(b-1)\2,kronecker(b,2*k+1)*(b-2*k-1)^(2*n-1)))
d(a)=my(m,b);[b,m]=core(a,1);if(m>1,if(b>1,1,1/2)*m^7*prod(p=3,m,if(isprime(p)&&!(m%p),(p^4-kronecker(b,p))/p^4,1))*d(b),b==1,2,D(b,2)+3*b^2*D(b,1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDNTsMwDBZXXoBrQWyyPVddskogTdmJtwA6NWuLqihtlG0HnoXLLohngqfB2Y80RbKdL99nf_HXT6hjv_4Ih8P3ftflz383dy9geUADucIKBonUd2AnpTGKt3sPTjJYwQvNLo5Du3FtBMcWSeCSnMg0JSGe-fMT_-2ab1mTm6mjRqrjsLMKbxuo0fhP8NJ0-WrZv5vNGFuoWeFS3PiV4mRKkpxCI_nqiUIcGwhmwT499tsQe99CwOn0HvwkIEOoyvzaQkAsBJOuSA1YZJs-qTmtQONsQbbSlC5COO3n97EbI9SZyRRnes6ZDBl2Ajxk-UpCcn7hXnb6Dw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000279)

Using the formula on [A000061](https://oeis.org/A000061), or in [this paper](https://oeis.org/A000003/a000003.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

## 400. [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 314 bytes, [A000279](https://oeis.org/A000279)

*Thanks [@user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for helping me debug my code in the Prolog chat room!*

```
factorial(0,1).
factorial(N,X):-
	A is N-1,
	factorial(A,B),
	X is B*N.

choose(N,R,X):-
	K is N-R,
	factorial(N,A),
	factorial(R,B),
	factorial(K,C),
	X is A/(B*C).

a(_,0,0).
a(N,K,X):-
	A is K-1,
	a(N,A,B),
	choose(N,K,C),
	choose(N,A,D),
	G is N-1,
	choose(G,A,E),
	X is B+3*N*C*D*E.

a000279(N,X):-
	a(N,N,X).
```

400th answer yay!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVCxboMwFJzjr0CZbPdMTdI2TQYkQ6IMSAxMkRCqrKhpkUiNAKkbv07thkKzvbvz3bvnujGV@RDtdzkMF33uTFPqikoEzCczTnFiO0EWyitbLxUByGIWFSJmiZPTIp76hJw/jWnfrSsbfcnNl935Uih2R2S3oJlIEE/J6pFGPLatiKZvkJB21DYj@V8t@a3m6LHU1GSMmrDC3uHjfNAoHa10mO95WPOUx3zPD26zlHK12U7f4Ra52R924qrrqmw7mqsiDOnfS2VVXExz1R1d9rUnQq@v@68lcqsUjCEPsMIaT3jGCzZ4xRaBLGziDw)

[Next Sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000314)

Comment: stop giving us hard sequences lol

Answer (score 2):

## 402. [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 254 bytes, [A000303](https://oeis.org/A000303)

```ruby
def a000303(n)
  # BYTE COUNT HAS TO GET BIGGR
  # BYTE COUNT HAS TO GET BIGGR
  # BYTE COUNT HAS TO GET BIGGR
  (1..n).to_a
        .permutations
        .count { |x|
          x.chunk_while { |a, b| a < b }
           .max_of(&.size) == 2
        }
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZDBCoJAGITvPsVAEC7EYkm3PGSIdUkoO3SSTVeUdBVdyUqf3SzBeoDm9s838A/jF/dSsqTrAh6CaZqma7oqiAJMYJ5dCxvntHexXR/hOrAtF@bOtg9/4OqcUkGozDzWX4Nozou0kkzGmSi/rp9VQuKJpm5GE6ipH1Xi6t2iOOFvyma4NGBY4YL2JwiastrLQnVKy/jBCQwDi5G3ChdBl3/6LEkfzYdP4xo1Qdu9AA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000254)

Ruby has the perfect builtins for this, and Crystal is very similar to Ruby, so it does too.

Answer (score 2):

## 405. [Cognate](https://cognate-lang.github.io), 175 bytes, [A000309](https://oeis.org/A000309)

```
Def Fact (
   Let N be the input;
   For Range from 1 to + N 1 (*) 1
);

Def as A000309 (
   Let N be the input;
   * ^ N 2 Fact * 3 N;
   * Fact + 1 * 2 N Fact + 1 N;
   /
);
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY8xDoIwGIX3nuKNUGJsZdEwmRgmJcYDmFRSkIGW1J_TuLAYR2_gPbyNxWLcHP_vvbz3_uu9tLVRpIfh1lM1W74eG10hVyUhYgC2mlDgpEFnjcZ0PWUjzq3DQZlao3K2hQRZJN4oEfEYksUZY2OQumAthEjF6m8cx9HjRejlSFFM-AMSH8u9WvzOoM99T5j93LvGEHaqQzQVxtNAASmC6fvjGw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000175)

Answer (score 1):

## 89. PowerShell, 201 bytes, [A000386](https://oeis.org/A000386)

```
function f($m){if($m -lt 1){return 1};1..$m|%{$a=[bigint]1}{$a*=$_}{$a}}
function A000386($n){if($n -le 2){return 0}3..$n|%{$b=[bigint]0}{$b=(f($_-3))*(f($n+$_-3))/(f($n-$_))/(f(2*$_-6))/(f 3)-$b}{$b}}
```

[Online test suite](https://tio.run/##PY9hi4MwDIa/@yvCyEHrrq5VNgaHB/c7xpApdRZcHc5xH3r57V46h/mS9w3Jk@Q@/Nrx0dm@V80w2nlun76Z3OChFXiTwcUEqp/AyDDa6Tl6MPRlsgxvfx8BL@Wpdlfnp7MhdmmJVcxEyQr60VoXx4NAv@A84yzkK05TwTQfafVK0xSd4PZKFVKmUfntYnYvo7BaZJ5y@fDSUEiFdRwlmlv@59J0INCB4zVZZvYSQgIctukGEJugCcpvCIY2oFpA9yne17KWMqH5Hw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000201)

#### Dissection

Pretty straightforward: the sequence has the formula

$$A(n) = \sum_{j=3}^n (-1)^{n-j} (j-3)! \binom{n+j-3}{n-j,2j-6,3}$$

obtained via some algebraic manipulation from the description in [A058057](https://oeis.org/A058057). There are a couple of tricky bits:

```
x..y
```

produces a range from `x` to `y`, but it counts down if `y < x`, which is not what I want. That's why both functions have special cases.

```
x..y|%{foo}{bar}{baz}
```

is an abbreviated foreach loop. In more familiar pseudocode it might be

```
foo
for $_ = x to y
  bar
baz
```

Answer (score 1):

## 108. [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 32 bytes, [A001589](http://oeis.org/A001589)

```
a => ((4&(**),(**)&4) + *(+))(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcSxDcAgDATAVVyhf5MutGQXGiQasJAzvxOuONvL14xeo0l9BCgJqrxOqVCyKDKJxrA9pqPjPKa9Dv7i/gA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000032)

The shortest working solution would probably be `a=>a**4+4**a` :P

Answer (score 1):

## 111. [Ceres](https://github.com/alexander-liao/ceres), 42 bytes, [A000442](http://oeis.org/A000442)

```
!3*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04tSi3@/1/RWMtBgSjw//9/Q1MA)

Spacing is to get an unused easy sequence. Many trailing spaces...

Note that this works for very large values because Python and sympy, though it doesn't look like it because of printing...

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000042)

Answer (score 1):

## 112. [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 49 bytes, [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042)

```
.+
$*
$(Let's just add some padding here, yes)?
1
```

The extra part at the end is for it to be 0-indexed, to comply with the spec.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLRcMntUS9WCGrtLhEITElRaE4PzdVoQDIysxLV8hILUrVUahMLda05zL8/98cAA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000049)

Comment: That next sequence looks familiar...

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm considering making a programming language that finds the number of positive integers less than 2^n in the form Ax^2+By^2 :P I swear this kind of sequence comprises at least 25% of all OEIS :P they should make a keyword for this

Comment: @HyperNeutrino [Index entries for sequences related to populations of quadratic forms](http://oeis.org/index/Qua#quadpop), perhaps?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino According to [their indexing](http://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Qua#quadpop), there are 53 distinct sequences like that.

Comment: @KSmarts `ಠ_ಠ` yeah that's too many

Comment: @HyperNeutrino that'd be creating a language for a specific challenge, not sure whether it is allowed.

Comment: @NieDzejkob probably not I wasn't going to anyway :P it's too useless

Comment: To the next answerer: the next sequence probably requires arbitrary precision numbers because you have to compute `2^n`

Comment: *waited a day for the OEIS to not be `Ax^2+By^2`, but it came full circle*

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn More like "full ellipse"

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn It was either `Ax^2 + By^2` or binary bead necklaces...

Comment: @BusinessCat Don't forget partitions.

Answer (score 1):

## 127. [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 58 bytes, [A000156](https://oeis.org/A000156)

```
/o
\i@/1!&w]!k4Pt&wwh..*.&[?~&].hn6*&#2*?+!K;;[q$KW;e)[k[?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00HfUFGtPFYx2ySgRK28PENPT0tPLdq@Ti1WLyPPTEtN2UjLXlvR29o6ulDFO9w6VTM6O9r@/38jAA)

This uses a dynamic programming approach to compute the number of ways to compute `m` with `k` squares for all `m <= n+1`.  Using `n+1` instead of `n` allows me to avoid using a conditional when `n=0`.

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000058)

Answer (score 1):

## 129. [ExtraC](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/extrac), 482 bytes, [A000082](http://oeis.org/A000082)

```
import math

int isprime(long n)do
	if(n equals 1) return 0
	if(n equals 2) return 1
	if(not(n modulus 2)) return 0
	long max be sqrt(n)
	for(long i be 2 AND i less max AND increment i)do
		if(not(n modulus (2 times i plus 1))) return 0
	end
	return 1
end

long n be readint plus 1
double r be 1
for(long p be 1 AND p minus 1 less n AND increment p)do
	if(not(n modulus p))do
		if(isprime(p))do
			r be r times (F(1) divide p plus 1)
		end
	end
end
print((int)(r times (n times n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDPbsMgDMbP4Sl8hNsS7QUmTTvuHdLitkjBUP5UffvMJilatgMI@7P5fjY@S5rP6@p8DKmAn8tNKUcFXI7JedRLoCuQsUEN7qIJ8F7nJcNoIGGpieDtKExdGDchFBZ9sHWpov7ua3/7@QknhHxPXGjUcAlpM3WSnuDj@5OfC@bcSltI54QehbKB/ffRExSmz9wZJR7NwRjJqqFjSqS2OcUy4WxlA1ujsqGeFs6KNKpOF1vccCJ4R1K7UdIfxtiXd0CMprO/dv1KDc0s7SPoL83btu7hLLLXPg@XtSnkksM/UNGaL6N7J@0P4vHX9f0H)

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000482)

Answer (score 1):

## 131. [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 116 bytes, [A000090](https://oeis.org/A000090)

```
00000000: a64d a048 8040 a06a 52a0 6acc a06a 8d53  ¦M H.@ jR jÌ j.S
00000010: a048 4ca0 6a8c 253a 253a a64d a062 8050   HL j.%:%:¦M b.P
00000020: 80a0 1f20 803c a64d a05e 8053 a062 4ca0  . . .<¦M ^.S bL 
00000030: 438e 253c a64d a05f 804c d3a0 4820 5e8d  C.%<¦M _.LÓ H ^.
00000040: 53d0 80a0 1f20 8046 a53c 205e 264c ccd3  SÐ. . .F¥< ^&LÌÓ
00000050: a048 2043 8d53 a062 4ccc a05f 8e53 d080   H C.S bLÌ _.SÐ.
00000060: a01f 2080 3b4c a53a 8e25 3c8b 2581 008e   . .;L¥:.%<.%...
00000070: 205f ae35                                 _®5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdC9asMwEAfwvU9xizsesr4qnAyFQsngQmn2BFlShg59kgyFvICXdOxDyA/m3kkKpVMNNrLx/e5/NyX/sa6iXQN4qyN4oR04oQWdrAcjvQDrQ6ivLhoFkL9e8rzDxzy/v9G9nOmB@7vq9CwxokMpdQGkUb4@WgsrqYURJM27kYu7oRuKOuFrcyQ5ThDRn6Sgkwq3apO4WlWndAHMMwJuC3HAPTnENkgRpJVLnODXOPGQAaKicu2og0kuAjxhV5UjjsuF4sEBm6PJMSqKP6m0Bc@s5FTSkhhCpBXtl8@a6Tlft3C4H5fzcmmQuW1ICq3qStsoZc0cLdG3KFzdEIUqE/Gej8hyg2yB@hNB9KuaqLvnLbskDajgJhrZ9SAEDQ8lzWbM14FGxA7xpjyQIrmrT8rAf9cxf5t1dT8)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000116)

Comment: If I read the haskell for the next sequence right, `A000116(n) = A000013(2*n)`, which is confirmed in comments of A00013.

Answer (score 1):

## 132. Java (OpenJDK 9), 903 bytes, [A000116](https://oeis.org/A000116)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if(input<=0) System.out.print(1);
        else System.out.print(A000013(2*input));
    }

    public static int A000013(int n) {  // Uses the formula from the OEIS page
        double result = 0;
        for(int d = 1; d<=n; d++) {
            if(n%d==0) {
                double t = totient(2*d);
                double b = Math.pow(2,n/d);
                result += (t*b)/(2*n);
            }
        }
        int r = (int) result;
        return r;
    }

    public static int totient(int n) {  // Follows the definition of Euler's Totient
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
            if(GCD(n,i)==1) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int GCD(int a, int b) {  // Uses Euclid's Algorithm for GCD
        if(a<b) {
            if(b%a==0) return a;
            return GCD(b%a, a);
        }
        if(a%b==0) return b;
        return GCD(a%b, b);


    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNj9MwED1vfsVcKpImpB9ISCjNYQUF7WHFoXBCHJzESV2ccWQ7WxDa317GjgNdVhspH543b@bNm5zYA3utBo6n5se7y0X0g9IWThTNRytkviyi65hk2OX3zB6LKBrGSooaasmMgXsmEH5HNyFoLLP0elCigZ6g@GC1wO7bd2C6M4nLvDnUDJFrIGIJyM8QAvHhl7G8zwUmBaUJtJQyjJayBObIf9o7tPGEtbGHduU6gUBTo80Hambjjc/h0vDn2O2ars2beLv0BRKX@hj9r9/1njPdN5JygNUKvhpuwB45tEr3o2TQatX7wOf93QEG1nFq3SiqxkFzM0onf@30EMPXaiiwKaDZlUjPNJ1McSPhoindQP48F3F8q6zgJH67bPxof8GKQLeVfFDneJvhasZD67SE2C6rZEXUyVUadrqdFE10pykJUl2C5nbUCPpFX2YxT3z5qKRU58mahrcChRUKQbWwHyXXrwx8mWihc61GfOaMmJwROzJGXBvz6f2HGDORlOUmmahpWoQ5gl4ffVGzK@DeLPPH6sk692MtRUMSb2WntLDH3m3XcaY/je2qf1KqBfM7Cm2Z9zQcXBfCM2DJrM7RF9U1o7oy2REIzkiQl/54ubz9Aw)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000903)

I thought I ought to do this one, since it re-implements [A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013) and I did [that one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135446/69481) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

## 133. [CHICKEN Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/), 643 bytes, [A000903](https://oeis.org/A000903)

```scm
(define (g x) 
(cond ((= x 0) 1) (else x)))
(define (div4 x)
(/ (- x (remainder x 4)) 4))
(define (factorial x)
(cond ((< x 3) (g x)) 
(else (* x (factorial (- x 1))))))
(define (a37223 x)
(define y (/ (- x (remainder x 2)) 2))
(* (factorial y) (expt 2 y)))
(define (a37224 x) 
(define y (div4 x))
(cond ((> (remainder x 4) 1) 0) ((= x 1) 1) (else (/ (* 2 (factorial (- (* 2 y) 1))) (factorial (- y 1))))))
(define (a85 x)
(cond ((< x 2) 1) (else (+ (a85 (- x 1)) (* (- x 1) (a85 (- x 2)))))))
(define (a00000000000000000000000000000000000000903 x)
(cond ((= x 1) 1) (else (/ (+ (factorial x) (+ (a37223 x) (* 2 (+ (a37224 x) (a85 x))))) 8))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHRboMwDHznK/xog6pBYFonrfsXFNw1WksnWlXw9SxO0iWlPCwSKLEvd77LRR/4xBt9MPqb@3nGjvemZ8AvGAky1Oe@A8QdjFASVATIxwvbHlH2h@3MrbGlDF8ANxaJA59a03c82ENDJF9E71t9PQ@mPborQeDDImvysqLrVDAXsoh35BW5Ffna@k2p2pGF0gSrkyjLrORmnpJO4mn8uYKy2yfexscQiYPXOPnn0q6kZLPyoVVJaDJUbmUeHbnSRM7XojWtmN2@LmNTqUThIfekhD3sk4aiJ9ryX@u9rFP1NYPF4wP7ie4vFPwXabjBkizYyn@efwE)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000643)

Comment: It's 627 bytes, not 526, and the Next Sequence link does not point to any of these sequences. I just finished writing a program for A000643...

Answer (score 1):

## 137. [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/), 701 bytes, [A000232](http://oeis.org/A000232)

```
function A000232(index) {
local GBTriangle = [[]]
local numbers = []

for(local i=1; i<index*index*index; i++) numbers.append(i);

// Generate primes with Sieve of Sundaram
for(local i=1; i<numbers.len(); i++) {
  for(local j=i; i+j+2*i*j<numbers.len(); j++)
    numbers[i+j+2*i*j]=0;
}
for(local i=0; i<numbers.len(); i++) {
  if(numbers[i]>0)
    GBTriangle[0].append(2*numbers[i]+1);
}

// Build the triangle
for(local i=1; i<=index; i++) {
  GBTriangle.append([])
  for(local a=1; a<GBTriangle[i-1].len(); a++) {
    GBTriangle[i].append( abs( GBTriangle[i-1][a] - GBTriangle[i-1][a-1] ))
  }
}

for(local i=0; i<GBTriangle[index-1].len(); i++) {
  if(GBTriangle[index-1][i]>2)
    return i;
}

}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##fVK7bsIwFN39FXe0E1FM2g1SqSx8AN0iD4bclBsFhzpJWwnx7WkMmARSdfFwdF73yNVnQ9Zi0bZZY7Y1lQbepJTRc8TJpPgj4MiKcqsLWC3fLWnzUSDEkCRKXXHT7DdoKwcqxrLS8gtO8WwOtDi7BIO3A8NQeNmTPhzQpJzEnLHpFFZo0Ooa4WBpjxV8U72DNeEXQpnBujGptno/jvF2BRourhFHBtAT85gcnodRQEH@KMg7QUcH3yu5MVUs5@x0lyj/S6SM3zzUq7y49uMlUvmbo6AnhjPhUtwEy4aKFOodQn3VjM@Nh1O61D7AuydK3N2vnVIvBk1oMlO@vvZGd13p1hX0puLwIE60gskY7B4QLvzkLhoNN@S7KwYthiP@QXODRpdBLdaNNUDn0U6s7b6Lqbn/utGLEO0v)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000701)

Answer (score 1):

## 138. [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/), 689 bytes, [A000701](http://oeis.org/A000701)

```
proc sigma(n: int): int { // A000203
	var sum: int = 0;
	for d in 1..n {
		if n % d == 0 {
			sum += d;
		}
	}

	return sum;
}

proc sumodd(n: int): int { // A000593
	var sum: int = 0;
	for d in 1..n {
		if (n % d == 0) & (d % 2 == 1) {
			sum += d;
		}
	}

	return sum;
}

proc part(n: int): int { // A000041
	if n == 0 { return 1; }

	var sum: int = 0;
	for k in 0..(n-1) {
		sum += sigma(n-k) * part(k);
	}

	return sum / n;
}

proc helper(n: int): int { // A000700
	if n == 0 { return 1; }

	var sum: int = 0;
	for k in 1..n {
		sum += (if k % 2 == 0 then -1 else 1) * sumodd(k) * helper(n-k);
	}

	return sum / n;
}

var n: int;
n = stdin.read(int);

write((part(n) - helper(n)) / 2);
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory. I'm surprised such a nice language was available for so long.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndHRaoMwFAbg6@Qp/puNpEONdqNswYs9ijTpKmqUqNtF2bO7xGgLAwcdBOHE5JzvnBzPRafraepse0RffjQFM28ozcDnLy5IErwLITKxp@SzsOjHJvzKISQlp9ZCuRhpHBtcKCHlCQYPbjN3J@Yd4u7gKYdy58k3dYsSq4fRGp9NUheH@mPTKrUBeHm9A8BuAo5HMOXCzIcpv0vUFXbY8IjnlIZeQ59Y7qcSPtuGtPJSEcfMRAtlkSyzjyqOXShbcfkbhgTmhjvrutN2g3cQ4r@86yAXGnNpqnWAAsNZG0QpdN1rP8/d@m4zfUVFf/F99cCW1AHRD6o0sdWFYr4VSemXLQfNWJg/R3TNy7nLknE5TenhBw)

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000689)

Answer (score 1):

## 139. [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 52 bytes, [A000689](http://oeis.org/A000689)

```perl6
my $n=get();
$n= 2**$n;
print substr($n,$n.chars-1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3UkElzzY9tURD05oLyFIw0tJSybPmKijKzCtRKC5NKi4p0lDJ01HJ00vOSCwq1jXUtP7/39AYAA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000052)

Comment: The next sequence would be a lot easier if it weren't for the teens.

Comment: @KSmarts well, there is a Mathematica program, and Mathematica 11 hasn't been used yet...

Comment: If you'll give me $300, I'll do it in Mathematica. Or give me $240, and I'll do it in Maple.

Answer (score 1):

## 151. [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes, [A000125](https://oeis.org/A000125)

```python
lambda n:(n**3 + 5 * n + 6) / 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSiNPS8tYQVvBVEFLIQ9Im2kq6CuY/S8oyswrUchNLNBI01EoSsxLT9UwNNDU/A8A)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000031)

Alright, so the next one looks like an absolute doozy when you look at the title:

> Number of n-bead necklaces with 2 colors when turning over is not allowed; also number of output sequences from a simple n-stage cycling shift register; also number of binary irreducible polynomials whose degree divides n.

Yeah... I dunno how people comprehend this stuff... But the formula doesn't look too bad.

> `a(n) = (1/n)*Sum_{ d divides n } phi(d)*2^(n/d)`, where `phi` is [A000010](https://oeis.org/A000010).

Here's a Python 3 implementation:

```python
import math

phi = lambda n: len([i for i in range(1, n + 1) if math.gcd(n, i) == 1])
A000031 = lambda n: n and sum(phi(d) * 2 ** (n / d) for d in range(1, n + 1) if n % d == 0) / n or 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY07DsIwEET7nGIapHWIIA4dUgrOgSgMzmeleGMlpuD0ZkFpKJhuNJ8XX2mc5ZQzhzgvCcGlsSjiyGgxuXD3DnLG1AldGf28gMGCxcnQka0g2MMacP8dHoaHJ6nABm0LezPFpVad7M@ZwInH@gykGPIGJRqUJUhwhNoPxf@hCHaa6XlttCzQqs1xYUk08ZoouEgbs9r2TW1U@Q0)

Comment: Unfortunately, 29 bytes is unavailable. 31 is the lowest available score

Comment: Sike, you thought. :P And yes, I do love my Python 2 for golfing.

Answer (score 1):

## 152. [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 136 bytes, [A000031](https://oeis.org/A000031)

```
EulerPhi[x_] := Sum[If[CoprimeQ[i,x], 1, 0], {i, 1, x}]
OEIS[x_] := Sum[If[IntegerQ[x/d], (EulerPhi[d]*2^(x/d)), 0], {d,1,x}]/x
OEIS[#]&
```

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000136)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv7/37U0J7UoICMzuiI@VsHKViG4NDfaMy3aOb@gKDM3NTA6U6ciVkfBUEfBAEhVZ4KZFbWxXP6unsFoejzzSlLTU4sCoyv0U4CKNeBGp8RqGcVpAEU1NaHmpOgY6gBN0a@AmKMcq/Y/oCgzr8QBxHWw/A8A)

This is just [my previous Mathics answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135446/69481), modified for the new sequence.

Comment: Next one is quite the doozy - only 45 terms known, apparently

Comment: @Stephen I only looked at the title before posting this. I guess it's one of those deceptively simple problems.

Comment: Those usually have a formula or at least a Mathematica program though :P

Comment: What have you done

Comment: I believe one of the linked papers has a formula for the next one, except it's a sum over certain orders of the integers, which is [quite nasty](https://oeis.org/A001011/a001011_4.pdf) (page 13 of the doc, page 147 of the journal). At least we have almost every language available again; we won't have to do INTERCAL again for another hundred answers or so.

Comment: @Giuseppe when you posted INTERCAL, very nice languages were available: OCaml, Shakespeare Programming Language, Chef, Mornington Crescent, Taxi... also, this problem can be solved with simple algorithm, so if someone posts an answer with the sequence hardcoded, I reserve the right to call him a doody-head in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

## 155. [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 83 bytes, [A000262](https://oeis.org/A000262)

```python
a = lambda n: (2 * n - 1) * a(n - 1) - (n - 1) * (n - 2) * a(n - 2) if n > 1 else 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctBCoAgFATQq8zyFwVpu6Du8iMrQX9ibjq9SUTN6jHDhCvth/Q5M0Y49vPCkAGkUUPQQlUFTC9b0Fc@0v9caNfymaBg3GmgcohWEjl7JvIciBtEls2Q6qqSfAM)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000083)

I shall starve this challenge of Python for the future. Fight me. ಠ_ಠ

...Also good luck with the next sequence. :P

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66111/discussion-on-answer-by-i-cri-everytim-one-oeis-after-another).

Comment: ...but now I can't comment on my own post. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

## 158. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 48 bytes, [A000376](https://oeis.org/A000376)

```
ḣ1‘Ṭœṗ
ÇḢU$;$F
ÇÐĿ
ṫ0ḢṢ⁼$
‘RŒ!Q3Ŀ€ÇÐfL€Ṁ’¹¹¹¹¹¹¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsWGjxpmPNy55ujkhzuncx1uf7hjUaiKtYobkHl4wpH9XA93rjYAij3cuehR4x4VrkcNM4OOTlIMND6y/1HTGpCaNB8g4@HOBqDMoZ3I8P///@YA)

## Explanation

```
ḣ1‘Ṭœṗ                  Helper Link 1; splits the list into two sublists, the first of which is reversed
ḣ1                      First 1 element(s) without modifying the original list
  ‘                     Increment
   Ṭ                    Generate a boolean list with 1s at the indices in (left)
    œṗ                  Partition, keeping borders
ÇḢU$;$F                 Helper Link 2; applies 1 iteration of the TopSwop operation
Ç                       Partition with length of the first element
 ḢU$;$                  Reverse the first list and concatenate it with the second list
 ḢU$                    Reverse the first list
 Ḣ                      Head; modifies the list
  U                     Reversed
    ;                   Concatenated with (the second list, implicit)
      F                 Flatten
ÇÐĿ                     Helper Link 3; completes TopSwops for a list
 ÐĿ                     While the results are unique (collects intermediate results)
Ç                       TopSwop once
ṫ0ḢṢ⁼$                  Helper Link 4; returns whether or not a list is sorted
ṫ0                      Last 0 sublists (gives the last one without modifying the original list)
  Ḣ                     Head; this unwraps the length 1 list of a single list
   Ṣ⁼$                  Is it sorted?
   Ṣ                    The list sorted
    ⁼                   equals (the original list, implicit) (non-vectorizing)
‘RŒ!Q3Ŀ€ÇÐfL€Ṁ’¹¹¹¹¹¹¹  Main Link
‘                       Increment (for 0-indexing)
 R                      Range
  Œ!                    All permutations (with duplicates)
    Q                   Deduplicate (technically unnecessary)
       €                For each sublist
     3Ŀ                 Apply Helper Link 3; completes TopSwops
         Ðf             Keep sublists where
        Ç               The end result is sorted
            €           For each element
           L            Yield its length
             Ṁ          Get maximum length
              ’         Decrement because the first "iteration" is the beginning list
               ¹¹¹¹¹¹¹  Identity function chained 7 times; has no effect in this situation
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000048) - More necklaces yay

Answer (score 1):

## 159. [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 778 bytes, [A000048](https://oeis.org/A000048)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
 static boolean isPrime(int n){
  if(n % 2 == 0) return n == 2;
  for(int d = 3;d*d <= n;d += 2){
   if(n % d == 0) return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 static int mu(int n){
  int r = 1;
  for(int p = 2;p <= n;p++){
   if(!isPrime(p) || n % p != 0) continue;
   if(n % (p*p) == 0) return 0;
   r = -r;
  }

  return r;
 }

 static BigInteger a(int n){
  if(n == 0) return BigInteger.ONE;
  BigInteger s = BigInteger.ZERO;
  for(int d = 1;d <= n;d += 2){
   if(n % d == 0) s = s.add(BigInteger.valueOf(mu(d)).shiftLeft(n / d));
  }

  return s.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2 * n));
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
  System.out.println(a(n));
 }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBTgIxEL3zFcPBpAuhInpbuZhwMFExctN4qLQLxd3Zpp1FjfLtOF0XXIiJl2b7Zvrem7ezUms1KJ3BlX7dbm3hSk@wYlBWZHM5mytE49NOu1IoWsoru7hGMotY7LjqJbdzmOcqBLhVFuGzA4EUMfhSlrlRCDbce1sYYZEAE66DzQTCCYxgPIZhAt5Q5REwXkcp17PS190axnCe6p6GyzFgqqHPDTXDjkIfUmQqDyYybDp8NCD5KmIRapxF7qJqG@Ivz2JnbXUH0Y770Xb9/l64u5vIJfD1BdGHg27tY14iWaz19h6F63Hjgc9hXY@KA39s1x96/Y0b1HGEB5y/jXJ6N4msraeBpVoNj5OH6XHQZ@n/MUeaIJXWokW2VnllppngRHWSyLC0Gd2YjPjlKTByPGCQ2q6tNn9xjKDHAyZNBM12NUmsS6uh4B0TM/IWF6D8Ijw9738g5wFo3qBZXTH7CGQKaTGRaN6JpUTtpcHLiqRjHspRKLET3Wy3F6Nv)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000778)

Answer (score 1):

## 163. [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 227 bytes, [A000448](https://oeis.org/A000448)

```r
A000448 <- function(n){
  if(n == 0)
    return(0)
  k <- 1
  l <- (0:k)^2
  g <- table(combn(l,2,sum))
  while(max(g) < n+1){
    k <- k+1
    l <- c(l,k^2)
    g <- table(combn(l,2,sum))
  }
  min(as.numeric(names(g[g>n])))
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BCoMwDIbve4ocU3Sjiocx5mDPMSbUUruijWIt2xg@u6ud5x0C@UL@/0/GZblyzoviCOc9NJ7kZHpCYp8dgGmQoCyBswAAo5r8SBipXdez0HRrg/zUsioPqFecRN0plL2tCbs0T523bBU9HybMrXihZnAGSrIYs7m1SRYhOsogbKv8F/zXdA5lDaFwB/JWjUYiCasc6pu@0J2FpXlxYhi6dzgz4@n2L1u@)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000227)

Brute force approach! Takes sums of unordered pairs of squares, `combn(l,2,sum)`, tabulates them with `table` to get counts, and then iterates until it finds one that can be written as the sum of squares in `n+1` ways (so it's zero-indexed). Then it extracts the `names`, converts them to `numeric`, and selects the `min`. This will lose precision after about `n = 64`, at which point (most) R implementations would convert the sums to `doubles.` That could be saved by using a `bigz` implementation but that's not what we have to do here.

It also times out on TIO for `n=10` because this is slow as all get-out.

Answer (score 1):

## 175. [PHP](https://php.net/), 122 bytes, [A000054](https://oeis.org/A000054)

```php
<?php
$n=file_get_contents('php://stdin');$s=0;for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++){$s+=ord("DJIKHHIMIEJGGFIJJJHEGFIJG"[$i])-64;}echo $s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJc82LTMnNT49tSQ@OT@vJDWvpFhDHShjpa9fXJKSmaeuaa1SbGtgnZZfpKGSCWSoZNrYquQBKW1tzWqVYm3b/KIUDSUXL09vDw9PX09XL3d3N08vLy8PVxDtrhStkhmrqWtmYl2bmpyRr6BSbP3/v5EJAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000122)

Uses delta encoding with the deltas represented by uppercase ASCII characters. The next sequence looks intimidating but it's just 1 at 0, 2 if sqrt(n) is an integer and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Note that hardcoding for less than 1000 digits is completely fine in this case, since this is a finite sequence, not an infinite one.

Comment: @Stephen unless someone says that this should scrape the subway's website ;)

Comment: @NieDzejkob and OEIS has a broken link...

Answer (score 1):

## 177. [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 214 bytes, [A000184](https://oeis.org/A000184)

```lua
function v(n)if n<1then return 1 end return v(~~~-n)*n end
function V(n)if n<1then return 1 end return V(~-~-n)*n end
function F(n)return math.floor(1/12*(2^(-~-~n+1)*V(-~(-~-~n<<1))/v(-~-~n-1)-3*4^-~-~n*-~-~n))end
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3BDoIwDIbvPkWP7XRC0SNefQSOJERYIMGOLIPjXh3HUE8mXpp@f/vlH@dmXc0sDz9YgQWFBgNSsu87Adf52QkwdNJ@YMEQghZSsqWHr1r9VysM@pd6j@r75dn4/mxGax1yxoXCosboBDkyqSquO5UlE2XLDppJX9S1TqDSJIoFq7EO5JafOIfWwuQG8bh1peML)
- Next sequence: [A000214](https://oeis.org/A000214)

Comment: dang, I was just testing out my PicoLisp implementation for this one, but it wasn't working on TIO...It's actually much simpler than the Maple implementation; using some gamma function identities, the formula provided by Mark van Hoeij simplifies to `2/3*GAMMA(2n)*(n+1/2)/(GAMMA(n)^2)-n*4^(n-1)` where `GAMMA(x)=factorial(x-1)`

Comment: Gotta love `easy` tagged sequences without a formula

Comment: Come on! `easy` but no formula and no program, two out of three links are dead.

Comment: Good news is that the dead links are archived on web.archive.org

Answer (score 1):

## 179. [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 62 bytes, [A000933](https://oeis.org/A000933)

```c
f(n){double c=(n>2)*~-~-n*~-~-~-n/3./4;return c+(c-(int)c>0);}
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDoIwEAC/0pCY7FpWsHqr9CGNF1yoIcHFNHAi8PVSvcxcZph4bOWdUgDBtZuW19grbkCcwfNOO8mf2dXtUt1t7OclimINTDDIjOxqtFv6tIOAxzVMEXxDV6u1f5ja4jfmKkBxMp0ip7KeUpS@DLn@jQc)
- Next sequence: [A000062](https://oeis.org/A000062)

Answer (score 1):

## 180. [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 63 bytes, [A000062](https://oeis.org/A000062)

```c
#include <math.h>
int a(int n){
  return (n + 1) / (M_E - 2);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCsIwFEXn5CsuFeUFraJbqLg5@geChJdKA@1T0nQSv73GgOByh3M5h@vEPM@LINxPvsVxcKnbdicdJMHRd8W8NBDbNEUBCdbYG@xAl9sZNQ6m0e8/f0w@PH6BwQWhrKvSabQa2cmdqqWvNlhJVtUz5q@gq2ToSEwpWms/)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000063)

Now since there is a lot of C versions, C must get the same treatment as Python.

Answer (score 1):

## 181. [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 276 bytes, [A000063](https://oeis.org/A000063)

```c
long Factorial(n){return n<2?1:n*Factorial(n-1);}
Choose(n,k){return Factorial(n)/Factorial(k)/Factorial(n-k);}
Catalan(double n){return n-(int)n?0:(int)(1/(n+1.)*Choose(2*n,n));}
A000063(n){return Catalan(-~-~-~-~-~n/2-1)-Catalan(-~-~-~-~-~n/4.-1)-Catalan(-~-~-~-~-~n/6.-1);}
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BDoIwEEX3nqIhIZkCBYrGGNAYY@KiZ3BTAZWAU1NhRfTqiES0C51uZvr757@mLK0knrquUngiO5nWSheyAqStzutGI8FltOYxOobGOE3uk@1ZqVsO6JWft6Y/@A6lOSArB7esZZ8MmWoOVU6MPAYF1hTXYTw0wANAl/vUeQdGDnpIXzs2YV/zqQE7bmWP8WAQ9bjslzDz/ylzf/hid5EFgqDtUWkQK8YT4bpLvkjoVfdoR7BGAjvKKFkRe5rt0fKEN96LF2f3BA)
- Next sequence: [A000276](https://oeis.org/A000276)

Comment: Wait wasn't clang used for 180?

Comment: @HusnainRaza but it wasn't used in the first 150 answers. On TIO there are 3 C compilers, so we can have at least 6 C answers. Yes, it's dumb, but valid.

Answer (score 1):

## 182.  [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 134 bytes, [A000276](https://oeis.org/A000276)

```lisp
(defun fact(n) (if (< n 2) 1 (* n (fact (1- n)))))
(defun a(n) (* (fact (+ n 3)) (1- (loop for k from 1 to (+ n 2) summing (/ 1 k)))))
```

Trival use of the formula specified by Detlefs on the OEIS page

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBDsIgEETvfsUchxpjqvHmzxBaDGlZCG2/ny6oe5rMvH1uDVuuldPsD4G3bqcYMHjwDcHDYAQHTWwbON4gpt3l92I7P/z3q6JPYzrINaUMnwoW@JKiqvb0RdS7HTEG@YB37ZfurMwliAMtWGY7tep1Ag)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000134)

Comment: Think this answer is invalid due to repeated language of last answer :(

Comment: @HusnainRaza this is the second time Common Lisp has been used, that's OK

Comment: @Stephen this is probably not what he meant but this is still valid

Comment: I think what he was trying to say is that this is invalid because it is chaining off answer 181, which is invalid because of language repeats. Still, that doesn't seem to be true.

Answer (score 1):

## 183. [PostL](https://github.com/alexander-liao/postfix-lang), 61 bytes, [A000134](https://oeis.org/A000134)

```
INPUT PARSE 1 + C 3.1416 * 0.290498\ - FLR \ 1 \ 0 \ 2 - = +.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvLsn5/9/TLyA0RCHAMSjYVcFQQVvBWcFYz9DE0ExBS8FAz8jSwMTSIkZBV8HNJ0ghBqggRsEAiI2AIrYK2nr//xsAAA)

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000061)

`_` is supposed to work in place of `floor` (or `flr`) but apparently it doesn't... hm

## Walkthrough

```
INPUT PARSE 1 + C 3.1416 * 0.290498\ - FLR \ 1 \ 0 \ 2 - = +.  A000134
INPUT                                                          Take a line of input
      PARSE                                                    Parse to a double
            1                                                  Push 1
              +                                                Add top two elements
                C                                              Copy the zero-indexed number
                  3.1416                                       ~pi
                         *                                     Multiply top two elements
                           0.290498                            Thanks to Husnain Raza for this magic number
                                   \                           Swap the top two elements
                                     -                         Subtract the second from the top
                                       FLR                     Floor
                                           \                   Swap top two
                                             1                 Push 1
                                               \               Swap top two
                                                 0             Push 0
                                                   \           Swap top two
                                                     2         Push 2
                                                       -       Subtract the second from the top
                                                         =     Switch: 1 if x == 2 else 0
                                                           +.  Add top two and print
```

Comment: For 999 this returns 3142, but it should be 3141

Comment: Where did you get that formula?

Comment: the formula round(3.1416*n-0.790498) works for all n for 2<n<1000

Comment: @HusnainRaza Thanks for the revised formula **edit** it doesn't work for `1 -> 6` **edit** fixed

Comment: @ChristianSievers Fixed, thanks!

Comment: just google sheets trend line *dabs intensely*

Comment: @HusnainRaza why the dabs D:

Comment: I've failed implementing this sequence, but here is my Jacobi symbol implementation in JavaScript, it might prove useful: `j=(a,n)=>{for(var j=1;a;a%=n){while(a%2==0){a/=2;if(n%8==3||n%8==5)j=-j;}t=a;a=n;n=t;if(a%4==3&&n%4==3)j=-j;}if(n!=1)j=0;return j;};` Also, the formula `d(a,n)=m^(2n-1)(m*prod_(p_i|m)(p_i^(-1))) * prod_(p_i|m)(p_i^(2*n)-jacobi(b,p_i))d(b,n)` doesn't seem to work, see a = 9, for example. (p_i are the odd primes)

Comment: @NieDzejkob, if you look at the Shanks paper, I think that line is supposed to correspond to equation 16, but it's missing an exponent of 2n. It also seems to simplify considerably to `d(a,n) = d(b,n) m^(4n-1) prod_{p_i|m} (1 - jacobi(b, p_i) p_i^{-2n})`

Answer (score 1):

## 186. [axo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo), 177 bytes, [A000017](https://oeis.org/A000017)

```
10=01=02=23=24=45=86=47=82*8=43*9=68*25*=825**25*1+=89+8*26*=725**6*[26*1+=][2*55*2*8*+[27*=][2*778**+[35*=][2*26*1+4*1+9*4*+[44*=][2*55447****+[44*1+=][3*288**1+84**-29*= }={ \
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xDgIxDAR7XnH1RkiJYydOsS/JUfACWiTE2w9fjsLS7shj@fl@HUfJzIVZKJWiVKM3aqcLnFox2BxiCGA4Q0n0kYI1sJ@sYUYO/JgCM4SINKVjgd4dUatddW1qzIAGVsVfU@0ALrRuVYiHWpIrcJcBbl9@tj1eLrcf)

I'm aware that hardcoding is apparently "lame" but this took me like half an hour so I'm not gonna trash it ;P

This essentially hardcodes all of the values and puts them into the memory, then uses the `=` function to read the specific memory address and output it.

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000177)

Answer (score 1):

## 187. [SageMath](http://sagemath.org), 321 bytes, [A000177](http://oeis.org/A000177)

```python
import sage.combinat.partition
var('t', 's', 'isSquare')

def A000177(n):
  t = Partitions(n).list()
  s = 0
  for i in range(len(t)):
    if len(t[i])>6:
      continue
    isSquare = True
    for j in range(len(t[i])):
      if sqrt(t[i][j]) not in ZZ:
        isSquare = False
    if isSquare:
      s = s+1
  return s
```

[Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000321)

You can try it [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 1):

## 192. [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 326 bytes, [A001824](https://oeis.org/A001824)

```
t110⛽t⛽na4n1an1➡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///D/MlLP8yfCMRTZgHZSz7Mn7SmBEQAOZtAtCGUA1UFFDBAiExpAOl5NHsvTBKmdeOH@RMWf5g/awaSXB7CWJA@iGAipuDEVSAxEyR7V0FcBpZcDeGDFCOM3IiQRHFxTxfCSDi9CiKOsHsjFuNA9s2aAZRohoTMhOUQPGUmmhUTlj@at/D///9GRiYA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000326)

Abuses  (floor) to convert a string to a number and  (ceil) to increment. Also uses ints instead of booleans in conditionals, but the interpreter does seems to be okay with it. Uses the following formula: `a(n) = 2*(4*n^2+1)*a(n-1) - (2*n-1)^4*a(n-2)`. The program operates on integers, but the language specification looks like only floats were supposed to be available. This allows computing the sequence infinitely without accuracy problems as the interpreter is implemented in Python.

Answer (score 1):

## 197. [D](https://dlang.org/), 347 bytes, [A000056](https://oeis.org/A000056)

```
import std.stdio, std.conv;

void main(string[] args){
  int n = to!int(readln)+1;
  double x = 1;
  for(int i=2; i<n; i++){
    bool prime = true;
    for(int k=2; prime && k<=i/2; k++)
    {
        if(i%k==0)
        {
            prime=false;
        }
    }
    if(prime && n%i==0) { x = x*(1-1/(cast(double)i*i)); }
  }
  writeln(n*n*n*x);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/BbsMgDL3zFd6hFSTduky7TJQvqXaghVRWiKmAdpGqfnsGZGsfsmX8/J5lM884nn1IEJN5y4F@U8ujp6tk7OrRwKiReEwB6bT/Bh1OUdwYAFICAgXJv@SSB6uNI9F2MnPGXw7OwpTp@u994GUe1YcE3FFObVtdAA7eOzgHHG0xCxcra/tfMhTJQq/XMOwUbnNjyPI6tngUYM9xNSj1Lh6tJ1lQTVSvXfxbUXBnz5wdHotohcUKbvWIqeHda7flRx0TX44T2KAQskpL/ARM1hGnprxJSHaf58@vXw)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000347)

Uses the formula a(n)=n*A007434(n), and the formula A007434(n) = n^2*Product_{p|n}(1-1/p^2).

Comment: [Crude implementation of the next sequence in Python.](https://tio.run/##fZHBboQgEIbvPMVkT@hai0CyaVMPvW7SSx9gG9LiSmLRIiT16e2oNHLYdg7O/PAxDj/D5NveivlwOJBnxpiQJ0IUtRm898H6EXyrYey74E1vUfXrgrH6K6jO@Am@36oLre55BkeseVKLC92FjBtPNVhoegfKTpiDw15eX7UboVo2sd2W@JbElmQJd/BawrmEF@Vb5Qo4hw6YAM7YA8Hp5w/dQLwBjv9IAMPpMXQeamBk1RaONci1XD/LIMsfjQWn7FXTqkAmz4HHBjvEdwhP3MB2VKQo/wPdcZni4h98CdMsA@d5YnkqRCrkr1hMv90uMQmdqUh0zQdn4/o8OHwh2pnR00810GhxESc@ZRjzDw "Python 3 – Try It Online") It's ridiculously inefficient though.

Comment: @icrieverytim That's because you wrote it in Python.

Comment: Oi, what do you get out of bashing Python for its speed? :P In any case, I realized I know all C-style languages to some extent, so I'm porting my solution to Go. Please don't ninja me, I'm on mobile. ;-;

Answer (score 1):

## 198. [Go](https://golang.org/), 466 bytes, [A000347](https://oeis.org/A000347)

```go
import . "math"

func A000347(n float64) int {
    result := 0

    n += 4

    for x_1 := 1.0; x_1 < n * n; x_1++ {
        for x_2 := x_1; x_2 < n * n; x_2++ {
            for x_3 := x_2; x_3 < n * n; x_3++ {
                for x_4 := x_3; x_4 < n * n; x_4++ {
                    if Sqrt(x_1) + Sqrt(x_2) + Sqrt(x_3) + Sqrt(x_4) <= n {
                        result += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFRT8MgEH7nV1z21K7aUSAuWvfg6xITo@8asrQbsYWNQuJi@tsrFEy7uMjLfcfdd3zct1fDaomeMMaUrRHiiUxhp6w0HZhDBZ1qrBFKukyNF0JWJ8sbYc7w9VG8J8WKpJA5TGaYvidTwmLhcQMSaqWBy7OLVrtZptpXuoPCF924EEgINASWwy285rDN4ZmbA9c3sLUNYAoE43u0XCF05LtPvq@g5UIiJNqj0gYWdWsWQ0xyWLSOvECotnIH8buJ09Mobu5Y6rXANwJ3dNXZxsDDBjAaLyRkG2ABe/1eqKsWOS6DaNexBDkmWRanTM3EN7tSGb42NZOL5olAA4GUYQkTgf4hTCQWSLQc8YzErpL8ETW8nbRJnDbvVMRkhukMs@jg9VmzxbllFVd7evT/zZQF1KPoh7FaxumoH0YHvdVJGsX4DYjRMG@JcL9fu3BpRWvyF@1MbmTy675I0/hOP/wA)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000466) (*Easy.*)

Answer (score 1):

## 203. [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 96 bytes, [A000050](https://oeis.org/A000050)

```julia
function A000050(n)
x = 0:(2^n)
y = x'
z = x.^2 .+ y.^2
z = z[z .<= 2^n]
length(unique(z))-1
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/rTQvuSQzP0/B0QAITA008jS5KhRsFQysNIzigOxKILtCnasKROnFGSnoaStUAmmwQFV0lYKeja0CUGEsV05qXnpJhkZpXmZhaapGlaamriFXal7K/4KizLySnDwNmPmGRpqa/wE)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000096)

Needs the `-1` in `length(unique(z))-1` because it always includes `0`, which is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

## 216. [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), 411 bytes, [A000095](http://oeis.org/A000095)

```java
J(a,b){if(b<=0||(b%2)==0) return 0;j=1;if(a<0){a=-a;if((b%4)==3)j=-j;}while(a!=0){while((a%2)==0){a/=2;if((b%8)==3||(b%8)==5)j=-j;}t=a;a=b;b=t;if((a%4)==3&&(b%4)==3)j=-j;a=a%b;}if(b==1)return j;return 0;}n=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()+1;l=(n==1)?1:0;if(n%4>0){l=(n%2>0)?1:2;for(d=3;d<=n;d+=2){if(n%d>0)continue;P=true;for(p=3;p*p<=d;p+=2)if(d%p==0){P=false;break;}if(!P)continue;l=l*(1+J(-1, d));}}print(l);
```

Also prints the input for some reason. [I don't think it's possible to fix it](https://tio.run/##S0pNzCvOSM3J@f@/oCgzr0TDM68kNT21SK8gsag4FcjRyEstVwhOTszLSy3SCK4sLknN1cvM09TLS60o0dDU1DbUtP7/39DAwIALAA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNbsIwEIX3PUVYBNn8NQlUajuZdl1WSJxgjI1I6g5RMKJVyNlTO0RUXXk8/t6bN1aG@HQw1nbdWtBMyabYC5Vjcr0KFWcSMZFRbdy55iiBElPw75QnsiGcU7h4bOWxpSxxXkJ7ORTWCBp5XXOrBQ0@DT1iNkieg6SfEaqnQeyQgFCBQtdzdLMej/8PIaRYQRuSIqZyiFfCPWfLyOYSbXfEbGqx/Tk587UoWC7YfLsPdkJOU7AoOOjf09ckjON49eZThnac@cr3M9gfa6FxCTpHBj3FrP8hjrUHdkd2BZ8NbNDV/ghs5dlqUuWooQq0h3Vc9etvcE/2ZEDVhj77@KPNn4dFOxHpdC3m6SzSUkLbVnXho1oJXffy8As)

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000411)

Answer (score 1):

## 222. [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 110 bytes, [A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670)

```julia
function A000670(n)
 S = 0
 for k = 0:n
  for j = 0:k
   S = S + (-1)^(k-j)*binomial(k,j)*j^n
  end
 end
S
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1LCsMwDET3OoWWUtuAsmmhkEXP4H0gnwZkO3IJyfkdx9DNYx7MMP6IOuS8HDbtmgw/IvJ8CRkDOuxQAJe0Ybji2wCr@WqhWO04vCM1LfcUGs@3US2tOkQKj2K@v1Zfm6HCQWH@bWp7NPq/tcKcTw)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000110)

Implements the formula found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) to compute `a(n)` as a sum of binomial coefficients. I suppose I could have implemented this in another language like Racket or something but whatever. Next seq is the Bell numbers, this sequence is the ordered Bell numbers which I find amusing (since they're out of order).

Answer (score 1):

## 230. [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 86 bytes, [A001147](http://oeis.org/A001147)

```
................I?1O@.../s;.\...........*...............p..W/..../......?-2q:(*2O..W\p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/18PDXjaG/o7AGn9Ymu9GCRxLTR1BXp64foghj6Eb69rVGiloWXkDxSPKfj/3xQA)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000086)

Expands to the cube:

```
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
I ? 1 O @ . . . / s ; . \ . . .
. . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . p . . W / . . .
. / . . . . . . ? - 2 q : ( * 2
        O . . W
        \ p . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
```

Comment: @NieDzejkob 86 byte answer just so we can all see your _opus magnum_.

Answer (score 1):

## 239. [Boo](http://boo-lang.org/), 346 bytes, [A000429](https://oeis.org/A000429)

```
import System.Numerics
def f(n as long,k as long):
 p=BigInteger(1);for i in range(n,n-k):p*=i
 if k>1:
  for i in range(k,1):p/=i
 return p
def b(n as long,i as long,k as long)as long:
 s=0;if n<1:return 1
 if i<1or k<1:return 0
 t=b(i-1,i-1,k-1);for j in range(0,n/i+1):s+=f(t+j-1,j)*b(n-i*j,i-1,k)
 return s
def a(n):
 return b(n,n,8)-b(n,n,7)
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000346)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxUsQgEIb7PMWWkIAXbHRyh4WdjY1PkChkNlwWBrjCp4/kEj3HsWDY2fn3/7/dwftlwTn4mOHtM2Uz371eZhPxPVUfxoJlBH2Cs6dRuO@KdxUE/YzjC2UzmsgUP1ofAQEJYk@jYSRIOt6FWmMFaME9qTIEf1ROqKI5rJpo8iUShGvq8CsV/8nf/@KYdHss9nRS3e6grnl4UiXK3dptBVkPDKUS63NyZ55uNK2gAzaFKDXastxMRTfxusBIrKdtjP@QbvfpGa3X2HvDurd45HIrHvgSIlJmPbtvOV@@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## 282. [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 126 bytes, [A011628](https://oeis.org/A011628)

```
29*7+9*8+╝╛@%╗╜0=⌠00.ó⌡n10-1╛R⌠²╛@%╜=⌡cI"Did you know that Vim is vastly superior to every other existing editor? #flamewars"X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoIwFIDhq7xgXCCa4oIMRgcXVwfj2kDVxkJN@wB7B9bGQUzkCnoDvUkvUhlc//@jGVZUCOP9LA2TKA3nkbMPZ@@rsbM3ZzuycO2TkOn37dq@jMkkHuZ2aJ/XX3WD6LNNsOY5GFnBuZQN4Iki7HgBXENNNQoDurowxaUClMBqpgxIPDEF7Mo18vIILOco1RJGB0EL1lClg733yQ8)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000126)

#### Explanation

```
29*7+9*8+╝╛@%╗╜0=⌠00.ó⌡n10-1╛R⌠²╛@%╜=⌡cI
29*7+9*8+╝                               Put 233 in the second register
          ╛@%╗                           Calculate input%233 and put it in the
                                         first register (I'll call this n)
              ╜0=⌠00.ó⌡n                 If n is 0, output 0 and exit
                            ╛R⌠      ⌡c  Count integers smaller or equal to 233...
                               ²         such that their squares
                                ╛@%      are congruent modulo 233
                                   ╜=    to the input.
                                       I If there is at least one such integer
                                         (i. e. n is a quadratic residue mod 233)
                           1             then output 1,
                        10-              otherwise, output -1
```

Comment: The resut for `n=2` seems wrong (and from the description, I don't understand how it gets the right result for `n=7`)

Comment: Unintuitive operand order got me during a last minute change... hang on

Comment: The explanation claims you count how many numbers `<=n` have square congruent to `n`. I guess that's really something like `<=233`. (BTW, there will always be two square roots.)

Comment: @ChristianSievers that's right, I made a mistake when rereading the code, fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

## 285. [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/), 151 bytes, [A000211](https://oeis.org/A000211)

```
function A000211(input) {
if(input==0){
return 4;
}
if(input==1){
return 3;
}
if(input==2){
return 5;
}
return (A000211(input-1)+A000211(input-2)-2);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4szSwqSs35/z@tNC@5JDM/T8HRwMDAyNBQIzOvoLREU6GaKzMNwra1NdCs5ipKLSktylMwseaqRZIxRMgYo8oYIWRMQTJQtgaKNbqGmtqoAkaaQARU/7@gKDOvBK7aVFPT@j8A)

Didn't take much to learn this language!

[Next Sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000151)

Answer (score 1):

## 286. [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon), 1118 bytes, [A000151](https://oeis.org/A000151)

```
from fractions import Fraction

def tofrac(a):
	global Fraction
	return [Fraction(x) for x in a]

# a(x)*b(x), first n terms
def mul(a, b, n):
	x=[0] * min(n, len(a) + len(b) - 1)
	for i in range(min(n, len(a))):
		for j in range(min(n - i, len(b))):
			x[i + j] += a[i] * b[j]
	return x

# a(x^e), first n terms
def powarg(a, e, n):
	return [0 if i % e else a[i // e] for i in range(n)]

# c*a(x)
def mulc(a,c):
	return [x * c for x in a]

def divcfrac(a,c):
	return [x / c for x in a]

# a(x) + b(x)
def add(a,b):
	return [(a[i] if i < len(a) else 0) + (b[i] if i < len(b) else 0) for i in range(max(len(a), len(b)))]

# a'(x)
def polyderiv(a):
	return [i * x for i, x in enumerate(a)][1:]

# f(x)*exp(g(x)), coefficient of x^n
def exptaylor(f,g,n):
	global add, polyderiv, mul
	fac = 1
	for i in range(n):
		f=add(polyderiv(f), mul(f, polyderiv(g), n))
		fac *= i + 1
	return f[0].numerator // fac

R = [0, 1]

for n in range(len(R), int(input()) + 2):
	P = []
	for k in range(1, n):
		d = divcfrac([Fraction(x) for x in powarg(R, k, n)], k)
		P = add(P, d)
	R.append(exptaylor([0, 1], mulc(P, 2), n))

print(R[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPBbqMwFDyHr3jSarV26jahhz1Uy3XPVa6ISgZs5BRs5Dhd8vXZ9zCElPaSEDNvZt540l@cvV61dx1oL6tgnD2B6XrnA/ydDpKkVhqCIwCT/CXZNK0rZbsANl6Fs7eQzyds4KCdhwGMBVkkyQ@QeLYt8UOANv4UwEJQvjuN5N25ZVJAKcAS/5Dl@wK20BnLrIBWWdSFh/Gh5PAIKU82xG@I30vbKPYJy4llRBxXCBw2YiKKqM2QG@Q@FvCQgcwNCZf5sbhtNUz239S33nv3T/qG7KvJ/pzGHoxGiz9BgWpPishhtwNVwMq75WNE1ZZCmgPBrEV1TzegsepzrAStzUcVr2YN363h8RZw2XLWkXWNc@X9HBszGJ3/maMf7e9pkpWrt@Xydn0jcmBxfgk8mvg1y/euvdTKm4/Yq9mCwU2HSCeie2XPnfIyKAQWefoy8miqlBp61uADilROaW0qo2wAp2F4s6MIIoK8tM4zLRph7wqM24vFg6DUsVeyggzSLwWzsVMZRbb41nwcQ@q7ZRpOTeAER7JtBlSw9LafxnY/TQuhBlYCYUlyQNl8LyDF5UjbLtoU3wFJjQ3M2P4cGKfLeCZLrzRWRLvvy0g6lXFT4/tbR77/h04VPgh4p6kCv8k8MdO2rwJq/H14kn2vbM2WQKNdEeuKsOdp8aT3ZPWQP6YFv15/7/8D)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A0001118)

Answer (score 1):

## 288. [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 186 bytes, [A007437](https://oeis.org/A007437)

```swift
func divisors(_ n: Int) -> [Int]{
	return Array(1...n).filter{n % $0 < 1}
}

func A007437(_ n: Int) -> Int{
	var summ = 0
	for i in divisors(n + 1){
		summ += i*(i+1)/2
	}
	return summ
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsJADEXXna@4iMKMfTj1gSBa6NJvEBFRCwGNkk4VKf32OnZRcZVA7rk55YsKN2/bouITzvSk8i6lPoBX2LIziDPs/LKvVSAXVwkjFzm@dZokCZukoKu7SM0YYWixRtqoRqmuLLd2OZ8t/7v89E3Po6CsbjdsYFVQ3AUE4t97RojU@GDQpcINaKwpTM1kqoKmN/keVdP2vLZeatGBDyF2miIM4mwQ9S5kjAc@)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000186): Number of 3 by n Latin rectangles in which the first row is in order.

Answer (score 1):

## 289. [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 149 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage), [A000186](https://oeis.org/A000186)

```
←Đ000`ŕ4ȘĐ4ȘĐĐĐ5ȘĐĐ5Ș↔⇹5Ș6Ș8Ș3Ș6Ș4Ș⇹3Ș↔⁺3*~4Ș-+~ĐĐ1~⇹^4ȘÅĐ3Ș⇹+⁻ŘΠ⇹↔Đ↔9Ș↔!3Ș⇹3Ș*⇹!÷*3ȘĐ2⇹^⇹!3Ș4Ș⇹÷*⇹Đ0≥*!*+⇹Đ3Ș⇹⁻3Șłŕ⇹ŕ↔Đ↔⇹3Ș⇹3ȘĐ3Ș⇹⁻Đ5Ș4Ș-3Ș⇹łŕ3Ș↔ŕƥĉ
```

The program is a port of the Mathematica algorithm listed on the OEIS page.

Most of the work done is managing the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9LCsIwED1LtylCdazoZcQjuHDjplDBSndZWMjSTc9Q1GUTycpD5CLxzaQFCby8eTNvPsfzKcbQaKuLoji4bu2N1QL8ykTwheYebk@QjTdbb0gI6iBSytYvUhWURV6xZ1khtUc8Xq0mKcxD/Xbm@wCFwWrATrwZzY0UvmwcFPHgFXdggeZRyACxa2h7lalcgmRGbxB3cR0CwDRg2k/wr1Ru4mWTwrZ0hus@vW1jLH8)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000149):  floor(e^n)

Comment: Is there an (online) interpreter somewhere we can use to verify this solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I can post the testing file I used to the github page. It'll be pyttesting.py. 

Yes, I know I haven't implemented separate files for holding code - I'll get to that very soon.

Comment: Actually, I've now implemented an interpreter that takes a file as a command-line argument

Comment: @mudkip201 If you'd like me to add Pyt to TIO, let's meet in http://talk.tryitonline.net.

Answer (score 1):

## 291. [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 130 bytes, [A000337](http://oeis.org/A000337)

```
> Input
> 1
> 2
>> 1-2
>> 3*1
>> 4×5
>> 6+2
>> Output 7
As usual, padding is required
to make this a valid answer
Whispers rules!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY07DsIwEER7n2Jo@RQBAp0lSipK6pW8AgtjHK@XHIUDcTDjRBSjNxqN9Ma7l8RZarU4x6TFWHQtW2Nb2czYLbsJ@@@nn3hYzetFS7vjaE4CFaWwRiLnfLzBCzIP6jM7U1540oNRmgiENwXvQFFGzub6lyNrYFnU2v8A)

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000130)

Answer (score 1):

## 293. Commodore 64 BASIC, 431 bytes, [A000132](https://oeis.org/A000132)

```
10 R=0
20 INPUT N
30 FOR A=0 TO FLOOR(SQR(N))
40 F=N-A*A
50 FOR B=0 TO FLOOR(SQR(F))
60 G=F-B*B
70 FOR C=0 TO FLOOR(SQR(G))
80 H=G-C*C
90 FOR D=0 TO FLOOR(SQR(H))
100 L=H-D*D
110 E=FLOOR(SQR(L))
120 IF E*E<>L GOTO 200
130 Z=1
140 IF A<>0 THEN Z=Z*2
150 IF B<>0 THEN Z=Z*2
160 IF C<>0 THEN Z=Z*2
170 IF D<>0 THEN Z=Z*2
180 IF E<>0 THEN Z=Z*2
190 R=R+Z
200 NEXT D
210 NEXT C
220 NEXT B
230 NEXT A
240 PRINT R
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000431)

Sorry, but no TIO link this time. This will have to do:

[image: an animated GIF]

(bytecount measured according to [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11574/55934))

Answer (score 1):

## 294.  [Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 218 bytes, [A000431](https://oeis.org/A000431)

```swift
import Foundation

infix operator **
func **(_ base: Int, _ exponent: Int) -> Int{
    return Int(pow(Double(base), Double(exponent)))
}

func A000431(_ n: Int) -> Int {
	return ((4 ** Int(n)) - ((2**(n+1)) * n)) / 8
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCsIwEDybrxg8JbVq1YIiIggi@BVSNYUF3YSYoiB@e934AvcyzCzzuFypjmXb0tm7ELFxDR@rSI6VIq7pBudtqKILyDJVN3wQ1Dvsq4udY8sxxw725h1bji/BoL9MeFeQCzY2gRPX3l312jX7k9XJbXJ82NdujFEP9S5ZFUVRTkbSxH@puKvOJ1PrUra8otnIX4SxbOPeSFiGpA0xU4@2lvEEEkeBwWCB8dSkGB9IrJSj2192818jpRXtEw)

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000218)

Note that I have previously used Swift 4 (twice), but this time I used Swift 3. This version thankfully works in both Swift 3 and Swift 4, so this can be tested online.

Answer (score 1):

## 296. [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 161 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage), [A000133](http://oeis.org/A000133)

```
←ĐĐĐ1⇹1⇹««⇹1⇹«⁻⇹3Ș⁻1⇹«⁺1⇹«*+⇹⁺1⇹«÷
```

All of those spaces at the end are padding.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UduEI2Bo@Kh9JwgfWn1oNZz5qHE3kDY@MQPIgInsgjC0tIEUnHd4u8LAgv//TQE)

[Next Sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000161)

Answer (score 1):

## 301. [Trefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 165 bytes, [A002407](https://oeis.org/A002407)

```
"HTRF"4($$&1>::1+::**\::**-3>::*2Pv
        v\$\+#-1_z#;$.@;:R$;^  +2;wOO%#;_v
        >  1^1                  $$<      <
Yup, Trefunge. Don't worry, I'm not insane.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KylKTSvNS0/VtbTQLagEM///V/IICXJTMtFQUVEztLOyMtS2stLSigERusZAvpZRQBmXAhSUxajEaCvrGsZXKVur6DlYWwWpWMcpKGgbWZf7@6sqW8cjlNopKBjGGSpgABUVGwjDhiuytEBHIQTqJj0Fl/w89RKF8vyiokodBU/1XIW8/BKFzLzixLxUvf//DQ0MuAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000165)

Answer (score 1):

## 302. MOO, 135 bytes, [A000165](https://oeis.org/A000165)

```
return 2 ^ args[1]* $sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.math_utils:factorial(args[1]);
```

The `$sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.sysobj.` is pure padding to avoid a duplicate sequence; `return 2 ^ args[1]* $math_utils:factorial(args[1])` would do the same thing.

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000135)

Comment: Interesting way to do padding...

Comment: Wait, is it [this MOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOO)?

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MOO_(programming_language)&oldid=689316382)

Answer (score 1):

## 326. [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 205 bytes, [A000385](https://oeis.org/A000385)

```lua
function Sgm(n)D=0 for d=1,n do if n%d<1then D=D+d end end return D end
function Sum(a,b,f)S=0 for k=a,b do S=S+f(k)end return S end
function Seq(n)return Sum(1,n,function(k)return Sgm(k)*Sgm(-~n-k)end)end
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BDsIgEEX3nmLSxAQsJe1edr0BJ6gCSmqnSiDuvDoOrY3GxWQy8/Pf/7c05OwSnqOfEfRlYsh71YKbAxjVCQQzg3eAe3Ps4tUi9KqvDVhcJ9iYAj3Lsfty0sQGcRKO6w9rVHQXlla6dmzkP2b9Z7YPKrFpRKIWYlPJuSnUdeSHspoXNguxTC5xSNW7tl3Kz/IZfLRs5UpZCaiW@HvwGFkl6cXzGw)
- [Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000205)

Answer (score 1):

## 334. [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 157 bytes, [A000219](http://oeis.org/A000219)

```c
Sigma_2(n){int s=0;for(int d=0;++d<=n;n%d||(s+=d*d));return s;}
A000219(n){if(!n)return 1;int s=0;for(int k=0;++k<=n;s+=A000219(n-k)*Sigma_2(k));return s/n;}
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5BDoIwEAXQPaeoGJKWggI7UzBx260HMKQFbZDBlLICzl4LEWPcTH4y@W9GxEYIa6/q3pa3DAMZFRjUFwmrO42XLF2mVOYFMAjkNOGeFjKUhDBdmUED6tnsXZIkydLT2q/xDshnl7J/rlm5ZuEc9O3FDQm3J5of@whstnsF4jnICuW9kao7PM5eWyrAnIwLyx3J89QNSslLuys19gMZIT/afO7I2b4B)
- [Next Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000157)

Answer (score 1):

## 337. [Mathematica 11 (Wolfram Language)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 154 bytes, [A000159](https://oeis.org/A000159)

```
A000159[n_] := CoefficientList[ Sum[ 2 * (n+3) / (2 * (n+3)-k) * (2 * (n+3)-k)! / (k! * (2 * (n+3)-2 * k)!) * (n+3-k)! * (x-1)^k , {k,0,n + 3}] ,x] [[4]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsIwGIRf5bo1NsXE6qDiIK4OguNPlFBaDCERNEJBfPaYiIpu3313wzkdTp3TwbQ6xrUQQs7m5I8KixU2567vTWs6H7bmGgj7myNMMELpq4ZhjPIbassy/uYiD2zxrzOlir3Fa5ZwqCU7WHDcLRfco0LzUOCDAtFUqWXcXYwP9Dkok4tP)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000154)

Comment: Note that the next sequence is finite as an "erroneous version of A003713" so hard-coding is allowed. Perhaps the next solver could use a more difficult-to-use language?

Comment: You should probably add your answer's chain number as well as a link to the sequence you are implementing to comply with the question's rules.

Comment: @Giuseppe [Done, I just used a useless language :P](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156507/59487)

Answer (score 1):

## 339. [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 209 bytes, [A000287](https://oeis.org/A000287)

```
0i:0)?!va{*$"0"-+00.
:{6401~<vv?(6
vv?)4:-5<>0n; v<v<v<
> 1-}r>:?v~n; @+*}@+
&&    ~  1    :@@:@4
~5    ^$-<    !^<^<*
>>:32,*3!1-@@:}*@:8^
!v+3*2:@+@@*}<>f2,*v
?>@@:}*@@+$:v^:@@+6<
 v@{@{$,@$+4<
^>{@{@1+:&:&)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwEETv@xWphGKzRhIbi6xLul8S8CL24kFhL6X99ZriDuwww2Oe0/e1bWGi0I2NPmZnD@HgMYQz0DykEFdWHY8D1N8l8lfO4X03yrsgm@iXT6ZR11oKukUQ2tbUW42Ju5MISYL1uodiPe/eFC7sIGfqLyfXN9FXanFCtwKNYu8uJCjiFs7PCiiM@Q8IWtJSN3FgMCqzzPYkFhNDyTVIRGqp7bYtph8)

[Next Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000209)

This is the chain's third answer in ><>, meaning it can't be used again until we hit answer #450.

The next sequence should be pretty easy if you use a language with trig and rounding built in.

Answer (score 1):

## 341. [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 803 bytes, [A000206](https://oeis.org/A000206)

```python
Func Divisors(number: int) – list:
    Return Filter[->divisor: number % divisor == 0; Range[1; number]]

Func GCD(a: int; b: int) – int:
    Return Element[Filter[->number: a % number == b % number == 0; Range[1;Min[{a; b}]]]; 0]

Func EulerPhi(number: int) – int:
    Return Length @ Filter[->a: GCD(a; number) == 1; Range[1; number]]

Func A000013(number: int) – int:
    Return Sum[Map[-> d: (EulerPhi[2 * d] * 2 ^ (number / d)) / (2 * number); Divisors[number]]]

Func A000011(number: int) – int:
    Return (A000013(number) + 2 ^ (number / 2)) / 2


Func A000206(number: int) – int:
    If number == 0:
        Return 1
    If number % 2 == 1:
        Return A000011(2*number) / 2
    Else:
        Return (A000011(2*number) + A000011(number) + 4^(number/2 - 1) - 2^(number/2 - 1)) / 2
```

[Next Sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000803)

### Demo

As Physica is not available on TIO yet, here's a GIF:

[image: Usage GIF]

### How it works?

OEIS states that this is equivalent to the even orbits of binary necklaces of length **2n** under **D<sub>n</sub> x S<sub>n</sub>**, and so its formula is **a(n) = ([A000011](https://oeis.org/A000011)(2n) + [A000011](https://oeis.org/A000011)(n) + 4<sup>n/2-1</sup> - 2<sup>n/2-1</sup>) / 2** for even values of **n** and **a(n) = [A000011](https://oeis.org/A000011)(2n) / 2** if **n** is odd, with **n** for non-null values of **n**, with **a(0) = 1**. Diving a bit deeper in OEIS, we find that **[A000011](https://oeis.org/A000011)(n)=([A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013)(n)+2<sup>⌊n / 2⌋</sup>) / 2**. Using the formula for [A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013), the closed-form of A000011 becomes:

[image: A000011 closed form]

Hence the sequence I implement becomes:

[image: A000206 – odd n]

When **n ≡ 1 (mod 2)**, else:

[image: A000206 – even n]

Comment: For god's sake [we need MathJax back](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14578/59487)!

Answer (score 1):

## 342. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 164 bytes, [A000803](https://oeis.org/A000803)

```
2‹i0,q}3‹i8,q}0 0 8)I2-FDO4-¸«¦D}θ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6FHDzkwDncJaYxDDAsgwUDBQsND0NNJ1c/E30T2049DqQ8tcas/t0FEYaPD/v6GBgQEA)

[Next sequence: A000164 - Partition of squares again](https://oeis.org/A000164)

129 spaces padded after the last command.

Answer (score 1):

## 343. [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 382 bytes, [A000164](https://oeis.org/A000164)

```
HoDoRHoDoR hodor?!? 000164(HODOR? ) {
  $HODOR: HODOR = 0;
  HODOR{} (o=0; o<=HODOR? ; o++) {
    HODOR{} (d=0; d<=o; d++) {
      HODOR{} (r=0; r<=d; r++) {
        if(HODOR... HODOR hodor. h.HODOR. oHODOR!? (o,2)+HODOR... HODOR hodor. h.HODOR. oHODOR!? (d,2)+HODOR... HODOR hodor. h.HODOR. oHODOR!? (r,2)==HODOR? ) {
          HODOR +=1;    }
      }
    }
  }
  HODOR:: HODOR ;
}
```

[Hodor!](https://tio.run/##lVG7CsMwDNzzFSp0cHAxTikdYossGbIF8g2mpJPAa/C3u3426VBoPZwePonzeSVD1vuJRloSwBo7w2kAKWV3v7FpHudlgBa2BuCcqh5SAASpQjMVmwNGKBWQxjIScs7z3IFkIslopID79YFgI8FqNAGPBIDnI6sRQhQFSayAVeQ@UIpBPKPLteU/s81fbBvYiB/G1JNHOXYqVq7c5BjRVb/6aqJqnH@/veyMDpRUY7cX1Y4sLSD79lttXPsC)

[Hodor.](https://oeis.org/A000382)

Comment: This doesn't work in the TIO link for me. It produces `h is not defined` error

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I had to change it to get a valid byte count, and I guess I missed something. It's fixed now. Um, I mean, Hodor.

Answer (score 1):

## 347. [Pure](https://github.com/agraef/pure-lang), 824 bytes, [A003780](http://oeis.org/A003780)

```
using system;
arr = [0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,296L,0L,0L,0L,70420L,0L,0L,0L,16391166L,0L,0L,0L,3816021084L,0L,0L,0L,888375830566L,0L,0L,0L,206814474641944L,0L,0L,0L,48146529005876746L,0L,0L,0L,11208539472498838244L,0L,0L,0L,2609354391828066201746L,0L,0L,0L,607459192887167645884388L,0L,0L,0L,141416847085185500394182672L,0L,0L,0L,32921922778799648796216249818L,0L,0L,0L,7664242427921761934124201980862L,0L,0L,0L,1784240015038927382237215443432910L];
A003780 n = 262 * A003780(n-4) - 7125 * A003780(n-8) + 78668 * A003780(n-12) - 581608 * A003780(n-16) + 2138065 * A003780(n-20) - 5215246 * A003780(n-24) + 16969316 * A003780(n-28) - 43146455 * A003780(n-32) + 39514076 * A003780(n-36) + 7628882 * A003780(n-40) - 6116529 * A003780(n-44) + 23336 * A003780(n-48) - 2876 * A003780(n-52) + 64 * A003780(n-56) if n > 57;
= arr!n otherwise;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVPNattAEL77KTaBgt00MP8zi0ih97xByCEkdutDlSDZlD69OxIN7ForBDsz38/srD7O0/5yOc/H8WeZ/86n/e9h8zJN5aE8weO39qVqzc5BqM2icUW0toQDDQghpAlGBLsGg3a1BBYo4mKCVVqAZNyUKoCGWxa0okgQylWcpCZxUAclg8oqaSwowIwAe7yBi1asFOFobqIRwhGthOSyEE8hDFWAlEs@c2pbpUpJQ@7htZrk1whtcYUtm5sJLcuz3g0rC@YOsAaEtYzokXUAqMBRybM3YidUEZaUQ3h8HjY/0o4HlDHnRUbla/kf2Y73siv3xZG0i8au3BUPs@jCSEu1LhO7StgCIOQ8wJ6JYIWkJRLrM7Jg0KpVxqtULCDhnKloz8e0oLgqCniP4tWEW84prppcTVjevLwifWY1Qczcc8nqgOJKQld1kz6YusdDnu73oj5sHkr@GTdjeT/92k9/jvN@uHycT/N2Pk3bT9D8@jIetrdf3m53@QwX9X8)

This code assumes the recursion given in OEIS is correct.

This is the first time I use pure, so I hope I didn't do anything wrong.

[Next sequence](http://oeis.org/A000824).

Comment: Random unused language: Prolog

Comment: I’m not familiar with Pure, but I take it `arr` isn’t a hard coding of the output? Also, how does this take input?

Comment: It's a function. I accidentally made the input part of the code, let me fix that

Comment: Is it good now?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing according to the recursion given in [here](http://oeis.org/A003780), it is possible to get all values of the sequence using the first 58 values, and the recursion I defined for values bigger than 57

Comment: ah it's so annoying that I can't post two answers in a row

Answer (score 1):

## 352. [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 197 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py), [A000178](https://oeis.org/A000178)

```
╤!ε*

"
╤     # Push a list in the range [-n,n]
 !    # Get the factorial of each, where the negative numbers become 1
  ε*  # Reduce the list by multiplying (a.k.a. take the product of the list)";
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NY3NTcNAEIXvU8VLcgGUWGzCX0QBuSKuiMPYjL2rrHej9RiUQuiAFmiDImjErG0xp6d5P1/Lapvo62H4/fxa/HxfES0pS4y3wlPfWTC86xQuQK0gcWgEL5uwDq@ExZw7iE5mzZXG5Ngj1hCu7BofVpJMZpCG1b1n0belpA6lVLEVGAIyedx5lre@mtMTszyj7b26kz@70OCCi2PBBZSPc@iUYi7oSPvvXC4fh@GaDG1pRzd0S3d0Tw@0J5OfhsyWzO4P)

[Next sequence: A000197](https://oeis.org/A000197).

**Explanation:**

[A000178](https://oeis.org/A000178) is the formula: \$a(n) = \prod_{i=0}^ni!\$

I've already put the explanation in the program itself, wrapped in a string which we discard with `;` (after which MathGolf outputs the entire stack joined together as result). The additional newlines for readability are no-ops.

The next sequence A000197 is coincidentally also related to factorials: \$a(n)=(n!)!\$

Answer (score 1):

## 354. [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 195 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), [A000260](https://oeis.org/A000260)

```
4*>DI>csI<c9*-1MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Although 05AB1E is banned currently, the legacy version nor 2sable aren't, which are predecessors. 2sable and the legacy version both use a Python backend and the latest 05AB1E uses an Elixir backend. Some of the builtins are also fairly different between the three versions, although this program would act the same in the new and legacy versions of 05AB1E (it fails in 2sable, though).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fRMvOxdMuudjTJtlSS9fQdwiC//9NAQ) or [verify the first [0,20] test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9kcGySn72SwqO2SQpK9n7/TbTsXPzskov9bJIttXQNfYcg@K@jGfMfAA).

[Next sequence: A000195](https://oeis.org/A000195). (I just picked a fairly easy one.)

**Explanation:**

I use the following formula to implement [A000260](https://oeis.org/A000260):

$$a(n)=\binom{4n+1}{n+1} - 9\times\binom{4n+1}{n-1}$$

```python
4*          # Multiply the (implicit) input-integer by 4
  >         # Increase it by 1
   D        # Duplicate it
    I>      # Push the input+1
      c     # Binomial coefficient of input*4+1 and input+1
   s        # Swap so the duplicated input*4+1 is at the top again
    I<      # Push the input-1
      c     # Binomial coefficient of input*4+1 and input-1 as well
       9*   # Multiply this by 9
         -  # And subtract it from the earlier number
            # (this is the correct result, except for a(0)=-8)
1           # Push a 1 to the stack
 M          # Push a copy of the largest value on the stack
            # (implicitly output the top of the stack as result)
```

The additional `M` do the same, so are essentially no-ops.

Answer (score 1):

## 357. [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 167 bytes, [A000703](https://oeis.org/A000703)

```julia
function A000703(n)
    N = 24n
    for i in Iterators.countfrom(5)
        a = 2i
        a -= 7
        a *= a
        a -= 1
        a > N && return i-1
    end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9LasMwFNz7FFMvgpRPK7sphoICXWbTOxhHAhX3KX2WIffoopvepjfpRVzJLkWBPhBoNDN6My9j79rqMk12pC44T3hSSjXqXpAsEOcZGvWe5rv1DAdHOAbDbfA83HZ@pGDZv4qHRZ@mTR6XwZ1Gk8G1RnvNVhk8xJ2rFdiEkQlut3CGTkU8Exsbo8UFtveexZHCFqLZDG8cRLWp92uS8q6WRZHCUgqrHqtYSc2/nNlREAR9yHpGceKczd5wo7Gs@ks2e3sSJfD1AXM5my6YE8rtr3BRmn4w/1m@P99LedXkBw)

the reference implementation was `floor((7+sqrt(1+24*n))/2)`, which is a bit too easy and not enough characters, so I only used simple operators (`*`, `-`, `>`)

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000167)  <sub>if mathematica can compute `besselk`, hopefully anyone can</sub>

Comment: BesselK satisfies a simple recurrence relation: \$K_{n+1}(x)=K_{n-1}(x)+\frac{2n}{x}K_n(x)\$. But floating-point error is a problem. I tried this formula, storing the first two terms with 64-bit floating-points. Only the first 20 terms are correct. That is enough for 32-bit integers. So we need a language that uses 64-bit floating-points but 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

## 359. [MOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MOO_(programming_language)&oldid=978918012), 169 bytes, [A000304](https://oeis.org/A000304)

```
number = args[1];
if (number < 4)
  return number;
else
  firstnum = this:(verb)(number - 1);
  secondnum = this:(verb)(number - 2);
  return firstnum * secondnum;
endif
```

It's getting kind of annoying that all of the short bytecounts are used up, and you have to deliberately bowl to make an answer for the easy sequences. I tried to make it not look obviously bloated, and think I did a good job.

Similar to the previous answer, this sequence grows very fast and the code can only handle up to A(9) before integer overflow occurs.

There's been some rumbling about making the programming language support 64-bit-integers, but nothing's happened yet.

In case anyone cares, `return (n=args[1])<4?n|this:(v=verb)(n-1)*this:(v)(n-2);` is a 56-byte golfed version (although it could probably be golfed even further if I spent more than a few minutes on it).

[Next sequence](https://oeis.org/A000169)

Interestingly, the next sequence also grows very fast.

Answer (score 1):

## 360. [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 215 bytes, [A000169](https://oeis.org/A000169)

```
`#-
    OEIS  A000169
    Number of labeled rooted trees with n nodes: n^(n-1).
-#`

input num as Integer

set res to 1
set cnt to 1

while cnt < num
    set cnt to cnt + 1
    set res to res * num
repeat

print res
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY29DsIwDIR3P4WlLvyoqB1AArEwMHSBgR21pYZGap0ocVXBy4c0gISX03e@s19k2qf1vkxSwDDnY3FBPGRZlm@20TkNfU0W9R27qqaOGrRaSxCxRA5HJS0ysm7I7ZCvM07z@QrSpARQbAZBHnqsHBYs9CAL4EjQhqZozCPcWD4AY6s6iryfavH/X2KSZcj97O@VSRYxb8lQJQDGKo5r79dv)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000215)

Interestingly, this is the first language here that starts with `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

## 365. [Sass](https://sass-lang.com), 207, [A002534](http://oeis.org/A002534)

```
@function a002534($n) {
    @if $n < 0 {
        @return -1;
    }
    @if $n == 0 {
        @return 0;
    }
    @if $n == 1 {
        @return 1;
    }
    @return 2*a002534($n - 1) + 9 * a002534($n - 2);
}
```

[Next sequence!](http://oeis.org/A000207)

#### Try it here:

```js
let sassCode = "@function a002534($n) {\n" +
"    @if $n < 0 {\n" +
"        @return -1;\n" +
"    }\n" +
"    @if $n == 0 {\n" +
"        @return 0;\n" +
"    }\n" +
"    @if $n == 1 {\n" +
"        @return 1;\n" +
"    }\n" +
"    @return 2*a002534($n - 1) + 9 * a002534($n - 2);\n" +
"}";

function sassFunctionCallCode(n) {
  return '.answer::after { content: "" + a002534(' + n + '), }'
}

const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
document.head.append(styleElement);


document.getElementById('compile').onclick = function() {
  const result = Sass.compile(sassCode + sassFunctionCallCode(document.getElementById('input').value), function(result){
    styleElement.textContent = result.text;
  });
}

document.getElementById('length').textContent = "The Sass code has length " + sassCode.length + ".";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sass.js/0.9.12/sass.sync.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="number" value="4" />
<button id="compile">Compile</button>

<div class="answer">The answer is:&nbsp;</div>

<div id="length"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## 366. [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 202 bytes, [A000207](https://oeis.org/A000207)

```
catalan_numbers = 1 + x * catalan_numbers ^ 2;   a000207 = (1 - 12 * x - (1 - 4 * x) * catalan_numbers(x) + 3 * x * (3 + 2 * x) * catalan_numbers(x ^ 2) + 4 * x ^ 2 * catalan_numbers(x ^ 3)) / (12 * x)
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000202)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FjdPJSeWJOYk5sXnleYmpRYVK9gqGCpoK1QoaCmgy8QpGFkrKCgkGhgYGBmYAxVqGCroKhgaAZVWABlgngmIo4mpWQMoqK1gDFaqpaBhDOQY4VQKsgmkHGwYiINDkbGmpoI-0F6ISVwQH0E9tgBKAwA)

HOPS is an extremely powerful language for sequences: you input the generating function, it outputs the sequence. You can even define the generating function using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## 377. [Kitten](https://kittenlang.org), 258 bytes, [A000235](https://oeis.org/A000235)

```
define a000235 (Int32 -> Int32):
  0 0 0 0 1 a000235_tailrec

define a000235_tailrec (Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32 -> Int32):
  -> n, a, b, c, d, e;
  if (n = 0):
    b
  else:
    (n - 1) b c d e (a + b + -3 * c + -1 * d + 3 * e) a000235_tailrec
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000258)

Kitten is a statically typed concatenative language.

The formula for this sequence is \$a(0)=a(1)=a(2)=0\$, \$a(3)=1\$, \$a(n)=3a(n-1)-a(n-2)-3a(n-3)+a(n-4)+a(n-5)\$.

Comment: Really cool to see a Kitten answer! Too bad it never saw a proper release; I've been wanting to try it.

Answer (score 1):

## 380. [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 255 bytes, [A000180](https://oeis.org/A000180)

```red
Red [
    Title: "OEIS A000180"
    Author: "chunes"
]

factorial: function [n][
    product: 1
    repeat i n [
        product: product * i
    ]
    product
]

A000180: function [n][
    to-integer round 3 ** n * (factorial n) / exp 0.333333333333333
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLCsIwELznK4aetKCmvpDeevDgSVBv0kNJtzZQNiUm4N/XtFZRcE67zO7M7Foqu@5EJa4CARftGkoRHfeHMzIpZbKT0cBk3tXGBkrVnukeiVyIqlDOWF00KSrPymnDuHL@kmqtKb1yKZKhtdRS4aDBo9XPzFgghh7I/Fuitxqz/DNyZqbZ0Y0srPFcYoU4DjYxJp@A4CkWoEcLOV/9QuRdZSwVqu6jSSRYBoU1Nth@Lgn672@Aw8IT)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000255)

Answer (score 1):

## 381. Desmos, 179 bytes, [A000255](https://oeis.org/A000255)

```
a ( n_{nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn} ) = \sum_{k = 0} ^ {n_{nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn}} ( -1 ) ^ k ( n_{nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn} - k + 1 ) n_{nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn} ! / k !
```

$$ a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(n-k+1)n!/k! $$

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i6pw09jrdy)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000179)

Answer (score 1):

## 382. [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 241 bytes, [A000179](https://oeis.org/A000179)

```red
Red[]

A000179: function [x][
    if x < 3 [return pick [1 -1 0] x + 1]
    x: x - 2
    a: -1
    b: 0
    repeat n x [
        n: n + 2
        c: a
        a: b
        b: (n ** 2 - (2 * n)) * b + (n * c) - (-1 ** n * 4) / (n - 2)
    ]
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBBCsMgELznFXOsCaGaFEqll36hV/GQGANS2AYxkN@nqw2Zg@w4s@Ng9NO@v/1kbFW9pJTq/tCYV3IpfAlms6YCI8zY8EQPE31aI2EJ7gOj0CpIy1oDZYtz08xadIUMmg1lGjVkGaJf/JBA7PpHZ5Dmi@ZYynAaw0k4ZTwJB10IdY2OX7l0qEFC8DnyfhbgRBa4F3syvwlcs8KdREmxld3PFqo/aiwxUMLxBch2xb4f)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000241)

Comment: Didn't you already use language Red for [answer #380](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248842/52210)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The number of times a language is allowed to  be used increases by 1 for every 150 answers. So currently, each language can be used thrice, and each will be able to be used an additional time once we reach 450 answers.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right. It's been quite a while since I posted an answer for this challenge, so forgot about that rule.

Answer (score 1):

## 385. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 182 bytes, [A000798](https://oeis.org/A000798)

```
ɾṗꜝṗ'fUL?=;'2↔:ƛfUs;$ƛƒ↔Us;ꜝ∪$F¬;L
############################
#############################
#############################
#############################
############################
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuG5l+qcneG5lydmVUw/PTsnMuKGlDrGm2ZVczskxpvGkuKGlFVzO+qcneKIqiRGwqw7TFxuIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjI1xuIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyNcbiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjI1xuIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

[Next sequence.](https://oeis.org/A000182)

Answer (score 1):

## 386. [Zig](https://ziglang.org/), 350 bytes, [A000182](https://oeis.org/A000182)

```rust
fn a000182(comptime n: comptime_int) [n]i64 {
    var s = [_]i64{0} ** n;

    s[0] = 1;

    for (s[1..]) |*a, i| {
        a.* = @intCast(i64, i + 1) * s[i];
    }

    for (s[1..]) |_, i| {
        for (s[i + 1 ..]) |*a, j| {
            a.* *= @intCast(i64, j + 2);
            a.* += @intCast(i64, j) * s[i + j];
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJLTsNADBXbnsLKKklDNJ_mR4SEhDhFFKqoJNVUdFIyUwS0OQmbSohDcBQ4Dc6PRi3ejMd-9ntjz_vHm1gevoNFKZWG_GWTL_Td0zZ7hGu4EetNWWnTUPrBsFydKy3k0h2B4s-tLi7Dn4v7QkJGCKEhMxfleqPFOgd5BYM_F1JbkMhU-DPYTQDtOatAIUsyb4I7UoNtg4wnbVIlJMUc7a9FWYGpEuq6qQV7O3NA7Ps2jWWu3cqV-jZT2sR2CIApUAtsbCXSuIXW_zWbn_Tqs205HPlWY8zAaZ-SrrCKWfEZcHoG7JUhfpUe8fVYZ5XrbSVBxZO6G_P3V7MCMPpBG72ibnVV3gxz2AElvYohWRwnDdQB5gD18QjQCSKOLvd4EOGNMe6HzMMIjQgPvIDTJkqi0Pf4jEVBUxaREM2jlIWcQd1R6ep1_IFMVOQ0zNbfAw6H7vwF)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000350)

Uses the Zig language because the sequence is called the Zag numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## 387. [Cognate](https://cognate-lang.github.io), 1984 bytes, [A000350](https://oeis.org/A000350)

```
~~ First some helper words to make the prose flow like water.

Def Equal as (==);
Def Zero as (Equal to 0);
Def Positive to be (> 0);
Def Sum as (+);
Def Less as (- 1);
Def Last as (Modulo 10);
Def Quotient as (Floor /);
Def Mutable as (Box);
Def Value as (Unbox);

~~ Now we are ready to rumble.

Def Fibonacci as (
   Let N be the term we wish to find;
   Let A be a Mutable value of 0;
   Let B be a Mutable value of 1;
   do the following (
      put the Value of B aside for now;
      Set B to the Sum of the Value of A and the Value of B;
      A; should now be Set to the old value of b we put aside;
   ); N; Times;
   return the Value of A
);

Def Increment as (
   Let N be a mutable variable containing the input;
   Set N to the Sum of 1 and the Value of N
)

Def Chop as (
   Let N be a mutable variable containing the input;
   Set N to the Quotient of 10 and the Value of N;
);

Def End as (
   Let A be the first Integer!;
   Let B be the second Integer!;
   return whether the Last digit of A; and the Last digit of B; are Equal
);

~~ This is a function that determines whether its input is a member of OEIS: A000350.
Def Ends as (
   Let N be a Mutable variable containing the input;
   Let K be a Mutable variable containing the Fibonacci Value of N;
   While (the Value of N; is Positive; and the Value of N and the Value of K; End with the same digit; are Both true) (
      Chop the last digit off N;
      Chop the last digit off K;
   );
   return whether the Value of N; is Zero
);

Def A000350 as (
   Let N be the term of the sequence we want to find;
   Let K be the Mutable number of terms we've found starting with 0;
   Let M be a Mutable number to test for membership starting with 0;
   Until (the Value of K; and N; are Equal) do the following (
      Do either of the following-
      If the mth fibonacci number Ends with the Value of M then (Increment K) otherwise (do nothing);
      Increment M;
   );
   return one Less than the Value of M
);
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVZLbhNBEF0i-RTFClsowREgIUZBskkiRcYmkA8Su7anxtNiptt098SwyUXYZIO4BteA01DVn4k_SZQFURaZ-td7VdX58Wum50o4vL7-2bhi59XfR7-vruBIGuvA6hqhxGqBBpba5Bachlp8QXAlwsJoi1BUegmVJNmSopjdTucACzj82ogKhIXu_n4v86LPaLSXBB1F6kfNibbSyUtk2RSh-6bVnDa1d3kav9-htV6wA3tJJKhQFo113lQa9pLvh0Y7iSoojyqtDTyLqnHjxLRCrxnqb1F6IaomyM7V1Es7hMSE2luS2CAYFPl3LtI0NbnHVo_kVCsxm0nv2gGgKh1MuBNGiTCpOcBS2pJ9C6nyLFkN2Eq09Vz6CnQB_dZieIfFnrfItc9R6IpYkGoe8tPPonFec5Hsh1SdzNnUgNLLLNqd-hQuhGG0yXTNbwBC5RuhkvMgA1vqpso5ItfJ0WIsTdK22CkDwCX5Grx7L4NJBmeyRuu_DbrGqI3cHeaAMT5WM4N1InMNYwF1i42R_o-ZVk5IxXhwPKkotU9y6p3Wu93bbnDS6YW0b0u9-I8Z24nktP1b8mZtw4ekW008SONU-MU8Vg7naB6vjwnrLVIt-bpBxHZZIlkYb-a3Jpdz6YshIlMx64ph5gffb2wnLsRZKS3Qr4CiUTMnNbMmyAl51KVC22aSzgYsgn2N9ZSkFPf94fHpaxj0-_3nL_u7qWN7G9bjB2PNTqOHOd3s7Cr4FONTKcm6u0ELl5-OVHYLb9uiUeYpXEpXBloEXVIPa0B0qFlhGuy1K-uHjW2rVQpSYfcYjOJC3UH1Rh98htsxiwzcc7niPbD4tUE1Q3_JhHJbl2yUvBL0qklkcxyaCXxyyeenIVisE8YxFx6fm2M3XmcvhuDtQeqYT1cYIVvKxa1BzpWT1QZ9o8DYZGWUe3cfzgMNKD12sfPWZCdaHAd5TUmLdoxiqX6IW9LbEsb8qaB7c8ZGPdCchV4FGjeqRtEnJeklsm9Mx9v0aoXhKaTF27iZY-I2POR_XpwYqcIzMBYLVnYj3710kT4KNacWja7pDjp-PINv-mfgHw)

Cognate is a new stack language that is unique in that it reads right to left (superficially giving it the appearance of Polish notation). But using the `;` word, you `can ; make ; it ; read ; left ; to ; right`. Having such fine-grained control over the flow of data makes it really easy to take advantage of Cognate's seamless comments (anything lowercase) to make things sound like English.

Mind you, this is incredibly overwrought -- you should probably never go this far with the natural language stuff -- but I got addicted to making it sound like English and wanted to see how far I could push it.

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001984)

Comment: Da hell is that next sequence lol

Comment: @AidenChow I'm guessing whoever decides to tackle it should do https://oeis.org/A045535 instead.

Comment: @AidenChow I think erroneous sequences can be hardcoded: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156507/9288

Comment: @alephalpha Huh that's interesting, I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

## 389. [ReScript](https://rescript-lang.org/), 1001 bytes, [A000192](https://oeis.org/A000192)

```ml
type rec expr =
  | Const(int)
  | X
  | Cos(expr)
  | Sin(expr)
  | Add(expr, expr)
  | Mul(expr, expr)
  | Div(expr, expr)

let rec eval_at_0 = (e: expr): int =>
  switch e {
  | Const(c) => c
  | X => 0
  | Cos(_) => 1
  | Sin(_) => 0
  | Add(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) + eval_at_0(f)
  | Mul(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) * eval_at_0(f)
  | Div(e, f) => eval_at_0(e) / eval_at_0(f)
  }

let rec deriv = (e: expr): expr =>
  switch e {
  | Const(_) => Const(0)
  | X => Const(1)
  | Cos(e) => Mul(Const(-1), Mul(deriv(e), Sin(e)))
  | Sin(e) => Mul(deriv(e), Cos(e))
  | Add(e, f) => Add(deriv(e), deriv(f))
  | Mul(e, f) => Add(Mul(deriv(e), f), Mul(e, deriv(f)))
  | Div(e, f) =>
    Div(Add(Mul(deriv(e), f), Mul(Const(-1), Mul(e, deriv(f)))), Mul(f, f))
  }

let rec iter = (f, a, n: int) => n > 0 ? f(iter(f, a, n - 1)) : a

let egf: expr = Div(
  Mul(Const(2), Cos(Mul(Const(3), X))),
  Add(Mul(Const(2), Cos(Mul(Const(4), X))), Const(-1)),
)

let a000192 = (n: int) => eval_at_0(iter(deriv, egf, 2 * n))
```

[Try it online!](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=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-AB+Na0YB-J1Qf1QUNE+r0qDBFwfd0QADmvVBYn8+uYBMxACZhRzuKWyAiAMyV1j2hTMQ3m2vUCtKXE17JUAAsjebHL7JIdWCYbocLh8s7qAE4y4DA1BwldNkcxl6YFRRfo80olwdSOqsAApcgAOi0xBzVBnc8XVAbTCAA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A001001)

The exponential generating function of the sequence is \$2\cos(3x)/(2\cos(4x)-1)\$. Here I compute the sequence using symbolic differentiation. Very inefficient.

ReScript is a rebranding and cleanup of [Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/), so I can reuse [the Reason code for A000187](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238178/9288) with some small modification.

Answer (score 1):

## 391. [Egison](https://www.egison.org/), 374 bytes, [A000191](https://oeis.org/A000191)

```haskell
-- The egf (exponential generating function) of the sequence
def egf := 2 * sin t / (2 * cos (2 * t) - 1)

-- Repeatedly applies the differential operator to the egf, and substitutes t with 0
def a000191List := map (substitute [ (t,0) ]) $ iterate (flip d/d t) egf

-- Takes the 2 * (n + 1)'th term, because Egison is 1-indexed
def a000191 n := nth (2 * (n + 1)) a000191List
```

[Try it online!](https://www.egison.org/console.html)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000374)

The exponential generating function of the sequence is \$2\sin(t)/(2\cos(2t)-1)\$. Here I use symbolic differentiation again, but using Egison's built-in `d/d` function. Still very inefficient.

Egison is a functional programming language featuring its expressive pattern-matching facility. It can also be used as a Computer Algebra System.

Answer (score 1):

## 393. [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 181 bytes, [A000212](https://oeis.org/A000212)

```red
Red[
    title: "OEIS A000212"
    author: "chunes"
    date: 2022-08-29
    tabs: 4
    version: 0.6.4
    company: ""
    rights: "nein"
]

f: func[n][to 1 round/down(n ** 2 / 3)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY@9DsIwDIT3PMWpEz8qTQNCULEwMDAhwVhlKE1KI4FTpSmIpy@h8WTfnT/ZTqtxvGpVMoTyxj91geRyOt9w5JyLXCSTUw2@tS5YdTuQ7qOoKh/SgguR8l0q9pFR3fsCm6l/a9cbSwX4aruKUm1fXUXfQIoMZx6tDwsJaUMJk4w1BZqB6pJk6S1yODuQypT90IywWEAgw3ouxz@WfVrz1CgJh3CHjF90zpBHA5qmECMskTM5/gA)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000181)

Answer (score 1):

## 394. [kalker](https://kalker.xyz/), 248 bytes, [A000181](https://oeis.org/A000181)

```
f(n) = Σ(i = 0, n, (-1)^i (n + 4) (n - i)! (2 n + 3 - i)! / (12 i! (2 n - 2 i)!))
f(n) = Σ(i = 0, n, (-1)^i (n + 4) (n - i)! (2 n + 3 - i)! / (12 i! (2 n - 2 i)!))
f(n) = Σ(i = 0, n, (-1)^i (n + 4) (n - i)! (2 n + 3 - i)! / (12 i! (2 n - 2 i)!))
```

[Try it online!](https://kalker.xyz/kalk)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000248)

Kalker is a scientific calculator that supports math-like syntax with user-defined variables, functions, derivation, integration, and complex numbers.

Since writing the definition once is too short, I write it three times.

Answer (score 1):

## 395. [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 424 bytes, [A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248)

```
; = factorial BLOCK
    IF (< num 2)
        1
        (* num (; (= num (- num 1)) (CALL factorial)))
; = choose BLOCK
    ; = num n
    ; = numerator (CALL factorial)
    ; = num k
    ; = den (CALL factorial)
    ; = num (- n k)
    ; = den (* den (CALL factorial))
    : / numerator den
; = n (EVAL PROMPT)
; = k 0
; = s 0
; WHILE (< k (+ 1 n))
    ; = s (+ s (* (CALL choose) (^ (- n k) k)))
    : = k (+ 1 k)
: OUTPUT s
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#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)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000424)

Answer (score 1):

## 401. [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 303 bytes, [A000314](https://oeis.org/A000314)

```
exponential_generating_function_of_a035351 = x * exp((2 * exponential_generating_function_of_a035351 - exponential_generating_function_of_a035351 ^ 2) / (2 - 2 * exponential_generating_function_of_a035351));  a035351 = laplace(exponential_generating_function_of_a035351);  a000314 = 1 + int(a035351 / x)
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000303)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FrcY9VMrCvLzUvNKMhNz4tNT81KLEksy89Lj00rzkksy8_Pi89PiEw2MTY1NDRVsFSoUtBSAGjQ0jCAMYnXqkqI4TsFIU0FfAWiHrgJp9mhqWisoIFybk1iQk5icqkGCAWD9BgbGhiZA_YYK2gqZeSUaMBP1FSo0IeEGDb4FUBoA)

Or 36 bytes: `a=x*exp((a+a/(1-a))/2);1+a.*{(n-1)!}`.

Answer (score 1):

## 403. [Quipu](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Quipu), 234 bytes, [A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254)

```
" 0&  1&  2&  3&  4& "
"--------------------"
  \/  1&  1&  1&  2&
  1&  ++  []  ++  []
  ++  0&  **  1&  /\
      []  3&  []    
      %%  []  **    
      4&  ++  1&    
      ==  1&  --    
          ++  1&    
              ??
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000234)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720sDSzoHTBgqWlJWm6FjdfKSkYqCkoGAKxERAbA7GJmoISl5IuFqDEpaAQow9RbQjXxQVhaGsrKETHwmguCANktpYWRIF-DFAQBECqQBaBaAUFqKCqKkQApBouaAI1F6QdLmhrCxHQ1UUSBAEMlTBgbw8iIT6GenzBQjMIAwA)

Comment: Lol what kind of lang is this

Answer (score 1):

## 404. [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 309 bytes, [A000234](https://oeis.org/A000234)

```perl6
sub a($i, $m, $k) {
  if ($k == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  my $s = 0;
  my $l = floor($m ** (3 / 2));
  for 1..min($l, $i) -> $j {
    my $m2 = $m - $j ** (2 / 3);
    if ($m2.floor >= 1) {
      $s += a($j, $m2, $k-1);
    }
    $s += 1;
  }
  return $s;
}

my $n = get;

print a(floor($n ** (3 / 2)), $n, $n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NDoIwEIX3PcVbdNGqoNSETYN30QRMgRZSYGEMZ8cZbdTFLGba7/2MdezLbZuWG65KugOkp@k0ngJwDZTsUFUoPgcg1vMSAwpL20rjH5ATKpxsWnpamn4YopIeux3UGUcYrfm9GSKKPPcuKNmTjdPILpBt0mbcG@KJzPjMuCH8/KZTHm/ytz4uf7HAKfYVd2i5g@ESWZG4Vfx@fJOnJnKyYhWCvQNZ3@vZCjFGF2YSS0XCfxFSDjzablv5Ag)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000309)

Answer (score 1):

## 406. [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library), 198 bytes, [A000175](https://oeis.org/A000175)

```
(* Based on Herman Jamke's second PARI/GP code on OEIS *)
A000175(n_) := 2 ^ (2 * n - 1) * Product(k ^ Floor(n / k), {k, 1, n}) * SeriesCoefficient(BesselJ(1, x) / BesselJ(0, x), {x, 0, 2 * n - 1});
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000198)

[Try It Online!](https://matheclipse.org/input?i=A000175(n_)%20%3A%3D%202%20%5E%20(2%20*%20n%20-%201)%20*%20Product(k%20%5E%20Floor(n%20%2F%20k)%2C%20%7Bk%2C%201%2C%20n%7D)%20*%20SeriesCoefficient(BesselJ(1%2C%20x)%20%2F%20BesselJ(0%2C%20x)%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%202%20*%20n%20-%201%7D)%3B%20Table(A000175(n)%2C%20%7Bn%2C%201%2C%207%7D))

Symja is a Java Symbolic Math System. Its syntax is basically the same as Mathematica, except it uses round brackets instead of square ones.

Answer (score 0):

## 355. [Pyret](https://www.pyret.org/), 244 bytes, [A000195](https://oeis.org/A000195)

```
fun a000195(n :: NumNonNegative) -> NumInteger:
  num-floor(num-log(n))
where:
  a000195(1) is 0
  a000195(2) is 0
  a000195(3) is 1
  a000195(4) is 1
  a000195(5) is 1
  a000195(6) is 1
  a000195(7) is 1
  a000195(8) is 2
  a000195(9) is 2
end
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000244)

[Try it online!](https://code.pyret.org/editor)

One interesting feature of this language is that you can add unit tests to functions using the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

## 358. [CoffeeScript 2](http://coffeescript.org/), 304 bytes, [A000167](https://oeis.org/A000167)

```coffee
# BesselK satisfies the following recurrence relation: 
# BesselK(n + 1, x) = BesselK(n - 1, x) + n * BesselK(n, x)

b = [0.11389387274953344, 0.13986588181652243]

besselk2 = (n) ->
  while b.length <= n
    i = b.length - 1
    b.push(b[i - 1] + i * b[i])
  b[n]

a000167 = (n) -> Math.round besselk2 n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NboQwDIX3nMJSN9CZiQjhJ1SdLrqtegLEYqAGokbOKAFNb0/NqKXd2Z/fs597NwyIoffmOmfr@gCvGALaNwiX2YTBYIB5Qhicte5maASP/eI9Uo9cWhY5eoJo98UEB5BH@Erg/I@dftgBCB7/@MaiqGNpkwopla6VrrIqrwul8vwIDFWty0JrqWVZZFmuWtbf7Z8Z22JK4PQSAdwmYxE6YZHGeYLnMxBTAMOinXKKO@zEdQlT3DVmQy2nMpyK2zbhedcQH7mkaSrLar8B75d5Et4t9AF7AFoH5/klQ9sDQtYt@3tHwVkU1o3wu4XWbw)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000304)

This sequence grows very fast. Only the first 20 outputs are accurate. But CoffeeScript doesn't have an Integer type anyway. Its number type is 64-bit floating-points. So I think some inaccuracy is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## 384. [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 798 bytes, [A001002](https://oeis.org/A001002)

```
import StdEnv

:: Series a = (:+) infixr 6 a (Series a)

coeff :: Int (Series a) -> a
coeff 0 (a :+ _ ) = a
coeff n (_ :+ as) = coeff (n - 1) as

truncate :: Int (Series a) -> [a]
truncate 0 _         = []
truncate n (a :+ as) = [a : truncate (n - 1) as]

instance zero (Series a) | zero a where
    zero = zero :+ zero

instance one (Series a) | one a & zero a where
    one = one :+ zero

instance + (Series a) | + a where
    (+) (a :+ as) (b :+ bs) = (a + b) :+ (as + bs)

instance * (Series a) | + a & * a where
    (*) (a :+ as) (b :+ bs) = (a * b) :+ (as * (b :+ bs) + a ** bs)

(**) :: a (Series a) -> Series a | * a
(**) a (b :+ bs) = a * b :+ a ** bs

x :: Series a | one a & zero a
x = zero :+ one :+ zero

A001002 :: Series Int
A001002 = one :+ (A001002 * A001002 * (one + x * A001002))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZPBa4MwFMbv@SveqSSRgt1hDMHBYDsUdutRSnm1sQvUODTdutG/fe7FVI3tmAcTvy/5fSTvmR8UmrasdseDghK1aXX5XtUWVnb3Yj4YSxJYqVqrBhBS4EkkQJtCn2q4J4X3nmAsr1RRAK1fGhsYMH8EvJgxcIQkgg0IgvWqAb5xKjZO9Ro3MIeFII0xWx9Njlb9zc5wPa6ICd0/KWSBYy7RPiSjOQzeGLZmTJvGoskVfKu6CrPOXkH4fFO1Yi6iE1I/ENuNAaAyarrfCQizW44z0u59S4mmjGiykVM5xnPxrZttuxOSSlPhBI4NdHJAlbfUGYkTtvyHLQO2DEwHktKHcUkEqhleVWzop7NL9MtwEtDxu2QPY@wEYSNeXyXZYxUm1/gUx4s4vgt2UwcN6nDnvFckjDPuzAhOoyhEu7JIfwfhMgKtmf9Mx1566Ne2P3lxwH3Tzpev7fOXwVLnzS8)

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000798)

Its generating function satisfies \$A = 1 + x A^2 + x^2 A^3\$.

Clean is very similar to Haskell: purely functional, lazy, currying, operator overloading with type classes. So I can borrow [this Haskell implementation of formal power series](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoug/powser.html).

Answer (score 0):

## 407. [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 373 bytes, [A000198](https://oeis.org/A000198)

```dart
import 'dart:math';

int f(int n) {
  int d = 0;
  int k = -1;
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    d = 3 * i - 1 - i % 2;
    var c = log(n / d) / log(3);
    if (c.ceil() == c) {
      k = c.ceil();
      break;
    }
  }
  return k < 0
      ? List.generate(n - 1, (i) => f(i + 1) * f(n - i - 1)).reduce(max)
      : d * pow(3, (d * pow(3, k) - min(5, d)) / 2).ceil();
}
```

[Next sequence!](https://oeis.org/A000373)

Dart's first time here!

I avoided "choosing" the next sequence: the code was implemented using single-character variables and formatted using DartPad.

Implements the following formula available on OEIS:

> ```
> a(3^k) = 3^((3^k - 1)/2)
> a(5*3^k) = 5*3^((5*3^k - 5)/2)
> a(7*3^k) = 7*3^((7*3^k - 5)/2)
> for all other n, a(n) = max(a(i)a(n-i)),
>   where the maximum is taken over 1 <= i <= n-1
> (from Alspach and Berggren (1973) Theorem 4).
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBbbsIwEPzPKeanwgaSJtD@ENJeoJcwiUMtknVkDEWquHrTdR60luz17M7aM1sp5/vetJ11HouK0a5V/nORR5Ehj1qEkyS@IyBcKxRI8wmcGMRZQLV1GKiGU1nOYY8XDqvV2IqhcYslV2JkvA2esMmH0lU5lFxu7FEQnlFJPgLYypFgaogyKbVphERRoJwfxSBhLuVT7uC0Oo3gHo3baX9xxOw90on1jg9z9slRk3bKa/6Zha3ZBX/xFoxjhUyy4nooDbqlTJyuLqUWrbrJ6aEde1uis19iy@3/7ifJPa0h8bpmT8HURj6k3qP@ak2FVjFh9vMYI41jJNa7STn@zTGszjFHsC4pZ5v3/sd23lg693GsSR0aHetbp51pNfmCLMV0aZqQ/wU)